# Formatting Sandbox

Tags: discussion, support, markdown, testing, sandbox

**Notes:**

> - Answers will occasionally be moved to the [Sandbox archive](/q/296077) when there are too many of them. When using them to report bugs, keep an eye on the post.
> - You may also want to take a look at the Stack Exchange's [Sandbox chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox)
>
> - This site, Meta Stack Exchange, is usually used as a "test bed" for pending changes happening to the way text is rendered on all network sites. Changes to text rendering that are going to be rolled out to the network are usually deployed here first to test them out and fix any potential glitches. Currently, there are no such changes pending, but if there were, keep in mind that text posted here may render differently from the other sites until the changes roll out to them as well.

---

As per Jeff's suggestion in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/can-we-get-a-test-stackoverflow-com#comment1215_758):

You can use this question as a formatting sandbox. You can:

- edit **[this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/318543)** itself ([Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) questions such as this one require only 100 reputation to edit instead of 2,000)
- post answers to *this question* (This question might be [protected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question), requiring earning 10 reputation on this site to answer)
- post comments to this question or its answers
- test suspected bugs with the editor or the rendering
- post ponies (only when mods are asleep)

Beware that since the [changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) in December 2010, and [the inline hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) added in March 2011, **no syntax highlighting is applied unless the question's tags or an inline hint enable it**. So, to test highlighting here in the sandbox:

1. [As of January 8, 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/350567), you can use GitHub-flavor fenced code blocks in your posts, specifying the language after the opening fence:

   ````
   ```html
   While not hinted otherwise: <html></html> source <b>goes</b> "here".
   ```
   ````

   ````
   ```js
   var a = 3;
   while (not (a > 0)) {
       alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
   }
   ```
   ````
2. Or:

   - Create code blocks in any way (using the fence notation above, the four-space indent form, or using HTML `<pre><code>` tags).
   - Save your post!
   - Use your browser's developer tools to edit the resulting HTML. To open developer tools, press <kbd>F12</kbd>, or <kbd>⌥⌘ I</kbd> on Mac.
   - Find the `<pre>` element and add the attribute `class="prettyprint"`, or change it into one of the valid syntax hints linked above, like `class="lang-vb prettyprint"`.
   - Run the following in the location bar: `javascript:prettyPrint();` or `prettyPrint()` in the console.

Answers that are considered annoying or obnoxious, or that cause breakage for users, will be deleted. This is [codified as a policy as of March 29, 2018](/a/308514/).

Comment: ````<```>````test

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer stop trolling!!!

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry wait, how did you ping me?

Comment: @TheEmpty see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). (TL;DR: anyone who edited can be pinged)

Answer (score 56):

## The Comprehensive Formatting Test

### Supported Markdown

Stack Exchange maintains its own [Markdown Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.  It maintains a subset containing most, but not all [markdown features](https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/).

#### Code Formatting

- Inline code formatting or code spans

  - To place code inline, enclose your code in a pair of backtick characters (`` ` ``).  In the editor, you can highlight a portion of text in a single line and either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> or press the `{}` toolbar button.

    ```
      Use the line `System.out.println("Hello World!");`.
    ```

    Use the line `System.out.println("Hello World!");`.
  - Escape a backtick within inline code by enclosing the inline code with double-tickmarks:

    ```
      Within code: ``for line in `someCommand` ``
    ```

    Within code: `` for line in `someCommand` ``
  - A single backtick character in a line won't form a code block.

    ```
      The backtick character is '`'
    ```

    The backtick character is '`'.
  - To escape multiple backtick characters in a line, without forming a code block, escape the first with a backslash character:

    ```
    There are two backtick characters ('\`') in this line ('`').
    ```

    There are two backtick characters ('`') in this line ('`').
  - Outside of a code block, you can always escape any backtick character.

    ```
      There are two backtick characters ('\`') in this line ('\`').
    ```

    There are two backtick characters ('`') in this line ('`').
  - Use the same number of backticks, before and after a span, to escape any backticks within:

    `````````
      ```````` Escaped `` backticks `! ````````
    `````````

    ``` Escaped `` backticks `! ```
- Block code formatting

  - To place a code block, indent the lines containing your code by 4 space characters.  In the editor, you can highlight lines of text and either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> or press the `{}` toolbar button.

    ```
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println("Code Block!");
    ```

    ```
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
      System.out.println("Code Block!");
    ```
  - One may also place a [code fence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks), which is 3 or more backtick or tilde characters, each on their own line, before and after the code.

    ````
    ```
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    System.out.println("Code Fence with backticks!");
    ```
    ````

    ```
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    System.out.println("Code Fence with backticks!");
    ```

    ```
    ~~~
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    System.out.println("Code Fence with tildes!");
    ~~~
    ```

    ```
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    System.out.println("Code Fence with tildes!");
    ```

    ```
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    System.out.println("Code Fence with 20 tildes!");
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ```

    ```
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    System.out.println("Code Fence with 20 tildes!");
    ```
- HTML and other markdown are not supported within code spans or code blocks.

  ````
  ```
  <code> *Not in code!* </code>
  ```
  ````

  ```
  <code> *Not in code!* </code>
  ```

#### Line Breaks

- Simply placing one line break doesn't produce a line break when rendered.

  ```
  This is one line.
  This was intended to be on the next line, but it appears on the same line.
  ```

  This is one line.
  This was intended to be on the next line, but it appears on the same line.
- Using one or more blank lines produces a paragraph break.

  ```
  This is one paragraph.  It has some sentences.

  This is intended to be a second paragraph.
  ```

  This is one paragraph.  It has some sentences.

  This is intended to be a second paragraph.
- Use two spaces at the end of a line to force a line break.

  ```
  This is one line.  
  This is intended to be on the next line.
  ```

  This is one line.
  This is intended to be on the next line.
- Use an HTML `<br>` tag to produce a line break.

  ```
  This is one line.<br>
  This is intended to be on the next line.
  ```

  This is one line.
  This is intended to be on the next line.

#### Italics and Bold

- Surround text with exactly one underscore (`_`) or one asterisk (`*`) to render text in *italics*.

  `This is _italic_ text.  This is *italic* too.`

  This is *italic* text.  This is *italic* too.
- Surround text with exactly two underscores (`__`) or two asterisks (`**`) to render text in **bold**.

  `This is __bold__ text.  This is **bold** too.`

  This is **bold** text.  This is **bold** too.
- Surround text with both of the above to render text in ***bold and italic***.

  `___underscores only___ and ***asterisks only*** and __*underscore and asterisk*__ and **_asterisk and underscore_**.`

  ***underscores only*** and ***asterisks only*** and ***underscore and asterisk*** and ***asterisk and underscore***.
- 3 or more and odd does both bold and italic.  4 or more and even does bold only.  Using both `_` and `*` for the same purpose: outside ones count, inside ones ignored.

  `****Four!****`

  ****Four!****

  `_____Five!_____`

  *****Five!*****

  `______Six!______`

  ******Six!******

  `*******Seven!*******`

  *******Seven!*******

  `**__Two and Two!__**`

  ****Two and Two!****

  `_*One and One!*_`

  **One and One!**

#### Links

- Inline links:

  - [Display](URL)

    `[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)`
    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
  - [Display](URL "tooltip") - Whether there are spaces in the tooltip text or not, one of double quotes, single quotes, or parentheses, for the tooltip is required.

    `[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com TopQuestions)`
    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)(https://meta.stackexchange.com TopQuestions)
    ​
    `[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com "TopQuestions")`
    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
    ​
    `[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com 'TopQuestions')`
    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
    ​
    `[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com (TopQuestions))`
    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
  - Escape the first bracket not to render the link.

    `\[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)`
    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
  - Brackets within the display text must be escaped.

    `[Meta \[Stack\] Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)`
    [Meta [Stack] Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
  - The protocol and the colon separator (e.g. `https:`) are not required (i.e. protocol-relative links are supported).

    `[Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com)`
    [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com)
  - Domain-relative (i.e. absolute path) links are supported.

    `[help center](/help)`
    [help center](/help)
  - Path-relative and intra-page (i.e. fragment-only) links are NOT supported (i.e. URLs *must* begin with `http://`, `https://`, `//`, or `/`) (display text is rendered).

    `[help center](../../../help)`
    help center
    ​
    `[The Comprehensive Formatting Test](#answer-325826)`
    The Comprehensive Formatting Test
    ​
    `[Meta Stack Exchange](meta.stackexchange.com)`
    Meta Stack Exchange
- Reference links:

  - These can be created by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> or clicking the [image] button in the editor toolbar.
  - [Display][refName] *and* [refName]: URL

    ```
    [Meta Stack Exchange][1]

    [1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com
    ```

    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
  - They must have a blank line above the reference URL, or else it won't render properly.

    ```
    [Meta Stack Exchange][99]
    [99]: https://meta.stackexchange.com
    ```

    [Meta Stack Exchange][99]
    [99]: https://meta.stackexchange.com
  - Case insensitive alphanumeric reference names.

    ```
    [Meta Stack Exchange][Thissite42]

    [thisSite42]: https://meta.stackexchange.com
    ```

    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
  - Tooltips: Use double-quotes or parentheses, but not single-quotes.

    ```
    [Meta Stack Exchange][tooltip]

    [tooltip]: https://meta.stackexchange.com "Tooltip"
    ```

    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

    ```
    [Meta Stack Exchange][tooltip1]

    [tooltip1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com 'Tooltip1'
    ```

    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

    ```
    [Meta Stack Exchange][tooltip2]

    [tooltip2]: https://meta.stackexchange.com (Tooltip2)
    ```

    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
  - Display name *is* the refName.

    ```
    [Meta Stack Exchange]

    [Meta Stack Exchange]: https://meta.stackexchange.com
    ```

    [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

- Bare URLs

  - Bare URLs get turned into links.

    `http://example.com`

    http://example.com
  - Angle brackets force links.

    `<https://www.google.com>`

    https://www.google.com
  - Capital letter in protocol makes the link disappear.  (But it will show up in the preview!)

    `Http://stackoverflow.com`

    Http://stackoverflow.com
  - Unrecognized protocol disables the link.

    `doesnotexist://stackoverflow.com`

    doesnotexist://stackoverflow.com
- Magic links that work in comments do not work in a post.

[edit] [help] [main] [meta] [tour]

#### Images

- Inline images, similar to links but with leading `!`:

  - ![Alt Text](URL)

    `![An image of a unicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg)`

    [image: An image of a unicorn]
  - ![Alt Text](URL "tooltip") - Whether there are spaces in the tooltip text or not, one of double quotes, single quotes, or parentheses, for the tooltip is required.

    `![An image of a unicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg Unicorn!)`

    ![An image of a unicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg Unicorn!)

    ​

    `![An image of a unicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg "Unicorn!")`

    [image: An image of a unicorn]

    ​

    `![An image of a unicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg 'Unicorn!')`

    [image: An image of a unicorn]

    ​

    `![An image of a unicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg (Unicorn!))`

    [image: An image of a unicorn]
  - Escape the first bracket not to render the link.

    `!\[An image of a unicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg (Unicorn!))`

    ![An image of a unicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg (Unicorn!))
  - The protocol (e.g. https://) is required, or else only the display text is rendered.

    `![An image of a unicorn](i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg (Unicorn!))`

    Meta Stack Exchange
- Reference images:

  - These can be created by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> or clicking the picture icon button in the editor toolbar.
  - ![Alt Text](refName) *and* [refName]: URL

    ```
    ![image of a unicorn][2]

    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg
    ```

    [image: image of a unicorn]
  - Like reference links, a blank line is required above the reference URL.

    ```
    ![image of a unicorn][98]
    [98]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg
    ```

    ![image of a unicorn][98]
    [98]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg
  - Case insensitive alphanumeric reference names.

    ```
    ![image of a unicorn][Site42]

    [sITE42]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg
    ```

    [image: image of a unicorn]
  - Tooltips: Use double-quotes, single-quotes, or parentheses.

    ```
    ![image of a unicorn][TooltipImg]

    [tooltipImg]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg "Tooltip"
    ```

    [image: image of a unicorn]

    ```
    ![image of a unicorn][TooltipImg1]

    [TooltipImg1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg 'Tooltip1'
    ```

    [image: image of a unicorn]

    ```
    ![image of a unicorn][TooltipImg2]

    [TooltipImg2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg (Tooltip2)
    ```

    [image: image of a unicorn]
- Image links - surround an image with a link.

  ```
  [![image of a unicorn][ImgSrc]][1]

  [ImgSrc]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg
  [1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com
  ```

  [image: image of a unicorn]

#### Headers

- The number of `#` characters determines the header level, from 1-6.  Any `#` characters at the end of the line are not rendered.  Above six `#`'s are no longer treated as a header and rendered as plain text.

  ##### Headings following a paragraph

  `# Heading 1 ###`

  ## Heading 1

  `## Heading 2 ####################`

  ### Heading 2

  `### Heading 3`

  #### Heading 3

  `#### Heading 4`

  ##### Heading 4

  `##### Heading 5`

  ###### Heading 5

  `###### Heading 6`

  ###### Heading 6

  `####### Heading 7`

  ####### Heading 7

  ##### Headings following a heading use different top-margin spacing

  ## Heading 1

  ### Heading 2

  #### Heading 3

  ##### Heading 4

  ###### Heading 5

  ###### Heading 6

  ####### Heading 7
- Alternates for headers 1 and 2

  - Use equals signs under the header text for heading 1.

    ```
    Equals Signs!
    ===
    ```

    ## Equals Signs!
  - Use dashes under the header text for heading 2.

    ```
    Dashes!
    ---
    ```

    ### Dashes!
  - The triple bar ≡ doesn't seem to do anything special here.

    ```
    Triple Bar!
    ≡≡≡
    ```

    Triple Bar!
    ≡≡≡
- Escape `#` with a backslash or use the HTML entity instead.

  `\# Not a heading`

  # Not a heading

  `&#35; Not a heading`

  # Not a heading

  `# Heading ending with hashtag &#35;`

  ## Heading ending with hashtag #
- Italic headers

  `# _Italic_ *Header* #`

  ## *Italic* *Header*

#### Horizontal Rules

- Use 3 or more hyphens, asterisks, or underscores by themselves on a line.  Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> inserts a horizontal rule for you.

  ```
  ---
  ***
  ______
  ```

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>

  ---

  ---

  ---

---

- Single spaces between the characters still works.

  ```
  - - -
  * * *
  _ _ _ _ _ _
  ```

  ---

  ---

  ---
- Multiple spaces *still* works!

  ```
  -  -  -
  *   *   *
  _    _    _    _    _    _
  ```

  ---

  ---

  ---
- Even irregular spacing is fine

  ```
  -   -          -
  *    *       *
  _    _      __      _                   _
  ```

  ---

  ---

  ---

#### Blockquotes

- Use `>` or highlight text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> to create a blockquote.

  `> Quoting something else`

  > Quoting something else

  `>No space between > and text`

  > No space between > and text
- One can nest blockquotes with multiple `>` characters.

  ```
  > First level!
  >> Second level!
  >>> Third level!
  >>
  >> Need blank line and one less < to go back to second.
  >
  > Same idea for back to first.
  ```

  > First level!
  >
  > > Second level!
  > >
  > > > Third level!
  > >
  > > Need blank line and one less < to go back to second.
  >
  > Same idea for back to first.
- Escape a `>` character with a backslash.

  `` \> I want a `>`! ``

  > I want a `>`!
- Markdown works within a blockquote.

  ```
  > Enjoy **this** `unicorn`!
  >
  > ![image of a unicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg)
  ```

  > Enjoy **this** `unicorn`!
  >
  > [image: image of a unicorn]
- Code formatting works within a blockquote.  Indenting requires 5 spaces: 1 for the blockquote, and 4 for the code indention.

  ````
  >     System.out.println("Hello World!");

  > Inline: `System.out.println("Hello World!");`

  > Code fence:
  > ```
  > System.out.println("Hello World!");
  > ```
  ````

  > ```
  > System.out.println("Hello World!");
  > ```

  > Inline: `System.out.println("Hello World!");`

  > Code fence:
  >
  > ```
  > System.out.println("Hello World!");
  > ```

#### Lists

- ##### Unordered Lists

  - Use `+`, `-`, or `*`, followed by a space character.  Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> or press the bulleted list icon in the editor toolbar.

    ```
    + One
    - Two
    * Three
    ```

    - One

    - Two

    - Three
  - Spaces are necessary.

    ```
    +Necessary
    ```

    +Necessary
  - The other main arithmetic operators don't create lists.

    ```
    / No
    % No
    ^ No
    = No
    ```

    / No
    % No
    ^ No
    = No
- ##### Ordered Lists

  - Use any number, followed by a period ("dot"), then a space character, or any .  Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> or press the numbered list icon in the editor toolbar.

    ```
    1. One
    10. Two
    42. Three
    ```

    1. One
    2. Two
    3. Three
  - `#)` also works.

    ```
    1) One
    10) Two
    42) Three
    ```

    1. One
    2. Two
    3. Three
  - Spaces are necessary.

    ```
    1.Necessary
    1.Necessary
    ```

    1.Necessary
    1.Necessary
  - The period ("dot") is necessary.

    ```
    1 Necessary
    1 Necessary
    ```

    1 Necessary
    1 Necessary
  - Can have a different starting number:

    ```
    50. fifty
    51. fifty-one
    52. fifty-two
    ```

    50. fifty
    51. fifty-one
    52. fifty-two
  - At most nine digits for the number

    `1. One`

    1. One

    `12. Two`

    12. Two

    `123. Three`

    123. Three

    `1234. Four`

    1234. Four

    `12345. Five`

    12345. Five

    `123456. Six`

    123456. Six

    `1234567. Seven`

    1234567. Seven

    `12345678. Eight`

    12345678. Eight

    `123456789. Nine`

    123456789. Nine

    `1234567890. Ten`

    1234567890. Ten
- Multiple lines within list items: indent 4 spaces, or do we need to?

```
1. Same line
    Continuation of the same line
1. Next line
Not indented
1. Next line
    Continuation of the same line
```

1. Same line
   Continuation of the same line
2. Next line
   Not indented
3. Next line
   Continuation of the same line

- Nested lists: indent 4 spaces.

```
1. Top level
    * Mid level
        1. Bottom level
    * Mid level
        * Bottom level
1. Top level
    1. Mid level
        + Bottom level
```

1. Top level

   - Mid level

     1. Bottom level
   - Mid level

     - Bottom level
2. Top level

   1. Mid level

      - Bottom level

- Code within list items: indention requires blank line then 4 additional spaces beyond list indention level.

````
1. Top level

        System.out.println("Indented");

    ```
    System.out.println("Code fence");
    ```

    Inline: `System.out.println("Inline");`
````

1. Top level

   ```
    System.out.println("Indented");
   ```

   ```
   System.out.println("Code fence");
   ```

   Inline: `System.out.println("Inline");`

- Blockquote within list items: blank line then indent 4 spaces.

```
1. Top level

    > Quote is indented.

> Quote is not indented.
```

1. Top level

   > Quote is indented.

> Quote is not indented.

#### Markdown Escapes

```
\\ \` \* \_ \{ \} \[ \] \( \) \# \+ \- \. \!
```

\ ` * _ { } [ ] ( ) # + - . !

#### Tables

- [Wasn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables) [supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138946/can-we-add-markdown-support-for-tables) previously, but [is now supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support).

  ```
  | Syntax | Description |
  | ----------- | ----------- |
  | Header | Title |
  | Paragraph | Text |
  ```

  | Syntax | Description |
  | --- | --- |
  | Header | Title |
  | Paragraph | Text |
- One can control the horizontal alignment by placing a colon (:) in the separator line -- first character for left, first and last for center, and last for right.

  ```
  |Left-aligned|Center-aligned|Right-aligned|
  |:-----------|:------------:|------------:|
  |Left|Center|Right|
  ```

  | Left-aligned | Center-aligned | Right-aligned |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | Left | Center | Right |
- Long-enough content will wrap.

  | Wrap |
  | --- |
  | This content is long enough to wrap because it contains a lot of words meant to cause the table content to wrap to another line. |
- Content that is too long without a line break produces a horizontal scrollbar.

  | Too long |
  | --- |
  | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz0123456789 |

### Unsupported Markdown

#### Footnotes

- [Not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes)

  ```
  Text with footnote: [^1]

  [^1]: Footnote text
  ```

  Text with footnote: [^1]

[^1]: Footnote text

#### ID within Header

- Part within braces is not turned into "id" attribute in the header element.

  ```
  # Header {#with-id}
  ```

  ## Header {#with-id}

#### Strikethrough

- [Not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63768/does-markdown-have-a-way-to-express-strikeout) [supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63773/can-we-add-strikeout-to-markdown-sharp-and-by-extension-the-stack-exchange-site)

  ```
    ~~Incorrrect~~
  ```

  ~~Incorrect~~

<sup>Though, as an alternative, you can use the HTML `<strike>` tag instead: <strike>strikethrough</strike></sup>

#### Definition Lists

- Not supported

  ```
  First Term
  : First definition
  : Second definition
  Second Term
  : First definition
  : Second definition
  ```

  First Term
  : First definition
  : Second definition
  Second Term
  : First definition
  : Second definition

#### Task Lists

- Not supported; becomes an unordered list.

  ```
  - [x] Perform tests
  - [x] Write answer
  - [ ] Perform corrections
  ```

  - [x] Perform tests
  - [x] Write answer
  - [ ] Perform corrections

### Stack Exchange Extensions to Markdown

#### Tags

- Enclose in brackets `[]` and text is prefixed with `tag:`.  Letters get lowercased.  They link to the main site's tag page for that tag.

  ```
    [tag:mytag] [tag:UPPERCASE] [tag:with1number]
  ```

  [mytag](/questions/tagged/mytag) [uppercase](/questions/tagged/uppercase) [with1number](/questions/tagged/with1number)
- Allowed characters: alphanumeric plus limited punctuation: Individual `-`, `#`, `.`. and `+` characters are allowed.

  ```
    [tag:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-#.+ABCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]
  ```

  [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-#.+abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789](/questions/tagged/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-%23.%2babcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789)

  - Leading and trailing `-` are stripped off, but the tag still forms.

    ```
      [tag:c-] [tag:c--] [tag:-c] [tag:--c] [tag:-----c] [tag:c-------]
    ```

    [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c](/questions/tagged/c)
  - Trailing `.` are stripped off, but the tag still forms.

    ```
      [tag:c.] [tag:c..] [tag:.c] [tag:..c] [tag:.....c] [tag:c.......]
    ```

    [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [.c](/questions/tagged/.c) [..c](/questions/tagged/..c) [.....c](/questions/tagged/.....c) [c](/questions/tagged/c)
  - Leading `#` are stripped off, but the tag still forms.

    ```
      [tag:c#] [tag:c##] [tag:#c] [tag:##c] [tag:#####c] [tag:c#######]
    ```

    [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [c##](/questions/tagged/c%23%23) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c#######](/questions/tagged/c%23%23%23%23%23%23%23)
- The `+` character is allowed. If there's only 1 in the middle, it will not render in the preview, but it will show up in the post.  If there are at least 2 of them, they'll show up in the preview and the post.

  ```
    [tag:abc+def] [tag:abc++def] [tag:abc++++++++++++++++++++def]
  ```

  [abc+def](/questions/tagged/abc%2bdef) [abc++def](/questions/tagged/abc%2b%2bdef) [abc++++++++++++++++++++def](/questions/tagged/abc%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2bdef)

  - Leading `+` are stripped off, but the tag still forms.

    ```
      [tag:c+] [tag:c++] [tag:+c] [tag:++c] [tag:+++++c] [tag:c+++++++]
    ```

    [c+](/questions/tagged/c%2b) [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c+++++++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b%2b)
- Meta-tags: Use the `meta-tag:` prefix.  They link to the meta site's tag page for that tag.

  ```
    [meta-tag:waffles]
  ```

  [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles)

  - Certain meta tag names are given special styling.

    [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [support](/questions/tagged/support)

    [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [mod-agreement-policy](/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy) [product-discovery](/questions/tagged/product-discovery) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)
- Certain words, regardless of case, don't form tags, regardless of capitalization or whether it's a meta tag.  There are no other words, 4 letters or less, that don't form tags.  The words "and" and "or" won't form tags.  In preview, "not" won't form a tag but the actual post will render it.  The preview renders them as the text is, e.g. `[tag:Or]` but the post will render it `or`.

  ```
  [tag:an] [tag:and] [tag:AND] [tag:band]
  [tag:no] [tag:not] [tag:noT] [tag:note]
  [meta-tag:o] [meta-tag:or] [meta-tag:Or] [meta-tag:ore]
  [tag:and-not-or]
  ```

  [an](/questions/tagged/an)  and   and  [band](/questions/tagged/band)
  [no](/questions/tagged/no) [not](/questions/tagged/not) [not](/questions/tagged/not) [note](/questions/tagged/note)
  [o](/questions/tagged/o)  or   or  [ore](/questions/tagged/ore)
  [and-not-or](/questions/tagged/and-not-or)

#### Spoilers

- Create a spoiler with `>!`:

  ```
    >! You must click on me to view me!
  ```

  > You must click on me to view me!
- Markdown, including links and images, can be contained within a spoiler.

  ```
    >! _Visit [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) to view this picture._
    >! ![image of unicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg)
  ```

  > *Visit [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) to view this picture.*
  >  [image: image of unicorn]
- Markdown [block elements aren't supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116613) in spoilers

  ````
  >! 1. Top level `and some code`
  >! 
  >!         System.out.println("Indented");
  >! 
  >!     ```
  >!     System.out.println("Code fence");
  >!     ```
  >! 
  >!    Inline: `System.out.println("Inline");`
  ````

  > 1. Top level `and some code`
  >
  >          System.out.println("Indented");
  >
  >      `!     System.out.println("Code fence"); !`    
  >
  >     Inline: `System.out.println("Inline");`
- Using HTML does work (copied from [answer to: "Spoilers don't support block formatting (and so don't format well)"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116614) by [badp](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/13992/badp) and modified)

  ```
  >! <h3>Using HTML in a spoiler</h3>
  >!
  >! <hr/>
  >!
  >! <p>paragraph</p>
  >! <pre><code>code block 1
  >!code block 2
  >!code block 3
  >!code block 4</code></pre>
  >! <p>Just a paragraph with <code>some code</code></p>
  >! <ul>
  >!  <li> nested </li>
  >! </ul>
  >! <ol>
  >! <li> list </li>
  >! </ol>
  >!
  >! <blockquote>
  >!  <p>even nested quotes!</p>
  >!
  >! <pre><code>code block 1
  >!code block 2
  >!code block 3
  >!code block 4</code></pre>
  >!  <p>Just a paragraph with <code>some code</code> and a link to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)</p>
  >!  <ol>
  >!   <li>with nested nested formatting!</li>
  >!  </ol>
  >! </blockquote>
  ```

  > #### Using HTML in a spoiler
  >
  > ---
  >
  > paragraph
  >
  > ```
  > code block 1
  > code block 2
  > code block 3
  > code block 4
  > ```
  >
  > Just a paragraph with `some code` and a link to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
  >
  > - nested
  >
  > 1. list
  >
  > > even nested quotes!
  > >
  > > ```
  > > code block 1
  > > code block 2
  > > code block 3
  > > code block 4
  > > ```
  > >
  > > Just a paragraph with `some code`
  > >
  > > 1. with nested nested formatting!

#### Syntax Highlighting

- Where it's [supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), insert an HTML comment specifying the language for the following code block immediately following it.  Subsequent code blocks are not highlighted unless they have their own syntax highlighting specified.  (Sites such as Stack Overflow will infer the syntax highlighting from tags on the question, rendering this hint unnecessary.)

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
        
    System.out.println("Hello World!");

<br>

    System.out.println("Not highlighted.");
```

```java
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

```
System.out.println("Not highlighted.");
```

- Use `language-all` to highlight subsequent code blocks.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-java -->
        
    System.out.println("Hello World!");

<br>

    System.out.println("Highlighted.");
```

```java
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

```java
System.out.println("Highlighted.");
```

- Others besides Java

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
        
    echo "Hello World!"
```

```bash
echo "Hello World!"
```

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->
        
    printf("Hello World!\n");
```

```c
printf("Hello World!\n");
```

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
        
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
```

```cpp
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
```

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
        
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

```java
<!-- language: lang-js -->
        
    console.log("Hello World!");
```

```js
console.log("Hello World!");
```

```
<!-- language: lang-json -->
        
    {
        "message":"Hello World!"
    }
```

```json
{
    "message":"Hello World!"
}
```

```
<!-- language: lang-perl-->
        
    print "Hello World!\n";
```

```java
print "Hello World!\n";
```

```
<!-- language: lang-python-->
        
    print("Hello World")
```

```java
print("Hello World")
```

```
<!-- language: lang-ruby-->
        
    puts "Hello World!"
```

```java
puts "Hello World!"
```

- Code fence language hint

````
```java
System.out.println("code fence highlighting");
```
````

```java
System.out.println("code fence highlighting");
```

You can also use `lang-default` to let the highlighter guess about what language to use.

#### Stack Snippets

Stack Snippets are [only available on some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239507/271271).

```java
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    const foo = 1
    console.log('foo:', foo)

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    div {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div>Just some text in a div with a background color</div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

```js
const foo = 1
console.log('foo:', foo)
```

```css
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>Just some text in a div with a background color</div>
```

#### YouTube video embedding

YouTube video embedding is only available on some sites, which doesn't include Meta Stack Exchange.

```java
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pv01sSq44w
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pv01sSq44w

#### MathJax

MathJax is [only available on some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/271271), which doesn't include Meta Stack Exchange.

There are two format varieties used.

On [Mathmatics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) the code:

```java
$\LaTeX$
```

Would produce the following HTML:

```java
<span class="math-container">$\LaTeX$</span>
```

That HTML would then be converted in-browser by MathJax JavaScript code to the stylized [image: LaTeX logo generated by MathJax]. Here on Meta Stack Exchange, it produces:

$\LaTeX$

#### Editable schematics

Editable schematics are only available on some sites, which doesn't include Meta Stack Exchange.

```java
<!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

![schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DUDp.png)

<!-- End schematic -->
```

[image: schematic]

When enabled, it will produce HTML similar to:

```java
<p><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DUDp.png" alt="schematic"></p>

<p><sup><a href="/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9DUDp.png">simulate this circuit</a> &ndash; Schematic created using <a href="https://www.circuitlab.com/" rel="nofollow">CircuitLab</a></sup></p>
```

### Allowed HTML

Only some [basic HTML elements are whitelisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).  Also, only some attributes within those tags are whitelisted as well.  If specified, they must be in order!  Those that don't meet these requirements are completely stripped from the content.

- `<a>`: `href` then `title`

  ```html
    <a href="http://meta.stackexchange.com/" title="Tooltip">_Meta Stack Exchange_</a>
  ```

  [*Meta Stack Exchange*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)
- `<b>` or `<strong>`: no attributes

  ```html
    <b>Bold</b> and <strong>Strong</strong>
  ```

  **Bold** and **Strong**
- `<blockquote>`: no attributes

  ```html
    <blockquote>To be or not to be, that is the question.</blockquote>
  ```

  > To be or not to be, that is the question.
- `<br>`: no attributes

  ```html
    Put it on the<br>next line.
  ```

  Put it on the
  next line.
- `<del>` or `<strike>`: no attributes

  ```html
    <del>That's not right.</del> <strike>That's not even wrong.</strike> Correct.
  ```

  <del>That's not right.</del> <strike>That's not even wrong.</strike> Correct.
- `<dl>`, `<dt>`, and `<dd>`: no attributes

  ```html
  <dl>
    <dt>SO</dt>
    <dd>Stack Overflow</dd>
    <dt>SE</dt>
    <dd>Stack Exchange</dd>
  </dl>
  ```

  SO

  Stack Overflow

  SE

  Stack Exchange
- `<em>` or `<i>`: no attributes

  ```html
    <em>Emphasis</em> and <i>Italic</i>
  ```

  *Emphasis* and *Italic*
- `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, and `<h6>`: no attributes

  ```html
  <h1>One</h1>
  <h2>Two</h2>
  <h3>Three</h3>
  <h4>Four</h4>
  <h5>Five</h5>
  <h6>Six</h6>
  ```

  ## One

  ### Two

  #### Three

  ##### Four

  ###### Five

  ###### Six
- `<hr>`: no attributes

  ```html
    End of thought <hr> Next thought
  ```

  End of thought

  ---

  Next thought
- `<img>`: `src` then `width` then `height` then `alt` then `title`

  ```html
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg" alt="image of unicorn" title="Tooltip">
  ```

  [image: image of unicorn]

  - Specifying one of `width` or `height` scales the image; must specify both to change the aspect ratio.  They can't be `px` and they max out at 999.

    ```html
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg" width="999">
    ```

    [image]

    ```html
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg" width="100">
    ```

    [image]

    ```html
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg" height="999">
    ```

    [image]

    ```html
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg" width="999" height="100">
    ```

    [image]

    ```html
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1jg.jpg" width="100" height="999">
    ```

    [image]
  - Animated gifs are supported.

    ```html
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXtId.gif">
    ```

    [image]
- `<kbd>`: no attributes

  ```html
    <kbd>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()-_=+`~[{]}\|;:'",<.>/?0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</kbd>
  ```

  <kbd>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()-_=+`~[{]}|;:'",<.>/?0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</kbd>

  - Nested `<kbd>` elements are allowed.

    ```html
        <kbd>Outer<kbd>Nested</kbd></kbd>
    ```

    <kbd>Outer<kbd>Nested</kbd></kbd>

- `<ol>` or `<ul>` with `<li>`: `<ol>` can have `start`

  ```html
    <ol><li>First</li><li>Second</li></ol> <ul><li>Something</li><li>Else</li></ul>
  ```

  1. First
  2. Second

  - Something
  - Else

  - Start at desired number up to 2<sup>31</sup> - 1.

    ```html
      <ol start="2147483647"><li>First</li></ol>
    ```

    1. First
- `<p>`: no attributes

  ```html
    <p>Paragraph1</p><p>Paragraph2</p>
  ```

  Paragraph1

  Paragraph2
- `<pre>`: no attributes

  ```html
    <pre>System.out.println("Hello World!");</pre>
  ```

  ```
  System.out.println("Hello World!");
  ```
- `<sup>` and `<sub>`: no attributes

  ```html
    x<sup>2</sup> + A<sub>0</sub>
  ```

  x<sup>2</sup> + A<sub>0</sub>

  - They can be nested.

    ```html
      a<sup>b<sup>c<sup>d<sub>e<sup>f</sup></sub></sup></sup></sup>
    ```

    a<sup>b<sup>c<sup>d<sub>e<sup>f</sup></sub></sup></sup></sup>
- Others are NOT supported, including: `font`, `span`, `div`, `table`.

  ```html
    <font color="red">Red text?</font>
  ```

  Red text?

  ```html
    <span style="color:red">Red text?</font>
  ```

  Red text?

  ```html
    <div style="color:red">Red text?</font>
  ```

  Red text?

  ```html
    <table><tr><td>Not</td><td>Supported</td></tr></table>
  ```

  NotSupported
- Escape your `<>`

  ```html
    HashMap<String, Object>
  ```

  HashMap<String, Object>

  ```html
    `HashMap<String, Object>`
  ```

  `HashMap<String, Object>`

  ```html
    HashMap&lt;String, Object&gt;
  ```

  HashMap<String, Object>

### Unicode

#### Emojis

```html
&#9786;&#x1F409;
```

☺

#### Right-to-left

```html
ABC&#8238;DEF
```

ABC‮DEF

#### Zalgo

Z̸̧̦̥͔̻̞̟͔͒̓̄̓͐͆͋̃̅͆̓͘̚͝͝à̷̛̜͇̺̖̯̭͓̱̱̣̺̲̪̰l̷̢̳̤̮͈͎̩̱̳̱̱̞͆͂̽̀̃͒̿̄̅͊͘͘̚͠͝ͅg̷͙͋o̶̧̩̓̓͌̄͊͐̓̇̏͝ ̶̛͚͖͍̦͕̞͈͆̋̓̈̏̈̓̊̅͆͘͜t̸̬̮̖̖͙͔̮͊̔͊͌́̈́͒̇͒̽̑̎̚̕͠ė̶̖̰̬͙͙̇̈͌͘͜͜x̴͔̎t̶̖́̒̏͒͌̈́̏͊̒̉ͅ ̵̨͍̬͔̼̣̘̖͍͖̘͍͋̑͛̂̾̋ḧ̸̡̘̬̲̣̺́́̿̀̈ͅé̷̦̰̻̤̲̺̠̏͒̉͛̍͌̍ͅr̶̩̯̱̜͆̌̾͌̑̇̊͒̃̀̽̍̚é̴̜̉̇̿̈́͌̕.̸̢̱͔̲̫̇͌̽̌͂͊͊̈́̇

Comment: **Bold**, _italic_, _**bold italic**_, `System.out.println("code formatting");`, [no-ref link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: Comment only magic links: `[meta]` [meta], `[main]` [main], `[edit]` [edit], `[help]` [help], `[help/on-topic]` [help/on-topic], `[help/dont-ask]` [help/dont-ask], `[help/behavior]` [help/behavior], `[meta-help]` [meta-help], `[tour]` [tour], `[so]` [so], `[su]` [su], `[sf]` [sf], `[metase]` [metase], `[a51]` [a51], `[se]` [se], `[pt.so]` [pt.so], `[chat]` [chat], `[ask]` [ask], `[answer]` [answer], `[astronomy.se]` [astronomy.se], `[math.se]` [math.se], `[meta.astronomy.se]`, [meta.astronomy.se], `[meta.math.se]` [meta.math.se], `[mcve]` [mcve].

Comment: Unicode characters work: ☺ ᵃᵉⁱᵒᵘ ₐₑᵢₒᵤ s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶o̶u̶t̶ Z̸̧̦̥͔̻̞̟͔͒̓̄̓͐͆͋̃̅͆̓͘̚͝͝à̷̛̜͇̺̖̯̭͓̱̱̣̺̲̪̰l̷̢̳̤̮͈͎̩̱̳̱̱̞͆͂̽̀̃͒̿̄̅͊͘͘̚͠͝ͅg̷͙͋o̶̧̩̓̓͌̄͊͐̓̇̏͝ ̶̛͚͖͍̦͕̞͈͆̋̓̈̏̈̓̊̅͆͘͜t̸̬̮̖̖͙͔̮͊̔͊͌́̈́͒̇͒̽̑̎̚̕͠ė̶̖̰̬͙͙̇̈͌͘͜͜x̴͔̎t̶̖́̒̏͒͌̈́̏͊̒̉ͅ ̵̨͍̬͔̼̣̘̖͍͖̘͍͋̑͛̂̾̋ḧ̸̡̘̬̲̣̺́́̿̀̈ͅé̷̦̰̻̤̲̺̠̏͒̉͛̍͌̍ͅr̶̩̯̱̜͆̌̾͌̑̇̊͒̃̀̽̍̚é̴̜̉̇̿̈́͌̕.̸̢̱͔̲̫̇͌̽̌͂͊͊̈́̇

Comment: ‮**I love RTLO! It makes comments go crazy.**

Comment: Why is this so freaking long?!?!? It takes up over half of the page!

Comment: @Bookwyrm It turns out there are a _lot_ of features that can be tested, such as  [comment `@` auto-replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).  Comments are limited to 600 characters.  Comments are limited to 600 characters.  Comments are limited to 600 characters.  Comments are limited to 600 characters.  Comments are limited to 600 characters.  Comments are limited to 600 characters.  Comments are limited to 600 characters.  Comments are limited to 600 characters.  Comments are limited to 600 characters.  Comments are limited to 600 characters.  Com

Comment: **`bold formatted`** _`italic formatted`_ _**`bold italic formatted`**_ Tag link: [meta-tag:waffles] [Hover for popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325826/203888 "")

Comment:  .   .     .  **Bold  .  Bold  .  Bold    .**  _Italic  .  Italic  .  Italic    ._  **_Bold and italic  .  Bold and italic  .  Bold and italic    ._**

Comment: Ⓗⓞⓛⓛⓞⓦ ⓑⓤⓑⓑⓛⓔⓢ,  , ⒜⒭⒠⒩⒯⒣⒠⒮⒤⒵⒠⒟ ⒞⒣⒜⒭⒜⒞⒯⒠⒭⒮, C̷h̷i̷c̷k̷e̷n̷ ̷s̷c̷r̷a̷t̷c̷h̷e̷s̷, U͟n͟d͟e͟r͟l͟i͟n͟e͟d͟, Sᴍᴀʟʟ Cᴀᴘs,  ℯ,   ,  , and of course ████████.

Comment: waffles! waffles!

Comment: _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_ _`a`_

Comment: This is a comment ‮mutpircstsop a si siht dnA‭

Comment: [‌](http://google.com)‮tnemmoc sdrawkcaB‭

Comment: sᶠaͦnͬdͫbͣoͭxͭᶦⁿᵍ,   ,    .  Hopefully this isn't ✌annoying or obnoxious✌.   D̳o̳u̳b̳l̳e̳ ̳U̳n̳d̳e̳r̳l̳i̳n̳e̳  U͙n͙d͙e͙r͙l͙i͙n͙e͙ ͙w͙i͙t͙h͙ ͙A͙s͙t͙e͙r͙i͙s͙k͙s͙  ¿uʍop ǝpısdn ʇxǝʇ sıɥʇ sı ʎɥM  ℑ   .

Comment: The answer seems to miss a link format: Simply put `[some link]` into the text and add `[some link]: https://https://meta.stackexchange.com` somewhere else. Essentially a reference link where Display==refName. Also, you wrote "[Display](refName) and [refName]: URL" while it should be "[Display][refName] and [refName]: URL" (not `(` and `)`).

Comment: @TS Thanks for the correction.  I attempted to update my answer to include the correction and the addition for when the display is the same as the refname, but apparently my answer is over 30,000 characters already (33,000?) and I can't submit my edit.  I wonder why I was able to go over 30,000 in the first place?  I also edited my answer back in April successfully even though it was presumably already over 30,000 character back then.

Comment: Hm, yes I already tried to update the answer myself (It's community wiki after all) and got the same message. As the answer already was above 30000 prior to my edit, I thought, that maybe the original author has some higher limit, so I wrote a comment. I guess you could flag your own answer - Maybe moderators have a higher limit - and there's good reason, why your answer is this long...

Comment: ͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏ ͏

Comment: too.many.unicorns.

Comment: Upvoted just because of the waffles gif.

Comment: You forgot to test the double space line break works just as well as `<br>`.

Comment: [test](example)

Comment: Tables are now supported!

Comment: "Attributes should be in order": Does [SE use RegEx to parse HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: [Add a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/368045#)  |  [Show **11** more comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/368045#) ‮.egassem siht sevorppa

Comment: 

Comment: One *could* also use backslashes: `_\_INT_MAX_\_` ⇒ _\_INT_MAX_\_.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//meta.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Meta way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 48):

[test broken link?](http://%20https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273213/adding-a-link-with-a-space-in-front-causes-the-link-to-not-work?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Hello **Important notice:** Purple Pika Wizardry co. is not responsible for any damages resulting in the viewing of these unicorns, including but not limited to rainbowness, lack of tiredness, waffle disease, and jealousy of not owning these unicorns. Continue at your own risk.

---

Here are my pet unicorns, Fluffy, Fluffy Junior, and Fluffy Senior!

[image: Fluffy]
[image: Fluffy Junior]
[image: Fluffy Senior]
[[image: Flaming unicorn]] <!-- ouch (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcEDA.jpg)
And guess what? They don't like skittles. That's right. *My unicorns don't like skittles*. I've trained them to eat the *superior* food, aka waffles (yeah, I've had a change in heart from [my evil past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive/320458#320458)).

[image]

> Don't flag this as Not an Answer. Unicorns are the answer to anything. Waffles are the answer to everything. Unicorns that eat waffles are the answer to anything and everything.

- *user405220*

> 

## test

> 

#### test

> 

##### test

Comment: I agree 100% that unicorns are awesome.

Comment: Your signature still doesn’t match your correct name, @PikachuthePurpleWizard.

Comment: @Mr.YouKnowWhoIAm yeah, but it sounds really cool.

Comment: I don’t think “Unicorns that eat waffles… **— user405220**“ is very _cool_.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, the mods are not asleep.

Comment: *Uses magical waffle powers to make all moderators everywhere sleep*

Comment: Okay... Kinda new to SE Meta... and I am loving it already.

Comment: [help/behavior]

Comment: [help/behavior]

Comment: test^test testing <sup>testing</sup>

Comment: `regex is awesome                                                                                                                            `

Comment: @ymb1 I don't think you get a notification for this (*silent wind blows...*)

Comment: Backtick test 2: ``bla blubber foo '[FooBar!=`BarFoo` && FooBar!=`FooBar`] bla' sorry for this stuff``

Answer (score 23):

JavaScript art again!

```js
! function() {
  function o(w, v, i) {
    return w.getAttribute(v) || i
  }

  function j(i) {
    return document.getElementsByTagName(i)
  }

  function l() {
    var i = j("script"),
      w = i.length,
      v = i[w - 1];
    return {
      l: w,
      z: o(v, "zIndex", -1),
      o: o(v, "opacity", 1.0),
      c: o(v, "color", "0,0,0"),
      n: o(v, "count", 40)
    }
  }

  function k() {
    r = u.width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth, n = u.height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight
  }

  function b() {
    e.clearRect(0, 0, r, n);
    var w = [f].concat(t);
    var x, v, A, B, z, y;
    t.forEach(function(i) {
      i.x += i.xa, i.y += i.ya, i.xa *= i.x > r || i.x < 0 ? -1 : 1, i.ya *= i.y > n || i.y < 0 ? -1 : 1, e.fillStyle = "rgba(" + s.c + "," + s.o + ")", e.fillRect(i.x - 0.5, i.y - 0.5, 1, 1);
      for (v = 0; v < w.length; v++) {
        x = w[v];
        if (i !== x && null !== x.x && null !== x.y) {
          B = i.x - x.x, z = i.y - x.y, y = B * B + z * z;
          y < x.max && (x === f && y >= x.max / 2 && (i.x -= 0.03 * B, i.y -= 0.03 * z), A = (x.max - y) / x.max, e.beginPath(), e.lineWidth = A / 2, e.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + s.c + "," + (A + 0.2) + ")", e.moveTo(i.x, i.y), e.lineTo(x.x, x.y), e.stroke())
        }
      }
      w.splice(w.indexOf(i), 1)
    }), m(b)
  }
  var u = document.createElement("canvas"),
    s = l(),
    c = "c_n" + s.l,
    e = u.getContext("2d"),
    r, n, m = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(i) {
      window.setTimeout(i, 1000 / 45)
    },
    a = Math.random,
    f = {
      x: null,
      y: null,
      max: 20000
    };
  u.id = c;
  u.style.cssText = "position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:" + s.z + ";opacity:" + s.o;
  j("body")[0].appendChild(u);
  k(), window.onresize = k;
  window.onmousemove = function(i) {
    i = i || window.event, f.x = i.clientX, f.y = i.clientY
  }, window.onmouseout = function() {
    f.x = null, f.y = null
  };
  for (var t = [], p = 0; s.n > p; p++) {
    var h = a() * r,
      g = a() * n,
      q = 2 * a() - 1,
      d = 2 * a() - 1;
    t.push({
      x: h,
      y: g,
      xa: q,
      ya: d,
      max: 6000
    })
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    b()
  }, 100)
}();
! function(e, t, a) {
  function n() {
    c(".heart{width: 10px;height: 10px;position: fixed;background: #f00;transform: rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);}.heart:after,.heart:before{content: '';width: inherit;height: inherit;background: inherit;border-radius: 50%;-webkit-border-radius: 50%;-moz-border-radius: 50%;position: fixed;}.heart:after{top: -5px;}.heart:before{left: -5px;}"), o(), r()
  }

  function r() {
    for (var e = 0; e < d.length; e++) d[e].alpha <= 0 ? (t.body.removeChild(d[e].el), d.splice(e, 1)) : (d[e].y--, d[e].scale += .004, d[e].alpha -= .013, d[e].el.style.cssText = "left:" + d[e].x + "px;top:" + d[e].y + "px;opacity:" + d[e].alpha + ";transform:scale(" + d[e].scale + "," + d[e].scale + ") rotate(45deg);background:" + d[e].color + ";z-index:99999");
    requestAnimationFrame(r)
  }

  function o() {
    var t = "function" == typeof e.onclick && e.onclick;
    e.onclick = function(e) {
      t && t(), i(e)
    }
  }

  function i(e) {
    var a = t.createElement("div");
    a.className = "heart", d.push({
      el: a,
      x: e.clientX - 5,
      y: e.clientY - 5,
      scale: 1,
      alpha: 1,
      color: s()
    }), t.body.appendChild(a)
  }

  function c(e) {
    var a = t.createElement("style");
    a.type = "text/css";
    try {
      a.appendChild(t.createTextNode(e))
    } catch (t) {
      a.styleSheet.cssText = e
    }
    t.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)
  }

  function s() {
    return "rgb(" + ~~(255 * Math.random()) + "," + ~~(255 * Math.random()) + "," + ~~(255 * Math.random()) + ")"
  }
  var d = [];
  e.requestAnimationFrame = function() {
    return e.requestAnimationFrame || e.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || e.mozRequestAnimationFrame || e.oRequestAnimationFrame || e.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(e) {
      setTimeout(e, 1e3 / 60)
    }
  }(), n()
}(window, document);
```

Comment: Backtick in comment `code` - `\`` - backtick+backslash+backtick+backtick

Comment: blah blah blah blah

Comment: `\`` [​](https://google.com)

Answer (score 16):

> > > > > ---
> > > > >
> > > > > ## Disclaimer:
> > > > >
> > > > > ***Please do not remove the RTLO.** (I like it the way it is, thank you very much.)*
> > > > >
> > > > > ***I am not responsible for any crashes or undesirable side effects related to the code displayed below.
> > > > >           Run all snippets at your own risk.
> > > > >           You have been warned.***
> > > > >
> > > > > ---

---

---

---

I hope I won't break anything!
I'm bored, so ‮**I will be using *RTLO* for everything I say! (except for the JS)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>This is some random nonsense!</title>
</head>
<body>
<marquee behavior="alternate" direction="down" height="600" width="600" id="marqueeVt">
<marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left" id="marqueeHz">
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</marquee>
</marquee>
<script>
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 canvas.height = 11700;
 canvas.width = 11700;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
 function marqueeDirection() {
  var marqueeVt = document.getElementById("marqueeVt"), marqueeHz = document.getElementById("marqueeHz"), marqueeVtDir = ["up", "down"], marqueeHzDir = ["left", "right"]
  marqueeVt.direction = marqueeVtDir[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]
  marqueeHz.direction = marqueeHzDir[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]
  setTimeout(marqueeDirection, rndtime(3000, 5000))
 }
 function rect(x, y, col) {
  ctx.fillStyle = col;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150), Math.floor(Math.random() * 150))
 }
 
 function circle(x, y, col) {
  ctx.fillStyle = col
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150), 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
  ctx.fill()
 }

 function rndcol(){
  return "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(16, 6)).toString(16).padStart(6, "0");
 }

 function rndcoord(limit) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
 }

 function rndtime(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
 }

 function rndrect() {
  setTimeout(function () { rect(rndcoord(canvas.width), rndcoord(canvas.height), rndcol()) }, rndtime(1, 1000))
 }

 function rndcircle() {
  setTimeout(function () { circle(rndcoord(canvas.width), rndcoord(canvas.height), rndcol()) }, rndtime(1, 1000))
 }
 
 function rndline() {
  setTimeout(function () { 
   ctx.strokeStyle = rndcol()
   ctx.lineWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
   ctx.beginPath()
   ctx.moveTo(rndcoord(canvas.width), rndcoord(canvas.height))
   for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 20); i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(rndcoord(canvas.width), rndcoord(canvas.height))
   }
   ctx.stroke()
  }, rndtime(1, 1000))
 }

 console.log("Loading...")
 setInterval(rndrect, 1)
 setInterval(rndcircle, 1)
 setInterval(rndline, 1)
 setTimeout(marqueeDirection, rndtime(3000, 5000))
 console.log("...done")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

‮*Note: Use this in fullscreen.*

‮[image: Warning] **WARNING:** *Prolonged execution may cause browser issues.*

---

---

### *Unicorns!*

> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>  <title>Unicorns!</title>
>  <style>
>   #container {
>    border-style: dotted;
>    border-width: 5px;
>    border-color: black;
>    padding: 10px;
>   }
>   
>   .unicorn {
>    border-style: solid;
>    border-width: 5px;
>    border-radius: 12px;
>    border-color: black;
>   }
>  </style>
> </head>
> <body>
>  <div id="container"></div>
> <script>
>  function rndhex64(){
>   return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(16, 64)).toString(16) // .padStart(64, "0") is unnecessary
>  }
>
>  function unicornimg() {
>   var url = "https://unicornify.pictures/avatar/" + rndhex64() + "?s=128"
>   var link = document.createElement("a")
>   link.href = url
>   link.target = "_blank"
>   var img = document.createElement("img")
>   img.src = url
>   img.classList.add("unicorn")
>   link.appendChild(img)
>   document.getElementById("container").appendChild(link)
>  }
>
>  function bgcol() {
>   var body = document.body
>   var bgcol = getbgcol(body.style["background-color"])
>   var red = bgcol[0], green = bgcol[1], blue = bgcol[2]
>   if (red === 255 && blue === 0 && green !== 255) {
>    green++
>   } else if (green === 255 && red > 0) {
>    red--
>   } else if (green === 255 && red === 0 & blue !== 255) {
>    blue++
>   } else if (blue === 255 && green > 0) {
>    green--
>   } else if (blue === 255 && green === 0 && red !== 255) {
>    red++
>   } else if (red === 255 && blue > 0) {
>    blue--
>   } else {
>    console.error("Error: " + body.style["background-color"] + "; " + bgcol + "; " + typeof bgcol + "; Red: " + red + "; Green: " + green + "; Blue: " + blue)
>   }
>
>   bgcol = red * 65536 + green * 256 + blue
>   body.style["background-color"] = col(bgcol)
>  }
>
>  function getbgcol(rgbstr) {
>   colarray = rgbstr.split(", ")
>   colarray[0] = parseInt(colarray[0].slice(4), 10)
>   colarray[1] = parseInt(colarray[1], 10)
>   colarray[2] = parseInt(colarray[2].slice(0, -1), 10)
>   return colarray
>  }
>  
>  function col(num) {
>   return "#" + num.toString(16).padStart(6, "0");
>  }
>
>  document.body.style["background-color"] = "#FF0000"
>  setInterval(bgcol, 1)
>  setInterval(unicornimg, 1000)
> </script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

*— from [MrYouKnowWhoIAm/unicornifypictures](https://github.com/MrYouKnowWhoIAm/unicornifypictures)*

Comment: Congratulations! You didn't break anything!

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard It may break the page now, since I changed the canvas size from 3600 x 3600 to 11700 x 11700. Do not use 12600 x 12600.

Comment: *Now* you broke something.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard _Of course_ something broke, the canvas is so big. The only reason you can't see the size is because of the marquee elements in the HTML that is 600 x 600 px. There was a (backwards) warning.

Comment: This might crash your browser

Comment: @smileycreations15 It actually says in the warning that it may crash the browser, especially if you leave the tab on for too long or you have multiple tabs. I tested it on Chrome.

Comment: You just made me want to learn javascript. I *must* learn how to make unicorns continuously appear out of nowhere!

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard I don’t know much about JS, but somehow, I could do that. I generate random URLs from `unicornify.pictures`, and use CSS to add some borders. The `setInterval` function adds unicorns every millisecond. And the rainbow background must look familiar somewhere... You can click on the unicorns to open the images in a new tab. One issue is that the URLs end in zeros, since my source of randomness is a function that returns random decimals (`Math.random()`) that are multiplied by large numbers. Nevertheless, it still makes endless unicorns that fill the page. ‮

Answer (score 13):

## Everything from the help page

### Code and Preformatted Text

```
four spaces code
```

```
code fence
```

```
another code fence
```

### Code spans

`code span` `` code span with a `backtick` in it ``

### Linebreaks

Line
Another line

### Italics and Bold

**bold** *italic* ***bold and italic***

### Links

[This is a link](https://example.com/)
[This is too](https://example.org/)
[And so is this](https://example.net/)
[Hover over me!](https://sketchywebsite.net/)

### Bare URLs

https://thishasnospecialformatt.ing
https://*non-forced-url*
https://*forced-url*

### Headers

> ## This is a header
>
> ### This is a subheader
>
> #### This is a subsubheader
>
> This is a subsubsubheader (normal text)
>
> ## This is an alternate header
>
> ### This is an alternate subheader

### Horizontal Rules

---

---

---

### Simple lists

- Bullet point

- Another bullet point

- *Another* bullet point

1. Point 1
2. Point 2
3. Tried to make this point 15 but the system knows better

- You can also make double-spaced lists
- Like this

### Advanced lists: Nesting

**You may edit this to add more things inside this gigantic nested list**

1. This is a list

   - This is something inside that list

     1. Another thing inside that list

        1. Continuing to nest...

           - How deep can this go?

             1. Oh no

                - This is going on...

                  - ... and on...

                    1. ... and on!
             2. There are now 2 branches!

                - Here's something inside that

                  1. Hey, this is fun!

                     - If not long
                     - Here's a blockquote

                       > Quote quote quote!
                  2. This is a very big list

                     1. ## Header inside the list
                     2. ### Subheader inside the list
                     3. #### Subsubheader inside the list
                     4. Subsubsubheader inside the list
                - Here's another thing inside that
           - This will go deeper

             - And deeper

               - And deeper

                 - And deeper

                   - And deeper

                     - And deeper

                       - And deeper

                         - And deeper

                           - And deeper

                             - And deeper

                               - And deeper

                                 - And deeper

                                   - And deeper

                                     - And deeper

                                       - And deeper

                                         - And deeper

- Finally!  Escaped the list.

### Simple blockquotes

> Here's a blockquote
> that spans multiple lines

### Advanced blockquotes: Nesting

> Oh no not nesting again
>
> > **Anything but that!**
> >
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > Wow, this is deep!

> Whew!  Glad it wasn't as long as the list.

### Images

This page is [image: valid XHTML].

### Inline HTML

<kbd>**OH NO YOU CAN NEST THIS TOO.**<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>This looks like a pyramid!</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

### Tags

Blue tag: [tag](/questions/tagged/tag)
Red tag: [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)
Invalid tag: [this-isnt-really-a-tag](/questions/tagged/this-isnt-really-a-tag)

### Spoilers

At the end of episode five, it turns out that

> what episode 5?  This is MSE ;)

### Tables

| This | is | a | table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| This | is | a | row |
| This | is | another | row |

### Comment formatting

Uh... you know this isn't a comment, right?

## Wow!  You made it all the way to the end of this!  Maybe upvote to congratulate my hour of effort?

Comment: If you were going to ruin the episode 5 of game of thrones...

Comment: Upvoted because you actually bothered to do this.

Comment: @Ollie Well, wish I'd done it.

Comment: @TechExpertWizard Do something crazier.  I'll have something out in just a sec, hopefully.

Comment: @Ollie ohk, BTW did you see what I did below?

Comment: @TechExpertWizard I did.  The Sandbox doesn't look like a Jackson Pollock though, so we need more.

Comment: @10R It's a reference to the [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers).  The only way to know if the spoiler's the same to click on it...

Comment: @Ano You were pretty amazing.

Comment: You know, I can't help but wonder what would happen if we filled all the posts in the Sandbox with # F̶̡̧̧̧̧̢̧̡̧̧̢̧̢̡̨̡̢̺̬̱̹̪͉̭̝̹̰̯͚͍̩͎͓̲̟̘̟̼̠̟̜͚̥̝̜͇͇̺͕̯̻̺̮͉̺̩̗̩̙̭͙͍͚̜͉͚͓͈̦̦͎̰̤͍͍̲̼͍͓̻̤͎̫͈͖̱̮͚̘̪̹̱͍̗̜͓̳̺̝̭̜̣̥͕̲̣̗̱̬̭̮̯̘̼͎͈̖̹̮̠̭͔͖̯̪̹̯̥̘̲͈̘̝̟̩̺̥͍͈̣̝̤̝̳͍̟͉̱̮͉̤̱͎̜̲̺̝̖̦̥͍̖͇̮͍̯̤̃̈́͋̎͗́̾̏͛̇̈͌͋͗̽͜͜͝ͅͅͅͅͅĬ̵̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̫͔̘̦̦͕͈̞͕̝̼̰̱͇̣̤̙̖̯͙̭̩̭̘̀̽͐̿͌̃̆̅̽̈̐̽͊̈́̀́̃̃̽̆͆̍͆̓̀̈́̀̇̅̎́̉̓̂̑̿̋̉̐́̌̈́̀̔̄̿̉̄͂͒̿̄̋́̏̈́̇̈̈́͛̂̒̊̇̃̎̂͒̀̍͆̓̐́̒͆͗̂́͐̀́͌͑́͗̑̓̊͌̿̿͂͌͒̍͂͛̐̊̄͒̌̃̀͆͛̓̍̐̉̿̅̊͑̐̓̀̔̄̇͊̊̿͑͂̍̍͑̍͌̐̍̔͌̈́̈́̉̄̅̾̌́͊͛̊̽͗̈́̌̂̐̔̒̄̆͛́̊͑͐͐̿̅͆̀̈́̽̐͛̀̃́͊̇͂̽̾̇̕̕̕͘͘͘͘̕͘͜͜͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅĻ̸̨̡̨̧͍͈̘͉̭̭̪̳͙̯̭̲̩̼̫̗͔̠̱̪͙̙̪̖̮̹̞̥̝̭͉̌̉̅̽͑̍͆̏̉̾͆̉̋̏͘̚͘͝͝͠ͅͅͅ

Comment: @Ollie How do you do that?

Answer (score 12):

Everyone likes waffles, so I've compiled the tastiest, most delicious waffles into an all-in-one, waffle format answer.

<sub>Images found on tenor.com, simplerecipes.com, modernhoney.com, shewearsmanyhats.com, cookieandkate.com, daringgourmet.com, thestayathomechef.com, and completelydelicious.com.</sub>

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

ababab

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

[image: Waffles]

I now challenge you *not* to run over to your closest waffle maker and make the most savory, delicious waffle you've ever had in your life, and eat it within 30 seconds of making it.

Comment: -1 for making me hungry, +2 for waffles :P

Comment: I can;'t eat waffles lol

Comment: I absolutely love that Google sometimes randomly shows [this “Images for formatting sandbox” section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABPpu.png) when searching for duplicate targets of (purported) bug reports about the formatting sandbox.

Answer (score 12):

I am testing the formatting for numbered lists that seem malformed when an element has no text

eg:

1. foo
2. bar1
3. 
4. bar2

possible fix:

1. foo
2. bar1
3. 

<nbsp>

3. bar

note the wrong number after the empty element (needs to be fixed by hand)

Comment: after further testing and discussion this seems to be a bug on FF/Win

Answer (score 11):

[▟████▙](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

[███████](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

[███████](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

  [▜████▛](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

           [▛](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

▗██▖ ▄                              █            [████](https://meta.stackexchange.com)                        [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

 █▘  ▘ █                             █             [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)                                [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

 █       ▄█▄   ▄██▖▗██▄  █    ▟     [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)         [▙](https://meta.stackexchange.com)    [▟▗██▄](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [█▗█▄](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [▄██▖](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [█▗█▄](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [▗█▙█▗██▖](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

 ▜█▙   █   ▝      █  █    ▝  █  ▟       [███](https://meta.stackexchange.com)      [▙▟](https://meta.stackexchange.com)   [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)    [▝](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [█▛](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [▜▝](https://meta.stackexchange.com)      [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [█▛](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [▜](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [▝█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)    [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

       █▎  █    ▗███  █          █▟▙      [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)             [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)    [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)         [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)      [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [▗███](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)       [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)      [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [████](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

 ▖   █▎  █     █     █  █     ▗  █     ▙    [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)           [▛▜](https://meta.stackexchange.com)   [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)    [▗](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)      [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)      [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)       [█▝███](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

 ▜█▛  ▜█ ▝█▛█ ▝██▀  █      ▙   [████](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [▛](https://meta.stackexchange.com)    [▜▝██▀](https://meta.stackexchange.com) [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)      [█▝█▛█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)       [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)         [█](https://meta.stackexchange.com)   [▜█▛](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

                                                                                                                                          [▜██▘](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Not completely accurate. In fact, you can also define a custom output filename (Without the -o option) as long as the "Create output file from stdout" option in PhpStorm is CHECKED. Example:   >$FileName$ $FileParentDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css --output-style compressed in the "Arguments" field, will output a COMPRESSED (Minified) Scss file with a filename ending in .min.css

Answer (score 11):

Lists in a spoiler block:

> unordered list:
>
> - first item
>
>   second item
>
> ordered list:
>
> 1. first item
>
>    second item

Comment: Absolute SORCERY! I love it.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>`<!DocType Html></kbd>

A HTML file
  
  
   
    A table
   
  
 
`
<kbd>`
 
  
   An XHTML file
  
  
   
    A table
   
  
 
`</kbd>

Answer (score 9):

This is a demonstration of how to use Stack Snippets to display animated stroke order for writing Chinese characters. It is related to [this question](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1681/16), but Stack Snippets aren't currently enabled on the Chinese Language site.

```js
var writer = HanziWriter.create('character-target-div', '赢', {
  width: 180,
  height: 180,
  padding: 2,
  showOutline: true,
  strokeColor: '#aa7ab7',
  radicalColor: '#007ab7',
  delayBetweenLoops: 500,
  delayBetweenStrokes: 100
});
  writer.loopCharacterAnimation();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hanzi-writer@2.2/dist/hanzi-writer.min.js"></script>
<div id="character-target-div"></div>
```

Comment: Hmmm... it's amazing that it works.  But seeing the code and having to click "Run code snippet" kind of ruins it.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones yeah, if this was a solution we could "run code snippet" for ruby text too, but it's way too clumsy.

Answer (score 8):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > H̶̛͉̣͇̯̺̋̉́̐͊́͂͑͐̌͘ë̴̢̬̫͚̘̼͈́̈̏̅l̶͙̪̦͙͖̲̪̞͊̅̑͒̾̈́̈̀̆̕͜͝l̸͈̰̻͕͈͚͈̋̓͆͋̆̚̚͠ô̵̡̝͎̖͓̩͚͓͎̭̱̪͚͐̓̊̄̌̽̀̀̓͂̈́ ̵̨̨̢̜͚̱̙͎̻̭̠͇̝̓͐̓̈͐̒̓̋̿͋̀̾̚ț̴̟͑͂h̵͍̘̮̠̺͇̞̔͒̐͝͝ĩ̴̗͕͕̩̇̓̒͒̆̅͂͜s̵̖̅ ̴̼̲̖̖͂̀̆͛̈͛̈̀̆i̸͔̫̝͒ͅs̶̠̼̭̠̻̥̻̦̜͕͛͐ͅ ̷̺͙͌̈̀̈́͆̚͘͝a̸͉̹̦̔̈́̑̈́́͑̕ ̶̖̮̜̼͇͚̬̩͔̼̈́͑ş̶̻̟͈̹̩̣͓̻̫̗̜̝͊͒̽͗̈́͝i̸̢̞̤̺̹̣͂̎̈́͝m̶̢̠͖̺̲̹͔̙̥̮̞͒̑̋̒̇̈́͘͜p̶̤̱͔̆́̽̒̈l̷̛͕̰͈̭͊̏̉̂̃̐̄̋̚̚͜͝ë̸̠͈̺͓̃̈̋̋̀͗ ̴̖̗̞̰̞̲̈́͛́͐̀̄̏̃̈́̕͜͠͝t̴̖̗̹͔̺̥̙̮͉̦̳̍̃̈́̉̔̾́́̽̂̔̚͠ͅȩ̶̙͕͓͉̀̊̀̕s̵͕̟̫̥͉̼̺̪̑̅̀̑̋͌̇̍́̔̚t̶̢͚͚̄͐̓ ̸̨͚̪͓̤͍̓̋̍̈́̉͛͛͛̀̾̑̈͝f̴̭̰̥̲͖̥̐͗̔̾͛͛́̂͋̿̽ͅö̶̖͍̭̂͗̎̔͊̈́̎̓̓̚r̸̨̘̪̟̱̲̭̞̙̈̾̈́̑́̊̿̽̒͌̋̔͜ ̶͚̯͈̐͒z̶̩͕͙͍̬͉̳̲̈́a̶͔̪̠͚̞̟̜̫͊̿́́̈́̈́̐͊̄̄̆̚ḻ̴̢̢̡̢̛̲̣̩̦̞͖̀́̔̓̅̓͜͝ĝ̶͈̘͍͈̤̥͈̺̗̙͇͚͐ǫ̷̼̮̘̥͔͈̮̲͕̩̭̆̅͌̍̽̆͌̑ͅ ̵̢̳̏̅͌̌̐́́͆͋̇͠͝͝t̶̡̧͍͎̰͍̠̤͈͈͂̊̾̎͗̓͒̏̌̌́͜e̴̡͎̪̜͉̘͓̖͔͓̳̫͌x̵̝̻̾͛̀͝t̷̺͇̭͍̰̼͈̣͓͚́͋͒̀̋͆̔͊̊͠.̶̧̥̣̠͓͕̣̹̞͓̬̆̀̾̃̚͝

Comment: Ť̵̛̜̮̭̒̋̋͛͘h̵̲̅͆̔̓̈́̊̊̕͝i̷͇̬͚̰̣̮͇̮͇̗͙͇̤͒̐͗̀͂́̍̈́̽s̸̬̈́̌͐̀͝ ̵̭̓͌̎̀̾͠ͅï̶̬̜̣͉͓͕͚͍̊̀̀̅́͋̈́̎̌̕̚s̶̯̹̤̞̺͎͌̌̾͑̈́̚ ̸̧͙̺̤̀̄̾̉̄̒̓̓̚ȧ̴̻̯͔͕ͅ ̴̛̜́͑̾̈́͗̕͝s̷̫̝̠̼̬͚̆̅̈́̒̍͊́͛̕i̵̲̣͆̇̈́͐̏͘m̴̘͓͋̂̊͝ṗ̸̬̻̠̻͖̯͖̥͉́̄̾̔̕l̴͔͉͙̲͔̄͐̏͜͝ͅę̶̘̰̙̙̬̈́̎̃̍̏̽̽̃́ ̸̡̗̝͉͖̠͂̃͊̑͆͗͝ť̴̛̬͕̺̣͌͐̆͝e̸̗͎̗̲̝̲̝͋ṡ̶̡̧͎͈̻̦̫̱̻̮͙͆̌̔̆̉̇̆̓̚͝͝t̶̻̪̞͕̐̇̏͌̈́͊̕͠ ̸̨̹͔̩̬͖̲̟̩̝̦̬̯̈́̅̓̇͒̏̇̓̾͘f̷̧̧̲̠͎̞̭̠̳̳͕̤̃͠o̷̧̺̪̞͔̩̮̩̣̱̱̦͑̐̋̀͛ͅŕ̸̗͍̈́̆͋̎͝ ̶̧̹͉̦̮͓̜͓̦̗̞̺̯̓́͛̒z̸̘̪̖̯̞̳͇͖̠̬̽̐͗̈͐̈́̉͛̅̚ą̷̮̳͍̞͍̣̫̥̤̟̆̈́̈́̌̃͑̏̔̚͠͝ͅl̵̘͎̈ḡ̸̨̻̜͎͕͇̗͕̯͓̟̪ő̴͙̮̯͙͈̮̥̮̽͑͋̈͝͝ ̶̞͈͊͘͘t̷̯̔͒ȇ̴͖̝̩̙͓x̷͕͈̄̃̑̍̽̉̌͝ţ̶̙̮̝̜̝̫̰̮̳̈́̊ͅ.̸̨̲̲̳̝̱͐̉̋͆̀̌̈́͌́̐̄̑

Comment: Glad to see you back!

Comment: :) I wasn't away, just not able to post due to increased workload.

Comment: A lot of users began to think you had left the site permanently; it would be nice if you addressed it in the Tavern.

Comment: I just want to quickly add the usage as it wasn't immediately clear for me:

`var userObject = {
        userId: 24,
  name: 'Jack Bauer'
 };`

Comment: You can test markdown here without risk of accidentally posting.

Comment: Yup. I was lazy enough to not find this post :D

Answer (score 8):

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

‎‎‎‎‌‌‌

[image]

Comment: This answer contains all the ways to post invisible content: 1. Empty header. 2. HTML comment. 3. Zero-width Unicode characters. 4. Zero-width HTML entities. 5. Invalid/disallowed HTML tag. 6. Allowed HTML tag with disallowed attribute.  7. A br tag. 8. A 1x1 transparent image.  9. Zero-length hyperlink.  10. Allowed but empty HTML tags.

Comment: Some of these [can be used to circumvent the minimum answer length check](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359283/its-possible-to-create-empty-content-fields-p), while [others cannot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280147/links-beginning-with-a-capital-letter-are-hidden-when-post-is-submitted/280154#comment129530_280147).

Comment: 

Comment: Has anyone found [the invisible image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBR5d.png)?

Answer (score 7):

Let's test some non-broken images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [wiley.com](https://rgs-ibg.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/cms/asset/d41e6e5b-b145-41d6-8258-6405da4944a3/geo296-fig-0006-m.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [wiley.com](https://rgs-ibg.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/cms/asset/00eadf89-df6b-4186-979b-4f1002d8b76b/geo296-fig-0005-m.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Link no longer broken! ;)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard no, but my script still tried to repair it two days ago on another post, and I was wondering why. I have hundreds of unit tests and couldn't reproduce on my development machine, but the server sometimes acts differently and then I have to rely on tricks like these to test.

Answer (score 7):

Default 
*Italic* 
**Bold** 
***Italic and Bold*** 
`Code` 
<del>Strikethrough</del>

<sub>g</sub><sup>o</sup><sub>o</sub><sup>f</sup><sub>y</sub>
<sup>t</sup><sub>e</sub><sup>x</sup><sub>t</sub>

That's supposed to say "goofy text" but it rendered far worse than I expected. Let me try again, changing the properties a bit this time.

## **<sub>g</sub><sup>o</sup><sub>o</sub><sup>f</sup><sub>y</sub> <sup>t</sup><sub>e</sub><sup>x</sup><sub>t</sub>**

Still, terrible. Maybe this might work?

g<sub>o</sub>o<sub>f</sub>y <sub>t</sub>e<sub>x</sub>t

Eh, a little better, but still quite bad. I guess that's what happens when you mix up `sub` with `sup`. More testing incoming.

```
testings̸͚̩̎ţ̵͔̓̍u̵͎͒̕f̶̧̌͒f̵̢͊youknowemoreandevenmoretestetestingstuffyouknow
```

[image: blahblahblahhh] 
 [random link](https://newegg.com)

I put `<code>` markup on the word "and" in the keyboard input markup but as you can see it did not render. I also discovered that when I put the `**` right after the image link it renders as so:

**

```
testings̸͚̩̎ţ̵͔̓̍u̵͎͒̕f̶̧̌͒f̵̢͊youknowemoreandevenmoretestetestingstuffyouknow 
 random link
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fPg6.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/u53M4.jpg **

Notice how both of the `**`s did not make the bold effect, and one of them was rendered **outside** of the code even though it was **inside**.

Test snippet to see if I even know a single bit of JS:

```js
alert("i am batman");
alert("i am not batman");
document.write("i am still not batman");
console.log("i am still not batman no matter what");
```

a big joke...

> ```html
> <marquee style="color:#FF0000";> JOE MAMA     JOE MAMA     JOE MAMA JOE MAMAJOE MAMA            JOE MAMA    JOE MAMA</marquee>
> <marquee style="color:#F0004F";>JOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMA  JOE MAMAJOE MAMA    JOE MAMA          JOE MAMA JOE MAMA   JOE MAMA   JOE MAMA       JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA  JOE MAMA   JOE MAMA     JOE MAMA                      JOE MAMA</marquee>
> <marquee style="color:#0010FF";>JOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMAJOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA</marquee>
> <marquee style="color:green;"> JOE MAMA                                                                                                                                                                                       JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA</marquee>
> <marquee> JOE MAMA                                                                                                                                                                                       
>                                                            JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA JOE MAMA</marquee>
> ```

Look! You can add italics to emojis!   
But adding bold to them hardly has any effect. Here's an emoji *with* bold and another *without* bold. If you look closely at the one with bold (first one) you'll notice a <sub>tiny</sub> difference.

There's another bug in this spoiler. The warning sign in the spoiler renders in a keyboard button and I put a part of the word spoiler into the keyboard block but it didn't render in there, only the warning sign did.

> spoiler spoiler spoil
>
> er
>
> ```
> ⚠
> ```

Special Unicode:

```
⑴⑵⑶⑷⑸⑹⑺⑻⑼⑽⑾⑿⒀⒁⒂⒃⒄⒅⒆⒇
①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩
⒈⒉⒊⒋⒌⒍⒎⒏⒐⒑⒒⒓⒔⒕⒖⒗⒘⒙⒚⒛
¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰
½⅓¼⅕⅙⅐⅟⅔⅖⅚⅘
```

---

Table test:

| ***hmm*** | `what` |
| --- | --- |
| ## oof | more oof |
| *ooof* | more ooof |
| **oooof** | more oooof |
| `ooooff` | more ooooff |
| > oofed | more <kbd>oofed</kbd> |
|  | wait a min |
| <sup>[foo](/questions/tagged/foo)</sup> | [image] |
| foof | ***<del>`bruh`</del>*** |

I put `<kbd>` markup on "more oofed" but it didn't render. And "hmm" wasn't supposed to be capital.

The following renders incorrectly in preview:

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d | i | d | i | b | r | e | a | k | t | h | e | t | a | b | l | e | ? | m | a | y | b | e | i | d | i | i | u | s | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |

---

Input: `<code><code><code><code><code>e<br>e<br>e<br>e<br>e<br></code></code></code></code></code>`

Result:

`e
e
e
e
e`

---

Input: `<pre><pre><pre><pre><pre><pre><pre>e<br>e<br>e<br>e<br>e<br></pre></pre></pre></pre></pre></pre></pre>`

Result:

```
e
e
e
e
e
```

---

Input: `<code><pre><code><pre><code><pre><code><pre><code><pre>e</pre></code></pre></code></pre></code></pre></code></pre></code></pre>`

Result:

`e`

Another time-waster, might wanna remove:

```
 SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
 SPAM
  SPAM
   SPAM
    SPAM
     SPAM
      SPAM
       SPAM
        SPAM
         SPAM
          SPAM
           SPAM
            SPAM
             SPAM
              SPAM
               SPAM
                SPAM
                 SPAM
                  SPAM
                   SPAM
                    SPAM
                    SPAM
                   SPAM
                  SPAM
                 SPAM
                SPAM
               SPAM
              SPAM
             SPAM
            SPAM
           SPAM
          SPAM
         SPAM
        SPAM
       SPAM
      SPAM
     SPAM
    SPAM
   SPAM
  SPAM
 SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
 SPAM
  SPAM
   SPAM
    SPAM
     SPAM
      SPAM
       SPAM
        SPAM
         SPAM
          SPAM
           SPAM
            SPAM
             SPAM
              SPAM
               SPAM
                SPAM
                 SPAM
                  SPAM
                   SPAM
                    SPAM
                    SPAM
                   SPAM
                  SPAM
                 SPAM
                SPAM
               SPAM
              SPAM
             SPAM
            SPAM
           SPAM
          SPAM
         SPAM
        SPAM
       SPAM
      SPAM
     SPAM
    SPAM
   SPAM
  SPAM
 SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPA M
SPA  M
SPA   M
SPA    M
SP A    M
SP  A    M
SP   A    M
SP    A    M
S P    A    M
S  P    A    M
S   P    A    M
S    P    A    M
 S    P    A    M
  S    P    A    M
   S    P    A    M
    S    P    A    M
     S    P    A   M
      S    P    A  M
       S    P    A M
        S    P    AM
         S    P   AM
          S    P  AM
           S    P AM
            S    PAM
             S   PAM
              S  PAM
               S PAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
               S P AM
              S  P  AM
             S   P   AM
            S    P    AM
           S     P     AM
          S      P      AM
         S       P       AM
        S        P        AM
       S         P         AM
      S          P          AM
      S         P           AM
      S        P            AM
      S       P             AM
      S        P            AM
      S         P           AM
      S          P          AM
      S           P         AM
      S            P        AM
      S             P       AM
      S            P        AM
      S           P         AM
      S          P          AM
      S         P           AM
      S        P            AM
      S       P             AM
      S        P            AM
      S         P           AM
      S          P          AM
      S           P         AM
      S            P        AM
      S             P       AM
      S            P        AM
      S           P         AM
      S          P          AM
       S         P         AM
        S        P        AM
         S       P       AM
          S      P      AM
           S     P     AM
            S    P    AM
             S   P   AM
              S  P  AM
               S P AM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
                SPAM
               SPAM
              SPAM
             SPAM
            SPAM
           SPAM
          SPAM
         SPAM
        SPAM
       SPAM
      SPAM
     SPAM
    SPAM
   SPAM
  SPAM
 SPAM
SPAM
 SPAM
  SPAM
   SPAM
    SPAM
     SPAM
    S PAM
   S  PAM
  S   PAM
 S    PAM
S     PAM
S    P AM
S   P  AM
S  P   AM
S P    AM
SP     AM
SP    A M
SP   A  M
SP  A   M
SP A    M
SPA     M
SPA    M 
SPA   M  
SPA  M   
SPA M    
SPAM     
SPAM
MSPA
AMSP
PAMS
SPAM
MSPA
AMSP
PAMS
SPAM
MSPA
AMSP
PAMS
SPAM
SPAM
 SPAM
  SPAM
   SPAM
    SPAM
     SPAM
      SPAM
       SPAM
        SPAM
         SPAM
          SPAM
         SP  AM
        SP    AM
       SP      AM
      SP        AM
     SP          AM
    SP            AM
   SP              AM
  SP                AM
 SP                  AM
SP                    AM
 SP                  AM
  SP                AM
   SP              AM
    SP            AM
     SP          AM
      SP        AM
       SP      AM
        SP    AM
         SP  AM
          SPAM
           SAM
            AM
           AMP
          AMSP
         AM  SP
        AM    SP
       AM      SP
      AM        SP
     AM          SP
    AM            SP
   AM              SP
  AM                SP
 AM                  SP
AM                    SP
 AM                  SP
  AM                SP
   AM              SP
    AM            SP
     AM          SP
      AM        SP
       AM      SP
        AM    SP
         AM  SP
          AMSP
           ASP
            SP
           SPM
          SPAM
         SP  AM
        SP    AM
       SP      AM
      SP        AM
     SP          AM
    SP            AM
   SP              AM
  SP                AM
 SP                  AM
SP                    AM
 SP                  AM
  SP                AM
   SP              AM
    SP            AM
     SP          AM
      SP        AM
       SP      AM
        SP    AM
         SP  AM
          SPAM
           SAM
            AM
           AMP
          AMSP
         AM  SP
        AM    SP
       AM      SP
      AM        SP
     AM          SP
    AM            SP
   AM              SP
  AM                SP
 AM                  SP
AM                    SP
 AM                  SP
  AM                SP
   AM              SP
    AM            SP
     AM          SP
      AM        SP
       AM      SP
        AM    SP
         AM  SP
          AMSP
           ASP
            SP
           SPM
          SPAM
          SPAM
          SPAM
          SPAM
          SPAM
          SPAM
          SPAM
          SPAM
          SPAM
          SPAM
          SPAM
          SPAM
         SPAM
        SPAM
       SPAM
      SPAM
     SPAM
    SPAM
   SPAM
  SPAM
 SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
 SPAM
  SPAM
   SPAM
    SPAM
     SPAM
      SPAM
       SPAM
        SPAM
         SPAM
          SPAM
           SPAM
            SPAM
             SPAM
              SPAM
               SPAM
                SPAM
                 SPAM
                  SPAM
                   SPAM
                    SPAM
                    SPAM
                   SPAM
                  SPAM
                 SPAM
                SPAM
               SPAM
              SPAM
             SPAM
            SPAM
           SPAM
          SPAM
         SPAM
        SPAM
       SPAM
      SPAM
     SPAM
    SPAM
   SPAM
  SPAM
 SPAM
SPAM
SPAMSPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
SPAM
S
```

Hmm...

> the above is not an image

...ok you get it

Comment: @mindstormsboi testing

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭What a peculiar comment...‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭What an odd comment...‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬‭⁪⁯

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯Huh, very strange...‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫‮ ⁪‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯testin ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭‮ ⁪⁫⁬

Comment: Telephone Trumpet Testing    ⁫⁯⁫⁪‪‭‮‮ ‎   Alphabet Yummy    ⁫⁯⁫⁪‪‭‮‮ ‎

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫‮ ⁪‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪tset ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭‮ ⁪⁫⁬

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭What a peculiar comment...‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫‮ ⁪‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯test ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭‮ ⁪⁫⁬.

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫‮ ⁪‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯test ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‭‬⁮‭‭⁪⁯‬ ‭⁭⁫⁪⁬⁯‮‬⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮‬⁯⁪⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁯ ‬⁪⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯‬‭‮ ⁪⁫⁬⁭‮ ⁪⁫⁬

Answer (score 6):

File names on code:

````
#### `code.js`
```js
alert("Helloworld")
```
````

> ##### `code.js`
>
> ```js
> alert("Helloworld")
> ```

Comment: I learned from an [answer on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384932/238886), that writing `[edit]` in a comment creates a special link.  Let's find out what it does: [edit]

Answer (score 5):

#### Revolving Door Algorithm

for ["Gray code" for building teams](https://mathoverflow.net/q/363372/70594)

```js
function generate() {
  let n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
  let k = parseInt(document.getElementById("k").value);

  var c = [null]; // JavaScript arrays are 0-indexed
  var j, output = [];
  var skipToR4 = false, skipToR5 = false; // to simulate gotos
  // R1
  for (var i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
    c.push(i - 1);
  }
  c.push(n);
  while (true) {
    if (!skipToR4) {
      // R2
      output.push("{" + c.slice(1, k + 1).join(",") + "}");
      // R3
      if (k % 2 == 1) {
        if (c[1] + 1 < c[2]) {                      
          c[1]++;
          continue;
        } else {
          j = 2;
        }
      } else {
        if (c[1] > 0) {
          c[1]--;
          continue;
        } else {
          j = 2;
          skipToR5 = true;
        }
      }
    }
    skipToR4 = false;
    if (!skipToR5) {
      // R4
      if (c[j] >= j) { // try to decrease c[j]
        c[j] = c[j - 1];
        c[j - 1] = j - 2;
        continue;
      } else {
        j++;
      }
    }
    skipToR5 = false;
    // R5
    if (c[j] + 1 < c[j + 1]) { // try to increase c[j]
      c[j - 1] = c[j];
      c[j]++;
      continue;
    } else {
      j++;
      if (j <= k) {
        skipToR4 = true;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = output.join("\n");
}
```

```html
<label for="n">n:</label><input id="n" type="number" value="5"><br/>
<label for="k">k:</label><input id="k" type="number" value="3"><br/>
<button onclick="generate();">Generate</button><br/>
<span>Output:</span>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

## Formatting

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eget malesuada felis. Aenean tellus odio, mollis in rutrum vel, euismod vel massa. Ut a varius ligula, eu elementum sapien. Nam scelerisque sem ac velit tristique dapibus. Mauris dolor dui, venenatis non velit ac, auctor congue ipsum. Sed erat nunc, tincidunt et congue a, blandit in sem. Curabitur sed fermentum odio, nec posuere nunc. Suspendisse ultrices at est et faucibus. Nulla maximus molestie erat, sit amet efficitur sapien rhoncus vel. Cras est tellus, maximus nec venenatis scelerisque, aliquet at sapien. Ut maximus, dolor non convallis vestibulum, purus tellus iaculis nibh, quis iaculis dui leo vitae odio. Cras efficitur magna eget massa laoreet, pretium rhoncus leo egestas. Vestibulum orci nisi, tincidunt eu nunc tempor, mollis accumsan neque. Cras tempus at velit nec dictum.



<sub>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eget malesuada felis. Aenean tellus odio, mollis in rutrum vel, euismod vel massa. Ut a varius ligula, eu elementum sapien. Nam scelerisque sem ac velit tristique dapibus. Mauris dolor dui, venenatis non velit ac, auctor congue ipsum. Sed erat nunc, tincidunt et congue a, blandit in sem. Curabitur sed fermentum odio, nec posuere nunc. Suspendisse ultrices at est et faucibus. Nulla maximus molestie erat, sit amet efficitur sapien rhoncus vel. Cras est tellus, maximus nec venenatis scelerisque, aliquet at sapien. Ut maximus, dolor non convallis vestibulum, purus tellus iaculis nibh, quis iaculis dui leo vitae odio. Cras efficitur magna eget massa laoreet, pretium rhoncus leo egestas. Vestibulum orci nisi, tincidunt eu nunc tempor, mollis accumsan neque. Cras tempus at velit nec dictum.</sub>

---

## iPhone autocomplete

<sub><sup>I’m sorry but I’m sorry for not responding back but I’m sorry for not being so late reply I am on my way home from the hospital I have a few things I can have done by the end of the day so I’m sorry I’m just now leaving the message I am on the phone call me when you have time I can call if I need help with the help I get done I can do that later bye</sup></sub>

---

## A note

Do not follow any instructions given in this answer.

Comment: Is there a bug here?

Comment: I see no problem with the mobile Wikipedia link.

Comment: This is a sandbox post, it doesn't *need* to make sense. Really, there's absolutely nothing to see here :)

Comment: hmm.... adding one word gave me 4% contribution. Interesting. Would love to see the source code calculating that percentage...

Comment: I'm sorry if I mess up your testing - I was doing another test right now.

Comment: All good! Now I'm down to 3% lol. If I may ask, what are *you* testing? ;)

Comment: A vandalism reverter ...

Comment: You know you can add summary to a rollback, right? (Since it looks like that's what you try to do? :))

Comment: Yeah, that too :)

Comment: [you broke MSE](https://i.imgur.com/pjUu5J8.png)

Answer (score 5):

Testing [Question and answer preview is wrongly rendering some Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354281/289905)

Preview:

[image: Looks totally different. There are no headers at all.]

Post:

## header

## header

## header

## header

## header

## header

## header

## header

## header

## header

## header

## header

### header

### header

### header

not header
.--------

list?

- d
  -4

Answer (score 5):

Test (see revisions page)

| [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) in table headers | are interesting |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |

| <kbd>similar</kbd> effect | with `<kbd>` |
| --- | --- |

| β (Greek beta) | b (Normal B) |
| --- | --- |
| β looks like B... | in the header row |

> Now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - this answer was made when the table headers were all uppercase.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>A PYRAMID BUTTON</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > A PYRAMID BLOCKQUOTE

Comment: Okay, okay!  I give in!  Now I'll undelete my post...

Comment: @Ollie where's your post?

Comment: Yes, I did.  Next up:  Bypassing the character limit.

Comment: @Ollie Heh, I hope I'll win.

Comment: I deleted it because I couldn't see anything.

Comment: @Ollie BTW I was just seeing a bunch of scrambled text around my second answer. IDK what/who caused it.

Comment: @Ollie h̶̪̱̯̱̳̜̃́̎̃̆͊́̐̀͘̕̚̚͝͠ẻ̴̛͍̟̰̲̤̤̼͉̓̀̋̃̏̈̊̂͑h̸̟̤̫̥̬̊̈́̋̏͂̾́ ̴̛̘̭͎̀̈͂̊͒͘͘l̶̰̺̆̇̅ͅȏ̶̮̬̠̠͚̪͑́̔̊̄͝l̶̨̖̞̾̐̐ but BTW how do you make the scrambled text stretch that long?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1571/discussion-between-tech-expert-wizard-and-ollie).

Comment: Yes, [let's](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox).  I still want to test stuff.

Comment: @Ollie heh, good idea.

Comment: @Roc Really? Amazing!

Comment: Oh no, the button isn't working :(

Answer (score 5):

Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

On ELL, many of our questions ask about statements much like the "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully" notice that appears when a post seems suspicious, so when I first encountered it, I initially read it as part of the post and not as a warning.

Answer (score 4):

```
[tag:not]  
[tag:or]   
[tag:and]
```

[not](/questions/tagged/not)
 or 
 and

---

In the editor:

> [image]

---

In the post body:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

```css
.post-tag,.geo-tag,.container .chosen-choices .search-choice,.container .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice{color: #39739d;background-color: #E1ECF4;border-color: #E1ECF4}.post-tag:hover{color: #33658a;background-color: #cee0ed;border-color: #cee0ed}.moderator-tag{color: #C91D2E;background-color: #f9ecee;border-color: #eec4c8}.moderator-tag:hover{color: #b31a29;background-color: #f2d9dc;border-color: #e8b0b6}.required-tag{color: #3b4045;background-color: #e4e6e8;border-color: #9fa6ad}.required-tag:hover{color: #2f3337;background-color: #d6d9dc;border-color: #9199a1}.disliked-tag{color: #6a737c;background-color: #e4e6e8;border-color: transparent}.disliked-tag:hover{color: #5e666e;background-color: #d6d9dc;border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)}.post-tag,.moderator-tag,.required-tag,.disliked-tag,.favorite-tag,.company-tag,.geo-tag,.geo-tag,.container .chosen-choices .search-choice,.container .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice{font-family:Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;position: relative;display: inline-block;padding: .4em .5em;margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;font-size: 11px;line-height: 1;white-space: nowrap;text-decoration: none;text-align: center;border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-radius: 3px;transition: all .15s ease-in-out}
```

```html
<a class="post-tag moderator-tag">moderator tag</a><a class="post-tag required-tag">required tag</a><a class="post-tag">tag</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Comment: XSS will not work.

Comment: Of course it won't but how can you be sure unless you test it 

Comment: 

Answer (score 4):

<sub><kbd>l</kbd></sub><kbd>o</kbd><sup><kbd>v</kbd></sup><kbd>e</kbd><sub><kbd>l</kbd></sub><kbd>y</kbd><kbd><kbd>^͡^͡</kbd></kbd>

.͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌ 
͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌ 
͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌ 
͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌ 
͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌ 
͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌ 
͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌ 
͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌ 
.̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ 
̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ 
̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ 
̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ 
̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ 
̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ 
̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ 
̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ 
o̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅o̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅p̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅s̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅i̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅e̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅s̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅!̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅̅   ͪ͠ ̴ͣ ͯ

```js
// print combining diacritics
for(var i=768; i<879; i++){console.log(new DOMParser().parseFromString("&#"+i+";", "text/html").documentElement.textContent +"  "+"&#"+i+";");}
```

---

Comment: `H̿̿̿̿̿͟o̿̿̿̿̿͟o̿̿̿̿̿͟r̿̿̿̿̿͟a̿̿̿̿̿͟y̿̿̿̿̿͢!̿̿̿̿̿͟͢aaaͮeͨ`

Comment: i found adding the "underscores" best worked between the letter and it's diacritics

Comment: .̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́ ̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́̈́

Answer (score 4):

Testing `<sup>`: 2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Testing `<sub>`: 2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Both mixed:

2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sup>2</sup><sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sub>2</sub<<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>222</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sub></sup></sup></sup></sup></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sup>2</sup><sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>22<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>22</sub<<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2222</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 4):

```
2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2


</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>
```

Remove code block formatting at your own risk or see [first revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/359375/1).

Comment: I wish you could see this in its glory days  It was a beautiful pillar of 2s.

Answer (score 4):

##### py language code

```py
>>> eval("public_variable+2", {"__builtins__" : None }, safe_dict)
12

>>> eval("private_variable+2", {"__builtins__" : None }, safe_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'private_variable' is not defined

>>> exec("print \"'%s' has %i characters\" % (public_function(), len(public_function()))", {"__builtins__" : None}, safe_dict)
'public information' has 18 characters

>>> exec("print \"'%s' has %i characters\" % (private_function(), len(private_function()))", {"__builtins__" : None}, safe_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'private_function' is not defined
```

##### python-repl language code

```
>>> eval("public_variable+2", {"__builtins__" : None }, safe_dict)
12

>>> eval("private_variable+2", {"__builtins__" : None }, safe_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'private_variable' is not defined

>>> exec("print \"'%s' has %i characters\" % (public_function(), len(public_function()))", {"__builtins__" : None}, safe_dict)
'public information' has 18 characters

>>> exec("print \"'%s' has %i characters\" % (private_function(), len(private_function()))", {"__builtins__" : None}, safe_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'private_function' is not defined
```

##### pycon language code

```
>>> eval("public_variable+2", {"__builtins__" : None }, safe_dict)
12

>>> eval("private_variable+2", {"__builtins__" : None }, safe_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'private_variable' is not defined

>>> exec("print \"'%s' has %i characters\" % (public_function(), len(public_function()))", {"__builtins__" : None}, safe_dict)
'public information' has 18 characters

>>> exec("print \"'%s' has %i characters\" % (private_function(), len(private_function()))", {"__builtins__" : None}, safe_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'private_function' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4):

Test to determine if language specifier is case-sensative for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381438/is-the-language-name-case-sensitive-for-syntax-highlighting)

#### All lowercase:

````
```lang-python
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        print(i)
```
````

```python
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        print(i)
```

#### All caps:

````
```LANG-PYTHON
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        print(i)
```
````

```
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        print(i)
```

#### Language name all caps:

````
```lang-PYTHON
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        print(i)
```
````

```PYTHON
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        print(i)
```

#### All mixed caps:

````
```LaNg-PyThOn
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        print(i)
```
````

```
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        print(i)
```

#### Language name mixed caps:

````
```lang-PyThOn
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        print(i)
```
````

```PyThOn
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 4):

[what-would-happen-if-i-formatted-an-entire-question-like-this-on-stackoverflow-or-any-other-site-especially-given-that-tags-do-not-support-linebreaks-and-a-reader-will-have-to-side-scroll-just-to-read-the-question-yeah-probably-not-the-best-idea-but-hey-i-could-use-stuff-like-this-for-emphasis](/questions/tagged/what-would-happen-if-i-formatted-an-entire-question-like-this-on-stackoverflow-or-any-other-site-especially-given-that-tags-do-not-support-linebreaks-and-a-reader-will-have-to-side-scroll-just-to-read-the-question-yeah-probably-not-the-best-idea-but-hey-i-could-use-stuff-like-this-for-emphasis)

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, does `pipenv --support` (or similarly styled support config dump) work well in a question or answer? Let's find out (edited some content out for size).

Notice the `<details><summary>heading</summary>...</details>` used to obtain collapsed-by-default section in, e.g., GitHub issues doesn't work here:

$ pipenv --support

Pipenv version: `'2018.11.26'`

Pipenv location: `'/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv'`

Python location: `'/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/bin/python3.7'`

Python installations found:

- `3.7.2`: `/usr/local/bin/python3`
- `3.7.2`: `/usr/local/bin/python3.7m`
- `2.7.16`: `/usr/local/bin/python`
- `2.7.16`: `/usr/local/bin/pythonw`
- `2.7.10`: `/usr/bin/python`
- `2.7.10`: `/usr/bin/pythonw`
- `2.7.10`: `/usr/bin/python2.7`

PEP 508 Information:

```
{'implementation_name': 'cpython',
 'implementation_version': '3.7.2',
 'os_name': 'posix',
 'platform_machine': 'x86_64',
 'platform_python_implementation': 'CPython',
 'platform_release': '18.2.0',
 'platform_system': 'Darwin',
 'platform_version': 'Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Thu Dec 20 20:46:53 PST '
                     '2018; root:xnu-4903.241.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64',
 'python_full_version': '3.7.2',
 'python_version': '3.7',
 'sys_platform': 'darwin'}
```

System environment variables:

- `PATH`
- `TERM_PROGRAM`
- `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV`
- `SHELL`
- `TERM`
- `PIP_PYTHON_PATH`
- etc.

Pipenv–specific environment variables:

- `PIPENV_ACTIVE`: `1`

---

Contents of `Pipfile` ('/Users/[redacted]/Pipfile'):

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
boto3 = "*"
requests = "*"
six = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Contents of `Pipfile.lock` ('/Users/[redacted]/Pipfile.lock'):

```
{
    "[redacted]": ["snip"]
}
```

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

… and then presumably one could continue after the diagnostics.

Comment: [help], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [help/behavior] and [meta-help] – link to frequently visited pages of the help center. Link text is "help center" (capitalization is respected). All links point to the main site.

Comment: Well, it looks like you are saying “Get rid of the `\`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\`` part.

Answer (score 3):

## The Non-comprehensive Formatting Test

> > Hello world

> > > Hello world

> Hello world

> > > Hello world

> > > Hello world

> > Hello world

> > > Hello world

---

## ABC

### DEF

#### GHI

### JKL

## MNO

### PQR

#### STU

### VWX

## YZ

---

<kbd>La</kbd>

<kbd>La  <kbd>La</kbd>  La</kbd>

<kbd>La  <kbd>La  <kbd>La</kbd>  La</kbd>  La</kbd>

<kbd>La  <kbd>La</kbd>  La</kbd>

<kbd>La</kbd>

---

A *B* **C** ***D*** **E** *F* G

A*B***C*****D*****E***F*G

---

{waffles}

ODJIFU(#)RIF*U#ORINEJF(*HUER#U(WI)~I(!#WEU*R*KJIOK(I)@#O_+ER)FI

Answer (score 3):

http://[::1] works in the preview (and I assume also after submitting the post)

with markdown: [http://[::1]](http://[::1]/)

Comment: but it does not auto-detect the link in a comment: http://[::1]/ also not when I try to format it with markdown: [http://[::1]/](http://[::1]/)

Answer (score 3):

Testing leading spaces:  `false`  `false`

```
` false` <code> false</code>
```

> [image]

Without custom CSS:

> [image]

Comment: ``foo(     , bar)``

Answer (score 3):

@muru’s [space formatting test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329041/285232) displays

[image]

on my system.

Comment: Hmm, it works on Firefox, Chrome, Safari on macOS, but doesn't on Firefox or Chrome on Android or Safari or Chrome on iOS (where inline code spans are broken in other ways anyway). Guess there's no good way here.

Answer (score 3):

The `<ol start>` attribute vs. Markdown lists:

---

1. Item #1
2. Item #2
3. Item #3

2. Item #2
3. Item #3

9. Item #9
10. Item #14

8. Item #8

Answer (score 3):

https:// https://aaa
http:// http://aaa

aaaaa:// aaaaa://aaa aaaaa://google.com

google.com https://google.com http://google.com

`google.com https://google.com http://google.com`

```
google.com https://google.com http://google.com
```

(That’s a oneboxing test)

[image: profile for Stormblessed at Politics Stack Exchange, Q&A for people interested in governments, policies, and political processes]

[image: profile for Stormblessed at Politics Stack Exchange, Q&A for people interested in governments, policies, and political processes]

Community! I am writing a bunch of words so this doesn't become a comment because that would suck. Here, look at my link over there and read these words

with some line breaks

and formatting

and thean

please fix my link:

## [I am become HTTPS, securer of worlds!](http://metaa.stackexchange.com/q/3122/399694)

Comment: Ugh this got converted to a comment *three times* and I didn't notice.

Comment: test this is not edited

Comment: foo&amp;bar 
but `<tt>hahaha</tt>` works?
got <b>bold</b>? &nbsp; blah.

Answer (score 3):

(Recreation of the example post from [this upcoming blockquote change announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes).)

---

Quotes are cool:

> But are they?
>   How do they work?
>
> > Do they work and look good?
> >
> > ```
> > What about wtht code
> > And other stuff?
> > Seems OK.
> > ```

That's not bad.

> > > > > > > Quotes all the way down?
> > > > > > >               Turtles
> > > > > > >               Should we set a max quote depth?

Actual code above:

```
>>>>>>> Quotes all the way down?    
>>>>> Turtles    
>>> Should we set a max quote depth?
```

Now the same thing but with empty lines between each line:

> > > > > > > Quotes all the way down?
> > > > >
> > > > > Turtles
> > >
> > > Should we set a max quote depth?

Markdown above:

```
>>>>>>> Quotes all the way down?   

>>>>> Turtles    

>>> Should we set a max quote depth?
```

## Quoting headers?

### Headers?

#### Quoting?

> ## Quoting headers.
>
> ### Headers.
>
> #### Quoting.

What about images:

> [image]

In the proposed example, this style: `outline: 10px solid #ddd;` was added to the existing css rule: `.post-text blockquote img, ...`. It's crude, but it  provides that much needed border around the image differentiating it from the white background, while also making it obvious that it's part of the quote.

An empty quote block? Nope, that's a spoiler!

> 

There's actually a non-breaking space character in it.

Here's a spoiler block with some text inside:

> Gandalf is Magneto!

Both quote blocks above contain only a single line, but notice the height difference because the first one doesn't contain any visible characters.

What about quotes with spoilers?

> Quotes?
>
> ! With spoilers?
>
> > Curiosity [killed the cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEtGn.png)!

Indeed it does not work if they're on the same level, but works if they spoiler has an extra `>` relative to the current quote count of `>`'s.

Quote block with a spoiler block with an image inside:

> > [image]

Answer (score 3):

- List

```html
Unindented snippet
```

- List

  ```html
  Indented snippet
  ```

  Continuing list's indent level...
  Things written here fail to render correctly in the preview (show up as code block), but works when posted... 
  Try it by clicking [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/348875/edit)

  I suspect that it's because of the <sub>[edit above snippet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/)</sub> button

Answer (score 3):

Markdown spoiler:

> testing spoilers

```
code spoiler! scroll this way to see:                                                                                                                        SPOILER!!!
```

→ HTML special characters! ←

```
&rarr; HTML special characters! &larr;
```

Answer (score 3):

**How CommonMark renders the markdown preview (observed when [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/349029/edit)ing a post) for various Internet top-level domains (TLD)**

Bug: meta.so meta.se (reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349028/241919)

---

[Original top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Original_top-level_domains): example.com example.net example.org example.gov example.edu

[Infrastructure top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Infrastructure_top-level_domain): example.arpa

[Country code top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Country_code_top-level_domains): example.de example.fr example.us example.so (Somalia) example.se (Sweden)

[ICANN-era generic top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#ICANN-era_generic_top-level_domains): example.academy example.aero example.app example.auto example.blog example.coop

[Geographic top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Geographic_top-level_domains): example.africa example.asia example.paris

[Brand top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Brand_top-level_domains): example.abc example.bing

[Special-Use Domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Special-Use_Domains): example.example example.onion example.test example.local

Comment: this is a comment OVERFL..! ```NAME        FSTYPE  MOUNTPOINT              RO sda                                          0 └─sda1      ntfs    /media/D:Drive           0 sdb                                          0 ├─sdb1      vfat                             0 └─sdb2      ext4    /                        0 sr0         iso9660 /media/peter/BT Adapter  0 nvme0n1
                                      0 ├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs                             0 ├─nvme0n1p2 vfat    /boot/efi                0 ├─nvme0n1p3                                  0 └─nvme0n1p4 ntfs                             0 ```

Comment: This is a normal long comment. The content of the comment is correctly bound. This is a normal long comment. The content of the comment is correctly bound. This is a normal long comment. The content of the comment is correctly bound. This is a normal long comment. The content of the comment is correctly bound. This is a normal long comment. The content of the comment is correctly bound. This is a normal long comment. The content of the comment is correctly bound.

Comment: this is a comment `OVERFL..! NAME        FSTYPE  MOUNTPOINT              RO sda                                          0 └─sda1      ntfs    /media/D:Drive           0 sdb                                          0 ├─sdb1      vfat                             0 └─sdb2      ext4    /                        0 sr0         iso9660 /media/peter/BT Adapter  0 nvme0n1                                       0 ├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs                             0 ├─nvme0n1p2 vfat    /boot/efi                0 ├─nvme0n1p3                                  0 └─nvme0n1p4 ntfs                             0`

Answer (score 3):

This is a test of commonmark blockquote

> One level
>
> > Two Levels
> >
> > > Three Levels
> > >
> > > > Four levels
> > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > WE MUST GO DEEPER! (Seeing if quote levels are cumulative)

Answer (score 3):

Testing code snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Say hello world until the user starts questioning
// the meaningfulness of their existence.
function helloWorld(world) {
  for (var i = 42; --i >= 0;) {
    alert('Hello ' + String(world));
  }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
p { color: pink }
b { color: blue }
u { color: "umber" }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Link just after a special character

**REFERENCE**:https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581

**REFERENCE**;https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581

**REFERENCE**[https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581

**REFERENCE**%https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581

**REFERENCE**-https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581

**REFERENCE**#https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581

**REFERENCE**&https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581

**REFERENCE**>https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581

(Now see the above links in edit preview.)

---

## Link separated from the special character by a space

**REFERENCE**: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581

---

**Also, this bug seems to be specific with a special character.:**
**REFERENCE**https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581

Comment: $\LaTeX$/MathJax see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581)

Comment: $\LaTeX$/MathJax see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581) $$

Comment: $$ [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581) $$

Comment: $$[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581) $$

Comment: $$ [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581)$$

Comment: $$[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581)$$

Comment: What is happening here?

Comment: $\LaTeX$/MathJax see [this](meta.stackexchange.com/a/349611/771581) $$

Comment: Wow! A new thing.

Answer (score 3):

| HEader1 | Header2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell1 | >alert(1) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 3):

Test Magic links:

[meta] – link to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name (e.g. "Meta Super User"). Does nothing if the site doesn't have (or already is) a Meta site.

[main] – like [meta], just the other way around.

[edit] – link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is respected).

Help center links. Link text for all of these is "help center":
[help] should be obvious.
[meta-help] links to "What is meta?" (/help/whats-meta)
[help/on-topic] links to "What topics can I ask about here?" (/help/on-topic)
[help/dont-ask] links to "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" (/help/dont-ask)
[help/behavior] links to "What kind of behavior is expected of users?" (/help/behavior).

[tour] and [meta-tour] – equivalent to the FAQ version, but links to the site's Tour page (resp. the meta site's Tour page). Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected). Legacy names [about] and [meta-about] are still supported.

[ask] – link to the "How to Ask" page

[answer] – link to the "How to Answer" page.

Links to the front page of Stack Exchange sites (link text is the site name):
[so] – link to Stack Overflow
[su] – link to Super User
[sf] – link to Server Fault
[metase]/[meta.se] – link to Meta Stack Exchange
[ubuntu.se] – link to Ask Ubuntu
[mathoverflow.se] – link to MathOverflow
[a51] – link to Area 51
[se] – link to the Stack Exchange
Localized Stack Overflow sites can be linked as
[es.so] – link to Stack Overflow en español
[ja.so] – link to スタック・オーバーフロー
[pt.so] – link to Stack Overflow em Português
[ru.so] – link to Stack Overflow на русском
All other Stack Exchange sites, except Stack Apps:
[something.se] – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name.
[sitename.meta.se] or [meta.sitename.se] – link to a site-specific Meta site. Link text is "Meta ".

[chat] – link to the current site's chat site ne showing a list of active rooms from the referring site), the link text being "{site name} Chat".

On Stack Overflow and localized Stack Overflow sites:
[mcve], [reprex], [repro], [mre] and [example] – link to the Minimal Complete & Verifiable Example page for the site.

Tags (these work in questions, answers, comments, and chat, but are not formatted as tags in comments):
[Note that if you're on meta, [tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name) will still point to the main site. Except on Meta Stack Exchange, which doesn't have a main, [tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name) makes no difference from [tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name).]
[tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name) creates a link to the named tag on the main site.
[tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name) creates a link to a tag on meta. The text is linked

Supported magic links in chat

In chat, only a limited subset of the magic links listed for comments work, plus one chat-specific magic link.

Chat supports the following magic links: [meta], [main], [ask], [answer], all the links to specific sites, and tag links (with tag formatting). Chat also adds [chat-faq], which results in "chat faq".

The tag magic links work as expected on Stack Overflow Chat and Meta Stack Exchange Chat. However, on Stack Exchange Chat, the chat room in which you use the magic link must be associated with a specific Stack Exchange site, and will take on the formatting of tags on that site.

Comment: `[meta]`: [meta]; `[main]`: [main]; `[edit]`: [edit]; `[help]`: [help]; `[meta-help]`: [meta-help]; `[help-meta]`: [help-meta]; `[help/on-topic]`: [help/on-topic]; `[help/dont-ask]`: [help/dont-ask]; `[help/behavior]`: [help/behavior]; `[tour]`: [tour]; `[meta-tour]`: [meta-tour]; `[about]`: [about]; `[meta-about]`: [meta-about]; `[about-meta]`: [about-meta]; `[ask]`: [ask]; `[answer]`: [answer];

Comment: `[so]`: [so]; `[su]`: [su]; `[sf]`: [sf]; `[metase]`: [metase]; `[meta.se]`: [meta.se]; `[a51]`: [a51]; `[se]`: [se]; `[es.so]`: [es.so]; `[pt.so]`: [pt.so]; `[ja.so]`: [ja.so]; `[ru.so]`: [ru.so]; `[ubuntu.se]`: [ubuntu.se]; `[mathoverflow.se]`: [mathoverflow.se]; `[something.se]`: [something.se]; `[academia.se]`: [academia.se]; `[sitename.meta.se]`: [sitename.meta.se]; `[meta.sitename.se]`: [meta.sitename.se]; `[academia.meta.se]`: [academia.meta.se]; `[meta.academia.se]`: [meta.academia.se];

Comment: `[tag:tag-name]`: [tag:tag-name]; `[meta-tag:tag-name]`: [meta-tag:tag-name];

Answer (score 3):

Well, there’s [table support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/289905) now, so…

### Markdown

Minimal Markdown of a table, working *both* in the preview and the post:

```markdown
||
|-|
```

|  |
| --- |

Minimal Markdown of a table, working in the preview, *but not* in the post:

```markdown
|
-
```

### |

Minimal Markdown of a table, working in the post, *but not* in the preview:

```markdown
||
||
```

|  |
| --- |

These Markdown snippets don’t render at all in a post, but still produce tables in the preview:

```markdown
|
-|
```

|  |
|

```markdown
|
|-|
```

|  |
|

This Markdown doesn’t render at all in a post, *and doesn’t* produce a table in the preview:

```markdown
|
||
```

|  |
|

### Backslashes, HTML, other random stuff

| test|<kbd>ßßß[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)<sup><kbd><sup><kbd><sup><sup><kbd>`\`</kbd></sup></sup></kbd></sup></kbd></sup></kbd>ẞ| |
| --- |
| \ |
| [image] |

### Line Separator and Paragraph Separator

These don’t seem to separate table rows.

|dgfg|adasd| |---|:--| |234234|23|

|dgfg|adasd| |---|:--| |234234|23|

### Stack Snippets

When editing, the “edit the above snippet” link appears inside the table header.

| sdf ```js console.log(); ``` ```html Test ``` sdf | sdfsdf |
| --- | --- |
| sdfsdf | sdf ```js console.log(); ``` ```html Test ``` sdf |

Comment: There are significant rendering differences between the preview and the final post: see the [screenshot of the editing preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UpDB.png). Several minimal Markdown samples behave completely differently, and backslashes are handled completely differently.

Comment: Since [table headers are no longer uppercased](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357019/289905), I’ve [updated the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfN6Q.png).

Answer (score 3):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>How I broke this site</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Testing fairly manual matjax conversion and very makeshift psudocode instructions

| S₀ | S₁ | S₂ | S₃ | S₄ | S₅ | S₆ | S₇ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 15 | 8 | 0 | 1 | 15 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 | 12 | 6 | 15 | 15 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 15 | 2 | 7 | 11 | 8 | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 1 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 3 | 11 | 5 |
| 4 | 10 | 9 | 3 | 12 | 12 | 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 6 | 0 | 12 | 9 | 0 | 10 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 11 | 9 | 6 |
| 7 | 11 | 10 | 15 | 3 | 6 | 12 | 11 |
| 8 | 14 | 1 | 13 | 13 | 2 | 0 | 14 |
| 9 | 13 | 11 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 9 |
| 10 | 4 | 14 | 14 | 2 | 4 | 14 | 1 |
| 11 | 2 | 8 | 4 | 4 | 10 | 8 | 15 |
| 12 | 7 | 6 | 0 | 10 | 9 | 13 | 13 |
| 13 | 0 | 13 | 11 | 7 | 14 | 6 | 3 |
| 14 | 9 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 7 | 7 | 10 |
| 15 | 12 | 4 | 2 | 14 | 13 | 1 | 0 |

REMOVE
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline

REMOVE

\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation}

replace \n with \n| SPACE
replace & with SPACE SPACE | SPACE
replace \ with SPACE SPACE |

CLEAN UP TITLE BAR

Remove

\operatorname{

remove |text{Input}

remove }

Unicode subscripts ₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₀

add header

Answer (score 3):

Looks like, at some point in the last 3 months, all 4 Markdown language hints were made equivalent.
Previously, the first (`lang-markdown`) highlighted differently than the other 3, but all 4 look just like the first now.

---

Markdown highlighting test:

`lang-markdown`

```markdown
# Sample Output

heading
--

another heading
==

> quote text

`code text`

_italic_ *italic*

__bold__ **bold**

***bold AND italic***
```

`lang-md`/ `lang-mkdown`/ `lang-mkd`

```md
# Sample Output

heading
--

another heading
==

> quote text

`code text`

_italic_ *italic*

__bold__ **bold**

***bold AND italic***
```

Comment: OMG, didn't know about this!

Answer (score 3):

Didn't think my previous answer could fit some more stuff, soooooooooo...
<kbd>Hmm...
Hmm...</kbd>

Apparently tag ending for `<kbd>` is strange.

> <kbd>something</kbd>
> Interesting...

Heh.

> `my code`

> spoiler

| helllo |
| --- |
| This is my table. |
| Heh. |
| > something |
| Oh, so markdown doesn't work in tables. Heard of that before. |
| >! spoiler |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

heh.

Answer (score 3):

Testing a thing with the new editor.

Here's a footnote link to [Google](https://www.google.com)

And a [bracket test].

---

Testing unicode magic:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- end snippet​ -->
```

---

Testing escapes:

```
*(\*)[12]*
```

*(*)[12]*

---

Code in spoilers:

```markdown
>! <pre><code>
>! if True: 
>!     print "Hello World!"
>! </code></pre>
```

> ```
>  if True:
>      print "Hello World!"
> ```

vs.

````markdown
>! ```
>! if True: 
>!     print "Hello World!"
>! ```
````

> `! if True:  !     print "Hello World!" !`

Answer (score 3):

This is a test of a malformed link. Something similar was posted and detected by SmokeDetector, but deleted before I was able to see it on the SE site where it was posted.<a href="[This is just to verify what SE does wrt. stripping the](https://example.com/foo-bar/) ">malformed tag. I believe I know what SE will do, but I want to double-check.

###### Additional test (currently Chrome only, if working):

IIRC, the last time I tested this the backend Markdown->HTML render broke this. It does appear to be working in the edit preview.

[This is a link to a question which should highlight some text in Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/#:%7E:text=re%2Dopen%20vote.-,July%202021,-2021%2D07%2D30).

Comment: [This is a link to a question which should highlight some text in Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/#:~:text=re%2Dopen%20vote.-,July%202021,-2021%2D07%2D30).

Answer (score 3):

###### This heading was added to test if the IDs assigned to headings change

It looks like H4, H5, and H6 elements were added to the CSS. This is to test to see if they are live on the site for user contributions.

Using Markdown:

## An H1 (Markdown)

### An H2 (Markdown)

#### An H3 (Markdown)

##### An H4 (Markdown)

###### An H5 (Markdown)

###### An H6 (Markdown)

Using HTML:

## An H1 (HTML)

### An H2 (HTML)

#### An H3 (HTML)

##### An H4 (HTML)

###### An H5 (HTML)

###### An H6 (HTML)

Using HTML with an `id` attribute (expected to be stripped):

## An H1 (HTML)

### An H2 (HTML)

#### An H3 (HTML)

##### An H4 (HTML)

###### An H5 (HTML)

###### An H6 (HTML)

#### More testing for automatic generation of `id` and static assignment.

1. ##### Fun with lists and headings:

   1. ###### Issue 1: This is an h5 in a ordered list
   2. ###### Issue 2: This is an h5 in a ordered list
   3. ###### Issue 3: This is an h5 in a ordered list
2. ##### This is the same thing in HTML:

   1. ###### Issue 1 (HTML):
   2. ###### Issue 2 (HTML):
   3. ###### Issue 3 (HTML):
3. ##### HTML with a static `id` attribute for each `<h5>`:

   In the preview rendering, the `<h5>` elements are stripped, but content is displayed.

   1. ###### Issue 1 (HTML with static ID):
   2. ###### Issue 2 (HTML with static ID):
   3. ###### Issue 3 (HTML with static ID):

Comment: So `h4`-`h6` `id` attributes [*aren't* stripped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoaAA.png)?

Comment: @zcoop98 Tests here show: IDs are stripped in preview, but not backend processing. Custom IDs are not *necessarily* modified to make then unique to the post. So far, it's not clear if it's possible to have the ID conflict with another post, or even an ID which SE uses in their HTML. If the elements weren't stripped, I would have expected the IDs to be modified to add the post ID in order to force them to be unique to the post ID. So far, it appears that the ones SE auto-adds do have a hash of some type, but that the hash is *not* invariant (i.e. auto-IDs *may* change when the post is edited)

Comment: @zcoop98 Some of the elements which you show in your screenshot I *don't* see in the page. I'm *assuming* that you have an extension or userscript which adds all the `<a class="js-named-anchor">` elements, because I don't see them in the HTML that I receive from SE.

Comment: Good point! [Here's one with everything disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihkyl.png) (I didn't even realize that I had a script messing with headings... the more you know I guess. Looks like it's the [Post Headers & Question TOC](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md#post-headers--question-toc) script).

Comment: (Now I just feel silly for never connecting "post headers" to "headings in posts" in my head lol; I always assumed that title referred to the banner the script places above posts)

Comment: ***PLEASE DO NOT EDIT THIS ANSWER.*** If you edit this answer, then it's usefulness will be destroyed, as the HTML will be regenerated differently than it currently is. SE's Markdown->HTML rendering changed after this answer was last edited to remove the feature which this answer was testing. If you want to play with the Markdown for this answer, I [created a near-duplicate answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368059/271271) after SE made the change in Markdown->HTML rendering.

Comment: If this answer does get edited, an archive is available: https://web.archive.org/web/20230117184807/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/367348#367348

Answer (score 3):

##### Test using `<!-- language: lang-none -->`  (i.e. should NOT have syntax highlighting)

Where indicated, the following sections are separately preceded by a line which contains `<!-- language: lang-none -->`, which should still prevent application of syntax highlighting. Note that using HTML comments to apply code formatting is deprecated.

###### In code fences

###### With `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

```
var parent=document.getElementById('parent');
var child=document.getElementById('child');
var preventChild=document.getElementById('preventChild');
```

###### Without `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

```javascript
var parent=document.getElementById('parent');
var child=document.getElementById('child');
var preventChild=document.getElementById('preventChild');
```

###### Using 4 space indent

###### With `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

```
var parent=document.getElementById('parent');
var child=document.getElementById('child');
var preventChild=document.getElementById('preventChild');
```

###### Without `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

```javascript
var parent=document.getElementById('parent');
var child=document.getElementById('child');
var preventChild=document.getElementById('preventChild');
```

###### In HTML `<pre><code>`

###### With `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

```
var parent=document.getElementById('parent');
var child=document.getElementById('child');
var preventChild=document.getElementById('preventChild');
```

###### Without `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

```javascript
var parent=document.getElementById('parent');
var child=document.getElementById('child');
var preventChild=document.getElementById('preventChild');
```

All of the above function as expected in the preview below the text input while editing.

Comment: T̶h̵i̵s̵ ̵i̵s̵ ̵s̵t̵r̵i̵k̵e̵o̵u̵t̵.̵

Answer (score 3):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>Eye in the pyramid</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

> <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>Psych!</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Answer (score 3):

red { color: red }
yellow { color: yellow }

red color markdown text
 yellow color markdown text

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Test—will this render? Typed in visual editor.

> "Quote," quoth the quoted.
>
> <sub>*Small text*, chapter 4: "Fancy quote formatting" (2008–2022)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Posting an answer so that I can test stuff with comments

Editing so that other reviewers don't have to waste their time on a formatting sandbox answer (editing from the review queue marks the review item as completed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<div>
$$\frac{a}{1-a^2}$$
</div>
```

The following can only be done by ♦ moderators (and employees who have a diamond):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C4%ABlaka%E1%B9%87%E1%B9%ADha_Dh%C4%81ra%E1%B9%87%C4%AB

**14: Post Locked** - A post was locked by a moderator.
**15: Post Unlocked** - A post was unlocked by a moderator.
**18: Question Merged** - A question has had another, deleted question merged into itself.

The following can only be done by ♦ moderators (and employees who have a diamond) on *questions*:

**16:** Community Owned - A post has become community owned.
**17:** Post Migrated - A post was migrated. (Meta Stack Exchange only)

The following cannot be done by ♦ moderators:

- 17: Post Migrated - A post was migrated. (if older than 60 days)
- 21: Post Disassociated - An admin removes the OwnerUserId from a post.
- 22: Question Unmerged - A previously merged question has had its answers and votes restored.

[image]

or use an img tag

[image]

> `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3JGL.png" />`

Answer (score 2):

Do they look the same?

```
 Aa - sum(q * r)
```

`Aa - sum(q * r)`

```
Aa - sum(q * r)
```

```html
Aa - sum(q * r)
```

```r
Aa - sum(q * r)
```

```
Aa - sum(q * r)
```

`Aa - sum(q * r)`

Should they look the same?

Answer (score 2):

```js
alert("This snippet is for testing/comparing CSS sizing units:\n\t\tvh, vw, vmin,vmax, compared to %,\n  ...and seeing whether they work in SO snippets...\n\t\t\tThe answer is \"kinda\", LOL\n\t\t(Resize your browser window to try.)");
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    * { box-sizing: border-box; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; border:15px solid green;">
  My 100% &times; 100% div<br>

    <div style="position:fixed; width:50%; height:50%; left:25%; top:25%; border:15px solid red; text-align:left;color:red; font-size:5vmax;">
      My 50% &times; 50% div
      <br>(font-size:5vmax)
    </div>

    <div style="position:fixed; left:25vw; top:25vh; width:50vw; height:50vh;  border:15px dashed blue;text-align:right;color:blue; font-size:5vmin;">
      My 50vw &times; 50vh div
      <br>(font-size:5vmin)
    </div>
      
    <div style="position:fixed; bottom:15px; right:15px;"> 
      <a href="https://web-design-weekly.com/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/">More on viewport units</a>
    </div>  
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

> blockquote

```
4 spaces
    8 spaces
```

test

```
    8 spaces
```

text  test

```html
<b>dsadas</b>
```

```html
While not hinted otherwise: <html></html> source <b>goes</b> "here".
```

```
While not hinted otherwise: <html></html> source <b>goes</b> "here".
```

Comment: I want to try the community shortcuts

 - [Mathematics] `[Mathematics]`
 - [Math] `[Math]`
 - [Mathematics.SE] `[Mathematics.SE]`
 - [Math.SE] `[Math.SE]`

Answer (score 2):

Placeholder 4️⃣ some tests…

---

text

---

text

Testing backslash:

@backslash not showing, right?

Code:

```
\@backslash not showing, right?
```

https://www.example.com

Let's upload a small image and see if it gets bigger:

[image: sample image, 288x268 pixels]

Original image is 288x268 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Testing image links for images that really don't need an 'open in new tab' link on hover.

`[![enter image description here][1]][1]`

[image]

vs
`![enter image description here][1]`

[image]

& for MM…

`![TITLE: REPORT TITLE][2]`
`[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbbYw.png`

[image: review image]

Answer (score 2):

just testing a url with square brackets and spaces

`[http://&lsqb;IP Address here&rsqb;/service/health](http://&lsqb;IP%20Address%20here&rsqb;/service/health)`

[http://[IP Address here]/service/health](http://[IP%20Address%20here]/service/health)

`[http://&lsqb;IP Address here&rsqb;/service/health][1]`
`[1]: http://&lsqb;IP%20Address%20here&rsqb;/service/health`

[http://[IP Address here]/service/health](http://[IP%20Address%20here]/service/health)

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

This is a test to see if I can trigger a potential bug with multi-paged questions and new answers.

> Nothing to see here, move along (~^w^)~

Answer (score 2):

I am experimenting with runnable snippets.

```css
.inner {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.inner::before {
  content: "I'm before inner!";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Inner 1</div>
  
  <div class="inner">Inner 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

let's see how many characters wide the code block is before horizontal scrollbar appears in post preview editor:

```
1234567890 10
12345678901234567890 20
123456789012345678901234567890 30
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 40
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 50
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 60
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 70
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 80
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 90
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
^ 100
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
^ 102
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
    WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
    ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

maximum on page / in editor on page:

```
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
^ 92
```

Comment: wheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: weird space here -> <- uniqode

Answer (score 2):

A new list?

1. This.
2. That.

Edits. Grace period edits?

[image: image for testing]

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Say hello world until the user starts questioning
// the meaningfulness of their existence.
function helloWorld(world) {
  for (var i = 42; --i >= 0;) {
    alert('Hello ' + String(world));
  }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
p { color: pink }
b { color: blue }
u { color: "umber" }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Testing whether [a formatting bug](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7751) was removed by CommonMark (Success?)

#### Before CommonMark:

[image]

Notably there is no white space or gap between "commodo consequat" and "Duis aute".

#### After CommonMark (if spaces and `>` are added):

> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
>   - Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. [*Yuck!* This is the problem!]
>
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

---

### Testing whether [a formatting bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335828) was removed by CommonMark (Success?)

#### Before CommonMark:

````
> ```
# test
````

Displayed as:

[image]

#### After CommonMark is displays correctly(?) as:

> 

## test

---

### Testing whether [a formatting bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327769) was removed by CommonMark (Success?)

#### Before CommonMark:

[image]

#### After CommonMark:

`[link1](https://example.com/q="one")` properly becomes [link1](https://example.com/q=%22one%22), which points to the URL `https://example.com/q="one"`.

`[link_uno](https://example.com/q="uno"&true=true "Link numero uno")` properly becomes [link_uno](https://example.com/q=%22uno%22&true=true) with a title of `Link numero uno`.

I don't understand the "last" problem

- `[Link with hint](https://example.com/page "URL: https://example.com/")`
- `<a href="https://example.com/page" title="URL: https://example.com/">Link with hint 2</a>`

Properly(?) renders as:

- [Link with hint](https://example.com/page)
- [Link with hint 2](https://example.com/page)

---

### Testing whether [a formatting bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327001) was removed by CommonMark (Success?)

#### Before CommonMark:

````
1. Testing a strange bug:
    - ```
      testing something
      ```
````

Displayed as:

[image]

#### After CommonMark:

1. Testing a strange bug:

   - ```
     testing something
     ```

---

### Testing whether [a formatting bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325017) was removed by CommonMark (???)

#### Before CommonMark:

```
[wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D3+to+v+of+(v%5E2+%2F+2)+%2F+((v-k)%5E2+*+k)
```

Displayed correctly in the editor and incorrectly in the actual post

#### After CommonMark:

The url [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D3+to+v+of+(v%5E2+%2F+2)+%2F+((v-k)%5E2+*+k) displays *incorrectly* in both the editor and the actual post.

Adding a parenthesis at the end of the link though, makes it appear correctly in both the editor and the post: [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D3+to+v+of+(v%5E2+%2F+2)+%2F+((v-k)%5E2+*+k))

---

Answer (score 2):

[Can I undelete an answer myself if it was deleted via Recommend deletion votes from review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349578/can-i-undelete-an-answer-myself-if-it-was-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-f)

---

This is testing for undeletion when a post is deleted with

> Review ends with 4/6 recommend deletion votes and none of them was cast by a trusted user.

<s>Anyone, feel free to flag this as NAA or VLQ.</s>

<s>**Non**-[trusted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) only (below 20k rep), feel free to recommend to delete this post~</s>

**Moderator**, consider replying if you get any mod flag?

Comment: I flagged as NAA

Comment: Undeleted myself, waiting for mod's response if they get any flag or not.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Even have a link for you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/369802 You get a disputed low quality review auto flag. I have three now ;)

Comment: Other links that may interest you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311536/369802. Basically, only mod-deleted answers are 'permanently' deleted. If an answer or question is mod-deleted, the community can't vote to undelete it, and neither can the OP of a post :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell thanks! Really appreciated for contributing to science :)

Comment: Well, then you're really going to enjoy my final trick! *presses delete* :P

Answer (score 2):

*emphasized text* 
*emphasized text* 
_this_is_a_Filename.doc 
*this_is_a_second_filename*.doc

Rough markdown of this post:

```
*emphasized text* <br>
_emphasized text_ <br>
_this_is_a_Filename.doc <br>
_this_is_a_second_filename_.doc <br>
```

Answer (score 2):

Test

Test

[image]

Comment: Test of what? What is the intent?

Comment: @P.Mort. I was testing if and how zero-character links in Markdown show up in the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 2):

> Ą̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅĄ̸̢̢̧̢̧̧̧̡̡̧̡̧̡̧̧̧̧̡̡̢̨̢̢̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̳͕̯͔̫̠̺̯̣̪͉̙̙͍̺̰̭͇̣͓̞̞̤̬̣̖̩͓̪̲͉̫̩̻̘͇̠̱̰͎̬͖̭̞͈̣̙̥͖͚͔̮̮̤̠̠̝̣̰̲͈̰͔̖̯͈̻̜͇̺̪̻̩͉̺̼͍͉̩̟̤̦͚̠̭͓̫͚̝̦̺̗̩̝͉̳͕̖͉̯͔͎̹̖͉̞͉͎̪͇̣̭̘͕̜̜̘̫̞̖͎͍̣̟̬̳̝̙̱͔͈̰͍͍̻̮̮̙̪̗̪͈̯̖̻̥̝̤̹̞̳̩̼̥̯̪͔͚̹̼̖̗̮̹̥̻̼̳͓͔͎͚͔̗͕̲̼̯̭͉̩̻̲̗̫͇͕͇͔̟͕̖̠̞̘̳͙͓̞̝̭̥̣̗̲̰͚̹̙̱̹̩͓̒̈́̈̋̇̓̄̓̐̈́̔͒͌̽͐̊̓̏́̋̓̀͐͐̅́͊͗̋̋̔͆͌̓̌̾̋̊̍̎̓̈́̑̀̃̒̄̆͌͛̈́͋̇̏̂̽͆͗̃̔̈̐͌̊̔͑̇̆͐̆̑̂̑̆̊̓͊̃́́̓́̈́̌́̈́͗̊̃̿̌̀͑̂̾̈́̉̐̀̀̎̂̌͂͐̀́̈́̑̀͌͗̉̈̿̑͛͆̓̉̃̈́̅̔͛̊̎̏̀̓̓̓̽͆̉̉̅̈͐̑̐̑͗͛̉͆̋͑̓͛͐̑͊͂̐͐̃͋͌̒͐͆̎͗̆̌̾͊͒̑́͌̈́͒̄̃͒͛̇̅́̌́̈̄̄̋́̿̆̊̀̈́͗̅̀̎̓̑̈́̔̀͆̾͆̊̉̌͊̓̈́̔́̍̃̅̏̽͗̀̈́͆͊͆̽͐͐́̏́͌̓̐̔̒̿̀̓̒̈́̐͛̀̍̽̋̅͆͐̃̀́̏̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅ

Well, now we know Zalgo works!

Answer (score 2):

## Mario "pure css"

```css
body{ background: rgb(107, 136, 255);
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden; }


#m1,#m2,#m3{ position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: walk 400ms infinite forwards linear; }
#m2{ animation-delay: 133ms; }
#m3{ animation-delay: 266ms; }

@keyframes walk{ 
   0%, 32%{ visibility: visible; }
  33%,100%{ visibility: hidden; }}
  
.container{ overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute; }

.sliding-background{ background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvBip.png') repeat-x;
  height: 240px;
  width: 5076px;
  animation: slide 20s linear infinite; }

@keyframes slide{ 0%{ transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
                100%{ transform: translate3d(-1692px, 0, 0); }}

#mcont{ position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 130px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0); }

#clouds{ position: absolute;
  left: 2000px;
  top: 30px;
  animation: 15s cloud infinite forwards linear; }

@keyframes cloud{ 100%{ left:-500px; }}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sliding-background"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sliding-background"></div>
</div>

<div id='mcont'>
  <img id='m1' src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADUAAABnCAMAAACXfvq+AAAADFBMVEUAAACsfAD4OAD/pECmOaYSAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAKFJREFUeNrt1oEGAkAQhOHu9v3fOfod25wWYEb1g63mixR6/Pvl9ntRal9VlV3NJFxJdrVO9YqDGHjVPe7vQBFKx5pLtaUq7ijV9hpji5phiKL5V+FVkH26x3YFWSfuCbiVQrfqs17/FtyKAUqrlldRoCJRUo6ifCVW/635lRau+IBGtVqfCEegkifTFA+VuJVsAlXyS9yximNWZFGUqL65J9LbE8OFiaC8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
  <img id='m2' src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADUAAABnCAMAAACXfvq+AAAADFBMVEUAAACsfAD4OAD/pECmOaYSAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAKlJREFUeNrt1IEGAkEURuGaef93bnTF6S4XqP9QBwz9X0zavf37UOs9lVqX9t55NRK36sXV/dV+VgdeLauuY35D5VEY91IKy65wtijsexDfVjOMqxnyN08pNr9CU4r3OuO6XcE6SxRJg3510qpKqvCsadVGBnXIoM5HEgXY1UmhAElsinahqAKEqkgyCnWCVGomWUVIolL8xwK6FMc2RcKxUSGJYkn1Kz0A09YSSfwAvvQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
  <img id='m3' src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADUAAABnCAMAAACXfvq+AAAADFBMVEUAAACsfAD4OAD/pECmOaYSAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAALdJREFUeNrU1oEGw0AQhOEk8/7v3NMV/uwxgMzmxynuK0OdHh/tejZKXVuS8sqS2aoXV+ed/tUHTsuq/TK/ocoqc5lFVJFdYeYshfs9kojyMKto/a8ipczGoxdWFyrLx1NSVp1oh7pLKZIG6wwqEjNtsuK0dcYVSVMkrylPJPVFaeX/sKWUnn1dre1RRdIrElErr04UUKgujFV8Nqcp83JOU20RJudVg4ftfUX4G5r4qK4h4MiRCwDmpxaTaztkVwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></div>
  <img id='clouds' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAYCAMAAACsjQ8GAAAADFBMVEUAAAD8/PwAAAAAcOzIsoEVAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAHlJREFUeNqNkkEOxCAMxDrO//+8oBRGiDRaX+ZgX1rynAA8DWjAt0bqCqQV0AdCNEFkU/uIVVB7JXcAbOUCexkHCPsCtIPS+4eAPmE2avkj6AvejwiZOL2LsC+LgfY4YwUpBzlanG+Rwl5wXQPbvdowHTnTbW2A+/R/QA4CgdKC7TAAAAAASUVORK5CYII='>
```

Answer (score 2):

A snippet:

```html
<h1>Unicorns</h1>
<p>Unicorns are amazing.</p>
```

A snippet in a `<h1>`:

## I'm a heading

```html
<h1>Unicorns</h1>
<p>Unicorns are amazing.</p>
```

A bold snippet:


```html
<h1>Unicorns</h1>
<p>Unicorns are amazing.</p>
```

An italic snippet:


```html
<h1>Unicorns</h1>
<p>Unicorns are amazing.</p>
```

A snippet with a line through it:


```html
<h1>Unicorns</h1>
<p>Unicorns are amazing.</p>
```

A snippet in a list:

- Apples
- Bananas
- ```html
  <h1>Unicorns</h1>
  <p>Unicorns are amazing.</p>
  ```

A snippet in a code block:

```
<h1>Unicorns</h1>
<p>Unicorns are amazing.</p>
```

A snippet in a blockquote:

> ```html
> <h1>Unicorns</h1>
> <p>Unicorns are amazing.</p>
> ```

We can use lots of blockquotes to make it tiny:

> > > > > > > > > > > > ```html
> > > > > > > > > > > > <h1>Unicorns</h1>
> > > > > > > > > > > > <p>Unicorns are amazing.</p>
> > > > > > > > > > > > ```

A snippet in a spoiler:

> ```html
> <h1>Unicorns</h1>
> <p>Unicorns are amazing.</p>
> ```

A snippet in a table:

| Name | Email | Order | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | sam@example.com | Chips | $12 |
| Jim | jim@example.com | ```html <h1>Unicorns</h1> <p>Unicorns are amazing.</p> ``` |  |

## This is all very interesting, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

## 3D = 61

| <sup><sub>[***ₗₒᵣₑₘ***](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)</sub></sup> | ***ＩＰＳＵＭ*** |
| --- | --- |
| WƎᴚO˥ | ℙ |
| L̝̤̯̜̙ò̫̪̰͓ͅr̘͢e͡m͏̰̩ | Ì̷̷̟̙̮͙͖̖͍̘͓͘P̡̤͖͔̮̜̥̭͉̻̞̹̫Ś̢̘͚͕͎͜Ų̛͙͎̮̦͙̠͙̬̮̠̺̭͓̭̮́̕M̷̨̻͔̼̘͇̫͇̣̠̖͉̟̟̕͡ |
| ``` print("Lorem") ``` | `IPSUM` |

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>*H̅̋ͥ̓͛̽ͬ̆́͂̔̾ͬ҉̴̢̨͈̱̘̟ï̴̶͉͍̘͚̥͈͌ͪ̒ͣ̾̈́ͭ͗ͪͭ͟g͊ͨ͐͆̔̑͆ͫ͏̬̞̗̲̱̪̞̜̩͔́͞ͅh̷̰̬̼̯̝̫̩̜ͦͭ̌ͦͬͯ̚͟*</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You should call `foo(bar = TRUE)`. The `bar` argument is very important because it prevents foo overflow.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!

Answer (score 2):

```
A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line of code
```

-> [Layout error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/359713/revisions).

Someone else already reported this in [Revision page now fails the x-overflow - Code Review Meta Stack Exchange](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10589/revision-page-now-fails-the-x-overflow) .

Comment: Work already!!! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it

Answer (score 2):

### Images

Images can be added primarily by using the editor toolbar button
[image: "insert image toolbar button"].
This brings up a special interface that allows you to upload an image online
(via the imgur hosting service) through us - even from your clipboard.
Alternatively, it can be input similarly to adding a link.

**Clickable images**

- HTML `<a href="https://example.com/img.jpg"><img src="https://example.com/img.jpg"></a>`
- Markdown `[![Alt text](https://example.com/img.jpg)](https://example.com/img.jpg)`

**Non-clickable images**

- HTML `<img src="https://example.com/img.jpg">`
- Markdown `![Alt text](https://example.com/img.jpg)`

When uploading via the toolbar button
[image: "insert image toolbar button"],
the image becomes clickable by default.
This is preferable as the clicking feature is convenient for the readers of
the post - especially for very wide images.

---

## Validation of the examples above

**Clickable images**

- HTML [image]
- Markdown [image]

**Non-clickable images**

- HTML [image]
- Markdown [image]

Answer (score 2):

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ---

Answer (score 2):

[See](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405822/11573842)

When `<sup>` and `</sup>` are in the same line:

```
<sup>this is a test of wheather backtics work in sup `test test`</sup>
```

<sup>this is a test of wheather backtics work in sup `test test`</sup>

**^ Works**

When `<sup>` and `</sup>` are in different lines:

```
<sup>
this is a test of wheather backtics work in sup `test test`
</sup>
```

<sup>this is a test of wheather backtics work in sup `test test`</sup>

**^ Doesn't work**

Answer (score 2):

### Syntax Highlighting Test

#### `gibberishtag`

```
function greet(person) {
    return "Hello " + person;
}
```

No tag match, no highlighting.

#### `js`

```js
function greet(person) {
    return "Hello " + person;
}
```

There is no [js](/questions/tagged/js) on SE Meta... I have no idea why this highlights.

#### `lang-gibberishtag`

```gibberishtag
function greet(person) {
    return "Hello " + person;
}
```

No language name match, default to `lang-default`

#### `lang-js`

```js
function greet(person) {
    return "Hello " + person;
}
```

Language match, highlight as JavaScript.

#### `lang-default`

```
function greet(person) {
    return "Hello " + person;
}
```

For comparison

Comment: It looks like the fact that `js` highlights as JS here is a bit of a fluke. There is no [[tag:js]] tag here on Meta SE, and it's not a synonym of anything else. I'm wondering if there's maybe a fuzzy matching mechanic at play somehow... Strange.

Answer (score 2):

using table to present images horizontally

| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- |

caption as second row

| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 90-tooth finishing | 84-tooth laminate | 50-tooth combo |

caption as headers

| 90-tooth finishing | 84-tooth laminate | 50-tooth combo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

caption as text

| [image] 90-tooth-finishing | [image] 84-tooth laminate | [image] 50-tooth combo |
| --- | --- | --- |

Answer (score 2):

Testing out how headers work:

#### hello

### hello

## hello

#### **hello**

Trying to [abuse KBD tags](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9044333#9044333):

[waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles)

<kbd>[waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles)</kbd>

[<kbd>[tag:waffles]</kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns)

[<kbd>[tag:waffles]</kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns)

[waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles)

[[waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns)

Testing some stuff with flairs:
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
[image: profile for Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: Not like this ;)

Comment: @Luuklag how do I correctly format then? I saw the post explaining how to do so with equal signs, triple bars, and dashes, but how do I do so with hashtags?

Comment: You need a space after the hashes. Like # Hello

Comment: @Yay For testing one type of thing I just repeatedly edit a single post, sometimes out-of-site (deleted), to avoid causing 10K+ users pain.

Comment: Testing some comment section stuff: &mdash; &ndash; &minus; -

Answer (score 2):

[Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)<sup>[[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)]</sup>[), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)<sup>[2]</sup> The FGB provided ...

---

Comment: [  -+-  ]

[Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)[[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)][), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)[2] The FGB provided ...

---

Comment: `&#91;` [  -+-  `&#93;` ]

[Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)[[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)][), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)[2] The FGB provided ...

---

We are here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364246/282094

Test Answer: [Does Cyrillic kill proper display of hyperlinks in comments, but not in posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364243/282094)

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya

> Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'[b]), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.[2] The FGB provided electrical power, storage, propulsion, and guidance to the ISS during the initial stage of assembly. With the launch and assembly in orbit of other modules with more specialized functionality, Zarya is now[when?] primarily used for storage, both inside the pressurized section and in the externally mounted fuel tanks.

Comment: [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)[[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)][), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)[2] The FGB provided ...

Comment: [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)&#91;[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)&#93;[), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)&#91;2&#93; The FGB provided ...

Comment: [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)\[[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)\][), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)\[2\] The FGB provided ...

Answer (score 2):

Testing if powershell does syntax highlight when specified:

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\third.ps1"
#get $Current  = second.ps1
#get $Caller   = first.ps1 
#get $Original = first.ps1 
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials 
$action = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($myInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
. "$PSScriptRoot\third.ps1"
#get $Current  = second.ps1
#get $Caller   = first.ps1 
#get $Original = first.ps1 
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials 
$action = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($myInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
```

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\third.ps1"
#get $Current  = second.ps1
#get $Caller   = first.ps1 
#get $Original = first.ps1 
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials 
$action = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($myInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
. "$PSScriptRoot\third.ps1"
#get $Current  = second.ps1
#get $Caller   = first.ps1 
#get $Original = first.ps1 
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials 
$action = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($myInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
```

```
Get-Module -Name "VMWave.*" | ForEach-Object { Import-Module $_; Write-Host "Imported Module $_"}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Testing a table not preceded by an empty line:**
| | | |
|---|---|---|
|Bandwidth |XOUT, YOUT   No external filter| 1600 Hz|
|Bandwidth |ZOUT No external filter |550 Hz|
|RFILT Tolerance| |32 ± 15% kΩ|
|Sensor Resonant Frequency| |5.5 kHz|

❌ Oops! Does not work.

---

**Testing a table preceded by an empty line:**

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bandwidth | XOUT, YOUT No external filter | 1600 Hz |
| Bandwidth | ZOUT No external filter | 550 Hz |
| RFILT Tolerance |  | 32 ± 15% kΩ |
| Sensor Resonant Frequency |  | 5.5 kHz |

✅ Works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a near duplicate to [another answer of mine here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367348/271271). It appears at some point in the very recent past `id` attributes are no longer being automatically created for headings. This is a test to A) verify that, and B) see if it's still possible to use explicit `id` attributes on `<hN>` HTML elements. It also may test having more than one identical `id` attribute in the same page, which, if nothing is done by SE, is something that devolves onto the browser's behavior. Unfortunately, it's not possible to test this with just a revision of my prior answer, because `id` attributes *are* stripped when revisions are shown in the post history.

###### This heading was added to test if the IDs assigned to headings change

It looks like H4, H5, and H6 elements were added to the CSS. This is to test to see if they are live on the site for user contributions.

Using Markdown:

## An H1 (Markdown)

### An H2 (Markdown)

#### An H3 (Markdown)

##### An H4 (Markdown)

###### An H5 (Markdown)

###### An H6 (Markdown)

Using HTML:

## An H1 (HTML)

### An H2 (HTML)

#### An H3 (HTML)

##### An H4 (HTML)

###### An H5 (HTML)

###### An H6 (HTML)

Using HTML with an `id` attribute (expected to be stripped):

An H1 (HTML)
An H2 (HTML)
An H3 (HTML)
An H4 (HTML)
An H5 (HTML)
An H6 (HTML)

#### More testing for automatic generation of `id` and static assignment.

1. ##### Fun with lists and headings:

   1. ###### Issue 1: This is an h5 in a ordered list
   2. ###### Issue 2: This is an h5 in a ordered list
   3. ###### Issue 3: This is an h5 in a ordered list
2. ##### This is the same thing in HTML:

   1. ###### Issue 1 (HTML):
   2. ###### Issue 2 (HTML):
   3. ###### Issue 3 (HTML):
3. ##### HTML with a static `id` attribute for each `<h5>`:

   In the preview rendering, the `<h5>` elements are stripped, but content is displayed.

   1. Issue 1 (HTML with static ID):
   2. Issue 2 (HTML with static ID):
   3. Issue 3 (HTML with static ID):

Comment: And the result is: HTML `<hN>` elements with a static `id` are now stripped.

Answer (score 2):

#### Stack Exchange HLJS Colors

| Stacks Color Variable | Light Theme Color | Dark Theme Color | Color Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| --highlight-color | [image] #2f3337 | [image] #fff | More or less default text color (Near Black/ White) |
| --highlight-comment | [image] #656e77 | [image] #999 | Grey |
| --highlight-symbol | [image] #803378 | [image] #c59bc1 | Magenta |
| --highlight-keyword | [image] #015692 | [image] #88aece | Blue |
| --highlight-attribute | [image] #015692 | [image] #88aece | Blue |
| --highlight-namespace | [image] #b75501 | [image] #f08d49 | Orange |
| --highlight-literal | [image] #b75501 | [image] #f08d49 | Orange |
| --highlight-variable | [image] #54790d | [image] #b5bd68 | Yellowish-Green |
| --highlight-punctuation | [image] #535a60 | [image] #ccc | Lighter Grey |
| --highlight-deletion | [image] #c02d2e | [image] #de7176 | Red |
| --highlight-addition | [image] #2f6f44 | [image] #76c490 | Green |

Testing an example link:

- HTML link: [How do I search tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics#:~:text=Search%20tags,on%20%22advanced%20tips%22.)
- Markdown link (`[text][1]`), [How do I search tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics#:%7E:text=Search%20tags,on%20%22advanced%20tips%22.)

[image: Profile for Timothy G. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Answer (score 2):

Comment on this question: [Why has the parsing of the &nbsp; in tables changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375234/282094)

Adding &nbsp; isn't useful, just use correct markdown, you are missing a "|".

---

Your example:

| So that instead of this: | I get this: |
| --- | --- |
| [image: table without the non-breaking space] | [image: table with the non-breaking space] |
|  | *Looks much better, right?* |

---

My example (use image and specify width):
|1. I get this: | |
|--|--|
| [image] | [image] [image] |

My example (no non-breaking spaces):
|2. I get this: | |
|--|--|
| [image: table without the non-breaking space] | [image: 2] [image: 3] |

My example (with a small number of non-breaking spaces):
|3. I get this:      | |
|--|--|
| [image: table without the non-breaking space] | [image: 2] [image: 3] |

---

Adding the non-breaking spaces changes the size of the right column.

---

Notes:

#### Allowed attributes for <img>

The following attributes are allowed on the  tag, in the order shown below. Note that the mobile theme enforces a maximum width of 90%, so specifying a height might not scale the image proportionally on the mobile sites.

**Attributes must be specified in this order. You may omit attributes you do not want to specify, but specifying a later attribute before an earlier one will strip the tag.**

1. src=""
2. width="" (1–999; plain number without any extensions like px)
3. height="" (1–999; plain number without any extensions like px; pay attention to order warning above)
4. alt=""
5. title=""

You would be better off [using percentages](https://ict4me.sri.com/chat/html_tutorial/image_attrs_2.php) to enforce a specific ratio of the images while using three separate images, but using a single image of a grid is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

not quoted, but highlighted

```c++
printf("here's some code\n");
int x = 99 + 100;
```

quoted and highlighted

> ```c++
> printf("here's some code\n");
> int x = 99 + 100;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Stacks editor is broken. This is a proof.

<sub>Proof</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Testing spoilers and code fences:

> `none !   code block !`   
>
>  Text block
>
>  `none !   code block !`   
>
>  Text block

Hmm...

> `none ! code block !` 
>  
>  Text block
>  
>  `none ! code block !` 
>  
>  Text block

> `none code block` 
>
>  Text block
>
>       asd
>       asd
>  
>  Text block

Answer (score 2):

The following text is from [answer to: "How to indent a few lines in Markdown markup?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842817/3773011) by [AgainPsychoX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4880243/againpsychox). It is under a CC BY-SA 4.0 license.

This is normal text.

---

This gets indented, without enumeration nor dots.

---

Multiple levels seems to be possible?

---

Yes, but syntax gets messy, unless you write it single line :)

Answer (score 2):

Testing server-side rendering of NBSP in inline code:

`" ".join(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv))`

Answer (score 2):

Testing something with new editor and its ability to convert local links to question titles.

Some links which should get converted to question titles:

- [Quotes are ignored in search when there's a word/tag outside quotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380375/1099857)
- [DevOps.SE is in a favor of a mass-migration of questions based on topicality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380374/1099857)
- [Minor alignment issue in Activity page Impact section's tooltip](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380372/1099857)

---

Highlighting:

```python
print('test')
```

Answer (score 2):

## Text Fragment Linking

[test1](https://example.com/#:%7E:text=illustrative%20examples) `[text](link)`

[test2](https://example.com/#:%7E:text=illustrative%20examples) `[text][ref]`

test3: [https://example.com/#:~:text=illustrative%20examples](https://example.com/#:%7E:text=illustrative%20examples)

test4: [https://example.com/#:~:text=illustrative%20examples](https://example.com/#:%7E:text=illustrative%20examples)

[test5](https://example.com/#:~:text=illustrative%20examples) `<a href="">...</a>` **works**

```html
<a href="https://example.com/#:%7E:text=illustrative%20examples">
<a href="https://example.com/#:%7E:text=illustrative%20examples">
<a href="https://example.com/#:%7E:text=illustrative%20examples">
<a href="https://example.com/#:%7E:text=illustrative%20examples">
<a href="https://example.com/#:~:text=illustrative%20examples">
```

## Using all allowed URL Code points

https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-code-points

[test1](https://example.com/!$%27()*+./:;=?@_%7E&,-)

[test2](https://example.com/!$%27()*+./:;=?@_%7E&,-)

test3: [https://example.com/!$'()*+./:;=?@_~&,-](https://example.com/!$%27()*+./:;=?@_%7E&,-)

test4: [https://example.com/!$'()*+./:;=?@_~&,-](https://example.com/!$%27()*+./:;=?@_%7E&,-)

[test5](https://example.com/!$%27()*+./:;=?@_~&,-)

```html
<a href="https://example.com/#!$%27()*+./:;=?@_%7E&amp;,-">
<a href="https://example.com/#!$%27()*+./:;=?@_%7E&amp;,-">
<a href="https://example.com/#!$%27()*+./:;=?@_%7E&amp;,-">
<a href="https://example.com/#!$%27()*+./:;=?@_%7E&amp;,-">
<a href="https://example.com/#!$%27()*+./:;=?@_~&amp;,-">
```

---

- `~` : percent-encoded, unless `<a>` element used.
- `'` : percent-encoded always

Answer (score 2):

| text | match regex | replaced |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `` | `.*` | `foo` |
| `a` | `.*` | `foofoo` |
| `ab` | `.*` | `foofoo` |
|  | `^.*$` | `foo` |
| `a` | `^.*$` | `foo` |
| `ab` | `^.*$` | `foo` |

Answer (score 2):

##### Tabs being converted to spaces

In code fences:

```
    this is a test
    this is a test
    this is a test
```

In a `<pre><code>` block:

```
 this is a test
    this is a test
    this is a test
```

In a `<pre><code>` block using HTML entities:

```
	this is a test
	this is a test
	this is a test
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a test image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

HTML stuff (markup) in a Markdown table:

| syntax / example | explanation / comment |
| --- | --- |
| `thing1:thing2` | Greek letters: - alpha, beta, and gamma (γ). |

Answer (score 2):

> this is a test of [embedding links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) into block quotes

Answer (score 2):

Test wrong formatting from new editor:

Single line

`

```
const hello = "world";
```

`

Multi line

`

```
const hello = "world";

const foo = 42;

console.log(hello, foo);
```

`

Single line more backticks

`

```
const hello = "world";
```

`

Multi line more backticks

`

```
const hello = "world";

const foo = 42;

console.log(hello, foo);
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Table
| Foo | Bar | Baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | 789 |

Fullwidth symbol and URL：https://example.com/

The rendering of the preview during editing and the actual rendering are different.

Comment: If you haven’t seen it yet, see also this MSE post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359192/markdown-table-preview-does-not-detect-missing-blank-line-before-table-header

Answer (score 2):

| Site | Step 1: Draft your question |
| --- | --- |
| [es.stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) | La comunidad está aquí para ayudarte con problemas específicos de programación, algoritmos, o lenguaje. Evita hacer preguntas cuyas respuestas puedan estar basadas en opiniones. Resume el problema Incluye detalles sobre tu objetivo Describe los resultados esperados y obtenidos Incluye cualquier mensaje de error Describe lo que has intentado Enseña lo que has intentado y dinos qué has encontrado (en este sitio o en cualquier otro) y por qué no satisfizo tus necesidades. Se pueden obtener mejores respuestas cuando se proporciona una investigación previa. Muestra algo de código Cuando sea apropiado, comparte la mínima cantidad de código necesario para reproducir tu problema (también llamado un ejemplo mínimo verificable) |
| [hardwarerecs](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | Questions here get better answers when you… - …show us what you've done and why it hasn't worked for you - …list **all** your requirements for a **single**, **specific** piece of hardware - …avoid asking for technical support Remember, we don't do compatibility queries, build reviews or HOWTOs. For the full details on what sort of questions are appropriate, see [our guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality) and [the types of hardware we can recommend](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware). Questions about the site itself should be asked on [meta](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com). [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [rus](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | Вопрос должен быть о русском языке. Вопрос должен быть *конкретным* (чтобы на него можно было дать лаконичный ответ). Указывайте детали. Если у вас есть свои соображения, опишите их. Если у вас есть предложения по улучшению сайта, **[опишите их на Мете](//rus.meta.stackexchange.com)**. [посетите справку »](/help) [как задавать вопросы »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) | Сообщество здесь, чтобы помочь вам с конкретными проблемами по программированию, алгоритмам, языкам программирования. Избегайте публикации вопросов, на которые невозможно дать объективный ответ. Опишите проблему кратко Включите подробную информацию о вашей цели Опишите, что вы ожидали и что получили Добавьте сообщения об ошибках Опишите, что вы пробовали Покажите, что вы пробовали, что вы нашли (на этом сайте или в другом месте), и почему это не решает вашу проблему. Вы можете получить лучшие ответы, когда продемонстрируете ваше исследование. Добавьте немного кода По возможности добавьте минимальный код, необходимый для воспроизведения вашей проблемы (так называемый минимальный воспроизводимый пример) |
| [civicrm](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about CiviCRM?** If your question is *not* about CiviCRM, you're on the wrong site. **Detailed questions get informative answers!** Include your CiviCRM version, CMS, screenshots and *any* other details you can think of. **Show your research.** Let us know what you've learned while trying to find an answer, so we can get right to the point. Tell your story! New here? **[Take the tour!](/tour)** If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [matheducators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about teaching mathematics or the process of learning mathematics?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Five ways to get great answers:** Be sure to tell us... - ...the task you want to accomplish - ...your requirements for that task - ...what you already know about software available for this purpose Then, **write a specific and to-the-point title** and **tag your question** according to the category of software you're looking for! See also: [What information is required?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information/352#352) [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [pt.stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) | **Sua pergunta é sobre programação?** Preferimos perguntas que podem ser *respondidas*, ao invés de debatidas. Dê detalhes. Diga o que você já tentou. Resuma o problema Inclua detalhes sobre o seu objetivo Descreva os resultados atuais e os esperados Inclua mensagens de erro Descreva o que você já tentou Mostre o que você já tentou e conte para nós o que você encontrou (neste site ou em outro lugar) e o motivo que isso não resolveu seu problema. Você consegue melhores respostas quando você fornece pesquisas. Mostre um pouco de código Quando for apropriado, compartilhe uma quantidade mínima de código no qual os outros possam usar para reproduzir o seu problema (também chamado de exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável) |
| [mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about how to use the software [Wolfram *Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)?** [Search the site.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search) Look it up in [*Mathematica's* documentation center](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/). Then ask. We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [french](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about the French language?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/questions/how-to-ask) |
| [japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about the Japanese language?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Questions should also be educational to other people. **Questions asking for translations, transcriptions or proofreading are off-topic, and will be closed**. We're here to help you learn, not to provide a translation service. If you're struggling to understand a word or phrase, frame your question around asking for help understanding the specific word or clause in the phrase you're struggling with. Provide details. Share your research. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com)** instead. |
| [german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **To obtain a useful and quick answer, please adhere to the following:** - Tell us precisely what you want to know. - Tell us what you already found or understood. - If possible, provide an example and context. - If you are asking for a translation, meaning, or similar: [Tell us why a dictionary did not help you.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences) - We [do not translate or proofread texts](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/919/are-questions-related-to-peer-review-of-a-text-on-topic). Ask about a single, specific problem instead. Du darfst auch gerne **auf Deutsch** fragen. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about parenting?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Opinions should be backed up either **with a reference**, or experiences that **happened to you personally**. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) |
| [drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about the Drupal CMS?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Remember to report the Drupal version and relevant modules you are using. If your question is about code, include the relevant parts. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) |
| [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question a programming puzzle or code golf challenge?** All challenge questions on this site should have: 1. A **clear specification** of what constitutes a correct submission, so that it is possible to indisputably decide whether an entry is valid or not. Test cases are highly encouraged. 2. An **objective primary winning criterion**, so that it is possible to indisputably decide which entry should win. Please follow a [standard template](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1511) and post first in [the meta Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140) for feedback. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Improve code that you wrote or maintain, through peer review.** Your question **must contain code that is already working correctly**, and the relevant code sections must be embedded in the question. Please avoid stripping out key details that may be relevant to the review. If your code is incomplete or not working, you should ask for help [on another site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598). You may wish to mention specific concerns: performance, security issues, etc. We recommend reading our [Guide to Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436). If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) |
| [scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | The community is here to help you with questions about science fiction or fantasy. Provide details and share research with your question. If you are trying to identify a story you may want to check out our [helpful guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) on what to include. If your question is about a story that isn't science fictional or fantastical you may want to check out these sites instead: - [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) if your question is about works from the screen. - [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) if your question is about written works. - [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) if your question is about game play elements of a video game. - [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) if your question is about an anime or manga. |
| [graphicdesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | - Be specific. Show your work and explain where you’re stuck. - Read our guidelines for [**font-identification**](//graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083) and [**style-identification**](//graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2930) questions. - For feedback on work, read our [**critique guidelines**](//graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681). - Subjective questions are okay [**if answerable with facts and reason**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). - Technical support or questions using graphic-design software for non-design purposes are off-topic and should be asked on [**Super User**](//superuser.com). For more help, please see [**What topics can I ask about here?**](/help/on-topic) and [**What types of questions should I avoid asking?**](/help/dont-ask) If your question is about this website, [**ask it on meta**](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com) instead. |
| [video](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about video recording and production?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.video.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/questions/how-to-ask) |
| [writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about writing, copywriting, publishing or editing?** If your question is about the strictly interpreted correctness of English grammar or syntax rules, please [ask on English](http://english.stackexchange.com), not here. We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) |
| [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about physics?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Homework-like questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. See: [homework guidance](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/). Provide details. Share your research. **Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations in questions.** If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/questions/how-to-ask) |
| [rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about role-playing games?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. The community is here to help you with questions about role-playing games. Make sure to specify which game (name and edition) you are asking about, provide details, and share research with your question. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about WordPress development?** We focus on technical questions. A basic level of PHP and Javascript will be helpful in understanding many of the answers. We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research. Read the [help section](/help/on-topic). If your question is about **3rd Party WordPress Themes and Plugins** (e.g. WooCommerce, ACF, Divi, etc), these are off-topic. You can visit the official support routes, the .org support forum, and the relevant communities (e.g. Facebook groups), or ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) instead. If your question is about this website, or something that happened on this site, ask it on the [meta site](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about the Stack Exchange API, applications written with the API, or scripts that work on Stack Exchange sites?** - [Use app template](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=app) If your app is still under development or if you're experimenting, [add the placeholder tag](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=app+placeholder); please remove the post when you're done testing if you don't publish ([details](https://stackapps.com/questions/4573/my-app-has-to-be-published-first-but-its-still-under-development)). - [Use library template](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=library) - [Use script template](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=script) For questions, bug-reports or feature-requests... - ...use the support tag for help using the API. - ...use the bug tag for bug reports. - ...use the feature-request tag to suggest improvements to the site or API. Provide details. Post updates on your work. Share your research. [visit the help center »](/help) |
| [english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about using English?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research. If your question is about *learning* English, **[ask it on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)** instead. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) | The community is here to help you with questions about Ubuntu. Provide details and share research with your question. Questions about Pop OS, Linux Mint, Kali Linux, or any other distribution that is not an official flavor of Ubuntu are off-topic on this site, and will be closed. Check [this page](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) for more details. |
| [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about math?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. [Provide details.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) Share your research. Write an [**interesting, specific title**](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144) that summarizes the question. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about cooking?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Please note that requests for recipes are considered off topic, and will be closed. Provide details. Share your research. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) |
| [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about the operation of a website you control, or issues that affect entire websites?** We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/questions/how-to-ask) |
| [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites)?** Meta is different from other sites. See: - **[What is meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)** - **[How do I participate in Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)** [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/help/how-to-ask) |
| [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) | **Is your question about managing information technology systems in a business environment?** [Review our list of allowed topics](/help/on-topic). We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research. If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.serverfault.com)** instead. [visit the help center »](/help) [asking help »](/questions/how-to-ask) |
| [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) | The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems. Avoid asking opinion-based questions. Summarize the problem Include details about your goal Describe expected and actual results Include any error messages Describe what you’ve tried Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research. Show some code When appropriate, share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem (also called a minimum, reproducible example) |

Comment: Is this an actual request to delete this?

Comment: @Joachim Thanks. I used "delete", not to delete the the post but delete the answer body.... I assumed that some html tags should not caused problems but I was wrong. By the other hand, the problem is now solved... the post might be deleted or archived now.

Answer (score 2):

### This answer is to test some more complex link and image Markdown syntax.

The image used is:

- [Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png) `https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png`
  original URL: http://www.iconarchive.com/show/weathy-icons-by-icojam/24-tornado-icon.html
  Artist: Icojam
  Iconset: Weathy Icons (25 icons)
  License: Public Domain

The original intent for this answer was to verify some more complex link and image Markdown to make sure that a couple of userscripts were parsing it correctly. However, in the process of creating these, I encountered a bug in at least the SE post preview parsing of the Markdown. I don't know until saving this if there are issues in the backend processing.

#### Bug identified (only SE post preview; works in post rendered in the backend: i.e. once it's saved):

##### No support for multi-line tooltips

###### Simple examples: [working demo on CommonMark site](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%20*%20%5BThis%20is%20a%20link%20with%20a%20multi-line%20tooltip%20using%20reference%2C%20%60%5Blink%20text%5D%5Bref%5D%60%2C%20format%5D%5B7%5D%0A%20*%20%5BThis%20is%20a%20link%20with%20a%20multi-line%20tooltip%20using%20inline%20%60%5Blink%20text%5D(URL%20%2B%20title)%60%20format%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo%20%22This%20is%20a%20title%2Ftooltip%20with%20more%20than%20%0Aone%20line.%22)%0A%0A%20%20%5B7%5D%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo%20%22This%20is%20a%20title%2Ftooltip%20with%20more%20than%20%0Aone%20line.%22)

- [This is a link with a multi-line tooltip using reference, `[link text][ref]`, format](https://example.com/foo)
- [This is a link with a multi-line tooltip using inline `[link text](URL + title)` format](https://example.com/foo)

###### More complex examples

###### multi-line text + image + multi-line text with multi-line tooltips (inner and outer) [working demo on CommonMark site](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=*%20%5BThis%20multi-line%20%20%0Atext%20is%20part%20%20%0A%20of%20the%20link%20!%5BIcojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png%5D%5B4%5D%20some%20more%20%20%0Amulti-line%20%20%0A%20text%5D%5B6%5D%0A%0A%20%20%5B4%5D%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwRMuO.png%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27tooltip%0A%20%5C%27%233%5C%27%27%0A%20%20%5B6%5D%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fbar6%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(tooltip%20%235%20with%20escaped%20%5C(%5C)%20with%20a%20URL%20that%27s%20not%20an%20image%20%20%0Aand%20multi-line%20%20%0Atitle)); not working in SE post edit preview

- [This multi-line

  text is part

  of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png] some more

  multi-line

  text](https://example.com/bar6)

###### multi-line text + image + multi-line text with tooltips (inner and outer, both multi-line); [working demo on CommonMark site](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=*%20%5BThis%20multi-line%20%20%0Atext%20is%20part%20%20%0A%20of%20the%20link%20!%5BIcojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwRMuO.png%20%22INNER%20tooltip%3A%20this%20is%20a%20title%2Ftooltip%20%5B%5D%2C%20with%20something%20in%20%5Bbrackets%5D%2C%20(parenthesis)%2C%20%27single%20quotes%27%2C%20and%20%5C%22double%20quotes%5C%22%20which%20don%27t%20use%20escaping%2C%20except%20the%20actual%20delimiter%3B%0A%20and%0A%20all%0A%20escaped%20%5C%5Bbrackets%5C%5D%2C%20%5C(parenthesis%5C)%2C%20%5C%27single%20quotes%5C%27%2C%20and%20%5C%22double%20quotes%5C%22.%20Delimiter%20at%20the%20%5C%22end%5C%22%22)%20Even%20%20%0Athis%20is%20%20%0Asome%20more%20link%20text%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo%20%22OUTER%20tooltip%3A%20this%20is%20a%20title%2Ftooltip%20%5B%5D%2C%20with%20something%20in%20%5Bbrackets%5D%2C%20(parenthesis)%2C%20%27single%20quotes%27%2C%20and%20%5C%22double%20quotes%5C%22%20which%20don%27t%20use%20escaping%2C%20except%20the%20actual%20delimiter%3B%0A%20and%0A%20all%0A%20escaped%20%5C%5Bbrackets%5C%5D%2C%20%5C(parenthesis%5C)%2C%20%5C%27single%20quotes%5C%27%2C%20and%20%5C%22double%20quotes%5C%22.%20Delimiter%20at%20the%20%5C%22end%5C%22%22)); not working in SE post edit preview

- [This multi-line

  text is part

  of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png] Even

  this is

  some more link text](https://example.com/foo)

#### Links:

##### named/numbered: `[link text][ref]` format

###### "normal"

- [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png]

###### image with tooltips (inner and outer)

- [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png]

###### text + image with tooltips (inner and outer)

- [This is part of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png]](https://example.com/foo)

###### text + image + text with tooltips (inner and outer)

- [This is part of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png] some more text](https://example.com/foo)

###### multi-line text + image with tooltips (inner and outer)

- [This multi-line

  text is part

  of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png]](https://example.com/foo)

###### multi-line text + image + text with tooltips (inner and outer)

- [This multi-line

  text is part

  of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png] some more text](https://example.com/foo)

###### multi-line text + image + multi-line text with tooltips (inner and outer)

- [This multi-line

  text is part

  of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png] some more

  multi-line

  text](https://example.com/foo)

###### multi-line text + image + multi-line text with multi-line tooltips (inner and outer) [working demo on CommonMark site](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=*%20%5BThis%20multi-line%20%20%0Atext%20is%20part%20%20%0A%20of%20the%20link%20!%5BIcojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png%5D%5B4%5D%20some%20more%20%20%0Amulti-line%20%20%0A%20text%5D%5B6%5D%0A%0A%20%20%5B4%5D%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwRMuO.png%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27tooltip%0A%20%5C%27%233%5C%27%27%0A%20%20%5B5%5D%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwRMuO.png%20%22tooltip%0A%20%5C%22%234%5C%22%22%0A%20%20%5B6%5D%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwRMuO.png%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(tooltip%20%235%20with%20escaped%20%5C(%5C)%20with%20a%20URL%20that%27s%20not%20an%20image%20%20%0Aand%20multi-line%20%20%0Atitle)); not working in SE post edit preview

- [This multi-line

  text is part

  of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png] some more

  multi-line

  text](https://example.com/bar6)

##### `[link text](URL + optional title/tooltip)` syntax

###### "normal", no tooltip

- [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png]

###### link with tooltip

- [just some link text](https://example.com/foo)

###### image with tooltip (inner and outer)

- [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png]

###### text + image with tooltip (inner and outer)

- [This is part of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png]](https://example.com/foo)

###### text + image + text with tooltip (inner and outer)

- [This is part of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png] this is some more text](https://example.com/foo)

###### multi-line text + image + text with tooltips (inner and outer)

- [This multi-line

  text is part

  of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png] Even this is some more link text](https://example.com/foo)

###### multi-line text + image + multi-line text with tooltips (inner and outer)

- [This multi-line

  text is part

  of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png] Even

  this is

  some more link text](https://example.com/foo)

###### multi-line text + image + multi-line text with tooltips (inner and outer, both multi-line); [working demo on CommonMark site](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=*%20%5BThis%20multi-line%20%20%0Atext%20is%20part%20%20%0A%20of%20the%20link%20!%5BIcojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwRMuO.png%20%22INNER%20tooltip%3A%20this%20is%20a%20title%2Ftooltip%20%5B%5D%2C%20with%20something%20in%20%5Bbrackets%5D%2C%20(parenthesis)%2C%20%27single%20quotes%27%2C%20and%20%5C%22double%20quotes%5C%22%20which%20don%27t%20use%20escaping%2C%20except%20the%20actual%20delimiter%3B%0A%20and%0A%20all%0A%20escaped%20%5C%5Bbrackets%5C%5D%2C%20%5C(parenthesis%5C)%2C%20%5C%27single%20quotes%5C%27%2C%20and%20%5C%22double%20quotes%5C%22.%20Delimiter%20at%20the%20%5C%22end%5C%22%22)%20Even%20%20%0Athis%20is%20%20%0Asome%20more%20link%20text%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo%20%22OUTER%20tooltip%3A%20this%20is%20a%20title%2Ftooltip%20%5B%5D%2C%20with%20something%20in%20%5Bbrackets%5D%2C%20(parenthesis)%2C%20%27single%20quotes%27%2C%20and%20%5C%22double%20quotes%5C%22%20which%20don%27t%20use%20escaping%2C%20except%20the%20actual%20delimiter%3B%0A%20and%0A%20all%0A%20escaped%20%5C%5Bbrackets%5C%5D%2C%20%5C(parenthesis%5C)%2C%20%5C%27single%20quotes%5C%27%2C%20and%20%5C%22double%20quotes%5C%22.%20Delimiter%20at%20the%20%5C%22end%5C%22%22)); not working in SE post edit preview

- [This multi-line

  text is part

  of the link [image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png] Even

  this is

  some more link text](https://example.com/foo)

#### More variations: different delimiters

##### link with tooltip (escaping the delimiter; should work in posts)

- [title using `"` as delimiter](https://example.com/foo)
- [title using `'` as delimiter](https://example.com/foo)
- [title using `()` as delimiter](https://example.com/foo)

#### SE Chat: More variations, different delimiters

SE Chat doesn't require escaping the delimiter on a tooltip interior to the tooltip and will display the escape. It also doesn't support a delimiter other than `"`.

##### link with tooltip (NOT escaping the delimiter; should *not* work in posts) See these in chat starting [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63264398#63264398)

The following **do not, and should not, work in SE posts.** They are specific to SE Chat, which uses a different Markdown parser with somewhat different and more limited syntax.

- [title using `"` as delimiter](https://example.com/foo "tooltip: "tooltip: this is a title/tooltip [], with something in [brackets], (parenthesis), 'single quotes', and "double quotes" which don't use escaping; and all escaped [brackets], (parenthesis), 'single quotes', and "double quotes". Delimiter at the "end""): **Works in SE chat**, but the escaping for the single and double quotes is displayed in the title. The escaping of the parentheses and brackets are not displayed.
- [title using `"` as delimiter; not escaping delimiters](https://example.com/foo "tooltip: "tooltip: this is a title/tooltip [], with something in [brackets], (parenthesis), 'single quotes', and "double quotes" which don't use escaping; Delimiter at the "end""): **Works in SE chat**, with correct display in the title/tooltip, due to not escaping any delimiters.

##### Examples from CommonMark spec

###### Multi-line title: [Example #196 from CommonMark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#example-196) ([live CommonMark demo](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%5Bfoo%5D%3A%20%2Furl%20%27%0Atitle%0Aline1%0Aline2%0A%27%0A%0A%5Bfoo%5D%0A)) NOT working in post edit preview:

[foo](/url)

Answer (score 2):

This is strikethrough font: <s>abc</s>

```
This is strikethrough font: <s>abc</s>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<kbd><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</kbd>
```

Comment: [​](https://google.com)

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard is it magic?

Comment: haha! I did `[​](https://google.com)` and it works

Comment: [​](https://google.com)

Comment: Talking silently

Comment: [​](https://google.com)

Comment: It works! [​](https://google.com)

Comment: [ ](https://google.com)

Comment: [github [google](https://google.com)](https://github.com)

Comment: test [​](https://google.com)

Comment: [​](https://google.com)

Comment: tada!! [​](https://google.com)

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard so fast?

Comment: [​](https://google.com)

Comment: [Зонтик](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1346379/%d0%97%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba)

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard you can just do `u+202e` as many times as required to reach the minimum comment length.

Comment: u+202eu+202eu+202e

Answer (score 2):

So this is just a test of snippets. I see  how it works: when you enter code, then click Results, nothing happens. You have to submit it, then it will work, then, finally, you can post your answer. Three steps instead of two. Okay. I just wish I could post all the nice little snippets I've accumulated over the years for my own use. Can't do that, because SO has lots of rules and it is easy to get banned. I know; I have. I'm **very** careful when I post questions, not to post them in the form of "here is a neat way to do something".

```js
alert('hi');
```

```css
.a {color:green;}
```

```html
<div class=a>Test</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. I like snippets!

Answer (score 2):

Wait, what!?! I don’t own The Nineteenth Byte!

[image: strange…]

Answer (score 2):

Raw links are linkified differently in live preview and rendered result?

Code    https://github.com/
Code：https://github.com/
Code: https://github.com/
Code - https://github.com/
Code!https://github.com/
Code.https://github.com/
Code    https://github.com/
Codehttps://github.com/

In live preview, the links are linkified if immediately prefaced by a punctuation. If the rendered result, a space is required.

Answer (score 1):

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: @MikeM. please don't hijack random post, even in sandbox. It cause inbox message to be sent, which some people consider as noise. Post your own answer and test comments as much as you want under that answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's totally my bad. I didn't think anybody got pinged on community wiki. I meant to immediately delete that anyway. My apologies.

Comment: @MikeM. now post an apology for the second one 

Comment: @ShadowWizard you too for the now first one 

Answer (score 1):

I’m testing hyphens ("HYPHEN MINUS") on iOS 12. Specifically, typing multiple hyphens into the edit box. Typing 2 hyphens together results in a single "EM DASH".

Related question on the Ask Different Stack:
[How do I type a hyphen in iOS 12?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362020/how-do-i-type-a-hyphen-in-ios-12)

The text in parentheses describes the resulting string after typing N hyphens.

Below this line is a single “hyphen” (HYPHEN)

-

Below this are 2 hyphens (EM DASH)

—

—

And 3 hyphens (EM DASH + HYPHEN)

—-

—

Four hyphens (EM DASH + EM DASH)

——

-—

Five hyphens (EM DASH + EM DASH + HYPHEN)

——-

Long press and *second* character (EN DASH)

–

Long press and *third* character (EM DASH)

—

Copy/paste

---

---

---

Hello -

• (BULLET - Long press and *first* character)

Saying "hyphen hyphen hyphen hyphen" results in 4 contiguous hyphens

---

Saying "dash" results in an "EN DASH" and "dash dash dash dash" results in 4 x "EN DASH + SPACE" (not contiguous).

– – – –

Answer (score 1):

posting *sample* *answer* from api [tour]

Comment: [chat] from website

Comment: [Meta Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com) from api

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> or so
>  you claim
> ```

Answer (score 1):

***Testing some formatting***

Below are some formatting tests within an answer...

---

> Sample blockquote info

```
code block
```

[Blue Prism](http://BluePrism.com)

sample code snippet

```cs
// init webrequest
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

when i run this program it giving me only none

```
Var code = too much

this is a lot of code

help I'm stuck in a codeblock

aaaah

codeeeeeeee

CODE
Lots of code


Lots and lots
Var code = too much

this is a lot of code

help I'm stuck in a codeblock

aaaah

codeeeeeeee

CODE
Lots of code

Var code = too much

this is a lot of code

help I'm stuck in a codeblock

aaaah

codeeeeeeee

I edit in MOOOOOORE COOOOOOOODE

CODE
Lots of code
```

To exit <s>Vim</s> code block, just press Enter in the code and type ```` ``` ````. It works!

Comment: @ankii seeing if I get the warning that it’s mostly code ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333416/399694)).

Comment: [mre] does this work (typed `[mre]`)

Comment: @ankii oh that pinged you :P?

Answer (score 1):

test post please ignore 30 characters

test edit

Comment: test comment asdfasdf

Comment: Test reply asdfasdf

Comment: @Ano Test ping reply asdfasdf

Answer (score 1):

Very good! Fantastic! Very good! Fantastic! Very good! Fantastic!frefferfgerger

This **is a** test.

Still a test.

- List item

I keep testing.

Until it breaks.

- Another list item

  And it doesn't break if you indent by 4 spaces

Answer (score 1):

Testing.
Ok.

Does LaTeX formatting work?
Let me test.

[image: \binom{20}{2} \cdot (\frac{1}{10})^2 \cdot (\frac{9}{10})^{18} \approx 28.518%]

Cool! It does! Ok

Comment: That's some hawt stuff!

Answer (score 1):

> [The diff is informative; it will not apply directly because this site mangles tabs and whitespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543527/26420)

BET

```
--- drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.c~
+++ drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.c
@@ -1063,7 +1063,7 @@
 }

 static const struct tty_port_operations acm_port_ops = {
-   .dtr_rts = acm_port_dtr_rts,
+   /* .dtr_rts = acm_port_dtr_rts, */
    .shutdown = acm_port_shutdown,
    .activate = acm_port_activate,
    .destruct = acm_port_destruct,
```

ETA: nvm I'm rekt

feel free for anyone to commandeer this answer if your rep is too low for the sandbox

Answer (score 1):

Testing possible issues with the revision history for good measure ([Thank you for enabling YouTube embedding!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397409/6296561)):

iframe:

Script:

alert("Script injection protection broken")

Video raw:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hwz7YN1AQmQ

Video iframe:

Comment: There's no video iframe.

Comment: @mindstormsboi I know, it's not supposed to. Had to check (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397409/6296561)

Answer (score 1):

This is a code fence test.

```
New code
```

Answer (score 1):

### Yay! We just get to <sub>mess</sub><sup>Around</sup>

2<sup>2</sup> = 4 (unless we're talkin' common core)

Answer (score 1):

[asdhskdhflsdhfjak](https://javascript:a)

Comment: Um... I don't understand what's going on in this answer

Comment: @mindstormsboi Formatting sandbox answers are typically nonsensical. I wouldn't worry about them too much, unless they're Rude/Abusive.

Comment: yeah, just testing things

Answer (score 1):

[Can I undelete an answer myself if it was deleted via Recommend deletion votes from review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349578/can-i-undelete-an-answer-myself-if-it-was-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-f)

---

This is testing for undeletion when a post is deleted with

> Review ends with a mix of 1 or 2 delete votes and recommend deletion votes.

<s>Anyone, feel free to flag this as NAA or VLQ.</s>

<s>Anyone is also free to recommend to delete this post~</s>

<s>([Trusted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (20k rep): consider commenting after recommending to delete this post, so that other trusted users can skip it..?)</s>

**Moderator**, consider replying if you get any mod flag?

Comment: I flagged as NAA

Comment: I'm going to click the Delete button from the review queue

Comment: Review link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/72670

Comment: Undeleted myself, waiting for mod's response if they get any flag or not.

Comment: Yep, flag on this one too :)

Comment: If you delete this one then it will only need two votes to undelete

Answer (score 1):

Escaped characters in comments.

Comment: `_/\_` renders like this: _/\_

Comment: `_/\\_` renders like this: _/\\_

Answer (score 1):

This is my code:

```
collections: subcategory
{
    _id:"ZbwCsJEMi2DesyJA7",
    category_name: "ICT",
    subcategory_name: "Laptop"
}

subcategory.js

Template.Subcategory.events({
     "keyup .searchbox": function(event){
           var query = event.target.value;
           Session.set('query', query);
     }
});

Template.Subcategory.helpers({
     subcategory: function(){
         var filter = {sort: {}};
         var query = Session.get('query');
         filter.sort[Session.get('sortby')] = 1;
         return Subcategory.find({ subcategory_name: new RegExp(query, 'i')} , filter ); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Outdated comments may get deleted. [Learn more about comments…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: ``[link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code` ``. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter` or `@PeterSmith` will both work. [Learn more about formatting…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: enter at least 15 characters

Comment: testing how to undo votes on comments

Comment: Apparently if you mess with the Javascript you can undo votes on comments within 60 seconds of voting even after refreshing the page.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to be possible to undo votes on comments if you voted more than 60 seconds ago, not even by messing with the Javascript.

Comment: Here is the code to undo votes on comments if you voted less than 60 seconds ago: `let machin = document.createElement("form"); machin.method = "post"; machin.action = "/posts/comments/<comment id>/vote/0"; let fkey = document.createElement("input"); fkey.name = "fkey"; fkey.value = "fa360d325887bceb4de2c5522d095a7f65960ee9954efab80223ad4e67b23610"; machin.appendChild(fkey); document.body.appendChild(machin); machin.submit();`. Paste it into the developer console on the same site as the comment is on, and replace `<comment id>` with the ID of the comment you want to undo your vote on.

Answer (score 1):

- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 

Dots of shame.

Answer (score 1):

Testing testing runnable script

```js
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "js"
```

```css
p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target = "_blank">Click the link!</a>
<p> :) </p>
<p id = "p1"></p>
```

Comment: uh what?? @D.Pardal

Comment: Haha sory... I was just testing [comment shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/388250).

Comment: Ah ok, got it :)

Comment: [NOOOO I WAS RICKROLLED](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umDr0mPuyQc)

Comment: @mindstormsboi :)

Answer (score 1):

Minimal example for [HTML comments breaks formatting from that point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351323/179419), but bloated in order to avoid being converted to a comment when I want it to remain as an answer.

blah

blah

**blah**

**blah**

Comment: [ask] [ask] [ask]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Formatting quotes. The markdown is this:

```
> This text is being used as a test.
> The second line is treated as part of the first line.

> The third line is kept separate from the second line, but appears like a new section of quoteblock.
>
> The fourth line is kept separate from the fourth line, but continues the same quoteblock, but is spaced "far"  from the third line.    [there are four trailing spaces here]
> The fifth line is kept separate from the fourth line, but continues the same quoteblock, but is spaced "close" to the fourth line.
```

The actual appearance is this:

Formatting quotes.

> This text is being used as a test.
> The second line is treated as part of the first line.

> The third line is kept separate from the second line, but appears like a new section of quoteblock.
>
> The fourth line is kept separate from the fourth line, but continues the same quoteblock, but is spaced "far" from the third line.
> The fifth line is kept separate from the fourth line, but continues the same quoteblock, but is spaced "close" to the fourth line.

Comment: Yeah, the four trailing spaces creating a break like a `<br />` tag confused me for the longest time. The lack of a `>` in the space creating a break in the blockquote is part of the recent [switch to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark).

Answer (score 1):

This is a test to see if the [new highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) handles certain dark corners of shell syntax better than the old one. Code snippet from [this old post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608099/remove-comments-from-file-while-ignoring-quoted-comment-signs/608110#608110). YES is a comment, NO isn't.

```sh
echo 1 # YES
echo 2 $# NO foo# NO
echo 3;#YES
# YES
cat << E
# NO
E
echo 4 " # NO \" # NO" \" # YES
echo "5
# NO
$(echo 6 # YES
)
`echo 7 \" # NO \"`
"
eval 'echo 8 # NO, then YES'
```

Answer (score 1):

"Example" domain names that trigger editor warnings:

- http://site.com
- site.com
- https://site.com
- http://www.site.com
- [www.MYDOMAIN.com](http://www.MYDOMAIN.com)
- [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)
- http://mydomain.com

Hmmm, none of these trigger warnings?!

....not on the meta site, but they do on the main site. BUT not all main sites!

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   AAA
   ```

   AAA
2. > BBB

   BBB
3. CCC

   CCC

Answer (score 1):

This is just a test answer for images.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://storage.googleapis.com/jofre-ext/public_folder/test-image.png))</sub>

Comment: @Glorfindel lol you should put exception in your script to ignore the sandbox, can't see much point fixing broken images here. (Unless of course you post them on purpose for testing, but that's not the case.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars yes, you're right ...

Answer (score 1):

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193531#193543:

To make George eat an apple, press <kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd></kbd>

Will try to add some fake references.

References:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354

Answer (score 1):

Links to all my answers:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350258/401025
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353908/401025
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356537/401025
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327315/401025
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356570/401025

I'm going to need this since I will probably delete some of these in the future. When they're deleted they won't be visible in my profile (by the way plese implement [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/401025) feature request), and it's easier to have all links in one place than to go through all the answers in the formatting sandbox until I find them.

Answer (score 1):

I've deleted 5 answers today, let's see if I can delete this one as well.

Edit: That's weird, the system let me delete 6 answers in just 5 minutes. According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85523/349538) that shouldn't be possible. Maybe it's because some of them were already deleted and I undeleted them before deleting them again.

Comment: You did trigger the automatic vandalism flag for moderators at least :P When trying to resolve the flag I looked at your profile, and indeed not all deletions show up as having been in the last 35 or so minutes, so I think the problem is indeed with the undelete/delete cycle. Still, I would not recommend posting 5 new answers to try and find that limit/message: Many deleted answers can count towards an answer ban, and while I don't know the specific rules, I know I can't get you out of that one! I can confirm the message most likely still exists, there are complaints about it from time to time

Answer (score 1):

[Anchor tag link with scroll to text fragment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370143/prevent-markdown-links-from-escaping-the-tilde-character-on-stack-exchange#:~:text=to%20identify%20text%20to%20highlight%3A)

[Markdown link with scroll to text fragment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370143/prevent-markdown-links-from-escaping-the-tilde-character-on-stack-exchange#:%7E:text=to%20identify%20text%20to%20highlight%3A)

Comment: [Edit]? hehehehe

Comment: anchor tag workaround works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Zalgo text test (overflows on desktop, clipped on mobile site)

> �̷̧̡̢̢̡̛̛̹̟̪͉͈̮̜̬͕͇̣̥̬͚͍̗͔̜̹̟̣͚͈̯͔̙͉̤̹̬͙̪̬̥͍̗̅̂̓̋͛̈́̉͆̅̎̐̾̀̈̓̿͐̂̽̍͆̆͊̊͑̆̍̔͗͛̽̓̀̏̐̽͂̅̀͛̾̃̓̽̌̎̊͐̃͐͋̌́̄̾̓̔̆̑̔́͑́̑͌̔̂̕͘͘͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅ�̶̢̡̡̢̧̡̢̧̛̛̛̪̥̮̮̜͉̲̪̮͎͈̪̞̮͉͓͇͓͕͎̠̖̞͓͓̙͍͈̝̘͇̣̳̗͈̙̻̲͈̼̳̣̝̭̭̯̖̠̩̥̖̙͎̩̹̹̝̩̦̜͈͕̝̦̟̟̖̟̭͚̪̣͔̻̹̠̫̙̼͙̯̳͎͇̙̦͔̗͈͉̫̭̳̭͓͍̻̩͎̣̘͎̱͓̤͉̟̘̲̯͙͕̰̝̩̘̳̜͎̝̞͎͙̗̣̉̀͑̽̌͐̽̀͛̅̆́͗̾̓̆̇̓̌͆̅̾͋̓́́͋͆͐͋̒͑̇͆̇͗̑̏̅͋̉͐̄̿̈́̿̿͊̅̌̀̈́̐̀̑̐̃̅̌̓͆̄̾̀́́̍̀͛̀́́̈́̍̎͋̽̓̎͗̓̏̋̉͑̂̇͂͛̀̓̈́̋̈́̓̄̾̔̌̈͆́͊̈́̈́̊͊̍͌́͒̑̉́̑̀̀͛͌̔͛̓̾͑̑̋̽̏̇͐̍́͂̑͋̃̈̒͆̇͐̎̿̽̍̑̓́̐̾̍͒̏̈́̏͋̔̏͒́̆́͊͌̈́͆̔͋͐̉͋̎̑̑̄̈́̔̑̃̌̆̅͐͂̾͑̒̒̉͒̓̒͛̍͛̉̿͌̈́͋̀̀̌̂͛̍́̿̀̃͑̊̓̏́̄̿̍̊̀̒̄́̔̎̍̈́̏͗̃̏̓͂̑͛͒͆̃͋͐̕̚̕̚̚͘̕͘͘̕͘͜͜͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅ�̸̢̡̢̧̡̨̨̢̡̢̨̧̡̛̛̛̛̛̱̥͓̳͖̮̹̗͙̬̺̜̗̺̜̻̪̞͖̦͕͖̣̠͇̥̘̥̘̰͚̭̭̥͔̱̳͙̭̘̼̝̺̗̠̻̭̣͈͙͓͍̟̩͕͓͖̣̤̯͉̠̪̲̣̠͓̦̹͓̩͕͕̗̝͖͙̺̤̟̲̙̠̮͖̘̺̪̜̖̳̘̼̩͙̫͖̠͕̯̩͎̩̜̦͈̭̫̝̜̭̩͎̠̳̟̞̟͚̻̣͈̳͉̬̰̹͖̮̝̝̮͚̯̝̾̓̐̀̌͛̂̇͗̉̿̉̍̀̎̑̽̀͛͑̈̂͗͗͛̅̈̽̏̑̈́̀̀̈́̀́̈͌͂͒̈́̈́͑̑̓͛̓͊͐̍̅̑̌̔̐̆͛̆̑̎͊͑͒́̿̋̀̈̀̏͊̈́͌̐̈́̎̿̀̆̄̄̑̓̉̃͆͊̂̂̾͛̍͑̇̈́̈̋͑̾̑͂̄̋͆̓̊͑́̄̈́̌̿̓̈́͌̏̾͛̈̽̅̽̅̃̈́͐́͛̅̎͛̒͊̒̇̆͑͆̋̐͂̂̀̈́̂̏̍̉̒͂̈́̀̋̍̓̿̀̉̔̈́̒̿͂͋͛͘͘̚̕͘̚̕͘̕̕͘͘̚̚͘͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͠͝͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅ�̴̡̢̧̢̨̨̧̡̨̧̧̨̢̨̢̧̨̨̡̨̢̡̢̢̢̧̡̛̛̛̥̦̪̬̤̭͚͕̹͚͚̮̞̞̲͕̻̠̫̼͚̘̯̥̮͉͇̠̪̭̻̰̫̠̼̭̰̼̱͓̫̲̙̞̟̮̥̭͍͕̮̫͈͍̞͉̰̺͎̻̻̱̙̭̜̰͔̦̬̭̤̙̺̩̗̼͔̞͓̼̠̤̦̙͙̳͙̝̝͚̣̙͔̞͙͔̼̬̭͚̜̠̙̺̬̥̞̙͖̩͔̫̙̹̠͕̼̬̠̲̪͚̖͓̰̥̼̳͙̠͍̬̞͕̫̯̪͕̦̘̻̦̲̟͕̲̘̱̞̫̞͇̼̦̟̗̹̹̦̺͕̫̹̳̟̙͓̹͓̼̠̮̖̼̹͈̬͕͈̬̼͎͖͕͕͕̲͔̳̖͇̪̗̹͓̠̻̦̥̖͍͙̟͔̺̱̥͖͕͔̯͍̪̮̜̣͍̣̼̲̲͍̟͇̙̥̰̝̮̟͎̪̥̺̞̗͎̠̤̝̩͖̦̯̥͈̳͓̞̻̙̮͗̿͊̇̇̀̈́̇͒̈̎̎̇͗̽̌̓͐̇̒̽̇̈̈͛͛͋͛̿̏̌̽͌̋̄̋̏͗͒̉͊̾̌̓͆̐̃̄̿͑̂̅̄̈́̀̉̀͋̇͋͗̎̂̏̀͒͐͋̽̉̆̍̒͐̀̋̅͋̾̂͛̄̆̀̈̂̄̔͒̽̋̆̒̒́̈́͒̂͆̐̂͛̈́̃̋̔͂͐̍́̂͊͑̿͌̐̌̏̈̂̀͗̈́̉̇͆̂̍̋̍̔̔͛̋̍̅̈́̌̌́̂͊͌͛̂̀̎̏́̑͛̑̾́̈́̚̚̚̚̕̚̕̚͘͘̚̚̚͜͜͜͠͝͠͝͠͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̨̡̧̢̨̧̢̧̡̧̧̨̡̛̛̛͍̮̤̳̞̯͖̦̼̤̫̰̳̖̺̬͓̖̳̼͔̼̳͕͖̦̝̤̠̤̜͕̲̹̦̩͚̠͙̻̬̯̰̹̩͚̤̟͍̲̠̤̜̞͍̜̟̫̳̦͖̳̞̮̮͖̳͔̥̝̱͎͍̹̼̳̯̻̮̜̹͓͇̲̦̖͖̳̱̬͙̰͙̰̲͉̱̘̹̙̻̦͖͓͇͔̬̦̭͔̠̟͖̜̲̰̳̦̫̠̗̗̙̠͓̞͖̖̫͕͈̰̭͕̻͓̩̙̞͖͇̺͈͎̓̃̇̆̓̉̔͛̇̑̊͑́͑̐̅́̽̓̈́̈́̅͌̔̀̉̃̋̌͛̄̇̈͆͐͊̾̉̀̏͐̐͗͋́̐̽́̌̔̏̇͑̈́̔̊̆͛͋͑̈̏̿̇̏́̎̄̔̒͒̓̓͂͛̽̑̽͋̂̿̈́͌̋̊̏͌̉͒̽̐̓̈́̽̉̔̈̃͐͋̆̈͆̑̌̑͘̚̕͘͘͜͜͠͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̨̢̧̧̢̢̡̧̛͕̙͖͍̟̥͇̦͎͕͙̳̰͇̘͉̱̰̳̺̪̲̙͙̤̦͕͎̠̭͎̪͇̰̦̭̹̠̤̠̯͚̟̗̪̞̗̪͇̬͙̪̘͉͍̗͚̺̳͚̻̬̪̘̞͚͚̳̩̳̲͕̯̼͍̣̫͕͖̞͇͉̫̩̩̜̜͚̝̙̬͉͚͙̱̮̻̳͕͖̣̰͇͓̼͓̘̝͖̻̣͉̟͙͖͔̼͔̘͓̭̘̣͕͖̗͓̟̜̹̼̘̉̒͛̃́̈́͌͆̓͛͆̅̎́̊͆̂̋̓͆̎͊͗͑͂̋͑̀͐̄͂̇͊͛̉̍͋͌̈́̏̀̅̾͛̋̎̑̔̀͐́͗́͆̒̇̃̂͑͂̈̆̚͘͜͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅ�̵̨̡̧̨̧̧̡̨̢̧̧̨̢̢̡̢̨̢̧̨̡̨̨̢̛̪̺͓̗̲̪̥̙̣̯̯̼̙̝̳͉̲̣̣̼̤̹̹̟̤̻̬̜̯̼̲̤̜̟͎̘̙̻̩͍̗̮̦̘̙̗͓̞̹̭̮̥̯̜͇̥̩͓͈͉͙̖̜̤̯͙̫͍̲͖͇͕̹̮͔̪̮͙̘̯̖͕̯̝̺̲̣͕͔͖͉̹͇̞͇̥̳̰̦̲̠̫̭̙͓̘͉̪̻̼̣͙̥̰͎̜̰̞̳͍̙͍͙̻̳̘̦̘̣̖̪̭̭̼̳̘͉̮͓̬͕̤͓̣͇̬͉͈̹̙̝̬͉̜̥̠̰̱͍̼̼̳̥̜̯͈͍͓͖͓͚͕̱̫͇̦̙̙̬͍͚̦̥̙̣͙̯̘̺̪͕͓̥̻̱̹̲̹̥̱̙͓̙͚̝̙͓̟͚̰̻̞͍̣̖͓̞̗̜̖̹̰̬͙̯̬̤̼̫̪̝̺̲̪͎̗̙̗̹͎͇͚͙̼̯̻̹̟͓̯̼̙̻͖̰̜͌́̾͐̃̔̐͌̐́̂͋̒̔̓̌͜͜͜͜͜͜͜ͅͅͅͅ�̵̨̡̡̢̧̢̧̨̨̨̢̢̡̨̡̘̟̠̫̱̞̩͔̖̖͓̩̲̯̞̣̩̹̣͕͉̲̭̫̦̰͔̜̣̜̮̜͖̠̗̳͙̹̞͈̤̙̳̦̥̙̤̘̗͈̲̻̣̮̯̩̺̮͓̭͙͇͍̹̭̞̰̦̬̗̙̗͇͔̖̠̭̞̻͈͉͇͈͔̗̮̯̘͇͔̭͖̠̻̖̳̖̥̩̼͚͈̖͈̦̟̦͔̞͙̞̼̗̩͚̹̫̱̳͇͉͚͎̱̦̦͍͈̻͚͍̖̮̲̾̑̄̏̎̔͆̓͗̀̿͂̊͊͐͒͋̂̌̀͆͛͋̄̀̓̏̀̾͆̓̈̀̽͗̎̋̔͒̽̅̅͑͛͋̇͊̑͛̚͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̧̛̛̛̛̛̳͖͚̗̦̲̝̭̞͚̺̈̑̆͌̀̌̽̍́́̈́̄͌̄̆̎͋̀̽͋̽̃̒̓͗̔͗̔̽͆̇̃̎̓̅͒͗̎̎́͒͛̂̈́̈̇̔̈́͊͒̂͌̓̔̀̃̈̌̉̓̀̊̊̄̍́͋̄̿́̋̈̄̏̅͒̒̈̈͆̏́̐̃̅̅̾̽͗͐̑̾̓͛̓̋̉̉̎̇̀̑͛̕̕͘̚̚͘̚͘̕͘͘̕͝͝͠͝͠͝͝ͅ�̶̨̨̡̡̧̨̧̢̡̢̨̨̡̧̡̢̧̡̧̨̨̢̢̧̪͕͚̱͙͓͈̳͖̠̦͖͔̝̗̖̤͍̱̲͉̭̟̬̯̬̘͈͔͇͎̼̟͉͔̣̼̺̰͓͕̖͎͖̝̜̱͕͉̻͉̪̙̰͍͙̥̯̬̪͖̱̹̯͚̦̭̘̳͕̖͖̣̣̩̟̬̬͙͙̩̪̖̫̮͚̱͍̖̯̯̭͖̬͇̤̰͎͖̥̥̦͚̳̼̮̥̺͇̤̜̲͚̥͚͖̲̬̫̳̖̩̙͖͙̬̥͎͖̖̣͇̜͎͔͇̗̳͍̻̠̠̬̯̦̤͙̯̺̣̥̻̰̩̦̖̟̭͙̤̙̤̦̗̞͇̭͇͈̗͉̲̖̮̙̟̹̱̦̮̙̯̜̟̼͎̪̲̠̠͇̻͉̩̩͇̯͚͔͍̜̜̮͓̙̯̰̠͈̙̦̇͒͛́͂̍̾̉͜͜͜ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̛̛̲͙̼̝̮̙͇̱̪͔̗̃̒͗̀̆̐͆̾̉͂̄̽͊̔̏̽͒̄̾̅́̽̈́̇̿̓̽̐̃̀́̌͒̂̇̀̂̄̈̄̂̈́̐̀̈́̎͗͆̇͆̿́͑́͒̿͂̾͛́̏̑̌̓̂̃́͊͊̒̂̅́́̆̀́̒̔̈̑̌́̋́͌̇̋́̿́̋̋̏́͌́̋̊̔̃̿̔͆̀̓̚̚̚͘̚͘̚̚̕͘̚͘͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠�̵̧̡̡̨̧̡̧̧̢̨̢̢̨̧̢̢̨̧̨̨̧̧̧̨̨͎̝̻̦͕͇͓̟͇̬̫͖͎̜̜̝̝̙͇͍̭̼̤͙͉͎̙̝͖̪͔̰̺̫͕͚̺̠̻̪̦̙̜͍̪͖̰̮̥̘̳̪̥͇̫̤͕̻̳̭̲̼̫͔̜̮͚͎͍̥̹̹̜̺͎͖̣͉̻̱̱͓̭̝̫̪̮̬̥͔̹̼͍̥̟͚̦͕̙̠̙͙͖͈̣̱̤͕̣̹̭͚̟̞͈͉͈͍͙͚̹̻̝̝̤̫̙̦̩̥̺͉̪̝̹̪̦̪̮̯̠̭̠̯̞̯̙͚̳͙̜͙̱̜̣̮̹̤͔̥̳̲̠͚̺͉̳̹̫͕͔̗̠͔̣͓͈̩͓͔̞̺̗̞̰̹̯̩̳̻̼̝͓͕̟͓̱̟̺̬̮̆̋͒̑͜͜ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̧̡̡̧̡̢̡̨̢̧̧̨̡̧̨̡̢̛̛̛̛͙̦̗̱͕̬̱͔͈̩̞͙̩͕͍͇̲̹͇͉̬̜̲̗̟̘͙͚̠̙͔̬̭̙̳͉͎̲̥̜͙̖̫͇̪̙͕̺̜͎̪̼̟̮͎̪̠̗̱̜̹͚͇̖̪̯̯͙̮̖̙̞̖̖̖̬͕̦͕͉̙̭̗̺̪̫̺̯̬̱̘̹̫̳͔̲̩͈͕͔̤̙̱̱̗̗̪̝̜͕̳̯̩͍̣͖̜͇͙̩͕̳̖̙̙̲͙̖̟̞̳̣̰̦̹̬̗̺̯̫̙͕̳̣̙̬͔͓̙̰̩̗̬̠͔̺̼̪͙̣͎̬͉͉͎̮̗̪̥̼̪̻͕͚̥̲̰̹̳̦͙̘̬͕͍̼̭̗̟̭̬̳̳͉̞̙̟̱̮͉͇͍̞͙͙͎͎̻̖̝̘̖͖̭͙̹̤͇͚͉̭̹̣̭̼̗͕̞̖̰͍͓̜̹̤͍̣̠̮͚̘͎̦̼͚͈̘̺͇́́̀̄́̃͊͗̊̉̒̽̓̇̑̉͊́̓̈̒̑̒͒͌̎͆̅̈́̓̒͒͒̈́́̓͗̑̓̃̽́͌́̿͗͊̐͊̀̀́̄̌̎́̋̌̈́̌̃̏̍͗̍͐̈́͒̀͂̄̆́̿͊̓̇͂̑́̎͌̈́̂̾̈́͆̀͌̈͛̌́̈̆̃̑́̏̋͛̃̿̈͒͘͘̕͘̚͘͘̚̕͘͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͝͝͠ͅͅͅ�̶̧̧̧̧̡̡̨̧̛̛̛̛̱͉͇̠̦̮̣̙̲̤̘̗̤̹̰͉̫͈̼͉̦̝̼̲͚͙͉̻̭͉͇͙̰̗̞̳̍̅͐̓̌̃̋̈́̾̽̓͐̅̓̀̀̂͑͒̄͑̔̆̆͂͒̅͆̂̽̃́̔̽́̿́̋̊̆̀͊͑̍̈́̊͑̈́͒͆̿̂̑̊͐̓̅͆̊̊̃̐̍̔̾̿̂͛̓͒̑̿͆̿͛̾̀̃̆͋͗̅̈́̄͗̒͂̓̾̾͑̎͐͋́̓̐͗͊͑́͛͂̾̃͐̀͐̑̃̎͊͊͊̾̽̂̀̐͆̈́͒̏̃̌̀̽͊̄̃̔̈̍̃̆̈́̎̈́͊́̚͘̕͘̕͜͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͝�̶̨̢̡̨̧̡̧̨̢̨̡̡̧̨̢̢̡̨̡̧̢̧̡̧̧̧̡̢̛̛̛͙̣̮͍̱̝̥͈͇̱̬͓̻͓̺̞̯̺̬̜̤̝̪͔̩̩̘͙͈̠̲̱̠͎̰͍̱̻̯̦͕̙͇̬͕̦̫͚̙̝̘̮͎̞̖̲̼͙̠͔͓̲͙̥̖̜̹͇͖͈̝̞͕̻̯̝̣̣̭̹̝̟͔̻̥̻̫̯͚̟̦̰͖̞͇̭͖̰̥̙̻̘̠̭͕̲̩͇͍̜̳̻̺͚̤̭̘͔̱̩̹̰̥̲͓̮̺̟̮̫̝͖͍͚̦͉͎̙̥͔̥͎͖̲͎̟̼̤̘̱̦̰͎̱͎̟̹̰̫̲̥̤̜̝͖̜̙͖͚͎͈̦̺͈̺̙̹̤̻̝̭̥̰̺͍̺͚͎͓͚̱͍̥̲̳͍̩̎̇͗́̃̋̆͆̐͛̎͛̾̅̾͛̓͆̓̃̇̊͛͛̑̆͐̏̎͗̐̍̌̋̀̊͒͌̃̔̃̋́͑̂̓͊͆͑̐̃͋̀̏̃͆̑̐̐̋́́̀̈̑́͋͆̓̅͐̐́́͗̆̑͋̏̒̄͐̇̉̑̇͌̎̌̔̐͆̌̒͛̿̄͒̂͒̂̓͒̔̽͂̓͋̍̈̔̋̿̂̽̓̏́̃̀̀͂͛̎̽̿̂̎͛̅̉̑͒͐͐̓̎̿̒̍̐̿͛̌̂̿͌̃̐́͊͒͒̐̎͂̒̓̆̎͆͋̒̈́̀̽̈́̉͋̃̈̄̍̾̓̒̈͆́̚̕̚̕̕͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͠͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̧̨̢̡̢̡̧̡̢̛̛̛̛͈͓̞̯̟̳̲̱̰̠̖̳̤̼͖̬̟̰̤͓̹͙͎͎͓͈̲̘͍̩̟̟͍̹̰͖̬̱̟̱̬͚̘̱͓̠̝͉̤͍̪͉̩̠̱̹͍̥̣͚̙̻͖̟̙͈̲̯͎͕̪̦̭͉̟͖̟̹̮̙̝͖̼̥̫͔̬͕̺̐͗͌̒̀̓́͗̀́̽̊̆̈́͛̓͛̉͆̏̈̎̓̄̈́̓̈́̿͛́͐̎͒̎̎̀͑̌̂̄̑̿̅̀̋̈́̔̃͆̆̾̓̊͂̌̔̏͒͋́̌̑̽̏̾̓͗́̅͂̇̓̇̇͆̍̒́̃̀̎͗͒̃̀̊͐̒̏̍̒̂͒͑̋̅̕̚̚͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͝ͅ�̷̢̡̢̧̧̢̢̢̨̡̨̡̨̡̢̢̧̧̡̧̢̨̨̧̛̛̛̛̛͖͇̣̞̣͍͙̺̳͔̗̻̮͕̗͍̱̝͈̥͙̘͍̖̭̩̻̜͔̖̜̫̳̗̝̯̮̠̝̥̜̪̟̖̟̙͍̠̖̻͍̩̯̬͈̥̥͎̫̜̦̱͈͙̩͔͙̤̟̻͓̖̣̬͖͔̹̩̺̰͔̫̙͔̰͓̦̩̬̘͇͚̖̭̹͎̖̤̙̣̱̦̺̼͍͎̪̠͇̬̟̭̺͚̮̟̮̼͔̙̖̳͎͖̲̲̥͚̘͈̭͎̬̜̻͕̮̞͓̹̝̼͍̪͖̜͙͍̯͎͈̱͕̜̫̳̥̗̈͒̇̄͂̊̋̍̈́̅͋̉͒̂̈́̋̈̆͗̉̊̊̿̒̏̌͛̌̾͗̀͐̒̈́́̾͋̽̀̄̐̎̓͐̈́̅̅̈́̿̀̀̿̍̋͑͒̔̒̄̈͂̌͛̋͂͋̈́̀̋̏̋̒̄̉̌̏́͗̇̃̑̉̊͊̓̀̋̆̈̾͗̋̃̇̐̉̾͗̃̔̀̃̐̒̿͐͆̋̍̒͂̀̽̀̓̄͗͆̈́̓́͌̌̈́̊͊̏̒̐̋͌̏͌̌̿͒͗̾̇̔̔͑͆̀̊̃̿̾̇̐͑̂̎̆̈́̈́̌̂͗͊̎͋̆̓̀̀́̇̍̅̾͌̊̓̓̅͊̋̿͊̀̀͂͒͆̈́̊̿̿̊̊͊̏̅̀͂̃͆̾͂̇̓̔͒͐̉̕̚̕̚̚̚̚͘͘͘̕̚̕͘͜͝͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅ�̵̢̨̨̨̨̻̹̞̙̮̭̻̥̱̙̦̻̞̘̻̞̭͍̝͔̤̪̮͙̖̮̘̻̙̩̤̘̗̤̜̼͇̬͈̻̖̖͈̮͕̩̟̱̠̱͍̫͎̥̟̓̓́́͜͝ͅͅ�̷̡̢̧̧̡̡̧̧̢̢̨̧̧̨̡̢̧̡̢̡̧̨̧̨̨̡̧̢̧̡̮̱̠̭̱̳̤̼̠͉̹͕͈̯͕̦̞̝̠̫̥̪̪̯͔̭̩̣͇̬̜̝̪̫̲͇̖̤̙̺͖̹͇͔̻̼͍̗̭̣̲̣͉͔̟͚͓̞̗̫̼͈̲̙͕̰̲͉̯̪̠͓̯̬͍̣̖̻̳͇̰̤̠͚͔͖̰̘͎̱̪͖̻͇̱̹̯̱͖̮̼̤̭̦̘͙̗͓̮̦̙̺͉̥̠̟̻͕̺͇̭̣̣̻͎͍̼̼̥̜̭̼̦̯̬̱͎͎̱͎͍͙̰̪̩̣̞̻̯̯̙̱̯̦̟̤̯̻̲̲̯̮̣̥̠̻̘̘̦̝͙̲̹͖̰̥̣͇̟͓͓͈̺̲͓̤̭͇͉̙̙͍̳͕͇͙͍̩͕̙͔̱̤̫̺͉̞̱̪̰͓̲͉͖͔͎̲̳͓̳͚̗̟̟̤͙̳̭̥̭̲̤̳̲̟͍͚̼̘͙͍͓̀̂̋̈́̓͜͜͜͜͝ͅͅͅͅ�̸̧̢̡̧̨̧̧̧̢̧̢̨̢̡̢̨̧̭͙͚͙̫̟͍͎͉̳̬̺̭̘͈̳̯̖̯̬̘̱̗͇̦̲̺̗̲͓̬͉̯̬̘̙̮͕̣̠̬̫̗̝̭̘̰̤̼̝̤̬͔̥̻͖̭̼̭̤͔̠͎͙̱͙͕̩͍̮̱̱̮̗̟̭̗̠̜̼͇͓̪̺͈͕̤̮̮̤̘͔̣͇͚͕̩̳̲̦̫̼̙̺͓̺̪̜͖̠̮̥͇̟͖̱̤͇̼͕̻̰͕̩͙̠͍͇̰̯̮̟͖̺͍͔̮͓̻̲͓̭̬̭͉̲̱̹̝̼̦̘̹̼̗̣̰̥̻͈̻̺̙̼͕̦̖̳̩̫̜̹̻̘̥̺̲̟̫͙͔̰̏͂̾͒̓̎͑̄͊̇̽̀͑̏́͐̏̃̈́̔̋͑̓̉̀̍̓̈́͌̉̔̈́͋̒̂͛͊̄̈́̚̚̕̕̕͘͝͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̨̧̨̨̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̦̙̻̟̞͍͕̤̤͖̹̦̬̜͈̹̘͕̲̫̘̻͕̘̪͔͈̻̜͈̤̼̞̫̺͓͍̦̰͇̬̳͇̮̞̮͚̗̫̺̮͓̻͖̠̭̦͇̮̪͉̬̥̮̙̝̮̟̹͙̯͆͛̓̿̍͂̋̔̊͗͑̓̐̀͆̓̍̔̀̆̽̿̈́̎͌̉̏̀͗͑̎̋̔͌͗͐̍̾̾̾̆̉̈́͋́̿̔̒̑̾̂̀͑̓͌̍̄͊̓́̅͊̔͗̎͊͑̇̈́̃͗͗͗́̒́͐͐̅͆͂̐̿̏̿̓̉̐̂̽̎͊́͛̓̅͛́́̋́͐̔̐̆͒̀͊̉̀̈̒͋̀̄̓͋̄̓̐̍̋̎́̔͌͐̽̍̋̍̀̈́̋͋̓͋̚̕͘͘͘͘͜͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͠͝�̷̧̨̨̧̨̡̨̢̢̡̧̨̢̢̨̨̧̨̡̨̡̡̡̧̧̨̡̛̛̛̛͖̩̦̲̞̺̜̭̭̣̲͔̮͚̙̮̯̘͖̤̲͖̱̝̟͓͔̯̣͚̭̯̬̟̹̬̤̹̜͓͍̱͖̼̮̱̭̖̙̹̬̦̼͇̪̹͓͚̞̙̺͎͈͎͍̱̼͉̼͎̬̜͔̼̯͍̘͎̤̺̩̫͔̻͚̗̭͈̳͉̩̯͕̲̮͈͈̲͖̳̲̲̹͈̩̰͕̟͎̗̤̜̟̭͕̤̟̘̣̻̦̺̤̪̦͕̝̤̹̣͇̗̦͈̳̜͚̫̘͍̪̻̖̪̻̪̘͙͉̼̺̤̮̼̞͖̜͕̹̜̪̜̜̳̳̤̦̝͉͖̰̱̫̤̻͙̝̪̫̜͉͔̯̙̱̮̩͎̙͈̜̘̥̭͚̹̯̤͍͕͙͙͍̝̘̤̺̜͖͍̠͈̯̤̻͎̹̘̦̬̜̞̱̟̖̺̳̻̼̙̔̊̈́̉̾͌̂̓̒̂̉̂̉͆͛̃̒̿̉̿͒̍͆̒̓́̈̈̒́̄͋̊̄́̎͋̒͐̽̒̓̌͒̋̅̓́̾͑̀̅̉̃̀͋̌̃̑͊̂̓̅̃͂̈̏̌̇̔̄̓̂͛̂͛̏̽̍̃̄̒̆͌͊̐͆̎́͊̇̑͊̃͗͊̎͛̎̿̈́͗̎̆͑͋̑̋̈̇͂͑̊͂͒̓̒̓͋̈͑̆͂̀̇̊̂͂̾̂͋̄͛̏̉̋̅̔́̐͌͑͆͂̒̓̍́̌̿̅̿̋̈́̓̈́̿̄͛̓͋͋̇͆̔͊̑̈́̇͐̋́̂͒͛̈̔̌̈́̓̀̂̇̌̐̍̂̋̔͛̀͊̒̊͒̕͘̕̕͘̚̚̚͘̚̚̕̕̚̚̕̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͠͠͠ͅͅ�̸̨̢̨̧̢̢̧̨̡̧̨̨̨̨̢̨̧̨̡̛̮̭̯̞̞͇̜̞̯͎͔̫̱̭̫͔̜̫̘͈̲͔̥͈̖̗̥̙̯̺̥͙̳̰͚̦̤͉̺͚̗̞̲̝͔̫̼͉̥̫̰̳̝̣͙̙͈͔̬̺̭͔̭̞͚̱̤̰͖̰̪̣̙͖̱͇̺̭͎̙̟͈̖͍̖̙̺̲͕̩̻̭͎̰̗̪͙̩͔̘̝̫̫̹̳̘̹̪̜̙̥̹͕͖̞̳̠͇̘̗͍̤̻̖͇͈̻̦͕̬͕̖̙̘̬̬͓̝͈̣̻̟͔͉̳̞̣̜͕̻͔̘̤̲͕̠̣͖̹̩͖̖̺͕͈̦̮͓̯̭̼͕͍̖͕̞͉̳̜͙͆͋̇̒͑̎͂̋̌͆̋̔͐̓͗̂͑̉̂̇̏̽̒͌̉́̔́̿͛͊̓̉̌̈̉̀͌͆̏̀͋͂̌́͊͗̀̅̋͂͑͑̆͒̀͒̈́̀́̊̇̔͂͛͑̇͂̇̏́́̇͊̌̎̑̀̊̌̀̋̊̑̑͆̊̀̀̑͌̉̿̉̋̅́̍̇̄̄̇͑͑̒̐̋͊̋̊͗͛͊̏͗̄̓͊̾̓́̓͆͂̈́̊̎̆́̊̈́͌͌͋̿̑̀̂̎͘̕̕̕̕̕̕̕̕̕͘̚̚̚̕̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅ�̸̡̨̧̧̡̧̧̡̛̲̫̤̫̞͇͎̫͈̝̝͔̥͍͖̜̯̹̣̘̬̮͖̻̥̻̲̬̟͎͚͍͍̗̰̤̬̻̲͍̰̩̰̞̗͓͙̜͇̗̭̬̩̘͈͓̥̺̞̘͓̪͎̜͔͚͚̯̆͋̏̈́̈́̿̔̾̍̄̕͜͠�̴̨̡̨̢̢̢̡̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̟̘̦̣̺̠̲͍̝̪̮̩̞̬͉̯̺͈̱̩͔̩̪͚̳͙͇͇͙̼̣͙̬̥͉͕̦͚̣̟͚̞̣̙͖̫̮̺̩͙̞̠̖̟̟̱̫̝̞͎̩͈̝̭̹͇̤͔̭̻̪͇̟̞̤̣̭͓͇̬͙̘̠̱̰̖̦̹̭̅̋̐̃̄͑̊̃́̎̐̄͋̎̾͒̿̎͒̒̌̓̏̏̽̑͋̆͒͊̈́͛͒͑̓͛̊̑̊̑͌̐̉̊̓̏͐̇́̈̈́̂̈́̔̈́̔̽̇͗͗̋̈́̓͒̄̐͒͆̀̈́͆͗́̋͆͂̒̎̉̾̑̓͒̑̆͐̇́̃̊̏̾̄̈͐͗̿͋̉̋̈́̾̆͗̈̔̈́̊̈́̇̈́̃̍̊̈͌̑̀͛̀̒̆̂̎̃̃̄͛͑̍̓͌̾̌̈́̏̽̑́̑̾̔̈̔̏̏͐̿͆̈́̉̍̇̅̀̓́̊̀̀͆̆̈̀̔̅̓́͌̓̂̆̅̒̈́̎̆͌̄̈̀̍͆̑̔͆́̾̒̽͊͒̃͗̒̊̏͛̀̀̃̐̉̎͊͊͌̌̈́̈́̎̃̈̉͆̅̀̉͌͆̄͌̅͛̽̓̏͗͂̈̄͋̒̀̈́̋̌̏́́̉̕͘͘̕̚͘͘͘̕͘̚͘͘̕̕͘̕͘̚̚̕̕͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͠͠͝�̶̨̢̧̨̨̨̡̡̧̨̢̡̧̧̡̨̧̧̨̨̡̧̡̧̢̛̛̛̬͇̲͍͙̘̖͕̯͓̼̫̹̩͚͚̫̹̯̭̥͍̹͖̬̜̳̹͈͇̣̩̲͍̣͖͇̬̪̱̭̭͈̤͎͖̬͚̗̻̬̺̬̮͚̤̥͉̼͉̰̦̝̻̹͖̩̤̗̦͚̩̦̲̹͔͕̝̞̪̻̜̝͔̮̱̼͔͇̗͖͉̯̣̘͔͕̱̲̜̲̩͈̻̺̩̰̦͉̗̤̦̰̯̳͎̪̘̣̝͕̖̫͙̩͔͔̦̮̜͓̣̹͙̭͚͎̣̲̞̼͓̜̪̩̯̘̰̻̬̩̤̘͓̼̜̲͔͎͍̳̮̪̦̠͉̝̰̜̳̳͓̪̮͓̰̥̳̰̗̤̜͙͔͙͓̜̙̤͚͍̬͕͚͇̰̬͉͓̳͙͚̞̻̬͔͓̞̜̯̱̘͖̟̖̣̮̈́̄́̓̎͒̄̎͆̓̋̃͑̇͛̀͗͌̔̔̾̅͋̊̑́̽̎̏̆̈́̆͗̍̈͐̌̋̎̾͆̚̚̕̕͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̸̢̡̡̡̢̧̢̧̢̡̧̨̡̡̧̨̡̛̛̛͍̞̣̤̦͇͈̣̩̦̦̲͔̖͕͈͇̮͔̥̼̼̝̟̙͓̤̙̤̣̦͈͈͚̗̺͙͓̦͔͇̖̜̞̘̳̣̱̹̣̰̰̹͚͍̟̞͓̮̖̮̗̹̦̠̥͙̯̙̙̗͓̭̫͔̫̙̼͎͙̣̰̤͔͇̻̖͙̬̼͈̦͖̳̳̲̦̭̬̞̦̹̹̺͔̜̮̞̻̫͚͍̲̳̟͈̪̻͕͖͓̜̲̘̦̠̪͔͇̥͚͈̪͚̜͈̭͚̲͍̠͉̞̯͙͕̟̹̤̭̣̹̹͔͍͉̘͚̱̩̪͓͇̳̬̫̲͚͖̙̯̄́̔̽̇̒̃̉̒̏͑̎̊͛͒̅̌̉̓̽̐̾̂̄̌̔͌̉͗̓͂̎͒̈́̀̋̀̆͗̌̇̌̾̈̓̂͊͆̊̐͑͂̀̐̀͋͛̀̓̿̀́̏̊̾̋̑̋̇͂̿̑̔͒̄̾̋̐̅͋̃̃̐̎̽̈́̄̉̎͗̈́̀̃̽̒̒͐̆̐́̋̾̉̔̾̂̌͊͒̆̈́͆̇̍̆̈́̎̊̅̎́̄͒͂̉̃̐̒̔͛͑́̈́̓̽̏́̑̊̂̂̆͑̾̽̆̃̃͗͆̌̑̓̒̌͑̓̋̉̌͋̔̔̌͂̀͛͂̇̀͒̈́̈́͛̐͐̿̎͌̇̇̈́̈͐̃͂̍̒̍̈́̄̇̉͗̈́͗̉̇̃̿̓̊̓̐͐̑̃̌̈́̉̿̏̈́̈́̍͗́̓̅̎̈̃͊͛̂͆̽̅͂̎͐͒̀̿͂̈̐̀̊̔̑̆͋̂̓̊́̍̒͋̃́̋͊̾̏͛͊͘̕͘͘͘̚̕̕͘̕͘̚͘͘̕̕̕͘͘̕͘̕͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͠͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̡̧̢̨̧̨̢̨̡̡̨̨̡̨̛͇͉͈̠͔͚̞̯̰͇̺̯̟͎̝̫̯̪͙͖̜̯̼͈̙̭̥͈͈̗̘̗̗̟̗̫̱̭̞̹̟̤̹͖͈̳͓͓̬̺̮͉͍̩͍͕̬̥̰̰̥̦̯̲̲̫̘̰̰̜͙̤͍̙̖̺͓̭̜͕͖̮̗̲͓̝̪̺͍͖͇̰̜̳̦̜̘̜̪̗̭̹̲̥͙͍̺͕͓̥͈͈̪̹̯̩̭̰͉̰̙͉̝͙̫̫̤͍̖̬̅̃̾͛̆̅̍͋͂͌́̊̃͐̈̿̾́̒̓̈́̎̅̉͋͋́͊̿̔̿̔̃͐̂͌͋͋̅̇͆̓̂̄̏̐̈́̀̾͛̾̔̂͐͂͆̊̀̽͂͛̈́̄̓̽͐̋́̿̀̽̉̐̿̓́̿̋͌̀̉͂̃̾͒͊̈́̈͆́̈́́̊̓̆̐͑̆̔͘͘̚̚̕̕̕͜͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̡̨̡̡̧̨̧̧̧̢̨̡̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛͖̥͓̭͓̦͙̘̙̘̖̻̫͎͓͎̪̥͍̹̼̳͎͈̮̩͔̖͈͙̭̜͎̜̖̙̟̼͈͖̫͖̠̤͙̘̪̦̗̺̤̖͉͍͉̯͖̩͔̲͉̖͖̪̰̺̭͕̗̬̭͙͙͈̱͚̹͚̮̥̖̟͈͉͍̬͇͍̬̞͎͍̥̙̝̹̦̘̞̭̜͍͖͔̦̰̫̘͈̝̙͚̘̦̟͉͕̼͖̯͓̝̝̖̪͇̹̙̖͇̳̭͔̗͆̃̋̉̆̀̎͐̓̃͂̌͑́̋̈́̌̅̍̄̎͒͑̈̍̐̋̊͒͊̒̎̔̒̃̓̀̈́̏̊̇̄̊̔̍͒̎̈͋͌̀̅̀̍̓͒̆̂̈͗͌̒́̊̃̑͑̾͂̓̄͋̀̄͒̔͛̋̽͊̈́̀̌͛̈̿̓͌̎̊̈́͂̏̐͌͆͋͛̋̿͗͗͑̆̓̉̂̿̓̿̾̐̍́̌́̏̌̾̐͂͌̋̇̀̍͗̒̓͂̌͂̄̆͒̄̽͛̓͐̎̏̋͐̿̒̌͒̊̇̊̿͑̃̀̂̂́̏͂́̐̈́̓͂́̋̄̂͛̍̃̇̇̑̅̐̔̐̅̈̋̚͘̚̕̕̚̕͘͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̢̢̢̡̨̡̧̢̢̡̢̨̨̢̧̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̹̙̲̬̞̻̬̳͉̭̩͇͖͍͕̺̞̞̗̜̳̝̮̮̜̺͓͕̳͔̭͉͙͔͉̱̲͔̘̰͎̱͕͓̭̰̹̖̬͓̻̰̳͉̗̙̗͙̤͓̣̤̤̫̞̯̙͔̜̣̭̫͚͇̩̻̱̫̗͙̱͍̺̼͚̗͉̤̖̩̘͙̳̜̫̤͍̙̘̭̠͔̞͔̗͉͕̳̗͔̳͇̦̖̰͇̲̺̭̹̗͕̩̰͎͈̗̲̦͎͈̣͚̣͚̥̝͚̝͎̙̤̻͖̯̞̅̆̊̆̈́̎̓̽̀̈́͐̿͐̏̍̄̈́̓̋̔͛̇̊̀̄̀̋͛̈́̔͑̐̈́͂̒͛̓̎̉͋̂͋̋͒̌͌͗͛͌͆͂̉͐͑̔̈́͗̄̾͆̈́̐̔͐̑̐̈́̀͆̓͌͑͛̋̌̀̍͐̓̋̀̄̿́̌̐͗͆͌͌̀̊̂̽̓̔̈̍͒͆́̓̔́͑̂̑̀̌̅́̾͗͛͌͐͐̔͋̆̎͛͐͊͐̈̏͑͒̀̄̊̅̅̽̾͆̂̅͆͋́̌̽̉̾͒̑͗͋̅̇́͛̀̓̂͆͒̇̏̓͋͗̂̓̊̏͊̈́̿̈́͌̊̎̒̀́͑̇̀̉̌̚̚̚̕̕̚̕͘̕̚̕͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͠ͅͅ�̸̢̨̧̧̡̨̢̡̨̡̧̨̛̛̙̣̼͚̘̹̺͉̪̰̘̰̲̻̖̗̣̯̯͎͇͉͕͇̲̖̘͔͈͉̘͚̮̟͉̠͈̬̻̫͔̳͍̰̺̜̗͚̭̩̺̤̬̣̼̳̲͓̖͙̼͉͖͎̝̘͕̳̫͖̝͈̬̰͎̤̤̤̗̥̲̺͉̲͓̤̝̮̳͚͓̹̻̝̱̬̣̲̣̦̙̗̲̻̙̮̤̬͖̝͉̩̗̲̦̘̰̼͚̥̦̗͔̫̦͎̫̦͖̙̖͙̜̻͕̭̣̲̳̯̲͓̜̲͔͓̪͉̦̖͙̮̫̲͔̳̞̰̯͍̱͈̋͛͑̋̓͆͒͛͐̐̆͐̾̏͋͂̀̓̂̒̐̅̈̉̄̇͑̿͊̈́̓̀͐̉̽́̈́̌̅̊̄̑̽̓̄͆͊̿̈́̕͘̕̕͜͜͜͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̨̢̡̧̡̧̨̨̧̨̡̧̧̢̧̧̺̫̦̳̣̮̗̗͚̥̦̟̩͔̹̞̘͚̤̗̱̪̞̠̞̠͕̝̤̘̟̰̬̻̟͖̮͓͕͕͍̣̼͙̣͇̣̱͖̮̱̪̙̭͉͍̱̙̩̻͇͖͍̫̘̘͇̺̳̟̬͕̱̳͎̖̙̖̘̲̟̪͈̩̟̠͍̩̪̟͇̞̪͍̱̰͉̩̦̯̺͎͎͈̭͚̭̜͚̹̦̪̙̩̬̦̣̬̹̻̥̠̱͖̖̤̬͈̖͖̲͖̤̘̞̦͇͍̟̦͍̫̭̣̪͇̭͖̞̜̩̪̥͚̘̯̙̦̺̘̯̪̰̯̗̭͉̜͚̤̰̙̤̭͈̳̩̤̦̦̼̹̺͇̫̮̞̯͔̪͍̤̟̬͈͍͈̰̻̻̞͍̣̩̤͔̮̘͓͚̮͕̝̥̯̦̍͊̆̎̉̏̐̊̍͋͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜ͅͅͅ�̴̧̢̧̨̧̨̨̡̧̢̢̨̨̡̡̨̢̨̢̡̨̡̨̧̡̢̢̛̜̦̝̥̰̳̺͇̹͚̖͈̰̠͕̼͙̳̟̠͔̜̹̼͈͍͙̳̟̳̦͓̜̪͍̘̩̬͈̖͖̬͚̗͔̼̥̺͔͕̥̭̱̜͎̼̪̲̻̳̤͎̝͍̝̤͕̫̥̲͚̘̱͇͇͇̟͕̞͈͓̗̜̗̣̬͔͇͚̬̘̤̜̜̥̫̭͕̻̣̝̦̰̪̺͓̞̜̣̘͉͓̺͔̱̣̘͎͍͚̖̠̟̙̦̩̟͍̯̜̲̼̻̘̘̯͍̥̬̭̳̹̗̳͙͔̭̟̮͚̥̪͍̬̜͈̪̼̟̺͍͉͔̦̘̳̜̘̹̩̹̤͔̜͖͎̝̻͖̪͔͚̮̯̜̙̤̖̹͕̙̲͖͓̤̗̞͉̰͎͓͍̞̙̫͇̰͉̼͓͔̙̝̦̜̘̳̲̗̩̠͉͉̘̜̪̼̖̣̞̻͓̮̞̮͙̟̼͖̥͇̪̣̰͈̃̎̐̎̋͋̌͛͛͂̏͆͑̇̄̄͊̂̍͗̑̑͗̒̑̅̈́̀̃͛̏́͋̊̀̒̑̒̾͂̂͗̊̏̆̂́̀͋̀̽̕̚͘͘̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̢̨̧̨̧̨̡̡̢̧̡̡̨̡̡̡̢̡̢̨̧̧̨̨̧̨̡̨̧̛̛͚̼̳͉̯͉̝͎̩̝̭̠̘̮͔̫̖͖̣͙̘͔̪͉͙̹̤̗͈̰̲̭̰̝̳͙͇͚͙̟͇̼̼̪̞̦̥͙̤̼̲̤͍̮̜̻̯̙̺̣͈̗̬̹̣̱͍͇̦͚̩͕̖̹̖̰̼̩̭̙̥͎̤̩̝̜̭͕̜̬̰͙̪̥̯̥̦̬̖̲͍̠̼̝͚̗͇̰̩̭̱͇̼̬̝̺̥͈̣͙̫̖̪̯̭͎͖͓̱̫̻̖̮̪̤̰̝͇̦̹͔̟̺̹̱̹̜̰͖̦̼̠̳̣̭͉͙̖͖̜͔̙͙͇̞̞̠͔̭͇͇͇̪̙͎̠̯̯̝̪͈̩̖͔͈̠͉̣̖̭̤̮͎̖̯͚̠̪̲̟̲̦̙̺̝̤͇̼̟̹̳͈̝̬͎̭̺̳̜̟̩̼̩͇̭̞̝̙̘̹̳̣̳̫̬̝̲͔̫͍͗̇͊̎̃̄͊͆͋͆͆͌̓̀͆̈́̎͂͗̑̏́̊́̊̓̉̾̐̌̑͌̎̃̒͂̈́̓̐̈̋̾̐̏͆̎͗̆̊̉̄̎̒͌͂͆̅̀̀̋̏̿̍́̇̒̊͒̃̔͊̈́̈̈́̆͆̔̾̈͑̕̚͘̕̚̚̕̕͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠ͅͅͅ�̸̡̡̧̢̢̢̨̢̡̨̨̨̨̨̨̢̨̧̨̡̛͕̼͖̝̯̜̫̞̹̭̥͈̙̖͚͖̩̜̜͓̹̠̫͇̫̗̬̜̠̘͙͍̼͈̤̜̭͉̻̘̹̟̻͎̗̖̖̣͇̯̼̺̫̰̰̯͉͕̣̥̞̩͖̟̤̖̳͕͓̖̳̥̯̺̦̲͍͍͖̩̙͔̪͍͖͓͙͙̞͕̟͖͔͎̭̘͎͓͎̪͉̤̦͍̱̱̥̬̻̼̙̬̺̥̠̩̠̦̣͍̻̼͉̭̯̭͖̩͎̪̯̜̪͍̬̮̪̭̘̼̳̠͚̭̹̗͓̠̫̼̖̗̦̗͕͎̮͈̤͓̥͍̹͍̳͎͉̲̝̬͕͈̯͕̬̥̯͍̹̮͓̺̠̪̣̞͍͍̙̬̩̖̮͎̠͖͉͈̳̩̗͙̙̘̩̙̤̲͕͎͎͉̞͖̪̟̮͚̟̐̋̀͋̉̏̓͐̿̈̆̌̄̀͌͊́̆̈̈̆̾͐̾̓͆́͗̇̾͐̓̄̒̎̈́͐͛͋̈̉̓̿͑̈́̈͆͗̈́͐͐̌̄̃̍̈́̅͛̂̈́̄͗̀̃̏̂̆͗̄̓̇̉̔̊́͑̾̃͐̓̾̅̾̉̔͋̾̈́́͆͒͐́̈́̓̓͌̽͒̾́̋͆̍̈́̊̉̔̈̋̉̃̒̏̀̅̓͊͒̑̒͌̂̍̏̌̀̓̿̽̾̾́̉̊̈́̉́̈͗̀̎̌̊͋͊̃̎͒̏̆̂̑̄̈͐͑́̓̀̌͗͋͊͛̃̍̒͆̽͑́̄̅̊̅̐̈̂̆̋̅̀̕͘̕̚̚̕̚̚̕̚͘̕͘̕̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͠ͅ�̶̧̨̨̨̡̢̢̧̡̨̧̡̢̧̢̡̨̧̧̢̡̡̧̧̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̠͙̖̥̠̞̱̣͉̫̱̘̘̼̟̘̣̝͉̰͍̮̖̻̥̭͈̤̘̺̣̩͎̳̰̠͔̼̦̹̫̪̦̻͚͔̬̮̯̱̰̲̻̹̙̹̤̘͈̰̺͎͚̞͍̞̖̣̦̙̺̙̲͎̼͓̰̯͙̲̬͕̱̣͖̩͙̻̜̲͙̹̥̭̭̞̺͇̰͇͎̰̗̜̰̩̼̜̤̬͇͖͇̦͓̮̩͙͎̹̳̲͚͖̫̥̭̫̩͔̤̩͎̣̥̙̭̲̤̜͚͎͚͍̜̼͔̮͇͓̭̣̥̥̭̻͙̪̙̥̼̲̬͕̮̪͈̲̼͙̖̣͖̟̞̻͖̣̤̖̝͉̳̖͇̥̜̙̞͚̫̘̯͔͉̝̖̝̯̣̜̻̹̼͉̠̫͕̱̜̫̍͒̅̒̓͛̄̑̔͂̈́͐̃́̑͊͊̑͊̇̊̀͒̌̈́̊͐̊̒̈́͂̈́͐͒̽͛͑̉̒̈́̄̀̿̈́̍̒͊͌́͆͒̀͐̔̃̀̇̏̇̓̀͋̽̍́̓̓͌̏͊̆͂̄͂̾̒́͆͗͐̂̾̑̋́͊͛̊̊͒̓͆̈́́̿̋̏̏͑̀̐͒͂̐́̈̾͗̆̒̀̍̏͊̍͂̄̈́͐̐̇̄̍̑́̋̑͐̈́̋͛̿͊̽͑̂̆̅̈́͗̒̏̇̀̌͂̽̓̎͊͂̈́̈́̏͑̋͋̈́͂̍͐̊̑̔̾́̿̍͒͛̏̔̀̾̏̒̏̀̓̆̿̏̒͒̈́̆̌̑̓̒̂̐̈́͐͌̔̓̅̀̀̋̓́̈̾̐̽͋̓̆̐̑̃̐͊͛̊̍̃̿̄̀̇̕̚͘̕̕͘̕͘̚̕͘͘̕̕͘̕̚̚̕̕͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̧̡̢̡̧̨̢̢̡̧̢̨̨̡̧̨̧̢̢̛̛̛͍͎̼̗͕̬̱̻̜̹̼̝̠̣̖̙̪̰͕̭̥̞͔̙̫̞̠͇̱̺͉͕̹̼͔̩̮̰̗̪̻̭̱̻͙̠̤̞̩̠͖̤̲͍̠͖̣̻̯͎̯̲̣͚͙͙͎̗̲̼̱̗̯̭̥͎̣̘͓͍͔͉͎̱̞̘̘͕̻͓͓̗̹̼͔̻͕̮̖̟͎̹̪̮͓̰̖̠̟̭̯̜͇͖͉̤͖̭͖̙̭̝̠͈̲̘̞͕̦͙͓͖͍̮͖̲̬͙̞͎̳͖̬̭̠͉̭̫̮̥̱͓̻͔̲͙̦̤̻̠̣͇̱͔̯̝̹̲̣͖͔̼̤̠̹͇̦̹̖̙͕̣̤̳̪̲͇̦̘̰̣̝̜͍̗̣̎̈͌̿̊̎̑͆͐͗͑̈́̂̾̏͋̈́͛̿̍̔͆̿͂̅̋̔̐̍̇̀̐̇̅̾̽̇̾̂̆͗̅̓͂̏͆̓̓͒́̀̅́͂͒̎͗̆̍̔̂̋̀̐̂̑̎͛͒͑̒̽̔͋͊̈̿̍̌͑̀̉̊͂̄̒͋̎̈́̋͌͑̄̊̇͒̽͂͋̇̈́̈́͋̀̽͋̂̽͑̈̾̈́͊̽̓̓̏̌̋̿̀͒̽̌̍͒̃̓̏͗́̋̋̄̉̍̓̎̿͑̽̆̏́͂̓̿̋͐̿̅̎̽͗̅̏̇̊̌̈́̈̈́̽͌́͐̏̑̈́̍͑̀̆̾̆̉̄̅́̈͐̅̇̉͒̐͛̅̀̇͋̋̿͑̀̉̈́̃́̑̾͐́́̾̅̆̽̽͒͗͑̐̐̓̀̚̕̚̕̚̚̕̚͘͘̕̕̚̕̚̚͜͜͜͜͜͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̷̛̛̛͇̝͙͎̖̀͛̒̄̀͊̈́̐̐͑̈́͌̏̐̈́̓̓̉̊̍̂͑͐̆͂͊͑͊̌̎̍͛̔̈̏̊͊̀̒͊͂͋̈́̆̔̏̋́̅͑͋̒̎̈́̀̈̊̒̄͂̈́̃̀̀̈͂̓͛̎̐̑̈́̅̌̚̕̕͠͝͠͝͝�̸̧̨̧̡̡̢̢̨̡̨̢̨̢̡̧̡̢̨̡̧̧̢̧̢̤̣̹̠̪͙̖͓͈͇̜͔̫̹̞̮̠̠̙̱͖͍̦͕̜̮̼̳̝̰̱̺̤͍̦̯̣̞̩̲̘̠͙̖̜̖͚̥͉̤͖̻̣̹̭̰̯̪̰̟̙̱͚͔̹̥̱̥̻̰̼̗͔͓̩͇̯͇̼̞̗̠̦̺͔̖̟͓̲̤͚͍̜̦͖̺̗̪̻̩̩̙͚̰͎̮̣͉̭̱̼̩͚̺̺͇̞̮̜̩̘̙̪̠̩̼̦͚͍̩͖͉̼̹̲̥͇̗͓͇̱̝̭͈̥̜̱͓̠̺͖͓̪̼͙̖̞̲͖͍̳̯̟̙̩̙̫͎̯̪͓̻̹̬͚̮̣̲͇͎̦͖̦̲̭̭̘̙̣̤̝̩̠̘̬̯͓̼̗̪͕̭̠̳̬̫̳̱̱͚̥͇͉̥̭͔̭̗͔͕̺̰̞̽̈́̀̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜ͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̧̧̢̨̧̨̧̨̛̛̛̙̫̱̱̖͉̥̠̣͓̣̥͉̫̩̟̺͉̰͎͔̦͕̗̭̘̹̩̬͓̼̲̙̱͚̞͇̹͓͉͙̻̻͉̻̙̳͈̦͇͚̩̯̝̺͚̣͔̲̤̭̣̙̼̝͈̣̼̠̜̣͕̭̪̙̭͎̦̤͍̬̥̲̖͚͚͕͙̠̞̬̟͚̠̲̭͈̤͖̩̞̪̩̫̳̙̦͔͓͍͕̖̩̞̱͍̮͇͓̰̭̝͓̳̘̯̮̼̖͙͍̺̣͎̪͕̳͎̖̻̥͇̭̞̠͍̩͎̼͎̤̼̼̪͇͕̠͇̲͔͖̯̝̙̫̦̼͉̘̱̠̙̯̝̻̩̗̲̳̟̜̈̈́̿̾̆̍̆̀̉̓́̍͊̅̔̅͊͌͛͐͌͐̈́̇̔͒̃͗̃̀̔̆̾́̂͛̏̍̎̃̒̄͒̆̌̈́̂̐̐̀̈́̓̈͂̒̉̍̋̆́̽̿̚͘̚͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̧̨̧̨̢̢̡̢̨̡̧̢̢̢̡̡̧̧̡̨̧̧̢̢̡̧̼̰̮̳͈̣̰͍̗̱̻͈̬̩̙̻̮̹̼͎͎̱̪̜̩̻̜̪̲͖̞͍͉̗̲̣̪̖͔̥͉͔̻͎͍̹̼̹͙̜͎̖̱͎̼̞̼̥͖̻̦̯͔̗̜̤̯̖̲̫̮̠̯͈̱͈͉̫̗̜͚̝̖̟͉̤̙̬̻̩̙͖͔̝̫̳̘̟͇̘̭͚̪͔̲̮̗̻͈̹̣͕̻͖͈͔̭̰͎̜̭̺̪̼̱̯̫̥̺̹͇̱̜̰̥͇͍̜͉̞̠̩̯̘̻̣̪̠̯͈̪͓͕̗̫̻̺̗̫̺̲̥̫̦̙̰͚̳͕̦̩͈͍̞͙͖̖͔̩̭̻̞͔͚͉̗͚̮̜̯̫̻̘͙̙̹̲̱̗̲͖̰͕̟̙̜̲͍͇̩͍͉̻̯̖̫͉͖̪̭̥̦͈͚͇̻̗͈͆̈̈́̐̄̉͐̄̏̂̏̍̆̑̒̂̈́̄̌́̃͊͊͌̆͛̉̾́̌͆͊̓̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜ͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̡̨̨̡̛̛̛̛̛̛͍̫̘̝̦͍͕͈̩̥̙͓̼̣̠̥̜̮͕̙͙̻̠̦̱͙̹̜̺̙̱̖̤̬͍̜͇̹̮͐̽͗̿̈́̀͋͑̉̿̊͂͌̏̋̈̓̑̎̀͗̈́̊͋̎̒̓̿͊͗̓̒̇͑̔̈́̒̓̀̈́̾̄̔̍̽̍̀̃͌̂̊̍͋͋̋́̓̓͗̀̃̿̏̑̑͐́̓̾̓̓̿̏͊̋̋̋͗̃̿͒̈͆͊̂͌̂̄͋͌̉̈́͆́̔͒͂̅̔̈́͋̇͗̋̓̂̈́̋̒̂͋̇̓͋͐̓̅̀͆͊̀̎̿͊̐͌̏̂̿͌̀̑̓̄̒̀͊̓͆̔̀̿̏̾̉͗̃̂̽̂̎̇̉̋͊͐̏̉̉͒̅̅̾́̓͒̒̋͘͘͘̕̚̚̕̕̚̚͘̚̕̚̕̕̕͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅ�̶̧̨̨̨̡̨̨̛̛̛̛̻̙̺̙͔̪̟͕̱̲͕̞̼̮̰̲͙̺̥͉͎̫̰̞̙̼̻̪̭̦͈̘͚̗͖̹͚̝̬͇̣̤̦̪̖͕͔̦̟͚͇͉̩̻̻̠͈͍̣̳͙͓̜͙͈͓̣̊̾̄̑̏͆̄͌̑̀̊̀̿̑͂̍̈́̉̈͒͐͋̋̈́̀͊̈́́̀͌͑̌̓͑̊̉̓̓̄́̽̒̌̓̉̾̎̄̄̌̆̐͌͐͐͛̽̐̍̋͋̃̿̾̈́̈́̏̃̾́̈́́͛͂͒̇̔͌̅̿̂̑͊͊͗̎́̓́̈́͒͗̔̐̈́̓̓͐̈̂̆̈́͊͊̄̒̄̎̃̓̎͐͐͋̃̓͗̈́̂͊̿͆̄̈́͛̃̇̇͘̚̚̚̚͘͘͘͘̚͘̚̚̚͘͘͘͘͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅ�̴̢̧̧̨̡̡̨̡̧̢̢̢̛̛̟̯̘͉̤̖̩̬̫̰͓̲̰̞̲̳̖̗̻̺̱̠͙̟̭͓̮͉͈̘͙̥̦̳̝̫̬̱̱͍̗͍̼͚̣̠̥͕̞͈̩̼̙͉͍͈̩̟͎̞̼̣̰̲̺͇̼̠̖̙̳͔͎̬̜͓͚̠̲͓̰͎̟̼̰̰͍̯̬̗͚̗̮̠̰̮͉̪̘͎̖͍̫̩̭̠̤͙̜͙̫̫̰̣͖̤͎̊̋͆̉̀̈̀̄̏̾́̓̄̀͋̓̄̈́̋̓̈̀̈́̈̏̅̈́́̍͋̒̎̾̆̔́͂̂̀̈́͛́́͒̀̔̾̇̉͌̿̐͛͗̿̀͆̀͒̀͐̔̓̄̒̂̕̕͘̚̚̚͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͠ͅͅͅͅ�̷̢̡̢̧̢̡̨̢̨̡̧̧̡̛̭͇͎̮̱̭̩̰̞͎͉̫̘̟͎͔̫͚̟̪̬͚̖̖̻͈̳̠̙̬͚̗̳̥͍͔̤̤̲͖͚͉̻̣͓̤͓͕̯̰̤͈̰̺͈͈̥̠̮̰̫͕̖̳͍͍͓̹̺̼͚̺̦̠̭͖̘̬̳͙̤͉̗͎͕͉̦̟̻͉̭̳̥͎̘͍͙͖̳̠͓̭̺͉̹̙̰̦͙̭̰͕̻̭̻̙̱̟̻̞͈̬͔̝̟̮̜̰̮̠̟̟̥͈̜͉͓̮͚̼͙̰̰̖͇͉̣̣̫̗̙̣͖̪͔̈́̈́̆̑̍̓̀̾͒̊̔̃́͒͑̅̓́͂̄̈́̓͗͑̎̋̇̾͛͌̍̽̾͊̐͋̏̇͊̒̓̅͐̉̌̑̆̎̒̓̅̃̿̎̓̊͛̓̉̑̈́̉͗̉̉̽̾͂̽̈́̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅ�̴̡̨̨̢̧̨̡̡̡̧̡̛̛̛̛̛̞̪͙̭̙͚̗̙̮̦̖̖̟̰̹͎͚͕̯̪̠̺̹̺͚͓̪̯̫͔̗͕̻̦̼̤͓̟̭̲̦͙͙͉͖̗͕̯̥͙̩̱̩̝̦̟̗̘͙̮̳̱̺̩͖̫̻̞̫̠͇̖͈͖̺͓̗̟̖̭̗̟̗̩͓̼̺̞̥̲͚̘̺̜͓͓̺̤̻̫̼̝̥̣̹̩͚͔͉͖̦̼͍̬̤͔͍͚̀̃͂̋̃̐̎͋̄̎̾͐͌̾̉̏̂̀̃̋͐̽̈́͌̿̈́͛̍̐̽̉̒̓̂̉̀̌̀̏̄̒̄̃̑́̇̾͋̈͌̇͌̂̇̂̄̏́̊͛͌̎̾́̈́̄̇̏̓̏̑͑̉̎̓͐͐̌̒́̅̒̿̄͑̆͑̄̋͂̐̐̋̉́̃̆̈́̐̍̃̆͐͊̊͐̈́́͋͐̑̓̓͐̉̏̑͒͑̈́̾̃̎̐̏̊̃̊̑͌͐͊͆̿̂̇̆̓̉̃̆̈̌̊̒̌̽̾̎̾͆̔̓̈́̒̓͗̋́͂̈́̿̓͑̏̇̅͒̄̔̔̏̍͐̍̏̓̅̏̇͊̂͒̈́̇̓̉̅̊́̀̀̅̀͌̉̒͊͆̊͐̀̂̈́̀̌͗͐͌̈́͋̑̑̈̔̌̄̊̆̊̓̃̉͌͗͌̓́͛̆̆̅̇̇̈́̾̐̏͑̀̃͒̽̃̅̏̌̅̽̈́̍̋̓͐͆̕̕̕̕̕͘̕̕̕̕͘͘̕͘̕̚̚̚̕̚͘̕͘̕͘̚͜͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͠ͅͅ�̷̧̨̢̨̡̢̧̡̧̢̡̧̧̢̧̢̨̢̢̡̨̡̢̛̛̛͖̩̲̥̣͙̺̺̭̙̮̦̟͉̩͉̯̟̤̞̲͖͙̖̗̤̫͖͖͓̼̜̙̣̣̜̺̰̺̞̜͓̠̙̰̯̖̻̖̼̣̫̞̫̪͓̬̠̰̗̰͓̰͕̮̮͈̙̯̫̩̝̮̦͓̯̙̗͎̺̱̟̱̙̤̤̰̱͈̜̳͚̭̣̻̣̞̣͚̞̰͉͕̺̼̦̹̙̗̰̠̲̭͖̗͇͈̮̱͕̺̯̹̠̻̜͚̖̰̳̥̤͕͉͈̭̬̞͔͖̙̹̟̣͍͙̙͇͖̰̟̖̯͎͎͙̹̟͖̝͍͙̰̘̝͙̟̱͈̮̺͎̞̤̥͓̙͈̳̻̩͈̗̯͚̪̫͚͚̟̝̖͙͇͍̠̗̠̥̞̰̥̤̜̱͉̦̱͓̜͉̰̭͙̰͍͔͈̦̖͍̺͙͈̤̻̦͇͓̖̺̩̱͎̱̙̠̭͖̩̝̻̙̝̙͂́́̀́̑̀͌̀̍͒͗͗̈̈͛̃̑̾̂̋̉̓̿̉̓̐̇͗̓̉́̀̈́̔̆̆̈̔̑͑̉̾͆̾̓̅̑͒̆̍̉̇̀̓̑͌͋͛̊̈̍̅͗́͗̀̿́̏͋́̿̓̀̈́̋̆́̈́̄̏̅̅͌̎̀̊̉̌̾͋͑͑͌̏͌͂̂̀͑̋̋̿̂̒̃̾͋̆͋̑̀̋̿̀́̍̑̈́͑̏͂̅͂͛́̄̐́́͑́̄̔̑͗̈́̒̋̃͗̐̽̌͌̿̈́̀̎̑̉̄͊̐́͌̇͛͛̏̓͑̀̂̅̀͊͐̾͗͂͐͐͒̎̊̍̓́͛̈́̊̂͑̀̄̄͌͋̀̋͋̏̂̊̎͐́͌̀͛̓̎̽̾̉̆̇̿̈̕̚̚̚͘͘̕̕͘̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̡̨̧̡̧̧̡̨̨̧̢̧̢̨̢̢̢̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛͉̦̘̻̻͍̯͍̝͖͉͓̼̗͕͉̺͎̺͕̲̮͖̠̬̰͈̠͚̞̦͙͇̩̜̻̬̞̙̼̟̬͚͈͙̰̼̻̖̙̥̥̪̝̘͚̤̻̰̲̫̦̣͙̯̥̠͎̼̦̰̮͍͍̼̜̟̦̪̤̻̱̺͎̪̺̱̹̖͔͕̘͓̤̟̮͇̲̪̯̲̪̞̦̤͎̩̮͉͚̫̞̭̠̙͔͓̟͓̗͇͈̙̞̘̳͖͙͍̤̦̭̮̪̜̝̩͙̗̤̘͙̬͔̳̟̘͈͕͓͍̥̤̲̯̻̩̩̝̪͚̭͔̩͎͉̥̠̹̖̙̬̖̻̭̹̞̭͉̻̹̲̩͇͖͔̰̘̥̦͚̠̗̖͔̣̰̖͎̘̮͉͍̺̦̱̬̙̱͇̯̥͍̦̥̗͍̖̺̼̭̯̯̺̙͔̥̻̻͔̣̙̤̩̮͙̳̯͖̝̻̝̰͚̿̆̀̓̂̆́̂́̏̈̿͋̐̊͂͛̌̓̾̑̈́͛̈́̌̀͛̓͌̇̆̓̈̌́̈̀̐̄͌̏͒̃̑̈͑̏̆̿̍͂͋͌̉̍̇̂̇͂̆͂̑̓̌̽͂̏͑̈́̏̐̓̓̽̊͋͒̅̀̊̐̈́̓̇̂̓̽͌̉͋͒̇̿̋͂͂̏͊̄̃̊͌̿̇̓̒͒̔̒͒̎̈́͑̉̈́̈͒̌͗̈́̋̌̊͌̎̔̽̀̍͒̇̎̉̌͑͌͌́̐̓̌̈͌̿̊̅͊̆̽͒̈́́̏͂̅͌͌̏̂̓̉̔̽̈́͆͌͛̋̃̓̇̃͒͐͊̀̏̔͌̆̅̾͛̅̉̄̎̈́̃͐͌̌́̑̿͂͗͂́̽̽͗͒̓͐̍̋̊̐́͊̂̈́̆̿̓̚̕̕̚͘͘͘̚̕̕͘̚͘̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅ�̵̢̛̛̛̛̠̗̹͓̩͚̞͔̗̹̺̗̰̆͋͒̇̆̽̌͌̏̽̈́̈͛̅̏̈̈́͆͂̓͂̄̒̿̽͒͆͆̿̀̋͐͂̆͆̉̊̐́̈̔̓͊̂͌̿̽̀̊̄͑́̏̂͗͛̇͐̅̄̑̂̇̊͐͋͌̿̈́̈́͛́̽̄̈́̽͑̐͑̄̀̄̈́̑̊͗̒̔́̄͒̉̌̄̔́̍͌̓̍̉̂̒̃̇͗͆͑̈́̎̓̾̅̐͂̎̎̂̔̾̇̊̅̓̂͛͊͐̒̃̉͋͐̔̔͆̽̈́̋̎̀͛̅̂͌͛͐̅̈̒̓͋̔̕͘͘̕̚̕͘̚͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͠͠͠͝͠͝͝ͅ�̶̡̡̧̧̢̢̡̢̧̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̼̫̼͇̙͙͇͍̦̪͎͉̬̬̜͉̟̘̮͇̫̲̦̻̭̣̮͈̞͎̥͉̫̳̟͙̟̥͍̘͉̠̰͓̫̲̮͈͇͇̜̠̙̯̭̝̱͍͍̪̗̤̪̣̼̗̣̘̯̪̼̗̗̙̖͎̭̬̗̖̫̫̦̬͓̬͎̳̝͍͓̟̣͕̩̝̩̦̥͖̭̣̼̹̱̥̺̼̥̲̖̈́͑̅̃̑̾͆͐̒͌̒̒͌͌̽̈͑̈́͒̈́͒̂̓͋̀͂̾̓̇̃͐͌͑͋̏̿̈́̔̂̿̀̽̌̇̋̿̋̀̆̄͗̉̈́̏͐̾̀̈́̓͌͒̄́̀̀̑̋̀̽̉͒͐͋̑̾̔̓͑̓̐̓̋̀̓̄̈̅͐̄̂̆͗̀͊̃̐͒̓̒͑̎͋̆̾̄͛̑̈́̌͂̾́͐͌̈́͛͌̊̈́͛͋̌̉͆̈́̏͑̓̀̎̽́̏͊̆̽̽͛̄̓͐̔̇̅̑͑̀̔̀̈́̒̔̊̈̈́̋̃̎̓̃̒́̍̂̌̃̋̿͛̒͒̒̆͊́͛̐͋͋̈̅́̉̏͗̾̀̃̄̂̈́̆̈́̐̄̒̒̓͗̃͂̾̔̊͒̀́̃̎̇́̒̀̇͒̀͑̒̇̋̌̿̓̇̊̾̎̌̾͑̾̅̓͛͂̇̕̕͘̕͘̚͘͘̕͘͘͘̕͘͘͘͘̚̕̕͜͜͝͠͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͝͠͠͝͝ͅ�̷̡̡̡̧̢̨̧̛̛̛̛̣̥͉̭̻̻̬͚̹̥̪̣͖̻̱̟̼̹̫͙̣͇̰̻̟̺̺͚̳͎̘̳̞̹̫̘̥̦̬̟̮̞͙͉̟͍̣̮͉̱̞̫̺̻͈̼̞̱̬̜͓̳͆́͆͂̎̽̋́̓̒͐̌͊̓̓͊̀̌͛͊͆̈́͛̑̎̊̐̍̈̆̑́̊̽́̋͐̓̓͐̎͊̇̀̅̐͊̎̇̽̌̈̌̒͑̈́̈́̆̂͗͑̐͊͑́̽̃̉̃́͂̅͗̏̈̽̿̾͑̌̎̑̐̔̅̅̃̈́́͒̉̍̎̄̔͌̈̄̄̍͋̓͑̑͛̓̉̾̓̾͂͊͗͆̓̎̅͆̽̆̽́́̏̈́̊͐͘̕͘̚͘̕͘͘̕̕̕͜͜͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͠͝ͅͅͅͅ�̵̢̢̛̛̖̰̲̭̲̞̟̟͚͍̞͇̞͉̠͉͚̼͙̰̮̩̻̘̺̳̮̝̱̲̭̮̻͉̣̦͎̬̖̯̞̖̗͈̯̝̞̹͉̩̤̳̍̊̎̎́̀͂̋̑͗̇͆̅̈́̐̔͑̓͗̀̓̏̐̾̉̐̈́́̌̆͗̓̒̽̿̉͗̂͒̌̂̄̓̉́͑͑̃͊̔͆̑̍͗͒͒́̎͌̋̅̏̓͗͆͒̐̂͐̐͛̎̔̈̀̍̾̑̈́̐͊͛̊̈̐̎̊̓̈̈́͐̔̀͋̈́̉̔̿̈́̆̽̏̆͛͐̓̃͑͛͂͂̽́̿̅̒͘̚͘̕͘̕̚̕̕͘̚͘̚̕͜͝͝͝͝�̴̨̧̨̨̢̡̡̡̢̢̡̨̧̛̝͙̲͔̦̫̬͚͕̦͇̙͍͚̲̭̟̯̘̟̳͈̣͚͉̠̤̣͓̗̙͍̤͙̻̥͈̗͓͎͚̝͕̖̺̗͙̻̺̱̘̜͖̩̦̫̱͓͈͈̣̠̝͍͕̼̤̺̭̮͓̱̩̳͉̼̰͖̞̗̗͈̳͔̹͈͙̟̫͔̫̞̖͙̠̥̙̳̙̯̲̝̙̲̣̣̖͎̦͍̯̮͎͍́̀͋͌̋̏͌͐̽̿̓̃̅́̒̑̒̓̒̓̐̂͛̇̊̆͛͗̽̀̈́̈́̂̑̊̓̎̽͊͆̂͋́̅̔͛͋̈́̅̍̓͗̎͗͐̌͋̒̐͂̇̑́̌̉̏͂̂͋̉̑́̈́̋͆̓̓̓͋́͗̓̈́̈́̆̏̆̓̃̂̾̓̽͆̀̔̌̀̈́̅͑͊̃̆́̓̎͐̊͗͐̈̍̾͂̆́̅̓̃̃̽͌́̈́͑͊̈̇̊́͑́͆̂͛̋̽͒̔̑̊́̒͛̈́͋̉̃̍͐̈́̄̌̔͆̍̂̿̀̓͋̋̎͗̍͒̄̀̅̓̿͗͘͘̚̕͘̚̕̚͘̕̕͘͘̚͘̕͘̚͘͘̕͝͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̷̢̢̧̨̨̢̧̢̡̢̧̡̡̢̨̧̧̡̧̛̯̫̤̘̙̥͈̫̰̻͍̲͇̣̼̪͚̮̙̰͎̼̹͔̱̝̘͕͚̹̫̲̣͍̙͕̹̳̘̯̗̗͙̹̺̞̞̳͎̣̹͓̳̪͉͙̖̰͈͓̰͎̠̼̟̪͉̻̻͉͎̤̝̣̘̯̲̳̗̪̼̪̻͎̙̝̪̻̱͎͉̮͙̙̹̘̪̼͍̻̥͖͕̱̭̼͍̺̗̫͕̝̳̺̥͎̣̻̣̼̘̟̖̞̩̬͖͇̘̼͓̩̖͓̘̬͖̯͉̮̯̫̲̹̞̱͙͕̣͍͉̠̗͕̹̝̤̜̙̤̳̠̗͍͖͔̪̱̰̫̯͓̦̟͈̘͈͉̹̘̙̜̲̱̹̩̪̈̇̾̂̍̈́̅̌̿͛̌̃̅̅̽͂̃́̌̓̏̐̅̍̄̂̂̀̒̅͆̋̋͗̀͐̄͌̍̊̈́̆̓̔̅̿͗̽̐͌̔̋̈́̂͐̔̉̅͆́͊̌͑͛̒̏̋̄́̑́̾͑̍̀̈́́̀̔̍̎̌̌͌̾̿̾͌̈́̑̈́̃̌̾̒͐͂̈́̑̇̐̄̊̀̔̇̀̒̃̆̈́̀̕͘̕͘̕̕͘̕̕͘͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̨̡̡̢̡̧̢̛̯̩̤͖͙̞̠̗̗̮̼̼̣̟̫̪͖͎͕̖̤̪̝̙͙̗̯̫̩͎͉̲̖͈̜̠͖̦̘̲̎͌̐͆̏͆̎̂̀̽̊̄̈́̀͊̄̎̋͊͒̇̀̊̉͑͑̈́̐̐̆̾́̔́̓̽͛̑̑̀̍̿̔̽̚̕̚̕̚͜͜͜͠͠͝͝ͅͅ�̸̧̛̛̛̛̠͖͇͎͚̖̞̲̀̈́̈́̊͋̒̈́̾̌̈͂̈̑̀̊͆̇͗̓͐̿͒̽̿̅̃̋͛̓́͋̄̄͊̓͐̄͑̑̔͂͗̈̈́̍̒̾̄̑̐̀̒̾̌̌̈̂͊̽̍̈̎̊́͋̈̂̋̌͒͐̈̐̍̎̋̏̏̎̃̈́̀̈́̓́̐̈́͑̍͊͌͑͑̾͆͛̂̎͋͌͐̀̒̿̓̔̄̆̍̈́̐̄̐̀̋̔́͑̎̉̊̎̍̃̀̇̓̓̋̉̾̔̾̎́̽͊̍͒͛̔̕̕̚̚̚̚͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅ�̵̨̧̡̡̡̢̢̧̨̡̨̨̨̧̛̛̮̼͙͙̭͈̞̝̬͚̻̜͎͖̺͕̩̟̜̗͉͖͔͔̜͎̪̗̖̱̗̞͈̘̰̖͔̼͓̲̭͈̳͓̲̹̪͎̙͍̬͔̜͕͉͔̲̳̲̙̲̪̜̟̳̰̹͍̺̯̟͔͕̪͇̣̤͕̟̻̦̖̼̫͇̖̘͕̼͉͔̖̻͚͚̹͕͍̹̮̫͕̥̫̻̗̺͈̪̯̣̯̹̖̣̈́́̇̊͋͒́́͊͋̀́͌̔̃̄̓̈́͗̈́͊̀̆̌̊͊͌̊̓̀͋̃͑̆͋̏̎͆̃̽̅͂̊̓͛̄̀̔̂̌͋̿͋̀̀̏̿̈́̀̐͗͗̃͋̊́̆̽͌̇̆̒̈̇͑͂̈́̓̐͛͘͘̕̚͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͠͠͝ͅͅͅ�̵̡̛̮̤͙̦̯̗̝̩̭͖̤̘̤̙̰̲̰̤̖̗̫͙͈̤̞̈̈́͌̈́͆̂̀̌͑̐̀̿̆̓̈́͒̇̌́̑̆̒̈̎̎̀̈́͂̋̑̉̓͑͊͆̏͂͂͊̉́̆͂̇̓̕̚̕̕̚͝͠͠͝�̵̢̧̨̢̛̛̛̛̛͍̜̞̯̟͔̦̖͍̩̜̺̼̭̰͚͍̹̯̦̹͉̤͉͙̘͖̯͈̪̩̩͎͙̣͇̮̺̭͗̿̒̈́͒̋̇́̅́̃͑̃̂̓́̓̌̈́̓̾̒́̽́͋̾̄̈́̌̈́̓͒͛̉̃̆̈́̀̓̓̓́̂̔̀̀̄̿̑̈́̈́̑͂̋̈̅͑͋̓͆̅̂̒̅͋̓̑̀͊͒̒̈̈̓̃͊̈́͆̋̍̌̂̃̑͌̏̓͗̔̾́̊̓̈́̓̎̅̆́̉͛̌͗̍̆͛̅͆̒͆̄͂̓̓̒͛̚̚̚̕͘͘̕̕̚͝͠͝͝͝�̴̢̢̧̧̢̢̡̧̧̛̛̛̛̹̤͈̪͎͙̳͎͇͕͚̜̝̤͈̤̣̤̼̱̦̘͍̩̪̖̮̬͖͙̹̮̩̼̳̭̘̝̝͈̘͓̳̺̻̘̘̣̮͓̗͙̠̣̭̞̰̯̰̜͇̩̻͍̱͔̺̦͖͓͕̼͙̹̞̞̹͚̲͔͖͖̟̣̲̫̺̖̮̤̫̦̠̣̼̬͓̳̥̝͚͍̬̻̖̖͕͎̙̙̖̘̜̭͚̮̼͙̬͎͂̐̔̈́̽̄͊̈̆̈́́͂̈́͛̔͂͋̀̓̀̔̈́͗͑̎͋̐̓̐̽̉́̅͊̒̍̈̆̽̎̽̑̌͂̅͊̊̐͐̾͑͂͂̓͆͌̂͊͒̿͂͊͌͛̈́̅̀̾̇͒͒͌̀͐̔͗̎̈́̉͋̃̉̂̌̂̓͌̉̈́̊͆͊̔̆͌̊̃̈͒̔̐̃̈́̔̇́͛͐̔̽͆̅͗̏̉̈̅͐̄̇́̅͐͐͊̉̾͌͊̾͛́̊̃̇̋͆̿̌̉͒̀̅́̓̿̊̿̆̅̊̕̚̕̕̚͘͘̚̚͘̕̚̚̚̚͘̕͘̕̚͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝ͅ�̷̢̧̢̡̧̡̢̢̧̨̧̢̢̡̧̢̢̨̨̧̛̛̛̛̛̼̠̱͚̜̗̭͕̗̥̣̣̰̮͚͍̝̜̲͎̝̙̦̬̪͓̯̪͕̺̹̦̲͈̥̱̤̞̞̻̱͇̺̘̳͉̜̖̪̙͈̼̖̩̮̼̮͎̱̲͍̠̹͓͇̞͖̰̗̬̮̖̮͓͍͈̭̣̮̩͈̮̬̪̻̫̲̠̩̗̩̦͔͓̮̠̻̣̩̻̯̗̤̥͔̥̙̝̗͎͚͇̫̜̯̱͖͍͓̥͉̙̘̥͙̪̘̺̟̘̪̘̮̞̘̹̝͍̗̠̩̤̯̙̮͓̪̻̺̜͎̙͈̬̭̱̤̖̣̣̞̱͕͍̞̲͔͈̘̹͙̰͍̫͎̰͓̗͈̘͎͎̣͈̝̺͖͉͈͈̖̟̩̝̲̲̱̙̙̥̠̤̳͕̤̱̗̼̱͍̥͕͔̣͚̲̘̰͚̳̠͔̘̳̻͖͇̘̳̦̺͚̮̭̮̟͉̺̦͚̦̫̳̣̟͕͕͙͈̦͖̘̫̤̟̘̥̯̓̾̈́̎̈̿̓̏̎̿̍̈̿̒̍̇̓̒́̀̀̎̋̈̆̽̌͊̂͂̋́̔̔͂̀͋̃́͒̂͑͆͆͂̀̾͌̈̓̊̈́̉͒́͂̐͑̓̊̉̃́̈́̌̓̓͂̿̈́̌̈̃̈́̈́̎͐̃̑͂͌̈͌̔́͊̈̂̆̇̈́̌̾̋͛͑͆̄̀̈́̌̈́̊͊̑͗̄̀̀́͐̌́̂͊̃͐͑̐̽̍͑͛͒̈̂͋͛̔̽̿̓̿̔̍͑͑̈́̓̌͑̂̌̌͂̒̓̅̔̏͛̀̏͊̾͒͊̍̍͋͂̂̀̍̿̃̔̉͒͌͐̽̃̎̽̕͘̚͘̕̚̚͘̕̚̚͘̚͘̕̚͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͠͝͠͠͝ͅͅͅͅ�̷̡̨̡̨̧̡̢̢̧̢̢̧̨̧̨̧̡̧̡̛̛̛̛͙̪̤̦̟͔̘̞̞̱̞̬̺̜̩͎͙͙̝̘̗͔̦̤̤͙̼͓̯͇̲̰̮͙̤͖̜̱̜͕͚̞͇̰̠̦̩̲͚̣̺̬̫̼̩͚̮̦̘̙͔̝̹̪̟̖̼̲͇͉̯̩͈̠̭̩̫̪̜̗͇̱̗̤̜̙̺̗̲̝̲̮͉͇̬̝͉̬͈̩͇̺͙̲͉̖̻̲̭͕̲͇̲̙̳̮̫̺̰͔̺̱̗͉̝̭̳̖̦͕͙̝̪͎͍̘̣̬̬̪̰͇̦̱̬̻̘̘̩͚̟̻͎̙̭͚͔̲̯͎̺̪͕͉͙̣̤̜̩̦̠̞̦̞̯̱̰̰̥̰̫̠̥͖̂͑͋̈́̀̃͐̑̅̓̒͒̑͑̋̒̑̎̄̑̏͛͊́̏̅̃̇̈̑̎̀̽́̍͊̊̈́̒̓̍̍̍͒̿̅̓̑́̓̍͑̏̎́͗͐̀̒̽͊̆̄́̆̾̈́̄̐̀̔̇̒̀͐̎̏͂̿͛̓̀͐͗̎͆̀̂̉̄͋̈́̎̉̎̋̑̌̉̇̃̿͑̊͒̄̏͂̏͊͋̊̉̚͘͘͘͘̕͘̕̕͘͘͘͜͝͠͠͠͠͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅ�̴̡̢̢̨̡̡̡̛̮͉̜͚̝̘̺̻͙͖͕̞̺͉̹͖̮̳̠̹͈̤̟̮̲͙̲̞̼̬̪̙̫̣̥͔̥͉͕̫̠̜̯͙̱͓̞̖͕̙̄̉̐̐̓̾̍͌͐̓͌̾͂͊̽̽́̾̉̒̀̆̍̃̎͐̆̋͆̀̑̈́̀͌̔͂͊̓̓̈͆̃̒̆͑̅͂̄̅̐͛̎̍̍͊͛̎̓̅͐͛̽́̓̅̌̿̋̂͛̆͂̈́̍̇̓͛̈͘̕̚͘̕͘̚͜͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅ�̵̛̛̛̛̛̰̳̍̒̇̀̀͑̋̒͒̉͊͛̅͊̂͛̂̆̽͊̓̾͊͂̊̿̈́́́͒͂̈́̄́̎̽̃̽̌̋͋͑̃͂͛͆́̎̈̐̾̎̓̌͛̊̉͗̓̈͌̀̑͆̏͂̾́̄̄̈̆͋͛̈́͋̓̋̀̀͂̐͛̎͛̾͗͊̋̇̋̋̅͗͂̈̀̽̈̑̒̎̈́̆͑̉̀̒̔̽̄̃͑͗̎̑͌̂̽̈́̈́̍̓̊͛́̃̐̑̄̽́̆̃̀̀͒̏̈́̇͂̈͗̒̏͂̅̓̓͆̅̑̓͐̅̿͌̽̈̉̄̓̀̈́̍͂̏̉̂̑͂̑̒͋̑̑̂̎̂̈́̔̇̍͆̓͛̑̈́̔̃̂̈́̍̔́͌̈́͑́̏̅͑͊̈̆̉̏̆̈́͒̇̍̓̆̌͊̌͐͑̕̚̚̕̚̕̚̕̚͘̕͘̕̕͘͘̕͘̕̚̕͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͠�̵̢̨̡̧̢̨̨̡̧̡̢̨̢̨̨̢̨̢̧̨̛̛̞̠̹̙̠̩̘̘̱̹̞̞͍͉̥̼̯͓̦̺̰̠͖̰̼̼̦̜̰̞̺̙̜̳̫̝͚̪̦̮̭̪̭͍̦̪̝̩͇͎̙̫̬̞̙̰̝͙̜̞̹̪̰̳͈̼̺̗̫̺̗̰͖̙̬̜̗̫͍̜̗͓͓͉̺̩̟͎̖̼͔͖̥̭̜̙͙̠͍̪̥͇͖̟͇̠̱̩̭̘̯̫̬̦̘̜̺̟͇͍̱̗͎͔͇̞͈̲̗͇̣̼͔͖̝̮̲̜̙̗̗̤̼͈̬̤͓͎̫̬͚̲̹̪͙̬͖̫̳̘̜̥͍͇̖̣̹͎̹͖̠͔̜͆͌͒̍̋̈́̂̾̀͛̋̆̈̈́́̃́̈́͑͐̓̈́̃̏̈́͑͊́̓͂̿̀͗̍̔̔̓̃͋̾̀̓͗̓͗̇́̆̈́͐̿̀͛̿̅̅̒̓̀̈̔͐̄̄̎͐̕͘̚͘̕̚̚̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̸̧̡̧̧̨̨̨̢̧̨̨̨̢̨̨̢̨̨̢̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̮̼̙͉̼̗̠͍̭͎̮̠̤͎̘͎͔̪̺͎̱͔̦̳͍̝̭̼̣̳͖̦͙͎̫̪͍̘͈̪̮̫̣̮͕͔̳̖̙̮̲̳͉̗̘̜̗͓̳̯̥̞͚̣̺̯͈̯̩͙̠̩̗̳̟̘̬͕̟̞̺͓͙̱̮͚͉̙̻͍̩̗̗̻̜̣̣̺̤̮͉̗͕̞̖̯̣̝̗̤̮̪̤̜̰̺̣̲̯̝͉̫̫̭̫̮͙͓̤̗̠̖̫̫̥̬̯̦̥͎͈̜̺̤̼̙͖̺̘̼̭̜̠̥̘͖̭̺̱͚̩̠̞̭̙̦͙̗͍͍̰̭̦͕̜͕̘̭̩̹̹̗̰̫͙̰̲̣̹̖̻͕̈̓̒̑̍͊̈́͐̓̍̃̽̐͒̎̏͆̿͂̄̐̐͂̏̈̓̔̅͛̍̈́͌͌̐͗̀̔̂͛̒̏̍̅̒̓̋̋̇̈́͐̉̍͒̆̓́̾͒̾͗́̾̔́͊̌̄̾͊̉̋̆̂͌̎̀̈́͗̿̈́́̃̓̐́͑͗͆̓͋́̑̂̀̾͌́̈͗͛̊̀̇̀͊̈́̄͋̇̔̆̔̉̆͑̈́̉͒́͊̈́̏̃́͗̍̄̓̉͑͗͛͒̈́̈́̈̊̈́͛͆̄͑̎͒̓͌̽̀̎̎̎͂̄̏̇̐̈́́̐̀̌͊̋̔͗̐̍̓̓͊̌̄̀́͋̀̓͊̌̇̃̊̉͂̈͒̊́̎̌̇̊̒͗̀͗̓̎͒̒͂̈͋̃͊̈́͋̈́͊͋̔̇̓͑̍̽̽͐͗̓̔̄̇͑̉̏͒͆̄̂̈́͛̆́͌̿̈͑̄̓̌̓̌̈̿̃̒̈̍̀̑̓̏͐̋̿̕̕̚̚̕̚͘͘̕̚͘̚̕̕͘̕̚̚̕͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠ͅͅͅ�̷̨̨̢̨̨̨̧̧̧̡̧̧̨̡̢̢̨̛̛͎͕̳̻̻̦̠̜͉͇̜͙̖̞̬̗̫̭͇̗̺̺̩̱͔̹̻̙̮̪̥̲̱̳͔͚̘̞̬̻̬̳͇̮͔̳̥̙͕̲͇͕̯͖̻͖͍̗̲̩̳̪̗͚̻̩͚͇͚̦͕͕̰̼̤̬̘̝̼̺̖̹̻̪̘͎͍͇̘͈̲̞̹̠͙̫͔̙͕̞̹̝͈̗͇͚̩̟̲̬̤̜̥̩͈̖̬̙̘̩̰̼̗̤̳͙͓̙̰͖̠̪͚̲̤̮̟̬͍̮̗̰̬̼͖͖̳͎̩͓̩̭̬͇̳̲̫̼̺̹̰̬̤̼̱̜̦͔̠̫͖͈̣̞̣̲̹̮͖̥͆͋̑̑̒͑͂̀͑͑̾̾̀́͂̔́͒̌̾̀͌͆̉̒̋̒͋̑̔͂͒͑͌̐̌̈́̏̓̍̑̐̿͗̓̔̏̉͌̀̽̂̀̊̅̾́̿̿̀͆͒̄̌͋̀̀̒̽͌̓̂̈́̌̂͌́͐̋̉͊̊̀́̌̋̓͑́̑̈́̅͌̋̑͒́͗̾͌͐͂̃͊́̕͘͘̕͘͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͠͝�̷̢̨̧̨̡̡̡̨̨̢̧̧̨̧̧̛̙͕̲͓̖̜͔̦͚̺̝̗̲̳͚͍͖̲̺̥̤̙̤̥̼̯̺͓̗̺̪̹̺̠̟̬͉̩̣̼͈͖͎̺̣̦̭̝̣͍̬̯̝͕̖̳̻͈͍̭͔̤͖̯̹̰̩̤̪̹̟̹͓̰̩̭̪̪̯̻͔̝̝̲̖̯̟͙̠͈̖͚̥͕̜̙͇͎̰͚̼̹̟̫̼̠̭̫̮̣̟̳̰̖͙̼̩̪̫̬͔͙̦̣̝̮͚̳͕̞̞̱͙͇͔̦̣̻̪̲̫̟͙͙̱̩͉̰̤͉̻̖̠͎̻̖̭̺̫͎̠̺̳͖̭̗̟̟͖̗̣͓̣͙̹͈̭̝̥̝̘̪̣̪̜͕͙̲͕̗̻̲̭̝̬̞͎̫͍͔̫͔̭̹̜͇̻̠̞̤̝͚̣̤̞̲̟̩̮̩͚̖̣̣̠̖̦̤͍̳̙̜̤̤͖̬̤͂͋̐̽̇̌̓̏͐̓̌͒̈̋̐̌̇̽̊́̆͗͆͂̈́̄̽̌͊͂̂͒͑̈̆̎̾̐̈́̑̋̆́̇̅̏̍̍̂͆͋̌͆̅̅̓̀͐̓̎͛̇͐̊̔̆́̋̍̐̈́̉̃̂́̋͆̆̾̈̂̍̓͌̈́͊̌̒͒̓̓́͋̆͘̚͘̕̕̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̢̨̢̧̡̢̨̨̡̨̢̨̢̧̨̨̨̧̡̨̨̧̡̢̨̢̨̛̛̛̛̺̰͓͎̦̜̳͎̱̟̫̬̺̦̠̲͖̻̰̯̟͓̮̘̺̲͉̖͔̤̮͇̬͕̟̗͕̟͖̳͈͇̠͙͔̙̟̜̞̝̦̠̞̥͉̺̺͚͚̜̦̞̖͖̙̤̥̤̺͈̪̻͎̫̖̠̲̖̰̣̯̟̱͇͇̞̙͖͇̲̯̼̱̬̪͎̺͍̮͔̖̻̮̹͉̻̣̮̺̝͓̯̣̩̗̹͖̝̗̳͕͇̠̱͕͔̩͙̤̣̻͎̣̺͕̠̠̗̻̬͖̞̼̹̣̟̳̦̻͚̦͔̣͍̪̦̮̰͉̪̹̣͕͇͇̣̮̤̹̤̠̜̤̤̱̖͈̺̲̯̹̱̲̺̗̠̻̝̗̦̖͉͈̝̞̮̲̻̻̘̠͖̜̮͔̬͖̼̳̼̱̇̐̑̐̄̈́͆̏́̎̒̽̈́́̌̐̐̓̀̎̐̎̀͑̏͋͌̌̉̏̄͌̐̽̊̈̈̿͛̈́̄̿͌̎̿͆̽͑̀̅͒̌̓̈͑́̈̋́̂̿͗̈̇́͆͗͌̀͒̌̎̓̓̈͛̉͆̔͑̅͆̽͂̐̊͗̇̓̓̀̀͌̒́͒̎̑́͊͒̇̓̽͑̅̔͋͗̀́̾̌́̑͂͊̈͆͗̔̎̕͘̕͘̕͘͘̕̚̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͠͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̢̨̢̧̧̧̧̧̡̧̡̧̢̧̨̡̨̧̡̢̢̢̧̡̛̛̛̫̰̭̹̖̯̞̼̤̪̝̰̱͕̫͖̖̻̹̺͕̫͇͙̦̻͍̼̖͚͍̼̭̮̱͇͎͕̲̺̣͖̙̘̬̪͎̥̼̣̘̠̲̗̜̬̮̹̞̗̩̺͍̪̙̥͙̟̼̩̠̬̣̦͇̤̻̰̭͓̦͖̲̜̪̖̪̙̺͙̲͖̩̮̰͎̱̺̜̫̬̻̜̦̼͎̭̥̥̺̤̬̬̤̳̪̙͍̙̺̤͙̪͍̺͚͙͎͕͇̲̞̙̬̣̰̯̱̯̖̤̬̯̳̠͇͉̠̺̻͉͇͍͍̦͕͔̣͚̹̱̘̫̜̙̫̳̪̼̩̩̰̫̳̲̞̱͖̗̙̖̳͓̹͚̻̝͉͙̞̻̐̽̀̈́͌̏́̃͛͗̔̓̍̃̍̉͊̈́̈́̀͐̒̈́̆̀̂̏̈́̆̄͗̃̓̑͌͐̀̇̿̾̐̄̆̿̉̀͋͂͒̔̓̓̌̕͘̕̕͘͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̨̡̨̡̨̡̧̡̨̧̡̨̢̡̢̢̨̧̛̛̛̣̝͈̜̜̺̦̥̺̻̣͓̹͔̙͇̙̝̝̬͈̩̭̤͔̲̭̙͉̪̜̙̹̦̫͚̻̱͕̲͖̬͖͔̺͓͉̫̘͖̜̜͍̙̪̞̭̳͈̞͙̺̤̦̟̩̝̜̝̲̙̺͖̖̹͚̝͙̪͕̩͔̰̠͙̭̼̱̠̖̫̙͙͙̦̮͚̥̩͉̭͔̲̻̜͎̫̟̳̜̬͙̯̲̣͇̬̲̩̙͉͙̙̲̟͕̫̯̠̣͙͎̺͉̳̜͙͓̟͎̼̙̻̩̝͍̖̱͎̩̙̣̦͖͓̙̜̻̩͖̲͕̩̳̘͖̤̥̤̠̠̫̠̥͙͗́͐̆͂̌̌̔̏̎̔͆̒͛͗̽͛͋́̍̑̆͌̊̇̀̄͌̇́̾̐̐̽̿́̂̓̎̏̏͌͒̑͂̍͗̈̿͌͐̍̇͋̋̄̇͊̈͒̑̐͌̓͆̀̿̓̓̓̽̾̈́͋̈́̍̈́̀̄̀̿̈́̊̒͂̀̿̆̂͆͌̓̃͋̉̆͐͊̏̓̃̑͊̆́̅̈́̆̂̃͗̀̈́̇̀̑̂̇̑̾͗͌͗͛̀̈́͗͗̔̅͋͒͆͑͋̆̋̽̔̽͂̏͂͂̐̔̽͆̈͊́̑̓̈́̂̉͂̑͂̏̄̈́̀̋̌͋̎̎̒̀̾̎̓̂̑̀̉͊͊͛͌͊̓̃̍̽̓̓͐͋͊͌̀̅̌̈́̃̅̂̽́̃̀̇̌̌̑͐̈́̆͌́͘̕̕̕̚̚̕͘͘̕͘̕̕͘͘͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̢̨̢̧̢̡̡̢̨̨̢̛̛̛̙̲̥̮͉̯̟̰͖̻̝̳̥̯͈̮̻͈̰͎̤͙͍͇̩̥̜̺̘̪̪̳̲͍͖̪̖͚͚̟̞̜̥̱̖͓͉̙͈̻̩̠̰͎̼̩̯͍̠̞͇̻̹̯͔̻̜̻̮͖̂̄͋̀͌̍̐̔͒̓̈́̏̒̎̾̓̈́̽̏̾̽̍̂̈̃̂͐̈́̿͑̿̏͂̈́͗̏͆͑̎̅̽̿͂̿̐͗̒̑̇̔̓̀͛̒̈́͛̇̀̃̈̇̀̉̐̓̈́̀̂͊̾̀͂̑̅̒̅̀̔̾͐̑̏͐̐̈́͌̀̿̔̄̊̀̿̈́̄̎̓̂̈́̀̾̌̆͑̔̒̌̔̂̍̒͆̊̈̔̓̊̆̑̐̾̂̋̏͐̽́́̑̽̀̊̅̆̔͑̋͊̍̾̉̈̆͗̏̐͗̓̏̃̂͆̆̾́̍̎͆̊̈́̊̀̔͆̔͗̓͑̈́̋̔͆͌̇͒̚͘͘̚̕̕̕͘͘̚͜͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅ�̸̨̨̧̢̢̨̡̢̡̧̡̢̢̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̗̘̺̘̖͙̙̮̭̙̤̤̲͈̲͇̹̱͍̞̱̭̣̤͔̩̝̯̘̱͙͚̟͚͇̟̭̹̟̳̯̫͔̱̝̮̜̪̙̣̣̬̦͇͚̫͍͈͇̤̠̻̻̥̼͍͈̳̙̖̖̟͎̤͎̗͉̪͍̘͓̻͇̰͓̫̆̿̎̓̄̎̒͒̊̿̐͊̀̾͆̏̋̋̇̋̂̇͐̃͌̏̈̇̽͊̌̃̍͐̅̑̎̀͛͌̉̀̆͌̆̌͐̀͊̔̍̏̉̄̑̔̍̀̐̿͌̑͂̀̈́͋̂́̀̓͛̊͌͆̈̀̊͌̌͛̎̿̀͊͑̓͆̂͒̀̆̇̍̋͂́͂̓̊̊͋̓̋̍̌́̋̈́͋͌̽̀̉͗͊̓̀̊̂̔̂̑̐͐̊͋͊͑͐̍̄̌̈͛̀̓̋̿̌͊͒̿̔́̎̆̽̋̍̋̐̇̒̐̀͌̀͛̽͆̓̔̓͂̈́͛͂̅̒͛͌̈́̓͂̇̃̂̋͛͌̿̂͂͗̓͗̐͐̓̋͑̈́̈́̈̒̓̒̈͐̅̽̓̐͛̋̀̋̊́͐͆̈́̓̄̓͆̑̉̽͑́̆͋̅̀̋̽̀̚͘̚͘̕̚̕͘̚͘͘̚̕̕̕͘̕͘̕̕̚̕̕̕͜͜͜͝͠͠͠͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͠͝͠ͅͅͅ�̸̧̨̧̧̧̧̢̧̨̨̨̡̧̡̢̡̲̞͇͖̭̼͇̹̤̺̭̦̮̣̗̠̻̗̬̼̱̮͓͉͇̯̯̘̜̰̪̟͎̳͖͈̬̣̲̭̞͓̤̰̼̭͖͕͓͓̠̼̦͔̪̘̮̼̟͙̦̤͍̪̤͇͇͕͔͚̻͍̖̜̫̻̳͙͎̝̻̜̘̱͚̙̫̜͔̩̞͖̱̝̱͙͙͓̟͓̰̰̝̥͕̣͍̤̺̼̩̥̦̫̺͖̻͚̪͎̤͔̦͓̤̗̱̦̳̘̖̬̬̩͖̟̤͍͓̞͖̰͍̜̹̻͚̺̣̗̱̝̱̞̗̝̤͖̪̱̝̟̥͖̭̗̻͕̠̼̗̹̥͈̙͉̘̝̦̹͇͓̠̤̝̹̮̘̜͉̭̠͇͇͕̫͈͉͔̫̞͙̮̺͎̗̳̝̩̦̠͈̳̲̱̝̲͇͖͕̹̺̲̠̯̠̥̫͍̱̰̤̫͙̰̞̰̍͐͑̑̍̇̿͐͐̀͌͜͜͜͜ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̸̢̡̨̨̡̨̢̧̡̢̢̨̡̢̧̛̛̛̛̛͙̝͇͓̻̻̬̙̦͙̪̬̪̲̼̬̦̫͕͍̪̩͈̭̭̭̙͖͍̜̜͔̰͔̝̼͈̭̹̯͚̩͉͚̞̼͕̭͇̬͔̦͉̞͈̲̯͍̜̝̦̭͈̠͇͓͓͎͈͔͍̬̟̺̣̞͇̰̲̩̻̺̼̠̠̭͚͙͚͕̞̯͔͉̤̘̲̫̣̗̭͖͚͙̹̬̣̭̝̰̲̣͖͉̬̖͈͔̜̥̻̖͕̝̹͇̺̥̳̻̤̹͓͎̮̠̻̬̞̳̜̝̹̪̰̖̺̗̼̱̩̰̘̩̹̩̬͚̥̻̩͍͍̪̘̤̪͍͓̰̘͙̹͇̖̘̥͙̼̫̦͎̠͍̫͖̯̭̠̼̙͔͔̙͇̘̪͚͕͓̠͕͇̪̳̺̖̱̳͉̭̞̰͕̺̺̤̦̻͇̠͔̤̣͔̗̭͍̺͔̳̺̘̤̭̎͊̃̍́́̀́̓̏̓̐̑̑͋́̆̓͋͆͑͑̈̽͌͊͑̔̐̇͐̓̾͑́̆̔̊̌͋̏͋̒͐̊͑͗̆̆͗̔̔̒̈́̐͊̋͛̆̈͊̈́̂̑̋͌͛̾̈̿̄̓͋̀̍͛̎͊̆̐̔͆͆͐̐͑̎̋̉̾̄̍̈́̆̄͛̐͗͌͒̑͋͂͊͆̾̄̓̀̽̊̀̍͒̂͐͛̉̄̓̒̃̅͊͗̏̑̈́̃̂̾̍̈́̔̒̂̂͗̂̄̋̽̏̈̍̏̿̄͛̿͆̎͊̋̇̈́̎̓̌̈́̿̀̇́̓̌̈̄̅͆̉́̑̓̔̽̀̇̋̅̄͒́̽̐̑̀̀̓͑̂̉̈́̏͐͗̍̎̈́͑͑̈͊͊̽́̑̒̃̐͛̾͑̾̈́̊͘͘͘̕͘͘̚̚̕̕̕͘͘̚͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̡̡̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̠̟̣̜̩̰̫̽̈́̿̿̊͛̒̿͊̏̄̅́͛̾̆̆̍͛͌̀̈́̃̓́̈́̽̐̅́̉͐̾͆̏́̄̍̈́̉͌̃̈̌̇̄͋̍̈̑̅͛͑͂̐̈́̇̊̅͐̉̐̊͑̑̏́̇̈́̅̌̌̈́̓̓̒̎̈́͑̉̇̏̂͛̍̑̃̋̀̑̒̓͛̽̍̈́̏̂̽͊̇́̔̋̊̇͗́͊̉̀̄̀̑͂͑̋̂̏̓̄̂̒͊̆͑̋̀̄̀̒͐̈́̈́͑̊̉̎̊̿̀̀̆̓̏̄̉̈̇̃͊͋̃̿̒͋̀̈̊̈͐̈̆̇̓̒̋͒̑̔́̈́͒̎͗̒̅̂̍̀̅͒̉̒̿̿̈́̍̀́̐̌̍̄̀͐̓̊̚͘̕͘̚̚̚͘̕̚̕̚̚͘̕͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͝͝͠͠͠͝͠�̴̧̡̡̨̡̧̢̢̢̧̛̛͚̖̻̖̥͈̫̯͎̗͈͔̬̘̠̜͈͇̹̗͓̟̳̮̳̦̟̮̯͖͈̻͍͇̝̦̠̦̘͕̫̩̖̞̲͓̙̟̟͈͔̮̖͔͎̤̩͖̮̝̫̠̙̉͊̄̏̏̀͛̈́̔̈́̈́̃̂̀́̒͊͊̊̆͆̓̄͑̔̊̉̈́̾̈́̓͐̑̂̆́̐́̉͆͛͌̐̐͛͌̒̓̐̏̔͂͌̄̃̒̀̎̈́̑̏̀͑̾̂͋̐̋̆̃̽̽͆̀̏͑̑̐͂́̍͒̓̈̎͌̇̂̄̈̔͊̓̔̒̄̈́̌́͌͐̽̈̔͛̿͆̑̇̾͋̂̓̌̐̐̋͂̍̌̒͛̇͘͘̕̚̕̕̚̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͠͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅ�̵̨̡̨̢̢̨̨̡̨̡̡̨̨̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̘̲̰̝̟̹̣͉͈̗̜̥̺̩̰̥̯̼̟͓̜͓̹͎͙̩̳̮̱͖̘̬͖̮̮̖̙̯̤̥͕̮͙͙̺̩̤͇̜͇̺̯̗̰̫͓͈͎͔͉̪͖̻̟̻͍͖͔̺͕̲̳̘̩͙͖͎̱̬̞͔͓͓̳̖̟͍̼͎̮̣̳͖̦̬͇̹̘̞͍̭͎̺̖̙͉̖̠̣͚̦̙͍̱͕͚͎̜̺̠̻͚̩̩͙̙̞̩̹̬͕͔̖̥̣͚͓̟̬͎̖̜̫͖̹͙̱͉̫̱͈̘̩̞̞̺̬̬̻̤̰̾̊̇̂̿̃̀̋̍̔́̏̉̆̀͋̀͌̊̑̉͐̃̏̓͌̇̓̓͆͌̓͊̽̑̓̊̊͌̐́͌͗̇́͗̊́͋̽̇͆̂̌̂̿̉̋̎̅̓̂͐̃̌̋͐̃͒̈̉̃̅͐̈́̀̽͊̆̋́̈́̾̈́́͑̍̍̐̋͒͌̑̽͗́̀̿̉̌͊̔͌́̊̿̈́͛̎̀̐̑̾̉̈̒̈́̔́̂͛̀́̊̊̈̍̔̽̓̓̈́̋͋͆̍̃̋̆̈́̑̄̇̄̈́̂͗̾͌̎̈́͑̀̃͆̉͊̌̎̏̀̋̍͊̀͐̂̒͒̎̉̐̽͌͐̍̑̆̈́̈́́̿̌͌̾͆͒̓̿́̅̈́͗̑̇͂̔͛̄͋͐̅̂̂̓͌͌̀̓́̀̓̋̆̋̆̃̿͋̎͛̓̆̀̍́̀͛̎̓͒̊̐͋͊̿̽̉̓͆̂͒̈̈̈́͆̅͒͗́̒͘̚͘͘̚̕̕̕̕̕̕̚̚͘̕͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̨̨̨̨̡̧̢̢̡̡̡̨̢̡̨̧̧̡̨̧̨̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̣̙͉̝̺̱̼͚͖̤̖̬̺̲̗͉̟̥̮̖͍͖̤̟̲̤̟̗̜͖̹̣͚̼̬͙̲̗̘̞̝̮̺̰̙̦̝̯̖̼̘̖͔͍͉͚̺͙̮̱̠̫͍̼̜̳̩̳̜͎͍̹̤̝͙̥̼͓͖̳̫̩̲̱̘̲̼̞̠̠̜̲̤͔̥͍̙̩̞̖̩̘̞̩͉͎̮̭͎͙̖̬̦̯̭͙̬͚̯̜̪̝̙̝͎͇̱̬͕͖̠̬̣̻̹̼̙͉̹̘͍̲̤͎̮̮̫̬̼͓͈̮̗͙͎̥̟̮̥͍̘̭͍̫̱͈̩̣̬̳͈̙͖̯͚͇͚̮̲̬̤̰͚̳͈͚͇̳̞̖̬̟̣̻̹̰͕̰̠̃̏̽̓͒͊͆̈̀̊̈́̄̑͂͑̒̈́͌̓̆͑̈́̇̆̾̾̉͂́̃̄́͑̓͂̂͛̈́͂͊̿̒̅̋̈́̓̓̋̆̑̋̀̾̌͂͐̃̃̆̃͛͋̊̎̇́͆̐̍̀͒͛̀͐̈̀̒͋̓͊̂̾͑̄̉̇̒̄̈́̋̊̈͗̓̒̏͂͒̋͛̔͌͒̄͒́̌̇̇͂̈́̍̐̃́́͊̈́̑̀̋̿͆̃̇̒̎͊͒̇͋̈́͆̍͊͑̒́̒̑͋́̂̊̓͛́̐̍͊̀̊͒̂͋͑̒͑̈́̀̒͗̔͑̎̑̒̾̍̃̃̾͂̊̌͂͛͗̀̑́̋́̾̀̀̈̿͂͌̓̽̿̄̇̇̉̊̾̽̔̏͌̀̉̀͌͂͘̚̕̕͘͘̚̕̚͘͘̕̚̕͘͘̚͘̚̕͜͜͜͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̨̨̨̨̢̢̨̨̨̨̨̡̨̧̢̧̢̨̢̡̡̡̡̨̛̛̱̳̝͇͚̦͔̞͍̗͕͖͔̼͔͓̣̬͚̟̟̣͖̣̥̫̝̩̤̤̘͖̮̩̩̰̳̱̦̭̖̹̟̝͚̜̳̪̭͍̟͉͇͈̼̮̙̲͈̪͉͕̱̘̯͙̰͇̥̘̠͕͔̖̫̞̲̥͍̙̖͎̤̳̬̳̦̣̲̤͓̭̯̦̪̤͍͇͚͉̲̲̮̦̱̹͍̗͔͇̭̻̜̦̦̫̘̭̳̫͔̘͕͈͖͍̼̬͚͓̝̦͖̹̤̫͚̠̤̤̙̩͓̥̺̭̦̱͍̻͍̗̟͙̘̥̰͉̪̣̳͎̤̗̖̰̖̲̠̭̳̣͉͇̦̥̤̳͖̺̥̬̱̥̠̿̔̿̿͗̆͗͊̑̀̈̈̅̇̌̋̾̈́͊́̈́̇͂̊̆͛̏̉̈͆̉̏̃͛̔͋̀̔͋̅̑̏͋͛̏̈́͑̃̓̒̽͌̅̿͑̓͋̂̃̔̓̍̑̑̃͋̆͒̃̽͌̅̈́́̿̽̿͛̐̈́̇͊͑̄̆͊̄̇̐̓̈͒̾̀͌̀͗̉̔͑͂̌̈́̇̀̄̆̏̓̾͋̾̋͂͊̍̃̚̚͘͘̚̕͘͘͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̷̡̡̢̡̨̨̡̧̢̢̧̨̢̡̨̢̨̛̛̛̛̛̛͕̪͕̫̰͓̠̖̹̟̫̲̻͖̺̬̭̦̙̩͓̯̗͎̞͕̠͈͎̞̖͍̥͙̩̠̖̺̪͍͍̹̰̙̜̱̰͔̦̖̻͇̳͔̠̰̞̹̘̲̫̮̭̜̲̤̞̬̼͍͙̞̤̤͕̦͖̬̭̹̼̳̺̫̝̼̮̳̰̞̯̬̜̟̺̲͍͔̪̜̹̩̤̱̲̬̱̖͎͔͉̻͕͔̼̩̟͇̟̫̻̺̮̤͍̲̞͍͎̥͙̲̘̐̀̊͑͋͂̌̽̊͛͊̿͑̅̔̈̑̈̌̿̽͆̍͐̔̌͊̓̓̔͒̏͊̐̄́͋̂̀̿͊̈́̆̃͒͂͌́͊̊͆̄̓̂̇͋̓̿̓̅͌͌̂̓̍̽̈́͆̇͂̋̐͌̃̉͆̆̑̀͒͋̏̇̍̒̿͆͗̐̓͒͗̎͊͋͊̍͊͌͋͐̐̊̓́̂̇̓̋̅̾̋̌̔́́̀́̅̌̀̈́͋̈́͆͛̿͐̏̒͊̽̇̎́̐̏͆͒̒̈́̑͆̎̑̀̑́̏̄̇̈̽̽̈̎̇͂̋̒̆̑̿̉̀̇̽̎̂͒͌̋̈́̋̇́̈́͆̀͛̓̂̂̇̆́́̇̀̓̊̀͐͋̆̓̑̌͑̋̆̃͒̉̈́̓̎̅͌̈̓͒̐͋͑̅͋̋̋̏̍̄̀̒̒͘͘̚̚̕̚̚̕̕̕̕̚̚͘̕̚̚͘̚̕͘͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͠͠͝͝͠͝͠͝ͅͅ�̵̨̡̢̡̛̛̛̛̛̩̪̺̫̤̥̹͖͈̘͔̣͉̼̻̣͕̥̜̼̙̤͖̻͈̻͔̝͙̫̥̣̱͕̖̅͊̈́̓̑̈́̍̾́̑̑͋̊́̈́̈̔̅̊͂̉̄̔̌͌͂̾͑͂͂̋́̍̏̑̋̌̌́̿͒͊͊̈́̄́̃̆͒̎̀͂̀̿̆̀̅̆͆̈́̒̽̐̾͂̓̋̀̍̊̏̇̈̒͌̊̃͂̀̽̂̓̉͂̒̅̃̓̊̈́̿͛̈́̈́͂̑͊̒̐̓̈̎̍͑̿̈́͋́̊̎̆͒̊̂̿͒̐̃̀̈́͐̿̈́̎̎̏͊̐̓͒̽͆́̆̃̅̔̄́̎̓̉̀͊̏̓͊̍̉̌̌͊̅̊́̇̅̉̅͑͆͌̉͑̃͋̾̅͛̒̇͊͆̀̑̎̽͋͑̔̓̐̐́̒͆̂̉̐͋̽̚̕̚͘͘͘̕͘̚̚̚̕͘̕̕͠͠͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅ�̴̢̧̡̡̡̢̢̧̧̨̡̛̛̛̮͙̖̱̜͉̬͉͖̼̣̥̳͉̖͚̗̻̮͙̹͇̰͚͕̤̣̠͕̣͚̬̗̖͉̹̬̦͚͙̰̹̳̟̭̬̭̖̱̙͖̞̝̣͚̙͇̤̱̞̣͎̦͖͍̼̼̥̟̥̻̺̯̭̞͖̮̪̘̲̞͕̘̖͙̩̬͖͍͙̥̦͖̝̞̙͙̫̩̹͇̼̩͈̱̠̀͂̾̅̍̆̽́͑̈́̀̈̓̇͆̒̆̔̎̿̃̀͌̌̽͌̌̍̊̾͂͐͐̽̒̋̌̽͑̉̐͌́͗̓͗̓̋̏̉̾̔̀̇̊̎̔̈́͊͗̇̍̒̊̿͂̒͆͌̓̀́̈̍̊̉̽̓̔̏͛͛̇̌́͆̃̉͐̐̈́̐́̾͂͋̐̾̈̉̄̇̓̄̎͆̋͂͑̇̓̎̀̓̀́̏̏͌̓͐̍̊͋̀̐̿̈̄̅̊̽̈́͌͂͐͒̈̈́̋̔̂̽̈̚͘͘̕͘̚͘͘̚̕̕͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͠͠͠ͅͅ�̵̧̧̢̧̧̡̡̨̧̨̨̨̨̢̡̡̧̢̨̨̢̢̡̡̨̧̡̧̘̲͚̬͙͙͔͍̻̻̺̝̰̞̹͈̣̳̲̳̞̼̜͖͔͚̮̤͎̦͙͙̬͍͖̺̤̱͓̥̜̣̖̭̰͕̼̩̲̪͇̘͈͔̪̳̗̠̹̝͔͎̯̦̺͕̘̣̤͈̞̱̞̯̩͇͙̝͖̫͔͇̩̺͇̝̘̩̠̙͈̤͈̺̫͉͈͎͎̭̘̤̤̟͔̻̩͇̣̲͙̬̻̣̮̳̮̦̦̳̗͙̜͎̝̟̥̯͔͙̱̤̞̪͈̥̙̝̦̘̥̙͎̙̣̝͈̺̮̟̼͓̗͚̯͉̟̦̜̱̜̞̮̲̳̟̮͈͇͕̬̫̼̟̭͇͕̰͍͔̹̬̼̺͔͇̼̞̬̘̝̪̗͉̹̎͌̎́͆̆̉́͋̈́͋̈̊̍̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝ͅͅͅ�̸̢̧̧̧̨̨̢̧̡̢̨̡̢̧̢̢̢̡̢̨̢̧̨̡̧̢̧̢̨̧̢̨̜͖̜͎̖̫͉͔͙̬͙͍̖̟̟̖̺̰͍̬̘̠̮̪̻͎̺̬̪̥̜̟̬͇̞̝̗͔̼͖̤̖͚̻̦̲̩̻͙̭̠̼̜̯̘̤̳̼̳̖̮̭̠̯̻͎̮̫̯͉̥̞̪̼͔̣̮̯̯͚̻͉̻̥͙̤͎̙͕̱̥̤̬̦͙̜͉͓̼͎͈̮͙̻͍͙̞̩̼̮͔̬̩͈̦̤̣̼̯̟̫͓̜̳͕̪̼̱͈̙͖͖̣͓̺͎͔̝͇̩̘̦͙͙͙̮͕̺͔̣̬̤̫̹̱̰̲͍̠̭̱̞̝̞̞̰̻̹͙͕̰̩̤̖̹̖̣̦̭̝̹̟̣̳͔̠̞̖͎̹͚͍̬͙̝̹͕͙̫̠̠̙̙̤̮̺͙̝̳͕͔͇̼̠͕̝̣̫͕̹̮̩̗̳̠̫̳̫͎͕̎́̉̓͌́̎̂̃̎͆̃͆͋͐̓́̈́͂̅̈́̌̈́̈́̽̄̔̒͋͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̢̧̧̛̛̪̳̜̲͖͇͓̪̘̦̟͙̦̦̠̪̜͈̠̝̺̗͈͈̱̦̦̞̣̰̟͍͇̼͍͔̮͎͖̝̲͔͉̘̦̤͉̪͚̺͈̓̀͋̀̀̇͗̄́̈̉͋̔̑̿͐͌̈́̅̋͒͂̏̇̅͆̀̿̔͗̈́̑͋͆̒̾͂̓͂́̌̈́͗̇͛͆͒̂̓͗̊̔̆̎̂̔̔͆̃̐̑̀̆̾͛̈͗͂̓̍̊̈̌̋́̃͆̿̅̏̓̂̉̒́͆̌̾̓̏̽̾̆̽̄̇͛̐̈́̉̔̓́̾̀͂͋̓̈̕̕̚̕͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝ͅ�̸̨̨̡̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛͔̪̘͇̩̯͉̲͍̣̠̤̱̗͎̝̺̺̳̤͖͇̘̱͒̏̐̎͒̾̍̾̓̀͗̎̓̐̒̅̈̉̇́͂̈́̃͗͂̒̃̉͛̉̋̉̎̽̓̐̏̔̀̂͒̎́̆͆̀̈́̀̿̈́̾͐̒͛̂̏̉͐͊̌̈́̀̍̋̌̋̆͌̽̒̌̈́̍̇̄̈́̉͑̍͌̾̇͑͆͊͂̋͑̌͛̆̀̐́͋̏̓̊̋͛͒̀̎̐̐͂̔̿̈́̕͘͘̚̚̚͘͠͝͝͝͠͝͠͝�̵̨̧̡̢̨̧̡̢̨̨̨̧̡̨̢̡̛̛̛̛͖͔̫̺̙͉̰͖̮͇̰͍̰̗̩̩͈͇̺̖̥̰̲̣̱͕͙̳̹̠̹͙̘͖̻̲̜̰̮̤̻͖͙̭̙̝̺̦̲̝͖͎̦͈͈͖̪̺̠̣͎̮̟̫̬̲̯͎̖̭̼͉͓͎̮̹̹̬̞͈̯̞͚̰͖̳̱̼̣͔̫͍̻̝͓̗̱̮͇̯̲̹̠̯̬͔̹̤̻͉̲̲͕̙̩̖͙͉͓̰̫̩̤̲͎̺͇͉̣͇̪̖̗̦̲̠̻̙͈̥̺̹̹͕̣͍̩͈͖̜̼̱͚͇̟͙͙̻͚̩̩̟̮̼̰̗̲͇̘̖̗̠̲̣̗̼̰͎͎̺̘̦̝͇̮̞͓̘͙̈́̓́̀̄̾̃̎̿̂͋̂̽̑̊̏́̄̀̆̒̃̓̓̉̄̒̓́̈́̀́͂̃̔̐̒̽͋͌̀̄͛͊͐̽͑̽̋̿̈͑̄̓̓̾̔̅͊̌͑̊̎͆̍̌̋͆̐̒͊̽͌̓̅̅͂̿̈́̓̎̀̎̂͋̀͋̌̽̊̾̊͊̏̾̎̔́̀̑͂͂̋̀͑̓̍̇̌̓̈́̉̊͒̏̃͌͊̓̂̍̋͛̾͛̃́̒̃̿͑͗͋̆̿̑̈̊̀̃͋̀͐̓͆̀́͂̓̋́̾̔̋̈́̍͒͂̈̔͐̋͆̇̇͂͐͗͆̓̈́̄͆̐̅̎͆̐͑̀͆͑́̆͗̽̃̎̄̈̋͊̌͒̃̆͊̎͌̊͌̾̂͛̐̆̈́͘̚̕̕͘̕͘̕͘͘̕̕̕͘̚̚̚͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͠͠͝͠͠͝͠͠͠͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̢̧̧̨̨̨̢̨̧̧̢̡̢̢̨̡̡̗̦̝̟̯̰͓̪̫͈͓͇͓̯̗̖̖̝̗̲̙̼̫͎͚̤͔̱̜͙͔̝̩͍͓̝͎̹͙̫͇̬̟̟̠̠̪̰̟͉̯̹̗̼͈̩̬͉̮̜̱̬̟͎̻̪͇̞͔̞̰͖̱̱̤̣̮̱͚̰̞͈̯̘̲̬̜̝̱̗̤͙̰͕͕̺̺̞͙̬̫̲̙̼̦̘̹͙̖̳͓͍̱̲͖͕͔͚̦̬̠̱̟̻͉̳̼̻͓̘̼̹̖͍̖̞͙̼̳̩̰̙̣̰͙̮̖̫̯̭͉̟͔̼̼̫͔̰̺̪̲̩̱͖̬̪̗̘̪̘̺̤̭͈̣̯̞̣͕̟̺̞͇̯͇̬̦͕̩͉̱̰̰̣͙͕̝̭̜̩̝̖̜͈̗̯̥̳̙̞̦̟͉̮̫̹̫̠̲̠͖͎͙͇̹̲̞̘̀̂̒͛͐̌̒͑̓̅̏͊͑͗̋̃̾̾͒͌̏̈́̀̒̍̉́͊́̇̒́͋̆̋́̍͐̂̀̅̇̈́̊̔̃̊̄̂̆̊͛͆̈́̀̍̂͊̐̑̊̌̒̾̂́̒̀̔͌͗͌̓͗̒̌͛́̈́͛̾̑͐̎̂̿̍́͗͘̕̕͘̚͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̢̢̧̢̨̨̡̧̡̛̛̛̛͔̲̼͍̪̯̱̗̮̹̹̮̲͍͕͇͕̼̮̘̯̜̠͔̳̳̮̫͈̳̘̰̜͇͈͔̤̱̜̥͍̩̫̦͇͍̠͙͔͇̜̺̗̳̮̺͚͎̗̟̮̠̜̜̘̖̹͎̱̯͕̜͇͇̩̯̬̥̤͓͍̘͓̤̼̠̼̰̻͖͉̝͖͍̱̭͚͇͉͖̣̬̤̤̩̜̦͈̗͓̟̗̮͔͔͓̯̳̬̟͎̠̊̅͌̎͆̿̐̌̊̈́̎͗̌̔̇͊͆́̄̌̽́̊̏̅́͊̓̋̽̍̃̆̊̐̋͂̅̈̓̆̐̀͌̓͑̍̏̈́͗̒̀̓̋͐̀̈́̿̏̒̌̔́͛̋͆̏͒͆̈͗̃̅́̇̀͌̋̌͗̉̀̆̉͛̏̅̽̓̒͒̄̏̇̿̈́̿̿̆́̀̌̔͆͂̈́̂̆̅̋́̈́͆̓̅̍̆̒̈̌͑̆̔̔̎̾́̚͘̚͘͘̚̚͜͝͠͠͝͝͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̢̡̢̢̡̢̧̡̨̨̨̡̡̨̡̡̨̨̨̧̡̛̛̛͕̤̺̜̯̞̘̺̘̟͈̗̝̭̲̤̦̗̦̗͎͈̟͉̭̭̹̲̘̱̤̩͍̹̪̺̫͖͔̥̫̲̰͉͇̭͈̫͍̖̜͕̖̜̗͖͖̜̺̝̘͚̗͍̲̝͈̥̰̖̞͍̦̱͎̞̳̻͙̠̠͕̤̱̮͓͎͎̤̺̩͚̫̪̙͖̝̣͔̩̮͕̥̪͔̩̹̺̟̻̣͈̳̞̹͓͓͙̩̥̞̣̘͇̠̠͍͖̥̹̤̪̬̞̪̞͚̜͉͕͙̜̥̹̣̣͇̲̹̣̫̲̗̗̘̰̥̺̣̻̣̣̤̬̫͈͚͍͉̝̪̥̩̞͉̳͍͔̼͇̦͉̭̻͉̰̠͍̘͓̰̘̲̜̻̰͓̫͇̱̞͎͖̠͈̫̥̟̪̘̝̦̳̘͚͎̻̩͓͈̖͚̺̺͕̣͖̣̼͕̫̅͂͆̓́̄̀́̈́̇͂̊͊̆̔͂͛̽̎̃̆̃̅̋̎̽͂̌̍͊̀͆̾̈́̒͋̉̈́̈́̑́͂̈́̒́̈́͂́̐̋͐́̎́̃̉̏̌́̇́̍̏͋̽̅̌̀͌͊̈́̐̎̓̔̽͆̈͐̾̄̏̽͑̃̆̍̀͐́̽̓͒̊̽̔̆̏͑̍̂͑́͆̐̀̓̈́̀͗̾̐̿̔̒͌̎̈́̿͘̕̕͘̕̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̨̨̢̡̧̧̧̧̨̢̢̨̨̧͔̲̹͇̩͈̟͙̰̳̰͖͍̣̰̭̖̳̖̼̤̹̮̪͙̬͇̟͚̼̦̜̱̝̱̮̹̠͕̩͔͖͖̤̞̫̻̭̮͇͈͎̫̰̯͇͎̞̬̜͚̩͈͈͇̬͖̭̠̟͉̩̝̬̱͍̘̖̬̱͙̬̤̖̱͕̼̮̥̮͙̫̻͙̦̼̭͍̤͎̦͍͉͉̻͙͔͍̫̰̪̖̤̙͔͎̤̙͕̰̮̦̮͍̯̳̻̦̭̹̬̣̱̠̳̘̼̬̼̼͔̙̥͈͖̮̬͓͉̺̮͊̆̍̋͋̾͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠ͅͅ�̵̨̧̡̧̧̢̡̢̢̧̡̛͕͍̮̟̲͈̱̠̲͈̟̖̜̪̹̳̠̦̳̗͓̲͚̻̮͔̜͍͚̞͕̹͓̟̖̞̣̦̹̬̲͍̝̗̙̥͚̼͉͍͙̗̙̺̪̱̗͎̳̹̦̟͔͚̥̠̖̠̺͕̝̦̮͓̰̪͈͎̤̠̗̣͎̦̜̠͉͚̪͚͕̟̝̗̞̫͙̮̮̺̟̣̖̥͙̗̥͉̺̜̥̞͎̘͚͎̤̭͖̮̫̯̟̖̜̞͉̻̯̩͎͉̮̱̪̯̠̻̭̻̬͙̯͔̜̱͎̗̞͓̪̲̼̘̥͉̪̝̙̗̜̤̫̦̤̩̩̭̤̫͓̻̰̙͕̰̞͔̩̱͚̤̇̽̔͆̽̓͐̉̐̌̈̃͒͋̔̔̔͆̐̎̾̒̈́̀͒̿̓̾͑̍̍̀̿͑̍̄̊̅̑̓̔͛͛̄̊̾̒̒̐̽̏̌͋̍̋͐͗́̿̂̈́̄́̇̄̌̓̆̆͒̅̏̇̉̒̇̊͋͂͒͂̍͑̒̂̄̋̏̾́̏̌͛͆̊̔́̂͛́͊̄́͌̎͂́̕̚͘̚͘̚̚͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̷̨̢̨̨̧̢̢̡̨̛̛̛̛̻͔͚̞̙̘̮̹̥̜̮̯͇̙͇̫̭̥̣͚͙̥͇̳̟͈̭̙͓̺͎̬̪͕̳̹̹͕͉͓̹̱̣̰̫͖̠̭̣̩̹̻̮͈̩͕̲̯̰̼͔̦̞̬̹͈͍̭̟̖̘̀̊́̍̈͗̂̔̌̆͂̍̓̆̊̆̽̃̊̂̔́̒̏̃͌̍͋̒͂͑̐̑̈́͆̏̊̉͂̌͒̄̃͑̈́̊̑̋͑͌̾̒̈́̒́̈͊͌̿̏̋̋̃͑͆͂̈́͌̀̓͂̽̍̃̈̀͒͂̈́͛̈́̾̈́͂́̆̒̽̋͑̃̔͌̾́͊̾͗̈́͆͐̌̿͗̇͋̎̇́́́̄͒̓̑̅̽͊̑̋͑̊́͋͐̆̓̏̾̍͗̑̌̃̎̊̂̃́̒̈͌̾̈̇͛̈́̔̏̿̾̄͛͛͆̋̇̄͘͘̚͘̕̕͘̕̕̕͘͘͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠ͅͅͅ�̶̡̡̧̡̢̡̛̛̫̳̤̲̩̖͖͙̳̝̝͙̜̬̰̺̼͙̜͚̤̻̮̭̜͚̟͓͚̲̹̠̺̤̩̰͔̘̜̪̦͉͖͉̣͖̤̯͇̝͇̭̠͎͓̭͖͔̥̼̦̦̟̫̫̮͕͇͔̙̮̹̹̝̖̭͈̂̑̇̉̓̿̽̎͛̈́͛̆̒̉̋͛̌̓̀͋́̐̓̏͂̋̆̆̒̾̀̃̐̆̿̐̂͗̒̾̓̎̄͌͆́͆͌͊̑͗̑̋̽̽̂͒͋͌̑͐̅̈́͗̂̐̏̂̓̈́̔͊̓̌͒̉̀͗̐̏̔͂͐̃̿͊͂͑̈͊͑̀̊̅̓̉͛̋̎͋̍̃́̇̂̚̚̚͘̚̕̕͘̚̚̚̚͜͜͠͝ͅͅͅͅ�̷̧̧̨̨̢̧̢̧̧̧̢̨̧̡̢̨̨̡̧̡̛̹̪̰̲̼̮̞͈̠̼̱͔̻̻̹͕͓͚̣͎̰̰̦͉̩̼̬̳̰͕̫̪̦̼̳̰͇̣͓͓̹͙̖̪͙̬͇̜̩̤̗̺̟̩͎̗̺̺̘̼̰͉̺͔͇̣̰͙̗̭͕̬͚̥̼̺̤̖̻͕̫͙̟̰͎͓̰͍̮͉̗̫͉̖̫̱̤̝͇̘̳̪͉̯̮̟̣͎͇̗̖̝̞̣̮͙̗̘̟̺̼̪̖̼͚͉͎̫̯̫̹̗͕̫̤͔̟̩͍̥͙̦̲̪̲͈͚̰͓̤͉̙͎̠̤̪̻̺͗̇͌̌̅̀͂͒̈́̒̃̀̑͂̃̈́͐̈́̊̋̈́̎͛̊̂̆̐͌̆͂͗̈́̒̀̒͑͑̿̃͗́̀̇̽͐̌̏̂̈́̎̓̏͌͐̀̓͌̄̈́͑́̊̊͌̈́͘͘͘͘̕͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅ�̵̧̡̢̧̨̢̧̢̡̨̢̧̛̛͕͙̞̞̫̰̠̜̹͚̹͕̙̥̰̦̘̳̝͙̜̭̗͈̤͈̬̲͚̹͈̘͍͖̮̮͇̼͇̫̺̘͎͚͓̣̞̣̯͓̺̩̬͈͈͉̳̣̫̯̜̠̪̯̤͕̠̻͔͔̺̯̻͇͍̹̦͍͚͔̻̲̜̖͓͕͙͔̮͈̘̝̫̙̻̮̰̙͎̩̗̟͕͕̆̓̎͛͗̂̋͋̾͐̉͆̓̑́̈́̒̏̔̏̑̾͊̋́͆͌͂̊̾͐̇̿̌̇̓͐̑̈̽̾̀̌̀͂̓̈̓̈́̉͋̈̇̋͐́̅͒͑̊̊͛́̒͂̉̈́̒͂̏̊̀͛̀̔̂͌͆̊͗́͌̽͑͋̉̒̽̇͐͛̌͌͌̋̍͗̆͌̿͛͑̈́͘̚̕̕̚̚̕̚̚͘͘͜͜͜͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͠�̵̢̨̧̧̢̧̢̡̧̧̨̢̢̡̨̡̢̨̡̧̧̡̢̨̧̨̧̨̡̡̨̢̛̛̛͕̮̦̦̫͚̣̲̳̮̲͈̙̲̭̖͓̜̯̥̱̦̗̖͕̙̣͓̗̝̝͓̻͈̟̙̭͍̯̺̪͓͙̻̱̘̼͎̠̭̳͍̳̝̯̰̩̳̮͓̲̗̭̘͕͉͕̗̼̥̗̱̤̟̩͎͈̭̝͙͎̗̜̣̹̜͚̺̹̹͎̺͉̫̩̩̝͖̯̝̲̘̘̞̪̝̳͙̟͇̪̤͚̜̬̱̩͖̩͖͇͎̥̫̪̘͔̜̪̞̭̗͔͚̘̱͎͖̯̪̞̯̱̜̭̳͚͓̦̪͙̖̱̥̰̣̖̖͓̰͉̙̼̙͚̪̲̣̠̙̯̼̹͖̮̞͉̘̩̜̫̩͖͇̮̲̖͚̦̳̠̘̱͇̺̹͚̞̮͖̬͈͓̹͕̤̬̲̝̗̠̩̟̬͎̫̹̺̪͚͔͔̠̮̣̤̭̣̥͎̽̀͒̆̈́̂̓͂̉͑̈́͊̒́͒͐́̑̊̓͌̅̇̃́̅̿̾͂̒͑͗̾́͐́̽̑͑͒́̾̔̿̍͆̈̽̎̔͊́́̾͒̒̀͂̾̂̆́̓̏̃̿̽̈́̊̓̄̃̓͒̄̑͗̋̽̀͊̽̎̀̏̃̆̈́̋̈́́̑̀̾̈̋͌͛͆͂̊͒̌͋̍͛̎̏̄̈͗̈́̀̌̄̑̋̄̎͑̈́̈́̕̚̕̕͘͘̕̕͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͠͝͠͝͠͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̷̨̧̨̡̡̛̛̛̻̺͎̻̹̦̝̖͇͉͇̜̙͇̘͚̬̜̣͔̲͎̬̻̲̟͈̳̖͎̰̟̙̖͍̼͉̂̐͆̀̈́͐͑̓͒̎̀̊̽̎̋̊̏̉̆̔̎́̂̐̇̄̑̌̆̃̄̅͂̉̈́̾̀̅̌̀̉̓̋̈́̅̂̀̄͊͆͑̀̌̓̔́̂̏̇̊͆̓͆̓̆̒͗̓͊͐͊̈́̓̾̃̄͂́͑̋̆͑͑̈̊̑̑̄͆̽͐̈́̓̔̎́̋͊͑̋̈́̄͆͛̄͊̑̄̈͆͂̈́̑͂̀̀̀̍̔͋̊͋̃̏̚͘͘̚̕͘͘̚̕͘̕̚͜͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝�̴̢̧̨̨̢̧̨̧̨̧̨̨̨̡̢̨̢̨̢̛̛̛̩̦̱̪͓͍̤͓̱͈̝͇͈̼̣̞̺͍̟͔͎̻͙͓͙̯̥̗͚̱̞͈͉͎̠̣̮͚̺̰̱͔̹̳͍̻̥̥̼̟̬̪̟̱̺̙͈͕̝̼͔̻̣͙͔͕̥̤̺̠̯͕͙̘̲̣̤̬̥̜̥̫̤̮̗̘̹̱͍̻͈͇̘̰̜̙̖̝̳̻͎̝͎͚̭͓̱͚̙̭̹͕̖̖̝̮̬̥͚̣̯͓͈̥̳͔̪̥͍̗̻̱̻̖̙̺͓̰̱̞͇̫̺͔̰̪̹̺̹͈̖̭͙̜͙͚͓̣͎̞̠̙̹͍̫̱̪̪̠͖̲̮̬̙͖̖̘̥̣̭̳̻̱͓͔͚͙̹͎̟̺̗͙̠͓̗̱̪͚͇͍͍̯̝̗̮̙̳͙̮̻̘̯̮̩̣̪̖̻̬̰͕͎̫͍̯̅͂̓͒̌̓̍̋͌̓̏̾͋̀̂̅̒̈́̐̇̎̽͌̂͋̆̓̀͌̽̾͛̇̍̔̍̈͋̀̉̌̑̅͂̉̂̆̽̓̃̈́͒͒̀̌̄̅̐̑̈̿̏̀͗̍͐̑̌͛̔͐̾͊̇̄̓̈́͂̐́̔̄͗̓̓͂̎̀͗̈͋͊̇͐̈̉̆̃͂̾̈́͛̀̄͆͆̿̓̌͑̉͂̊̀̑̂͊̃͛͒̈́͌̏̅͊̂̓̐̉̊̈́̈́̃̓̀̌̿̾̌̑̾͊̄̓̿̀͒͂̾̄͆̂̏͂̇̄̀̓̽̄͑͒̈́̈̌̒́̆̈́̐̓̃̐͗͒̈́̌͆̔̋̓͑̿͌̀͒̔́̐͑̑͂͗́̍́́͒̍͊̏́̔̓̈̊̈́̆̽͐͐͐́͂̊̓̽͒̔̓̀̑͛̌̊̋͂̉̓́̽͒́̽͊́͗̕͘̕̚͘̚͘͘̕̚͘̕̕̕͘̚̕̚̚̚͘̕̚͘̕͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͠͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̷̨̧̧̡̡̧̢̡̨̛̛̛͈͚͇͔̻̫̻͕͕͕̻͖͙̥̠͈͙͖̲̣̬̻̘̜̬̙͍̪̠̭̖͖̥̙̻̲͚͎͖̝͎̼͙̝̖̭̬̠̥̬͉̠̬̪̖͍̗͎̙͚̯͈̩̈́͆̉͛̔̐̒̊̋̋́̈́͂̔͂̿̾̾̀̉̾̒͒̈͊̓̏̍̇͐͆̐̾́̂̈́̅̔̄̅̑̓̈͗̓̍̿̎̋̀͒͐͋́̑̿̓́̇̓̃̓̓̇̀̂̉̆͑̀͗͐̓̓̆͂͋̇̀̅̃̿̄̄͗̋́́̌͌̊̈́̓̋̍͛̓͒̍̀͆̅̈́͂͋̀̌̍̔͊̐͑̍̑̀͘͘͘̚̕͘̕̕͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͠͠͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅͅͅ�̷̨̨̢̧̢̧̢̧̢̛̛̛̛̛̛̥͇̬͓̪͕̬͔̮̝̖̰̯͉̲̤̖͉͎̥̞̬̻̱̫̫̗̺̪͎͉͍͈͈̮̣̫̫̗͚͇̻̬͕͖̲̜͔͇͎͙͕͇̯̪̭̟̺͍̞͖̠̯͍̲͙͕͔̖̼͈̙̳̟͔̪̗̯͙͉͈͎̪̙̝̰̦̠̝̩̗̪̮̝͉̠̭̭͇̪̯̣͔̩̙͎̗̪̥̹̣͇̪̺͉̲͚̝̲̜͇̳̮̪̺͚̣͔̝̩̺͇̠͍͎̖͍̘̠͇͔̯̟̪̜̜̼̠̮͔̩̱̞͎̳͎̯̃̆́͛̏͗̀̅̔͆͊̓̐̌͗̾̀̀̇̀̍͌͂̋̇͌̇͒̿̀̿͛͗̇̓̌̉̈́̑̅̓̉̅͂̀̍͊̿̍̎͑͐̎̉̇͗̀́̅͐͌͊́̎̉̀̋́̍̍́́̅̑͑̂͋̽̓͐̉̇̃͐̅̍̔̍̓̒̏͂͐̃̔̒̀͒̐̉̿̔̿͆͛̎̎̀̏̀̇̒̉̍̈̆͊̀̓̅̎̿̈͋̋̿̓̑̅͒͊͊̈́̍̀̓̑̀͋̿̐́̓̊́̏͂̐̊̏͘̚̕̕̕͘͘̕͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝�̸͍̝͔͓̘̥̻̮͇͍͖̠̒̂͊͊̽̒͂̉̆̓̾̒̎̉̀̍́̎̒̇͆̋͑́̈̅͌͛̍̿̀̎͊̇̂͊̉̍͛͂̚͘͝͝͝�̴̧̧̧̡̧̨̧̨̢̨̢̧̛̛̛̛̛͍̩̺͕͍͖̠̪͚̹̠͇͚̥̫̜̜̗̫̤̫̩̱̙̳̬͍̖̰̝̥̮͈͖̬̠̺͕͖̖͖̹̖̲͖̰͖͈͙̬̲̥͇̯̬͇͓̫̩͖̪̲͔̞̮̣̪̩̙̦̙̦̭̣̙̹̱̯̮̦̪̣̰͈̖̹̜͕̲͍̜̻̣̙͇͔̗̗̬̪̦͉̺̟̹̤͖̮̤͉͇̬̥͚̗͓̫͚̮̣̪͉͚̟̙̰͎͕͎̤͎̙̦͛͑̓̈̇̈́͐̎͆̒͐̈́̈́̈̽̑̐̔̊̂̈́̏͋͌̋̌̅̂̽͂̎͋̓͛̃̾̽̋̅̏̌̈̅̾̀̉̃̊͂͊̉̄͑̐̈̈́̍̔̓̈͒͂̔̽̈́̀̀̇̒͌̆̏̅̒̃̈̇̒͑̏͒͛́̍̄̆̀̓̓̈͆͗͛͊͋͋͂̂̈́̂̉͑̃́̒͗̆̄̓̉͆̃͐͋́̅̐͑̋͌̈̒̎̓̊̏̓͐͐̋̎̈́̀̈́̂̆̆̉̋̅̈́̉̈́̒̀͋̐͌̋̈̂͛͆́̇͗́̒́͊̂́̀̏̈̔͛͊̽̔̃̔̌̇̊́͊̄͋̎̓̿́̀̈́̏̂͐̋̔̏͌͆̔̈́͊̿́͋̉̌̐̈́̊͆͂̊̌̓̈́͆́͋̈́̄̈́̈́͆̿̈́̃̊̈̋͊̒̽̒̿̏̋͌͌̈́̎͑̉̾̐̀̈̈́̓͗͌̔̇̿̈́̍̐̀̈̔͑́͂̕̕͘̕̕͘̕̕̕̚͘̚̚̕̕͘͜͜͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͝͠͠͝͝͠͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̧̧̡̨̨̢̢̡̛̙̙̗̦̼̟̠̥̳͓̪̟͎̟̟̯̜̝̯̩̖̖͎̼̰͇̘̦̯͇̥̘̙̺͙͚͕̰̻̫̹̠̩͍̩̹͓͓̰͙͚̖͔͈͚̣̪̖̞̲̰̮͈̭̫̫͈̦̻̤̩̦̯̣̯̳͓̮̜͔͉̗̥͚̦̲̩͚̭̩͙̫̖̣͈̠͔̰͖̻̺̘̗͓͈̯̩̙̪͚͖̹̞͙̫̹̬̞̻̫̣͍̪̲͎͖͕̖͓̲͍̬͎̭̺̭̘͙͚͕̳̫̲̺̪̬̜͚̤̩̯͙̤͈̮͙̭̣̲̲̬̯̓̿́̈̌̍̎̆̄̓͑̀͂̈́̇̓͐͐̓̐̈́̿͛͑͛̔͐͐̋̀̉́͛̈́̈́͗̐̆̽̍̎͐̋̿̐̿͑̀̏́͌̏́̿͑̏͘͘̚͘̕͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͝͝͠͝ͅͅ�̸̡̨̢̡̢̛̛̛̤̝̺̪̭̬̳͍͙̫͎̺̘̬͉̗̻̼̩̘̞̖̪̻̹̞͚̗̳͎͔̺̲͚̪͚̠̙̲̙̜͇̹̭̗͇̗͔͈̹̦̫̫͎͉̞̯̣͚̲̣̫̱̯̩̝̜̫̼͖̮̰̫͔͎̘̻͓̝͍͉̻̹̤͕͙̲̞̳̙̩̜̮͎̫̙̖̘̣͂̌̌́̐̍͛̏͊͛̽͊͗͗͛͋̽̋̓͌͑̄͒̆̊́̑͋̑̎́̀̔̾̓̉̔͋̿̊͋̄̈́͋͐̓̍̈́͒͐̈́͗͌̿̀̓̐͊̀̅̓̂̀̏̌̌̒͌͌͋̌́̇͘̚̕̕̚̕͘�̶̨̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̲̰͓̩̳̞̥͈̤̣̝̬̞̤̓̀̓͑̈́̅̈́̂̒͗͋̔̒̋̊͌̅͋͗́̆̎͛̊̄̽͂̅̃̄͛͑̽̆̅̈́̎̄̅̾̏͆́̀̑͌̉͛̽̒͗̐̀̑̇̍͋̀͂̆̆̔͆͑͗͐̉̀́̊́͑͒̈́̉̔̈̄͛̾́̃͑́͊̎́̌̒̃͆́̄͌̒̌̄́͒̀̓̉̒̃͒͗͌̎͊̋̏́̑̈́̈̆̃̇̓͋͆̃̇͋́̈́̈́͛́̓̿̐͑͆͆́̅̓̑̏̓̊̄̈͌̒͑̉̈̂͌̒̈́̌͂̃̏͌̾́͋͆̈̀̄̋̑͌̽̒̑̋̓̆̓͑̏̾̌̌̏͐͐̎̇̑̓̀̇͒̽̌͗̒̅͗͗̀͆̇̈́́̂͂̌̽̄̇̈̎́͐̈́̈́̇̍̀̿̅̔̑̽̍͋̂̋̀͊̾̈́̋̐̿̇͛̋̉̔̉́̂͘͘̚̕͘̚̕͘͘̕͘͘̕̚̕̕̕͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠ͅ�̷̡̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̦̻̳̼͖̫̬̠̟̰͎̹̫̼̬̦̰̹͕̫̮̺̻̥̖̤͕͔̱̫͎͚̦͖̹͖͉̳̘̻͓͓̣̱͔̇̉͋̐̅͐̅̇͛̉̿͋̈́̿͒̊̀̉̎̾̐́̓́͐͐͛̋́͋̾͒́͋̒͌͐̆̓̑̌̍̅͗͋̈́̊̔̑̑̎̔̋̉̓͊͊̓̓̅́̓̋̋̒̓͆̆̔̾̿͂̂͗́̎̇͑̎̈́͌̋̅̽̓͌̿͂̆͊̓̋͑̓̋̈̈́̎̇̈̈́͆͌̇͛̍̓̃̑͛͋͊̓̐͐͆̀͒̂̎̑̉́́͊͛́̃́̈͌̅̈͛͛̊̆̿̄͌͆̏̅̑̑̕̚̚͘͘͘͘̕̚͘̕͘͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝�̵̧̠̜͕͓̫̳̱̉́́̊̏̀̏́͝�̶̡̨̨̢̧̨̧̧̢̨̨̡̨̧̢̢̢̧̡̡̨̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̖̱̺̥̙͖̟͎̮̫̖̞̗̳̼͍͖͇̯̠̲̘̬̯̜̠͍̩͉̲͖̳̼̬̹̠̥̥͍̝͉̥͇͔̺͇͉̟̦͇͕̥͇̱̤͓̻̖͉͍̰͔͇͚͍̺̱͈̠͎͈̺̘̥͉̺̜̜̙͖̣̩̼͈͖̘͙̘̤̯̠̼̯̭̠̦̱̺̬̗̭̙̜͓̭̖͙͙̦͔̣͚̲̘̠̝̟̻͇͓̣̟̙̳̬̟͎͙̪̜͇̞͍͔̯̠̖̼̤̣̭͇̹͈̘̭͇͎̲̯̝̯͔͇̞̦͓̳͇͎͔͈͉̺̰̣̱̩̺̯͉̗̱̞̹̱̱͚̙̙̥̜̥̙̪͎̝̠̜̣̩͇͔̟͉̞̝̻͙͈̼͍̞̻̺̻̺͕̱̲͕̼͙̲̭̝͚̞̩̤̻͎͐́̐̅̂̿̾̿̊̋͋͂̀͒̅̀̉͛͆̽̌͑̽͂̾͗̇̉̽̅̿̃̔͗͋̏͌͑̈̆̊̽̂́̄̾̊̆̒̎͂̓͋͊̅̏̅̋͑̉̌̎͂̈́̆̃̂̿̈͂͂̅̀̾̐̿͛̅̓̿̎͋̿̋̂̅̊͂̋̇̽̈̎̔̓̓̌̋̈́́̆́̐́̌͋̈́̆͌͂̽̈̎͐̈̓̆͂̒͋͑͛͋̃͒͑̈́̀̇̋̌͒͒̄̿͗͆̂͒͒͑̏͌́̔̒̃͌͒̄̇͆̅̇͂̓̓̀̈́̍̃̏̉̍̈́̇͆͆̇̈́̅̈́͛͗̎̀͋͂̇͛̽̇̉͗͌̿̆̉͑͂͑̔͛̊́͛̈́̃̎̕͘̕̕͘̕̚͘̚̕̚̚̕̚̚̚͘͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̷̢̢̨̡̧̢̢̢̨̧̨̨̡̧̢̧̧̡̨̨̢̨̛̛̤̺̝̻̣̖̣͙̰̖̞͓̜̺̳͙͖̯͎̩̩̲̭̪̬̬̦̥͙̹̖̻̬̖̥̲̟̮̺̤̗̻̜͕͓̥̱̪̥̪͖͖͕̤̖̤̜̲̲̤̭̯̲͍̣̯̰̬̣͓̤͓͎̱͈̲̲̠̗͍̹̟̤͈̹͓͈̦̻̖̗͎͚͈͕̲͍̘͉̮̥͓͈̖̼͓̹͚̣̖̺̞̮͍̳̥͕̪͈̪̬̞̻̥̪̳͈͍̯̬̤̺̥̪͎̘̗̩̗͕̮̩̠̻͎͖̼̖͕̳͙̱̼̹̥̖͔͕̞͙̝͇͍͚͖͓̟͍̞̣̣̲̝̹̗̺͈͈̤̗̖͈̯̾̌̄͆͛̎̀͊́͂͂̏̎̑̈̈́͑͊̉̿̎̉̑̈́̋̌̿̊̊̉͆͛͐̋̿̈́͛̀̊̀͂̉̀̔́̒͒͋̃̈́̃͌͆͗̑̐̓͛́̄̀̀͛͂̓͋́́͌͌̌͋̈́̒̇̄̉̇̂͊̄͋̒͗̋̒̽̈́̄͂̈́͋̇̑̉́͌̽͒̾̊͒̋̐́͒̆̈́̈̊͗͒̆́̑͂͋́̾̈́̾͂͒̅́̔̇̽̀̎͂͌́̿̿͛̃̀͊̉̿̈́̀̈́̊̈́͆̉̒̾̈̅̊̑̒̇̆̓̃̈́͋͗͊͊̒̏́̅͂̉͋̌͋̍̐̎̎͐͐͋́͂̆̈́̿̐̇͂̓̆͌̽͐̉̅͛͛̈̍̔̿̇̌̂̑͐̅̀̀̂̽̒͆̋̋̾̏́̓̎͐̾̽͌̿̂̑̈̂̒̇̾̒͊̆͊̅̈́̔́́̏͐̊̿͊̂̾̎̽̒̓͑̀̆͆̚̚̕̕̚̚̚͘͘̕͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅ�̸̨̧̨̡̢̧̧̡̧̺̟̼̞͓͔͍͕͈͈̜̖̰̻͕̗̞̗̮̺͙̪̰̝̤̫̬̻̗͕̠̩͕͍̟̝͖̱̰͉̦̟͍͈̺̹̠̞͓̝͓͇̩͔̠̖͖̯͖̥̲͉̠͎͍̟͉̘̥̤͎̬͙̖̳̜͕͓̫̘̰̹̫͍͇̤̥͉̪͈̞̥͖͔̬̗͉̗̰͖̞̈́̓͋̅̊̈́͆̓́̈́̔̾̌̌́̈̑̉̉̇̃̀͋͂̅̌̍̀̿̎̒̐́̍͛͑̈́͊̕̕̕̕̕͘̕͠͠͝͝�̸̨̡̨̧̨̡̢̧̨̛̘͍͍̤̥̱̩̲̩̖͖̲͓̼̖̼̞̤̬̫̼̯̞̻̯̘̺͎̪̗͓̣͙̩̮͖̬͖͙̣̜̝̮̝̯̱̫̱̜̩̱̙̠̤̤̝̟̥̺̺͙̘̩̟̝̪̲͉̜͓͇̥̫͓̘̦̩̦̼̟̬͍̖̥͍̗̫͕̺͖͙̺͙̼̼̼̟̜̳̳̯̪͍͇̻͔̣̲̠̞̮̲̙̪̲̹͍͎̅̂̅̀̑̓̍̇̄̈̾͛̀̓̽̃̈́͆͑̓̈́̊̌̾͛͌̄̏͊̌̂̐̆̒͑̇͋̄͌̉͊̉̀̄̒̎̉́̒̈́͋͋̽̋͂̏̈́̈́̏͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅ�̷̢̡̢̢̨̨̧̢̧͔͙̠̥̹̝̬͎̜̰̙̬͎̺̭̥̫͕̹̝͕̰̦̟͇̯̖͔̗̰͔̭͍͖̥͍̣͍̙̤̦̟͔̝̘̥̗̳̯͔̳̹̞͍͚̜̻͎͙̣̤͙̳͓̩̥̗͚̣̮͕̮͖̱̬̬̳̟͖̮̼͎̹̩̤͕͍̉̏̐̋̋̿́͒̓̇͊͒̈́̈́̍̓̃̍̈͆̽̆̃̉̏̇̕̕͘͜͝ͅͅͅ�̵̧̨̛̛̛̛̛̗̖͍͎̲̫͍̮͚͍̣̯̭̪̠͈̦̩͖͖̮͔͕͈͂̑̒̔̂̊̌̿̽͊̑̒́̔̊̋́̉́͑̈̾̀͛̓̆́̀͒́͂̒͐̑̅̓̔̎̇̓́̀͛͗̽̈́̒͑̍͗͒̀͌̈͗̈́̅̌́̒͑̀͌͗̌̈͌͆͐̾̾̎̀̾̿͛͑̀̒̇̈́̔̐̆͛͂͗͛̋̄̿̄̄̊͛̿͛̈͊̈̂̏̀̈́͋͊͌̿̏̃̆̋̿̎̏̑̍̊̈́͂̽͑̓̄̉͊̂̋̈́̑́͒͑̔̔̓͆͛̈́̋̽̾̉͂̒̾̓͌̈́͗̽͆͊͒̅̏̓̾͒̅̈̂̈̽̈́̔͑̈́́́̾̐́͊̏̓̋̂͒̽͆̈́̎̑͌̑́̽͗̒̆̎̒͛̾̊̂͑̃͊̑̂̋͊͊̈͗̋̈̍̔̓̑̓̔̑̍̈̇̈́̐̓̐̑̒̍́͌͆̾͛̓̎̿̈́̋͌͑̽̈́̂͗̓̋̀̓̃̎̇̒͑̿̉̿͘̚̚̕̚̚̕̚̕͘̕̕̚̚͘̚̕͘͘͝͠͝͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͝ͅ�̸̧̨̢̨̨̡̧̨̧̨̡̢̢̨̡̨̢̡̡̧̡̨̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̩̼̻̲͓̩͉̖̲͖̖̝͙̘̲̻̗̣͔̮͕̱̙͕̺̦̺͍̪̲̫̤̼̹͎̤̠͍͎͙̤̞̘̮̼̜̪͓͍̫͔̘̳͇̪̳͈̯̻͔͔̯͕̲̞̲̹͎͓̖̳̻̞̟͍̻̰̣͔̹̮̯̟̗̱̮̩̠͎͙̜̼͔̫͚̘̲̣͙̝̙̮̩̫̘̞̰̘͚͕͍̭̳͔̝̼̹̯̪̖̬̳̤͈̝̠͈̱̩̪̞̩͚̣̹̗̜̞͍̝̘͖͇̱̬͎̣̮̼̱̺̥̰̖̹̲̤̩̬̟̟̱͇̦̣̬͇̮͉̩̥̰͋̾͋̎̿̂͛̎̆͋̑̅̓̓͒͒̆̌̍̈̀̿̓̎̏̿͛̓̐̂̏̾̀̈́͛̐̈́̑̾̽̒͒̒͒̀̎͆̉̓̐̐̀̆̾̈́͐̏̇̍̃̎́̆̿̎́͛̄̍̐̍̃̓̓̿͆̅͛̌͛̈́̉̀̓̒̌͊̔͆͐͆͆̔̾̂̇͗̈̈́̀̿̓̊̇̓̍͊̾̾͗̅̏̌̽͛̇̃̀̋̉̄͗̒̆̓̔̍͂͌͛̇͒̿̍̿̀͛̄͂̈̑̌̊͂̉̿̅̈̎̀͒̑̏̑̈́̈́́́͊͑͆̋̄̔̐̈̽͊̅̂̎̌̉͊́͌̿͊̔͌͊̆͑̈́̿͐̏͒̊̊̎̾͋́̎͆͒̔͑̍͑̈̀̈́̏̓͂̎́̽͑̀̄́̓͂̿́̒͌̉́̄̊̏̈́͛͆̀͋͐͒̆̇̍͒̀̀̐̂̓̍̍̉̎̂̃̃̌͆̊̽̏̒͌̏̌̇̂̒́́̈̽͂̈́̚̚̚̚͘̕̚̚͘͘͘̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝�̶̡̢̢̡̨̨̡̢̢̢̢̡̢̢̧̡̧̢̡̨̡̧̧̨̨̛̛͍̪͙͕̩̟̩̣̤̘̦̜̻͓̤̬̲̜̭̯̝̝̻̘̳̱̻̯̱̩̙̹̜̣̜̤͎̤̣͕̯̫̟̤͙̟̳̫̯͈̞̤̻̻̳͍̹͉̤̗̜̝̣͚̝̫̩͙̼̲̪̼̤̣̼̼̼̘̭̜͇̠͔̞͖̩̥̥̯̥̞̩̹͔̯̫̦̘̻͉͉͖̥͖̱̱̣̝̤̰͎̮̯̪̖̦̤͎͔̞̙̺͇͖͕͍͈̲̲̜̤̺̭͇̮͕̠̗̦̯͖͈͉̪̦̭͍̱̮̦͚͈̣̞̺͉̼̮̖̖̬̘̗̮̫̮̟͙̳͚͈̜̞̬̦̫͉̪̤͈͇̱͔̰̪̠̺͕̤̜̩̳̣̪̼͓̦͙͈͕̙̫̭͚̹̞̞͕͕̮͎͓̪̙̯̲̲̗̖̩̱͇͇͌̋̏̐͊̑̈́͛͐͒̀̾́̔̒͋̀͗̎͊͗̆͐̌̏̐͌͑̃͊̒̂̐̇̐̇͗̏̋̓̍̾̎̅́͊̏̏̀̂͋͑̑͗͊́͑̈̇́̄͋̅̍̋̄͐̃̈́̍͌̀̅̊͂̋̍̐̾͊̾̀̀͒̀̒̓́̀͑͒͋̀̓̇͌͒͊̓̄̒͑́̾̓̈́̉̾̈́̓̐̄̎̈́́̂̿̂̈́̋̏̎͗͑̈̂͗͑̚͘̕͘̕͘̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͠͝͠͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̸̨̡̧̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̥̪̜͇̰͔̺̭̭̜͍̹͈͔̖̤͖͇̻̠͔̖͓̣͚̟͓͇͔͔̳̥̰̎̋̏̅̌̌̍̔͐̽̐̒̇̋̎̈́͛͑̍̏͂̏͋͐̓͊͗̑̋͛̔͂̈́̈́͊̒͊̃͌̿̔̃̿̈́̋̂̀̏́̆͌̒̀̑̑͛͌͋̃̏̑̑́͆̂̒͗͂̋́͌̿͗̈̊̏̈̽̍̂̌͊͑͗͋̀̋́̏̔͌̂̒̓͒̊̓̾̀̊̎̊͌͆͑̑̐͂̄̀̋̒̾̓̒́̈̓͆̂̊̓̓͑̆̈́̃̿̾̈́̀͌̆̍̽̋̊̂̾̎͆̽̈́̋̇̌͐̈̒̽͒́̒́̕͘͘̚͘͘̕̚͘͘̕͝͝͝͠͝͝͝�̸̡̡̨̡̧̨̢̡̡̢̢̨̢̧̡̛̯̦̲̬̰̮̜̮̦̳̙̪̞͚̲̟̮̦̻̖̝̭̜̦̤̙̗̘̘̞̰̮̞͙̩͇̭̤̝̬͓̪̙͉͎͖̫̰͖̟͖͇͔̜͚̤̬̲̗͙̦̬̥̥͓̳̥͕̲͈͈̦̼͓͎̬̞͓͍͎̹̹͚̹͙̮͖͉͎̬̬̺̬͌̒̈́̀̿͂̀͛̅̅̎̋̒̐͆́̄́̊̍͊̒̋́̀̀̾̀̿̄͆̆̀̀̅̋̌͋̈́̏̽͒̔̍͌̂̔͗̊̈́̒̀̐̔̊̑͋͐͛͂̽̍̂͐͑͘̕̚̚̚͘̕͘͜͜͜͜͠͠͝͝�̷̨̧̨̡̡̧̧̢̧̡̢̢̡̧̨̧̢̡̢̢̨̢̨̡̡̧̡̧̡̛̛̱̩̳̠̥̜͓̳̹̘̜̝̠̠͓̬̱̱̗̝̤̞͇̹̝̺̬̝̤̰̠̖͔̭̮͎̘̺̯͈̹̟̠̥̲̠̺̰̟̣͎͎͚͓̙̥̝̥͔̤͚̹̱̱̼͚͕͕̘̹̺͈̙͙͕͇͖͈͕̞̺̗̠̼̫̦̯̫̦̖̦͇͉̣̩̟̲͚̮̬͚̠̖̪̩̭̼̬̺͍͙͇̝̭̱̘͓̱͙̖͈̳͉̳̙̬̰̳̝̰͚̜͙̝͚̩͕̠͇̠̬̠̳̣͔̰̟͎͉̘͙̲͕̲̺̯̩͕͖̖̹͙̹̹̗̫̼͕͈̲̙͓͚̭͕͔̼̳̣̮͓̙̬̗̘͇̖̜͍̰͈̫͍̤̭̣̯̪̻̙̪̥̫̫̯̪̞̥̘̹̙̝̞̺̰̠̲̲̲̟͔͚͙͓̜̭̞̮̘̮̙̳̯̝͕͈̝̤͙͈͉͖̬̣͚̭̝̹̼̣̫̳̈̿͆̇̌́͒͛̃̄͐͐̑̿̐͂͋͂͑̈́̈͊̊͂̍̓́͗̏̔̀̎́͊̐̾͆͆̓̀̈́̀̍̅̃̓̋̃̒͂͐͂̎͂̀͆̇̔̓͂́͑̓͛̈́̆̔͊̔̎̾̀͂͋͆̈̃̐̓̎͋̍̉̉̀͆̈͊̈́͌͆̈͌͐̋̈͘̕͘̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅͅͅ�̴̧̢̢̛̛̞̙̱̝̟͚̗̠͚͍̜̭͔͉̼͉͕̙͈̙͖̰̹͇̳̣̠̤͇̜̬̝͈̬̲̯̝͍̺̪̰̑̆͂̉͊̍̍̄̔̂̄͌̃̀̊͂̾͆̒̀͐̐̍̂̏͊̈̃͑̑́͐̇͗̎̑̿́͒́̾͐̎̈́̽̐̿̈́̈̆̏̎̀̚̚͘͘͘̚̚͝͠͝͝ͅ�̶̛̛̛̥̥͈̘̣̏̆̄͊̋̈́̈́̀̉͋̈́̿̒̔̈̔͂͗̿̔͋̏̅͗͒̐͋͒̂̌̓̌͊͂̂́̎́̍̿̏͋̎̇͗̽̓̑̎̌͂͊̂̅̉̃͂̌̎̄̒̋̿́̾̀̒͗̑͂̀̅̌̈́̏̽͗̓̐̎̿̎̏̌̀͆͆͂̑̓́̽̂͆͛̑́͆̂͂́͆̋̂̈́͒̈̾̄̽͐̋͊́͊͂̄̉̾̏͐͛̓̏̒͊͌́͛̉̐̎̈́̈́̔̏̔͂̍̂͛͗̊̏̎̔̂͋̍͑̾͗̓͊͊̀̎͐̈͐͛̎̈͗͌̃́́̇͒̔͆̑̾́̉͒͒̓͒͐̎̌̐̉̔̕̚̕͘͘̚͘̚̕̕͘̚̕̕̚͘̚̚͘̕̕͘͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝�̵̢̨̛̛̭̳̞͚͇̩̬̹̱̖̫̖͈̬̝̞̫̝͇̖̟̮͓͔͓̻̂̍̾̀̃̂͐̔̊̾̍̈́͂̀͆̍̈̔̽̈́̌̓̏̏̽̏̅̈́̾̈́̇̓̎͑̒̎̑͐͋́͌̍̇̅͌͌̇͐́̊͋͒́̃́̒̔̊̓̆́̃̓̔͌̀̈́́̎̂́͒̈́̍̈́͆̅́́̽̄̓̈́͂̍͆̈́́͗̈̃͑͂͒̾̕̕͘͘̕͘̕͘͘͜͜͠͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅ�̴̧̛̛̛̛̛͕͔̥̱̰̮͇̤̻̗͚̰͈͔̜͈̙̟̜̗̮̣̎́̃̋̏̇͆͌̿̋͗̉̑̇̒͂͛͐̋͛̓̒̐̔͆̀̽̓͆̈́̎̇̿͐̅̈́͗̒̿̎̈͆̅͛̌͌͑̈́͋͊̅̊̓̈́̎͊̉͋̽̓͌͋͊̒̉̌̋͑͐͑̊̾̑̓͛̎͊̽̉̀̌̃̑̈́̇̌̂͗͗̒̇̈́̋͌͛̽͊͌̍͒͋̿̎͐̿̈̌̈́͑̈́̽̈́̾́͗̊̋̆̈́̃̍̔̆͑̾̓͆̈̈́͂̈́̃̂͑̀̓̓͒͂͌̊̎̚͘̚̕̕̚̚͘͘̕̚͘̕͘̕̕͝͝͝͝͝͝͝�̵̧̧̨̢̨̡̢̧̛̛̛̛̻̜͎̭̱̬̤̹̤͉̯̰̺̫̦̪͇͓̥͇̪̭̖͙̦̟̝͓̠̯̜̬̬̗͓̼̤̩̗͉̥̖̳̫̥̼̮̻́̽̇̓͊͂̆̂̀̈́̊̐̈́̈́͆̊̔͊̃͊̓́̀̒̀̑͑̾̈̈͂̾̓͒̓̑̈̈́̔̔͆̇̽̇͑͒͊̑̈́̔̈́̓͂͑̆̂̒͗̀͊́̋̃͑̿̇̎̉̂̿̈́̽̽̏̓̏͂͗̅̑̾̃̎̀͗̏̈́͊̑̀̅̾̎́̇͊̂͑̿̍̐̌́̌͌͗͂̽̽̋̄͆͌͒͆̐̂͋͑́̋̌̌̈́͗̿̈̅͆͆͒͛̅̑̂͋̈́̾͂̂͂̉̈̃͌̽̀͗̈́̎̐́͌̽̔̉́̈͐̋̽͌̉͛̂͗͑̌́̏͘̕̚͘͘̕̕̕̚͘̕̚̚̚̕͜͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͠͠�̵̧̧̧̨̢̧̨̢̡̢̢̢̨̢̡̨̢̧̧̡̨̢̢̨̢̧̡̡̩͔̪̣̼̭͓̙̘̪̯̳̱̗̲̣̪͇̪͈͙̘̻͔̯̗͔̗̤̲̲̤̪͍̮̘̗̟̭̬͉͚̺͔̻̹̭̫̣̰͓͕̳͙̬̭͓̪͓̺͚͕̺͚͍̰̥̮̯̣̞̗̰̦͔̬̗̩̥͖͖̲͖̩̝̝̲̮̳͚̜̜̺͈̼̺̗̰̪̖͎͓̼̟̟͎̝͇͇̗̬̼̮̗̼̗̮̥̹̳͓͚͍͕͚̦͈̞̦̖͉̟̤̪̼͍̦͓͉̯̠͔̬̻̖̣̟͓͔̫̯̩̣̯͓̳͎̝̟͍͕͇͖̲͈̻̤̯̜͚̩̣̲̤͚͖͕̹̳̲̰̯̺̞͉̲̗͍̤͇̘̺̞̦͇̲̀̍̋̍̔̆͆͑̌̽̽͒̓̍̍͑̒̽͋̇̉̿̈́̐̉̓́̉̽͛̇͋̆͌̿̌̂̋̂̃̿̾́̾̈̃͆̉̈́̾̉̍̊̀́̎͊̐́͂͛͛̈́͐̊̑͋̀͋̓́̚̚͘̚̚̚̕͘͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅ�̸̨̢̡̨̢̧̧̢̨͇͉̟̫͖͖͎̟͚͉̘̱̖͖̦̪͙̥̲̟̦̰̦̯̣͙̯͓̬̺̼̙̙̹̫̖̘̞͍̳̩̤̮͎̠̜̫͙̳̝̱̟̹̦̭͖͓̗̩͉͖͍̤̟̬̫̗͉̣̠̩̩̳͉̣̻̥̬͎̰̩͕͒̓̾̆̉̀̒̑͘͜͜͜͝�̷̢̨̨̡̧̨̨̨̡̧̧̧̡̨̡̨̨̡̨̡̡̧̧̡̧̛̛͈͖̣̭̝͎̮̜̲̹̙͍̥̞͖̠̜̭͎̥̩̝̗̙̞̬̻̭͇̺͉͍͔̙͕͖͇̮̞̩͖͖͉̮̝̻͓͍̝̗̥̰̺̘̯͇̥̹͇͈̦̲͉͓̰̝̤̪̙̩̟̘͉̜͕̺̰͓͎͕͖̜̲̪̭̱̺͎̖̼̼̮̳͇̠̠̬͎̙͍̩̖̘̤̻̩̞̤̣͍̠͔̝̗͈̜̼̠͕͙̣̲͎̭̦͇̰̙̤̠̣̮̻̬͈̩͇̥͔͎̬̺̪͎̤͓̲̜̬̬̫͇̯̺͈͕̞̫̥͉̰̩͉̗̪̜̭͍͖͈̳̗̞̤̪͔͕̭̟̮͓͖̗̻̰̹͖̩̻̱̫̤͙̤̮̖̬͖̣͓̹̮̬̬̫̪̠̣͉̮͇̻̹͇͇͍̱̠̦̙͙̠̗͓̲͔̘̤̠̙͓̮̠̹̬̹̣̯̯̀͊͗̈́̈́̌̏̈́́̐̀͛̑͂̀̐̿͊̏͑̽̌̐̄̂̏̋͘̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝ͅͅͅͅ�̶̨̧̧̨̨̧̢̨̨̨̡̨̛͔̼̱͔͓̬͙̼̙͈̬̹̦̺̯͕̥̞͚̪̩̫̻̖̤̭̺̻͉̘̞̞̞͇͈̯͖̤͍̤͎͕̱̝̹̯͉̲͙͔̤͕̮͇̫̟̼̹̰̤͉̳̩̼̝̫͇̙̞̻̮̙̪̲͎͉̼̼͚̫̰̠̟̻̹͍͕͙̟̞͎̤̥̖̫̜̺̗̲̩̰͔̪̞̼̺͔̟̜̼̻̻͎̺̜̮̝̻̰̺̪̮̗͚̰̼͕̜̺̣̠̺̩͖͇̼̗̯͕̖̳͙̟̹̭̺́̅͊̾̓̇̍̍̅̌͌̊̇̍̐̀̈́̚̕̕͜͜͜ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̢̨̨̧̡̢̡̢̢̨̢̧̡̢̧̧̧̡̧̡̡̨̢̧̨̢̢̡̧̨̢̛̛̙̫̫͔͔̭̝̤̟̗͕̪̖̲͚̰̺͇̠̱͓̲͇̯̱̘͍̜͓̹͔̟̟͚͉̝̹̝̱͎̫̠̩̭̬͖̱̺̱͚̘̤̠̭͎̥͇̝̩̺̱̤̹̥͉̮͉̞̱̬̮̩̱̙̺̘̮͉̺͙̖̖̱̦̹̠̻̖͇̹͙̮̼̤̮͖̙̠̤͉͍̞͖̼̼͚̘̲̥͚̗͚̥̱̤͖͖̰͉̤̭̗̼̝̮̦͇̫͎͈̫͔͓̗̬͖̲͙͔͚̟̞͈̪͓̫͉̻̖͍͇͖̙̖̖̮̘̣̼̭̳̺̗͎̣̩̝͈̮̺̱̭̥̞̭̰̺̬̣͈̤̱̜̥̙͔̟̖͇̟̳͓̜̖̗͍̩̖̬͇̙͍̗͎̣̙̬̤̳̞̖͈̫͈͈͒̐̇̈́̓̿̏͌̄͂̍̀͛̂̏͗͌̏̄̈́́̔͐̈̊̊͛͗͊́̆̊́̒̊͒̾̾̏͛̅̍͌̅͛̅͐͗̐̿́̍̂̿̋̅͊̈́͐̀̊̐͊́͊̎̐̍̊̐͛̅̍́̾̃̿̿̑́͗̈̈́͑̾̎̈́̑̾̚̕̚̕̚̕͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̧̨̢̧̡̢̡̨̢̨̨̡̡̢̢̛̛̛̛̺̜̹͉͔͈͓̮̜̦͎̞̝͙̟̻̦̰̲̯̳͙̮̳̳͉͈͔̰̞͕̲̗̜̦̞̲̣̘̲̼͕̩̺̮̱̖͎̤̘̗̬͕̰̤̤̞͔̪̖̮͎͓̟͕̦͚̺̝̫̘̘̥̙͎̬̭̫̣̣̝͙̖̩͋͋͛́̇͌̀̂̔̓́̎͑̀̽̓̎͌̌͑͆̆̈̿̽̍̿͗͐̾̀̿̑̾̔̀̃͐̎̊̄͂̓͆̒́̈́͗͗̾͐́́́͑̒̄̈́͐̏̏̋̏̃̽͐̉̿̒͗͂̃͋̇̔̆̑́̎̔̾̀̄̍̃͐͆͒̋̍̀̔̎͌͗̀̓̎̈́͋͊̇̆̽̏̒͊̀͂͊̎̑͗͗͂͋͐̂͂̀͆̈́̉̆̂̓̎̃̑̒̓͑͂̐̂͆̽̐̎̿͗́̕͘̕̕͘͘͘̚̚̕̕̚͘̕͘͘͜͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝�̴̢̢̢̡̧̢̡̢̨̧̢̨̛̛̟̟̦͇͔͔̫̯̦̰͉̪͔͙̜̯̥̼̖͔͕̣͍̗͓̮͙͈̮͖̹̜̪̟̞̙̩̞̲͍̮̟͔̬̬̰̲̦̘̦͉̠̩͔̭̠̣͔̟̠̝͈̲̘̣͍͎̖͈̦̻̖͖͖̬͓͎͉̤̺̥͕͈̱͇͕̗͇̘̞̤͇̖͇̭̱̞̹̲̙̭̥̙̮̭̦͙̦̫̖̞͎̲̤̗̜̱͎͉̤͉͉͈̤͍̦͍̻̘͔̰͇͍̲̞͚̰͖̠̪̗͍̤̤̝̼̗͚̙̥̲̣̗͔̮̙̺̯̙̙͇͙̟̙̍̍̊̾̾̈́͒̽̂̋́̓̑̍͒͂̇͐͑͗̓͒̈́͒̃̈́̌͂̓̒͛̄̓͗̋̍͋̀͊͆̀̽̎̑̔̏̔͂̌̈́̍̈́̍́͑̈̓̍͑̍̓̄́͊̆̀͛̓̏̋͐͊͋́̋̾̐̌̅́̍̈́̿̕̚̕̚̚͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͝͠͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅ�̷̨̡̧̧̧̧̢̨̧̡̡̧̢̨̨̨̡̼͚͔̼̙̬͕̗͖͓̤̯͔͓̤͈̖͇͕͍̣͍̦͙̹̙̟̬̜̯̩͎̟͈̥͇̯͎̞͔̦͓̯̗̻͇̠̝̲̥̯̮͎̱͉̜̩͓̮͖̳̘̖͕͓̼̪̥̬̩̥̪͙̟̣̦̝̗̤̣̞̞̩̟̖̗͔̘͚͉̞̺͚̼̩̹̝̤̦̭̹͚̬̬̪̟̗̣̹̘̹̲͖̭̗̪̞̲͇͚̘͎̗̙͕͕͓̰͔̘͙̦̙͓͚̟͔͓͈̰̬̟͙̟̥̰̻̼̭̱̘̲͖̠̮̯͖̹̪̬̺̫̝̖̝̦̠̣̥̭̮͈̬̜̞̯͙̥̠̝͎͍̻̗̬͊̒̀̇̈́͐͊̈́͜͜͜ͅͅ�̴̨̨̡̢̨̡̧̨̢̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̤̩͉̞̭̤͖̤̹̟̥̯͚̼͎͉͈͖̮̞̣̜̹̥̠̯̞̭͍̲̺̤͎̪̹̣̦̮̦̙̩͇͚̼̪̗͉̳͇̮͎̭̜̼̼̟̟̙̫̰̟̙̥͇͕͓̙̺͔͕̰̙͍̲̜̬̼̼̩̭̤̟͇̭͖̣̠͚̪̺̬̱̩͇̯̜̗͔̻̗͔͎̩͚̦͖͉͉̹̲̣̺̰̯̠͕̜͕̞͍̠̙̲̭͓͍̦̫̥͚̥̼̮̹̲͇̼̹͔̫̹̘͈͕͔̻̟̰̗̺͚̩͍̙̪̘͎̤̟̱́̈̆̓̈̿͆͑̾̋̿́͋͊̂̂̉͐̏͋͌͂͑̇̀̐́̐́̐̈́͗͋̽̿̒̽͂̓̽́̈͂͒͒͐̍̌͐̒͐̅̅͋͌̾͒͋̌̉̊̔̽̐́̍́̿̿͗͋̋̓͗̈͋͑̊͐͐̅̍͊̎͋̀̈́̅͊͗̐͊̇͆̈́̃̅̌̆̃̿̔͛͊̊͐̐͗̄̀̈́͆͌̆̓̈́̀̓̃͌̅͑̊̓̽̊͊͂́̈́͛̿̋͂̓̐̿̐̿̊̈́͋͗̊̉̐̌̏̽̓̌̏͗͊̎͌͗͆̈̑͋̂̿̄̌̓̇̆̓̉̅̂͆͆̊̇̔̉̈͗̐͒̂̚̚̕̚͘͘̕͘͘̚͘̕͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅ�̷̡̡̢̧̡̨̢̧̨̧̨̧̡̡̢̡̧̨̧̧̧̢̧̨̨̢̧̢̢̨̢̛̪͈̥̪̰̖̦͎͎̟͖̯̲͈̭̼̞͖͇̫͈͓̖͔͖͍͔̤̬̙̪̙͔͍͚͔͚̗̠̮̪͎̳̭̩̭̗͙͙͙̟͕͈͈̖̳̙͉͈͍̮̖̥̳̝͓͙͚̲̟̝̻̳̞̼̲̩̖̪̞͉̺̰̪̳̞͖͚̦͉̞̺̩̠̟̖̩̲͍͔͚̙̺̦͇̯͖̦͇̹̳̜͖̪̠̻͈͖̤̮̦̟̥̬̭̭̳̦͓̟͇͇͓̻̝͚̬̞͈̟̠̗̱̗͎̗͍͙̣̟̬̰̗̟͎͕͔͔̲͈̥̩̩͔̗̥̠͕̪̗̘͔̮̖͉̻͔̘̹̳̘̰̺̠̰̭̺͈̹̞̥̲̦̦̺͉̭̘̫̇͂͛̉̿͊͂̔͌̒̈́̉͊̈́̎̑͒͐̄̍͋́͂̔͌̒̒͂̈́̽̀͂̋̇̃̆̎̍̄́͐̅̐̾̀͒̌̿͑̏̽̅̑̉̐̉̀̅̆͒̑̄̽͆̊̆͊̌̂͑̓͌͛́͊̆̒̐̓͂̓̈́͋̓͛͋͂͊͘̚̚̚̕͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅ�̶̨̡̧̡̨̡̡̡̢̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̰͓̩͈̖͔̲̞͎̣͈̣̲̰̟͎̳̺͎̳̪̪͎̹͎͙̲̗̝̘̤̯̮͍͎̙̺̪̜̜͚̣̞͕͉̲̬̮͔̬͇̳̘͙̩̳̞͎͍̞̘̗͖̦͉̮̙̦͖̟͕̳͙̼̗͙͉̗̜̲̦̩̹̜͕̠̮̬̪̝̬͓͉͚̤̭͔̼̙̦̰͔̳̬̦̯͕̱̭̗͙̤̹̖̒̔͋̈́̃̔́̉́̌̉̏͌̍̔͌͗̒̎͋̈́̇̊̃̓͋̍̎́̍̆͗͆̈́́̍̔͂̈́̒́͌͂̑̂̄̀̂̾̉̀͛̀̒̊̋̄̓̈́̈́͊̍̽̈́̎̓̉͛̓͑̍̊̎̾͋̓͊̽̿͌̽̉͐́̈͐͑̐͌̎́́̈́̐̂͋̒̐̎͂̂̅͗͋̓̇̊͂̏̀͗̆͋͂͒̃͆̃͗͆̃̔̾̏̃͛͒̊́͛͑̅͊̎̏̈̔͋̽̿͊̆̊̈́̈́̔̓̀́̈́̊̆̀̒̓͛̌̊̾̅̔̒̏̄̽́͋̋͌̔̂́̒̆̌͐͋̅̀̒̆̂̒̍͌͑̀̈́̐̏̇̓̓̈́͐̀̀̽̌͊͐̾͒́̊̿̈͆́͋̀̽̃͂̀̍̈͗̋̊̿̎̎̾̋̏̌̎́̑͒̊͌͆̈́͘̚̕̕̚͘̚̕̕̕̕͘̚͘̕̕͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͠͝͠͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝ͅͅ�̸͕͕̱͔̺̘̆̓̇̈́̔̋̽͗̀̓͐̔̓̊̏̀̿͒̓̐́̂͗̑̅͆̈́̏̚̕͘̕͘͠͝͠�̴̢̨̧̧̡̧̨̨̨̢̡̢̡̡̢̨̢̧̡̛̛̛̛̛̤̻̜͍̯̼͎̫̘̝̩̘͙͙͚̗͚͍̻̠̳̣̘͔̘̬͖̤̘̲̟̬̠͇̝̞͓̗͇̝͈͍̣̫͔̝̩̙̙͔̩̳̫̼̙͔̼̩̣͔̻͚̫̳̼̱̫͕̻̼̯̘͇̼͔̭̝͕̥̮̪̗̳̝̰̲̪̬̪̞̳̙̟̲̳͔̩̮̖̞̭̲̩̥͓̣̘̮͖͕̘̺̯̼͍̳̹̰̝͓̼̺͇̘̺̘̟̯̹̖̠̳̠̼͍̥̜̠͕̺͈͍͓̬̼͎̘͓̜̲͉͇͉͉̰̖͎̰̯̱͕̲̲̗̖̜̹̲̦̱͉̪̠̫̫̮̫̩͉̟̙̮͎̀̈́̔̊͆̑̈́̊̎̆̈͑̋͗̂̀̍̆̏̉̄̋͊̆͑͂͒͂̊͌͌̒̓͋̈́̍̔̓́͗̍̆̈͐̃̏̔̂̈̔̆̾͌̉̑͐̑̎̄̈́͒͂̓̄̋̀̓̿̽̔̒̾̈́̅̀̓͊́̇͑̐̈́̔̐͒̾͋͒̈́̊̾͐̆̀͛́́̽̃̀̾̊͗̉̈́̀̐̐͌́́̉̆͂͑͛̈́̔̐͒̃̏͂̓̐̉́̃͆̊́͐̋̾͒̌͘̕̕͘̚̕̚̚̚̚͜͜͜͜͠͠͠͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̸̛̛̛̛̛̮̱͈̗̙̗̀̄̅̉̄̂̌͑̍̊͑͌͂̇̀̑̐͊̈̐̏̿́̈̿̄̂͂̍̃̂̑̀̆̏͒͌̓̑̉̾̐́̎̆̉͊̆̿̀̆̉̿̈́͊͛̓́̓̈̾̓̌͗̑̍͛͐́̄̍̀̽́̅͑͒̈́̋͑̅̈́̽̚͘͘̕̚̚͝͠͝͝͝ͅ�̸̢̡̢̢̢̨̢̧̧̢̨̨̡̢̢̛̰̝̺̺̞̠̩̣̪̜̪̯̘͍̲̤͚̘͙͍̻̹͚̫̳̥̜͕̯̺͖͉̬̝̞͍̞͕͔͔̠̩̳̮͖͕͙̹̩͓̦̤͕̯̩̱̯͍̬̞̖̻͈̪̥̪͔̥̤͖̺͚͓̖͎̥̲̹̗͚̹͉̲̝͉̞̙͚͕̙͎͈̹͇̯̯̰̖̳̙̪͎̣̖̬̠̳̜̖̟̰͎̪͓̞̮̼̠̼̰͎̙̯̤̞̠̫̘̜̹̼̺̞͖̟̮̙̲̻͙̭̬̘͚̹͚̲̜̟̟̮̭̟̪͍̮̫̮̩̙͕̺̼͙̪̦͙̱̤͓̖̟̦͈̳̩̭͍̺̗̫̯͔͔͓͇͕̯̤̥̠̣̼͓̜̙̺͉͖̬̘̖͇̳͎͇̟̜̘̖̞̩̘̘͊̈́̊̐͊̍͒̅̈́́̊͛͂̈͂̐̍̒̃̋̀̈̈́͌̒̓͌̃̍͋̓̎̈́͐̏́̿̆͑̽͌̔̊̊́͋̀͗̅̋̑̔̄͋͋̈̃̐̇͋̋͂͑̈́͌̿̅̃͗̓̒̆͗͌̈́͑͋̓̐̀̋̊̂̊̑͊́͌̎̎̔́̋̔͛̀̾͐̐̂͛̐̾̓̃̇̄̌̒͊̏́͛͛̇͛̾̌̀̈̈́̍̍̃͊̌́́̚̕̕̕͘̕̚̕̚̚͜͜͜͜͝͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̡̢̢̧̨̯̬̻̻̻̱̫͕͙͕̖̺̩̱͓̦̺̣̙̮̜͚̫͖͈̩͖̝͔̘͙̖̥͈̗̒̎̏͘�̶̨̡̡̡̨̨̡̧̨̢̨̢̢̨̡̢̢̡̧̨̢̢̢̛̛̛̛̛̛̛͙͇̠̳̪̞̯͖̲̦͍͚͔͉͈͙̱̮̯͉̜͉͎͖̫̗̪͓̯̲̯̠̰̝͚̺̖͈̫͍̫̜̦̘̝̰͍̪̪̘̤̼̠͚̖͎̱̳̮̪͙̼͈̼̦͖̲̜̣̻̙͉͇̬̖̱̭̣̥̦̟̭͙̼͖͙͕̹̗͎͍͈̭̜͉͓̳̹͈̪̲̟̳͚͈̻͖͎̺̘̱̘̰͎̗͇͈̰̜͎͎̭̬̱̹̜̱͔̘̜̖̺̪̯̟̺͔͕̮̲̦͉̘̠̰̩̹̗͙̙̹̼̹̦̭͕͖̭̘̩̪͓̻̪̣͚̾̀͛̿̇̀̄͆̌̎́̍̐͂̋̎̃̈̔̂̉̆͐͋̄̓̋͐̏͆̓̐̉̀̿͆̄͂̈͑̍͗̓͆̈̅̇̉͒̏͋͛̐̌͑̓̾̍͌͌̀̄͌̽͆̅̈́̈́́̿͐̉̋̾̌̇̋̀͑̔̉̈́̋͑́̓̇̿͐͌̆̅̍̿̿̃͂̂̉̑̐̆̃͆̐̈́̑͆̑̌̅͗̿̉̽́̋̒̿͗͆̈́́̍̀̇͒̀́̀̍̀͆̅̉̏̆͑͆͗̓̎̿̈́̆̑̿͑̇͒̈́̉́̾͂͆̈́̽̿̽̃̈́̊̅̂͌̐̒̏͑̓̿̉̈̈́̊́̐̑͗͌̊̊̋̿̋͂̃͋̓̈́̔̌̉͋̉̓͒͋̅̐̒̐̿̏̈̽͗̏̅̑̏̐̓̈̂̀́̑̌̌̍̎́̚͘͘̕̕̕͘͘̕̚̚͘͘̚͘̚̕͘̚͘̕͘̚͘̚͜͠͠͠͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̷̛̛̛̛̛̖̘̳͙̭̽͌̈́́̐͋̄̍̒̈́͌́̃͛̒̈́̐̈̈́̂͋̒͂̏͑̒̔͑̄̽̌̉͐̇̀͋͌̅͑̾͋͆̌͑́͆̽̒͐̊̾̾̐̄͗̿̀̈́̽̅̂́̅͛̾͐̌͑͐̈̆̆̈́̈́̏̾̂̌̌͒̈̓̇̈́̓́̿̔̊̐̈̐͌͒̈́͒͂̐̀̓͑̔͗̔̔̅̋͌͑́͗͊̂̈͒̌͑̒̒̀͒̆̎̈̃̈́͊͂̐̅̄̌̋̉̃̕̚̚̕̚͘͘͘̕̕̚͝͠͝͝�̵̡̡̧̢̨̛̛̛̝̟̭̼̱̘̦̜̬͖͚̪̳̠͖̥̹̭̮͇̝̟̠̻̬̗̭̙͚̬͖͈̥̬͉͓̎͊̍͛̂̀̋̒̐͋̾̑̋̓͗͂̃̿̓͊̃̐͆͂̅̆̿̓́̈́̇͑͒͐̓͑̍͐̃̀́̓̆͊̽͌͑́̎͑̒̈́͊̄̒̉͌̍̓̽̋͑̏̽͒̋̃͋͛́̍̿̐͒̍̿̓̅̐̀̉̉̔̄̎̈́̊͊͌̍̇̐̅̄̿̓̈̀̄̌̏͂̐̅̐̅͋͘͘̚̕̕̚͘̚͘͜͜͝͠͝͠͠͝͝ͅ�̷̡̨̢̨̡̧̧̢̢̨̡̡̡̢̧̢̡̦̮̤̗̞̥̩̰̼̩͔̯̠͚̞̱͎̣̤̜̜̰̻͓̠̼̜̫͔̥͓̺̻̳̻̠͉̗͙̲͔͓̙̣̬̟͙͙̠̤̘͈̰̗̩͕̦̞̬̠͕͉̦̯̰̩̱̣̦̠̲͇̝͚̤͔̝̱͔̙̳͈̳̭̹̰͉͓̲͈͉͙̟̦͎̝͕͍͍͚̤̖̰͓͚͔̲̤̩̙͚̥͍̰̫̮̫͓́̏̐̈́̈͌͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜ͅ�̷̡̧̨̧̡̢̨̢̨̧̛̫̹̪͕̤̦͎͍̙̘̗̝͍̣̻̝̼̼̼̰͕̫͍̩͖̪̠͈̼̦̮͔̟̖͖̖̝̭̭̥͙̮͙͈̺̗͇͎͍̳͚̰̙̭̹̞͇̳̦̳͈̣̫̳̹̩̺̘̼̹̯̝̦̹̗̟̲͓͇̻̞͕̬̙͚̪̲͉̭̺̺̺̼̥̟̻̬͍̫̮̬̼̺͓̝͚̟͚̺̣͔͚͔͉͇͙͍̦̪̘͍̝̭͖̫̠̜̣̼͇̀̐̎́̆̀͊͐̏̿̓̀̽̊͊̍͂̿́̂͘͜͜͜͜͜͝ͅ�̴̨̢̨̡̡̨̡̡̧̡̨̧̡̛̛̛̛̛̛͖͎͖̤͚̘̮͍̮̳̝̳͖̟̤̹̻̥̹̟̘̲̯͍̳̠̯̭̮͎̪̦̳͚̝̭̮̝̙̠̹͓̥̘̟̥̠̬̠͇̝̬̙͎͕̘̠̹̬̹̮͔͇̻͍̘̦̦͉̯͚̤͉͈̠̘͎͍̣̥͉̳̮̖̫̯̺̩̻͎̜͚̬̣̼̠̖̳͚̟͎̣̻̙̖̮͈̤̩͖̹͚̰͚͕͎͙̼̦̥̩͉̗̲̠̪̳̖̙̰͍͕̪̥̭̹̥̼̪̮̦̜̖͖̤̭̼̰̺̗̤̭̩̺̤̭͉̦̩͎̤͓̲͓͉͔͔̜͔̰͚̰͔͔͖̘͈̘̗̮̭͎̗͚̤̦͙͎̫͈̀̈͊̿́͒̔̂̆̌̋̐́͛́̅̊̎͒̅́̌̿̓̀̾̽̈̔̋̈́̽̾̂͒̊̋̾̓̇̀̊̽̄̂͑͐̈́̑͗̎̑͆̉̈́̓̀͋͌͛̐͌͂̂̅̃̆̌̏̊͛́̆̾̋̈́̉̀́̓͑̽͛̋̉̀̌̾̽̑͗͆̾͑͛̿́̒͐̉̌̾̑̿̿̀̈́͋͑̈́̈́̈̋̽̔̊̅͐̾̃̂͂͒̎̉̉̒͗̃̾́̄͋̅͑̈̀̒̌̈́͛́̑̉̎̋̆̍̽̀̓͊͋̊͆͂͑͋͛̀͊̓̍̍͗͑̑̆͐̅̈́̌̿͊͌̔̓̒͊̐̈̓̾̄̋͗͊̎̉̊̿͒̀̆̃͗̎͑̈́̂͆̐̏͗̾̅̀̍͊̆͋̾́̐̔̍̑́̿̾͌̅̈́͆̋̂̈́́́̆͊̅̄͒͗͋͋͆̿̉͊̎́̈̾́̈̒̓̒̓͗̇̓̿͌͐͐̽̄̾̈́͒̕̕͘̚͘̕̕̚̕̚͘̚̕̚̕͘̚͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̧̢̡̨̧̢̢̢̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̹̗̬̞͙͔̙͈͖̖̠̬͎̗͍̥̫͔̪̪̳̼̙̯̘͚̫̫̘̦̳͓̰͉̫̯̻̞̘͉͕̞͉̰̙̭͔̪͔̙̦̗͖͉͉̩̹̳̹̰̻̟̬͕̥̝͙̙̱̳̳̺̝̲̬̦̯̱͓̙̖̹̞̱̣̼̳̱̠̼̟̺̗̠͍̮͒͆̿̍͌͂͗̑̎͊̈́̀͛̎̅̓͊̆̽͒̓̄͆̿̊̇͂̏̈̆̈́͌̓̔̈͑͊̋͗͌̑̀̈̈̐̂͌̀̋̀̾̓͂̑͋̈͂͌͊̊̾̐̾̓͋̑̈́̂̒̐̎̔͒̆̽̀̔̀̒̆̉͐̐̾̎̎̾̇̍͊͗̏͋͑̈́̑̓̑̉͆̿́͐̒̾͊̈́̅̃̓͆̌͒̀͋̈́̏̐͌̋̌̈́̉̓̔̎̔͂̽͌̀̈͒͑̎͊́̉̄́͂̃̇͆͛̾̒̇̓̈́̑̐̃̈͗̏̾̿̒̂͑͐̒͋̒̇̽͂̂́̅̐͂͋̑͋̂̽͋̓͋̉̏͗̏̓̀̍͋̐̏̈́͗̇́̀̒̇́̅̂͗̉̄͑́̀̀̓̀̾̅̎̈̅̋̀̈́͂̂̽̓̀͘̚̕̚̚̕̚̚̕͘̕̚͘̚͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅ�̶̧̢̨̨̛̛̛̛̙̻̣̲̹͉̝͔̥̻͇̘̪̠̖͎̫̙̫̞̭̖̙͉̘͇̝͉̤̹̭͈͉̲͍̙̰̼̘̮͎͓̘͎͚̱̉͋̓̉̎́́̑̔̅̆̉̔͊̏̇͛̃̈́̓̏̄͊̀͊̎̀̈́̊̉̅́͐̀̓̀̀́̎̍͑̐̈́̉̄̈́͆͌̽̓̓̌̈̊͊͆̒̄̄͛͆̂͌̇̆͆̎͌̈̈͒̇͛̐̓̌́̆̈́͆̎̈́̎̎͑̏̎̈́̅̀͑̎̀̓͋͊̓͋͋́̐̍͊̐͊͆͛̾͂̒̄̃͋̃͒͗̄̀̅̈́͐̍̎̾͒̀̌̉̍͊̈́͗̋̒́͛̒̐͊͐̅̑͘̚͘̚̚͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅ�̴̡̨̨̨̛̳̩̟̘̳̖͈̭̪͉͙̪̪̙͉̩̜͉͕͖͓͎̓̄͗̎̔͑͋̓̈͛́͌̆̈́͑́͋͆̈́̃̐̿͂͂͒̈́͒̅͒̅͒̈͒̐̔̒̊̈́̈̑̋̆͌͆͊̓́͑̇̍̉͊͂̑̑͐́͒̂̅͐̉̇̅̅̚͘͘̚͜͝͝͝͝͠͠ͅ�̷̡̧̡̡̨̧̨̧̧̧̧̡̢̡̡̢̢̡̡̨̺̗̗͔͍̭͎̩̜͖̪̻̬̦̯̦͇̥͙͈̰̦͕̰͕͎̼͚̠̦͇̦̪͙̘͓͖̟̮̩͇̱̯͎̤̜̼͎̗͍̯͙̯̫̭̣̳̹̱͈̮̝͚̗͇͈͇̗̜̖̜̩̰̭̤̹͈͉̱̖̲̼̳̣͖̫̪̩͔̣̪̮̻̲̤͓̺̦̻̰̖̤̙̬͉̥̳̻̺̼͍̻̝̺̣̫̙̜̫̝̫̱̗͔͔͉̞̫̘̠̖͙̝̭̳̝̖̭̜͇͕̘͉͖̖͈͍̫̹̟͕̘͍͔̗̰̱̱͓̟͓̮͙̜̹̜͖̠̖̖͖͓͇̣̟̫͔̫̣̮͇̥̥̳̬̙̹͚̩̘̤͈̝̮̫̖̭̘͖̲͔̗͈̬̩͍̫͙̣̜͕̠͈̫̪̝̤̦͔̲̬̙͔̤̜̼̝̖̻͒̈̍̈́̾̾̆̏̉͆̆̋͜͜͜ͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̡̛̣͍̣̖͍̤̘̫͓̦̼̗̹͇͙̹̻̺̰͕̲̤̦̀̈́̈͊̿̋̽̐͊͜͝�̸̢̡̧̡̧̢̡̢̢̢̢̧̧̢̛̛̛̛̛̛̝͓̞͓̼͇͈̙̬̼̠͕̟̱͈̫̺͙̤̲̜͔̯̘͙̩͚̥̰͓̮͈̺̭͙̯͎̻̞͓͔̺̯͇̟̹̪̰̹̱͓̭͎̩̥͕̮̫̙̮̫͖̼̤̫͕͕̣̬̖̩͖̟̪̳̝̙̻̺̖̤͎̝̪̜͔̭͉̝̼̰̣̲̫̯̺͖͕̯̲̫̯͉͚̥̥̱̞͔̬̼͕̬̯̣͇̝̳̮̇̎̉́̑́̽͗̈́̂̒̊́̇̿͊̿̈̍̇͂̏̔̆̑͊͆́̏̎̀͛̄̈̈́̎͒̆͆͂̋̈́̓͛̈͊̏͛̆͆̉̅͊̾̾͊̾̾̈́̎̏̍͆̓͆̏͊́̄̿̋͌̓̀͌̓͌̐͆͗̄̈̒̓́̏̌̐̽͆͊̇́̈́̊͐́̍̅͆͑͌͑̅̃̈̊̿̎̿̉̀̀̈́͒̈́́́̔̎̔̋̓̈̉̌̾̅̔̉̅͛̒̍̈̿̿̒̏̐͐̀͒̈͆̈͌͗̿̌̇̂̈́̊̎̄͐̃͆͋͒́͌̇̓̉͂̍͌̆̆͊͐̆͆̾̇͂͐͊̿͋͌̓͗̒̇͛̍͛͆͗̃̌̎̈̆̑̍̏̓̎̈́̈́̈́̋̎͊̅͂̿̄͋́̉̈́̍̀͆͊͛̀͌̑̔͒̾̇̈́͘͘̕̕̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̕̚̕͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅ�̷̨̡̡̡̡̡̨̡̧̢̨̢̧̨̨̧̢̡̧̡̡̛̛̜̳͔̮͉̗̜̩͉͎͓̻̯̱̗̬̫̗̞͕͔̬̗͇̯͉̫̼̘͙̫̮̮̘̠͍͈̰̻̗͎̠̯̯̖̤͕̫͇̲͍̣͚͕̦̻̲͍̯̜̘̦̙̩̫̳͎̬̘̳̳̞̹͎̝̳͎̼̦̰̫͍̼̝̪̜̩͙͓̬͉͔̹̗̪̞̳̘̬̮̣̞̣͙͎̠̥̱̺̘͕̙̻͚͎͉͕͇̰̰̣̹̖̲̺̼͓͓̯̠̞̻̙̮̫̮̙̤̺͔̰͉̲̣̤̣̖̺͖̪͈͕͇̩͉͇̹͓̦̬͇̟̺̬͚̱̣̬̭̯̠̗͇͙̭̣̮̞͔̲̝̺̹͍̗̖̹̠͉̩͍̤̘͍̩̗͇̗̣̻̬͙͚̳̗͍͖̰͈̪͇̾́̌͗̉̎̐͛̍̈̉̔̽̂̍̓̀̏́̆͆́͌̽̍̂̒̏̀͊̋̿̑̀̓͑͆̒̑̓͆̇͑̓͋̌͊̇̋́̏́̃̓̀̓͘̚̚͘͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̷̢̡̨̡̨̢̢̡̡̨̨̡̧̨̢̡̡̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̤̬͕̩̯̣̭͓̝̖̺̝͉̠̤̫̪̜͚̪̪̺̻̼̼͎͓̼̣̼̙̝̺͉̖̗̝̰̙͓͉̗̺͇̻̜̼͈͙̬̺̣͚̭͉͇̰̝̼̟͈͖̙̩̳̗̤͖͎̪̗͚̘̼̦͇̱͚̩̹̺̝̻̱̻͔̟̮̻̻̞̪̜̟̼̙̦̙̩̼͙̬̟̳̺̜̪͇̠͓̘̙͔̹͓̼̲͙̻̞̪̘̱̣̺̻̬͚̰͈̗̲͖̏̄̆̒̈́̈͐̓͒͆̋͒̇͑̊̃̅̄̓̾̍͒̄̈͐̏̿̇͆̀̍͒̂̓̌͛̈́̀͆̉͒͆̄͊̾̒̎̽̿͐̈́́͑̓̍͗͋̾͐́́͊̏̒̑̎̀̉̀͑̋̾̍̅̈̽̿̄̇̿̒͂͂̓͋̆̽͆̑̏́̆̈̓̈́̒̌̀̔̈̀͆̋̓͊́̀̒̓̂̿̊̐͛͂͒̉̅̆̓̈͛̏͒̔̉͒͋̓͗̈́̋̀͂̃͒̈́̂̔̀̄̊̄̈͊͋͑͐̓̏̊͒̄͗͒̎͊̈́́̇͐̓̅͊̎̀̓̃̑͊̀̓̕̚̕̚̕̕͘͘̕̚̚̕͜͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅ�̵̨̨̡̧̨̧̨̡̡̨̨̨̡̡̧̡̧̢̢̡̧̡̨̛̛͔̺͇̘̬͙͈̝͉̩͈̫̞̫͓͖̙̥̻͕̝̻̝̤͕͓̳̠̭̼͉̦͙̦̖̻̞͔̫̤̦͈͙̣̠͔̻͓̺̜̪͇̼̩̗̜͙̫͙̤̜̟̝̼̱̥̳̥͇̦͍̜̜̙͔̜̥̯̤̼̪̟͙̲̳̞̪̬̠̙̻̹̥̤͇̫͎̳͚̣̮̲͕̗̜̪̪͇̱̯͖̖͓̥͔̺̜̟̲͍̯̜̬̳̪̟̗̯̭̦̩̳͍̗̦̺̻̝̰̻̰͇͔̖̹͎̬̯͓̬̟̳̱͔̦̤̘̞̠͚͙͚̦͈̭̼̪̖̗͇͎̪͇̳̪̝̠̮̼̪͕̬̹͖̭͚̥̘̟̙̮̘̩̫̝̘̫̱̫̰̫͔̟͉̲͇͕̠̪̮̝̲̲̮̦̥͖͉̭͓̲͇̙̥̳͙͕̱̼̣̭͖͔̮̝͈̱̹̥͓̥͕̦͙͕͎̙̠̯̜̟̗̑͋́̀̄̈́̔̌̓̆̎̇̈́̓͂́̀̾͋̅̍̐͌͂̿̓̅̈́̾̓́́̄̀͌̂̌̐̅̊̐̎̓̾̀͌̾̎͊̽̌̃̄̌͐̇͋̌̌͗̽̋̎͐͑̿̓̊̌̂̇̔̀͂̋͌̏́̓͂͌̽̂̈́̈́̽̒̽͛̓͐̽̇̄͑̄̎͌̿̑̔̇̿͊̔̇̒̐̓̉̾̈́̌̆̇̓̀̚̚̚̕̕͘̕̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̴̡̧̡̢̨̨̢̨̢̨̢̡̢̨̧̡̨̨̨̧̢̡̧̡̢̛̛̛̛̱̻͉̘̻̭͔̣̪͎̜͈̥̭̬͖̜̯̥̮̜̘̱̮̣͙̝̺͉̝̳̤̭̘͚̳̺̭̰̥͈̙͍͚̟̣̘̪̼̪͖͎̗̦͕̙̦̝͉̯̝̺͎͔͇̦̥͖̜̰̤̤͓̥͚̩͇͎̠̣͎͎̣̥̰̻̫̝̱̬̤̭̗̗̩̜̥̰̯͇̭̱͇̘̩̲̜̪̬̦̱̤̮̱̬͎̙̭̮̜̫͍̳̯͙͖̭̮͚̠̠̖͖̘̹͕̜̟̲̞͇̻̯̺̼̗̦̱̤̥̥̼̘̖̠̗̹̝̭̼̝̙̼̳̣̗͇͚̭̮̱̼͈̟̰̗̲̜̥̮̬̲̫̻̼̱͚͎̠͉͕̱̜̟̞̼̤̥̖̞͚̲̮̗̟̠̖̤̫͚̯̻̙̖͓͉̤̙̖͎̥͖̞̞̘̺̖̰̟̪̪͂͗̔̂͒̿̿̓̈̑̑̈́̌̊͗̔̈́̇͒̎͐̎̑́̏̊̎́̏̈̈̈͊̒́̀́͆̒̾̌̋͗̅͆̂̇̏̄͂̐̆̈́̓̌̉̌̂͌̋̈́̔̑͌̈́̾̽̍͛̾͑͑͊̊͋̓̂́̌̚̕̚̕̕̚͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͠͠͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̢̡̢̧̡̧̢̧̢̛̛̛̛̥͚͎̘̖̳̘͇͉͍̜͕͎͍̩̞͕̩̦̗͔̙͕̰͈̩̗͎̞͚͈̬̦̱̣̘̲͕̬̰̩̞͍̤̳̰̼̤̩̘̤͈̰̮̟͔̝̟͖͎͓̤̞̞̠̞̳̝̝̹̝̥͚͎̳̝͔͈̰̱̣̪̠̼͖̙͖̤̗̠̙̹͛́̅̍̆̄͋͐̓́̈́͒̌̿̈́͌̓̎̂͆́̆͊̊̇̂́̌͒̀͗͒͒͑̌̑̿̈́̀̽͛͛̑͌̊͗͛͑̈́̾͑͗̓͑͊̂̄̊͐͒̉̓̂͗͐̅͒̈́̍͗̌̀͐͋̿̍̈́̀̀̏̿̃̅̄̆͗͛̉̑̊̂͐̆̌͊͋́̀̊̏̄̂͐̔̾͗͌̏͌͌͂́͒̎́́͆̄̐̐̇͗̐͌͑̀̊͌͐͑̂́̓͌͂̈͐́̉̌̄̓̈̓͋̄̓̅͆̎̓͋͆͆̆̽͒̏͒͌̂̆̒̆̔̍̓̓̇͆̈́̈́͂͊̂͆̊̊̀̐̆̉̿̊̍̋͗̽͊̃̏̿̿̉̈̊̇̽̏̅͊̋̉͒͐͒̃̒̃̄̈́̀̈̋͒̋̀̀͒̄̉̒̎̋̄̆̂͑̽͐̐̑́́̏́̅́͋̈̅̕̚̕͘̚͘̕͘̚̚͘͘̕̕͜͝͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͠͠͝͠͠͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅ�̵̨̨̡̢̨̡̨̧̨̧̨̧̛̭̭̫̺̯̘̯̺̟̯̞͙̘̪͍̜͇̣͓̖̖͈͍͈͕͚͙͕̹̳̖̞̮̙̲̺͎̹̲̰̭̹̖̳̼̙̺̥͈̪͖͓̗͈̞̹̼̹̤͙͎̣̯͔̣̟̰͖̭̠̹͇̼̯͎̘̼̥̗͉̥̖͕͉̣̠̼̬̳̘̮͚͎̖̣̤͚͔̼̤̖̰̖͙̤̮͔͙̜̹̘̫̜͇̘̝͖͙̠̯̳̗͖̱͍̣̱͙̱̗̖̹͖̙͔͎͔̯̭͓̖͈̤̤̪͈̞͖̱̠̟͙͕̟̦͍̘̬͉̹͚͓̹̳͓̠̟̝̟̞̜̼̩͓̹̹̜̣͖͓̰̬͍̤̮̺̰̞̣̞͔͇͖̫̲̳̘̩͓͋́͂̔̇͌͋̈̽̐̌͐͐̓̽̀̀̄̍̃̌͂̐͆̽̄̀̊͂̈́͌͆̃͐͌̈́͊̒̀̏̿̓͑̔̍͐̌̉̋̑̉͒͌̔͐̈̓̂̀̍̓̓͋͐̃͆̀̈́̈́̃͑̐̽̈́̋̂͊͒͐͌̓̀̇̃̎̂̇̒̓̃͐̓̓̒͛̍̇̍̾̅̇͛́͆̾̒͊͋͐̈̅̀̓͒̀̈́͌̊̏́̊̈́̈̃̓̈́̓̇̊̒̈́̐͋͗̏̍͑̈́̉̊̈́̾͒̓́͐͋̋̓̒̓̈̈́̃̓͛̍̀͋̿̈́͑͗͘͘̕̕̚͘̚̕͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅ�̵̨̡̢̧̧̨̨̡̛̖̩͎̮̫̼͚̠̦̱͉̤͓̪̤͔̪̻̳̮͇̖̠̺̩̥̰̼̺͖̲̳͉̯͈͉̹̹͕̹̠͚̻̪̹͚̯̮̯͔̻̮̤̺̬̟͓̮̘̜̝̙̹͙̮̝͕̟̙̫͔̟̠͎̰̬̫̭͇̠͚͓̯̺̦̦̱̙̗̠͕̈́͐̊͒̍̔͂̉̉̈̈́͆̽̃̃̎̿͛̏͐͛͋͒͑̅̂͗͐̀͋͗͘͘͘͜͜ͅͅͅ�̶̡̡̨̨̡̧̢̧̨̧̡̧̧̧̛̩͉̞͍̫̹͍͇̭͎̜̦͍͙͈̗̙̜̩͓̲̦̩͚̩̤̦͉͍̻̳͍̯̯̥̹̻͖̮͉̘͓̭͇̙̗̦̫͕͈̭̯̠̻̦͎̯͈͍̻̪̬͕̝̲̻̳͍̤̗̤̱̺̫͈̙̠̞͈͈̳̟̜͚̳̝͔̤̮̜͖̳̘̝̦̫͉̣̮̤̬̝̠̞͔̥̩͓̠͕̰͙͙̤̪̳̳̫̤͖̯̺̗̝̠̬̟̰̗̠͍̰̼͖̪̗͗̽͆̊̑̊̾͒̃̋̿͆̈̐̓̈́͑̾́̈̏̑̐͛̊̃̀̓̂̅̊̓͒̊̿̒̽̓̄́̉͛͆͆́̔͘̚͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅ�̸̧̢̧̨̧̨̢̛̛͖̦̙̫̺̮̫̘̖̭̳̘̫͙̳̥̥͉̞͈̮̟̳̲̫̣̱͇̲͓͙͇̜͙͓̭̟̙̤̮̯̻̫̻̩̬̹͈͎̭̙̥̼̗̣̱͔̹̩̲̙̠̮͚̤͕̮̤̼̯͈̮͎̬͔̤̟͓̬̳̭̼̤̣͈̙͚̯͍͇̣͚̖̖̣͔͎͓̘̼͓͇̝̤̳͓̦̪͍̠̝̬̠̎̽̎͑̅̅̏́̆̈͋̑͐̏̿͒̉̈̋̾̋̄̑͌̋̈́͐͌̊̎̀̆̂͐̌́́̌̇̍̍̌͂̆̑̓̀̍̔̒̚͜͜͜͜͝͝ͅͅ�̸̨̡̨̡̨̨̢̢̧̡̨̛̛̛͉̯̳̯̣͈̩̭̳̹̠̮͚͖̬͙̗̬̼͚̬͓̤̦͇͍̺̫̱̺͓͇̣͍̭̙̮͍͕͇͍͍̼̭̰̲͎͔̘͉̩͔̤̰̝̞̗̖̪̜͉͚̻͔̝͖̙̪̳͙̪̙͇͕̦̜̘̞͚̜͈̠̺͉̪̭̲̮̼̮͍͍̹̬̣̺͙̜͚̖̦̘̜̙̱͇̺̖̘͚̻̟̖̮̘̣̖̤̬̪̞͚͍͚̖͔̞̪͕̣̗͚͉̳̤͎̱͓͍͚͚̜̹̱͕͈̹͕̰̗̩̦̰̣̮̻͙̲͉̖̞̟̩͔̟̮̺̟͎͓̺̠̥͇̙̫͚̭̪̺̳͕͍͎̰͕̗̼̞̞̦̰̦͕̘̱͎͙̗̜̞̬̞͇͓͓̯̦̲̤͉̝̙̰̻̗̰͈͍̰̠͚̲̲͖̦͙͔̳̥̜̘̻̦̯͙̜̙͚̙̿́͌̎͌͆͋̃̐̂̏̀̿͐̏̇͂͗͒̍͒͌̇̆̈̂̆̓̒͋̉͋̃̏̈̐̂́̐͗̓͌̓͊̽̄͑̆̏̈́́̽͋̃̄̂̈͊͛̀́͂̅̌̽͊̅̋̀͂̅̍͋̎̀͒́̊̑̌͊͐̉̂͑̓̅̆̽͌̊̆̇͆́̃̾͂̄̈́̽̈́͂͛̄̄͛͗͑̇͛̍́̉̌̋̒͊̈̿̓͆͊͆͐̇̎͋̾͐̈͋̊̔̑̅́͊͑̂̽̾̓̃͑̈́̌͑̿̃̿̏̍͌͒̓͑̋̊̍̀̐̆̒͌͂̆̕͘̕̕͘͘̚̚͘̚̕̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͠͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ�̵̢̧̢̢̨̡̡̧̧̧̢̢̨̡̧̨̛̛̛̣̰͙̦͍͓̱̫̠̻̼̻̞̬̲̣͎̻̠̦͉̹̥̝̩̞̠̰̠͔̺͈̰̣͍͔̼̮̱̜̻͙̮̰͉̯͉̫̤̱̥͓͇͚̫͕͚̮͖̰͚̳̻̙͈͚͚̱̱̮͚̣̤̝͎̭̥͍̣̱̪͇͕̩̖̱̠̻̟̣̹͇̠̝̰̖̻̯̹̲̪̟͓͔͈̯͕͍̺̻̭̪̱̜̬̖̹̭̥͔̥̘̻̻͈̝͉͍͍̬̻̘͕͎̩̺̜̻̻̟͍͉͈̪̫͉̫͎̰̝̫̪̥͈̩̦̜̲̦̹͉̹̮̦͙͓͉̺̬͇͇̼͍͍̮̹̯̺͈̝̯̼̝̼͕͔͖̳̠͇͈̦̱̰̖͚̹͚̳̫̤͍̲͙̫̯̝̼͇̬̦̱̼̗̟̬̦̪̝̠̻̲̪̙̙͚̘͓̦̮̤̻̺̜̬͔̞̘͙̣̘̦̙͎͕̹̪̮̞͑̈́̐͊̌͋͌̎̍̓͑̍̋̈́̀͆̄̒̑̄̏̈́̑̈́̑̊͆̆͆̉͐̓̅̾̈́̍͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͠ͅͅͅͅͅ�̶̧̧̡̡̧̧̨̢̧̢̢̧̨̢̧̡̡̛̛̛̪̩͈͖̪͇̻̫̘̥̦͈͉̮͙͖̭̙̪̠̞̖̬̖̼̦̱͉͔͕͎̥̺̩̠̙̭̻̲̳̩̫͚͍̟̻̯͔̖͙͔̪̣̪͚̞̱͕̖͇̫̱̹̗͙̻̺̲͙̪̫̤͎̞͕̪̦̞͎̯̪̬̝̜̜̹̱̥͔͚̩̜̩̻͕̱͉͔͈̼̲͎̗̮̲͈̟̥̥̠̼̗̰͖̳͉̦̞̯̖̜̲̹͎̙̜͈͍͕̘͈̼͎͎̭̝̹̗̟̰͇͚̫͙̭̞̻͖͚̬̰͚̖̼̖̞̦̝̮̞̬̥̠̠̟͖̣̜̝̭̱̟̈́̒̉̓̅̉̂̐̅̈̊̒̈̄̓̋͂͑͆̈́́̓̇͊̓̾̀̔̄͆̈́́̓̈́͌̐̂͑̎̃̄̃̓͂͋̏̿͛͑̀͂́̈́̊̎̔̏̉̾̊̽̄̾͆̈́͐̀͒̄̋̓̂̒́̈͆͗̒̑̂̌͋̐̍̓̿̉̈̒͆͛̋̌̊̏͘̕̕͘̚̕̕̚̚̚͜͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅ�̶̨̡̢̨̧̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̰͚̰̥͎̜͍̜̯̖͎̲͖̣̫̫̺̮͉̜̘̦͈̥̥̞̜̠̜̪̮̠̗̲͕̮̗̟̯̻̺̫̦̥̣̤̝̠̟͕̭͓̩͔̙̦͍͕̠̰̬̞̓̽̊̀̀͌̀̆̉͂̇̈́͌̄̈́͌͂̀͋͗̈͆̈̀̇̒̇͂́͋̈́̒̋̎̍̍̓̎̈́̆̑̑͌͑̈́̉̿̅͌͋͌̀̀̈́͒̆̌̌̒̌͑̄͌̔̽̄̅̄̉̓̓̏͒͑͆̈̈́͗̊͌́͑͆͌͛̽̓̀̊͒͒̏̅̋͛̈́͌͌̾̂̒̊̀̅́̈́́̑͂̓̍̈́͑̾̀̌̽̀̀͑̅̽͌̂̀̂̑̀̐͑̍͛͘̕̕̕̚̕͘̚̕͘͘͘̚͜͜͜͠͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͠ͅͅ�̶̧̢̡̧̧̧̧̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̻̺͉̘̦̫̫̝̺͕͖̹̜̫̭̞̹͙̯͓̹͙̹̭̜̖̩̣̜͉͕̙̳̪̤̟̭̝͔̦̰͔̖̦̟͔̗͇̼͚̝̦͎̫̻̹̟̞͍̘̪̠̠̦̣͍̥̰̼̘̼̮̩͇͈̠̻͓͎̻̳̻͙̟̬̺̣̝̝̻̬̦͔̼̻̦̱̼̺̣̮͈͉̗̜̦̬̠͕̘̠̼̻͖̱̝̭̳̦̥̮̝̠͙̹͔̣̫̺͍̯̳̝̖̘̮̮̰͉̓͛̃̽̓͋̅̎̀͒͋̽̂̽̍̊̀̒̓͂̓͐̏̃̈́̐͒̍̑̾͊̿̈́͒̉̃̎̓̈́̑̿̃͋̐̒̄̇̈́͆̐͐͗̋̉͆̇̈́͐̾̈́̀̆̊̀̊̆̐̾̿̒͗̂͑̉̈́̓̋͒̏͆̍̔̎̀̀͆͐́̋̅̑̓̍̂̋͑̈̀̃̏͊͊̀͑́͑͆̓́͗̅̍͐͆͗́̋̿̽̅͗͋̈̆̎͐͋̑̑̿̃͆̾͊̉̐͋̍̃̄̋̈́͆́͋̆͋͆̂̇͐́̑̽͊̓͌̍̀̃̓̽̂̐̋̆͑̑̕̕͘͘̕͘̚͘̚͘̕͜͜͜͝͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅ�̴̢̧̢̢̡̡̨̡̧̨̡̨̡̧̧̧̢̧̧̢̢̻̣̪͓̭͕̟͔̖͈̪͖̲̟͖̙͎͍͓̣̬͇̠̟̥͇͍͉̞̹̹̝͕̬̱̗̪̜̻̪͓͚̥̼͕̩̼͈̞̣̼̯̳̰͍̥͎̼̺̦̳͉̩̼̙̬̼͖͇̣̞̝̰͉͎̭̦͔̝̰̪̗̪͈̟̖̠͍̘͈̼̥̜͙͈͙͇̰͈͖͇̘͍̭̲͇̠̗̳͇̠͕̲̗̞͓̙̹̬̺̲͔͎͇͔̗͎̠̳̳̥̭̮̳̝̖̳͔̪̣̳̬͓̱͕̞͍̯̣̬̺̟̯̘͍͎̖͚̪͍̦͕̫͍̫͙̭̺̤̙̮̬͉̭̫̖͔̮͎̯̜̤̱̣͚̦͓͓̻͕͉̭̟͔̟̩̗͍̏̒̑̐̊͑̂̄̉̈̈́̄̂̽̀̓̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝ͅͅͅ�̴̧̡̢̡̡̧̡̨̡̢̨̘̩̤͈̗͓͍͉̳̝̺͇͎̩̖͙̖̫̘͎̩̟͚̖̖̣͈͍̟̖̦̩̙̺̟̙̼̳͖̦̲̮̘͕̤̩̞̟͈̭̜͖̬͙̭̗͕͕͙̳͔͓͇̪̤̺̬͈̲̈́̿̑̋́͛́͆̓̓͋͗̆͐̎͌̅̓͒̃̑͑̈̀͌͑̒̓̀͐̒̀̔͛̌͗̄̀̊͗̐̀̽͑̈͋͒̔̅̊̅̋̍͐̓͊̀͛̏͂͌̔͂̀̃̇̏̕̚̚̚̕͘̕̚͘͜͜͝͝͝͝͠͠͝ͅ

Answer (score 1):

Is overline possible?

---

`<span style="text-decoration:overline">RESET</span>`
RESET

---

Combining overline `&#x305;` using entities and unicode:
R̅E̅S̅E̅T̅
R̅E̅S̅E̅T̅

---

Answer (score 1):

> This text is bold in the markdown preview
> --

Answer (score 1):

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test | teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee | eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee & eeeeee&e |

test the edit

Answer (score 1):

[A draft for the expansion of a deleted answer in [Build a Turing *incomplete* language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204891/build-a-turing-incomplete-language)]

---

[This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html#Predefined-Macros) is the full list of predefined macros (it's possible to see that only `__DATE__`, `__TIME__` and `__TIMESTAMP__` are not deterministic. Remark: defining `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` will not affect the `__TIMESTAMP__`)

The directives that can read the hard drive is `#include`, `#include_next` and `#import`.

[This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Index-of-Directives.html#Index-of-Directives) is the full list of directives.

---

While it's sufficient to provide an implementation of [some basic arithmetic operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204949/69850), I'd like to explain the method in more details.

#### Input-dependent computation

In order to make the program powerful enough, it must be possible to make the amount of computation dependent on the size of the input.

This can be achieved by encoding a natural number $n$ as a sequence of $n$ pair of brackets `()()()...()()()`.

So if there are two macros defined like this (there must be two to avoid it being blue-painted)

```c
#define a() X b()
#define b() X a()
```

Then `a()()...()()` will expand to `X X ... X X a`.

It's usually convenient to remove the last `a`. That can be done by pasting the whole thing with something like `_delete_this` and `#define a_delete_this`.

#### Repeated fixed function call

Let `x` be a parameter, with its value being a sequence of $n$ `()`s.

Then it's possible to generate `f(` repeated $n$ times and `)` repeated $n$ times.

With some simple manipulation, it's not hard to define some macro `$P(n, args...)` to expand to `f(f(...(f(args))...))` **for a fixed function `f`**.

#### Repeated dynamic function call

Unfortunately, this technique alone won't be able to implement `$P(n, f, args...)` = `f(f(...(f(args))...))`.

(this is not necessary for the computations, but it's more convenient this way)

Define an auxiliary macro `$M`: `$M(f, args...)` expands to `f, f(args)`.

(note that [`args...` is a GNU CPP extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros); however this is only for convenience, all usages of it can be replaced with the standard `__VA_ARGS__` identifier)

Observe that `$M($M($M(f, args...)))` will expands to:

```c
$M($M(f, f(args)))
$M(f, f(f(args)))
f, f(f(f(args)))
```

Taking the second argument will result in `f(f(f(args)))`.

In reality, some defer/eval is required to make the expression expands correctly.

Then, use the previous macro `$P` to evaluate `$M` $n$ times on `f, args...`, and it's possible to get `f` applied on `args...` $n$ times.

At the moment, it's possible to use `$P` to implement the multiplication function:

```c
#define mul_1(x,y) x y, y
#define mul(x,y) $P(x,mul_1, ,y)
```

In this example, `mul_1` is repeatedly applied on the argument `(<empty>, y)` $x$ times. For each application, `mul_1` transforms `(accumulator, y)` to `(accumulator+y, y)`; therefore after $x$ iterations the result is `(x*y, y)`.

#### Blue-painting/Recursion

Let's say, you want to implement a function that uses `$P` based on another function that uses `$P`.

```c
#define add(x,y) x y
#define pre_1(x,y) y,y()
#define pre(x) $P(x,pre_1,,) // <-- this function uses `$P`
#define sub(x,y) $P(y,pre,x) // <-- this function uses `pre`
// similar to the implementation of subtraction using pair in lambda calculus
// returns x-y if x>=y, 0 otherwise.
// (terribly inefficient.)
```

This will immediately raises a problem -- the inner `$P` is not expanded.

Which makes sense, because the inner `$P` is created during the expansion of the outer `$P`.

There's a trivial workaround for that problem, however -- define a function `$P2` with the same definition as `$P` (and its helper functions)

This restriction makes sense, because `cpp` is not Turing-complete and it should not be possible for two functions to call each other.

#### Some example functions

With these tools, it should not be too hard to build some simple functions. Ideas from lambda calculus should be useful here.

```c
#define equ(x,y) sub((),sub(x,y) sub(y,x))
// return 1 == () if x and y are equal, 0 == <empty> otherwise.

#define modz_1(result, x, y, value) result equ(x, i), x, y, y value
// modz_1(result, x, y, value) = (result + [x == value], x, y, value + y)
// x and y are the dividend and the divisor.
// value iterates through the first x positive multiples of y,
// and check if any of them are equal to x.

#define modz(x,y) $P3(x,modz_1,,x,y,y)
// returns 1 if x is a multiple of y, 0 otherwise.
// apply modz_1 on (0, x, y, y) x times, then return the first value of the result.
```

Answer (score 1):

**your text**

blablabla fill this with more characters

Answer (score 1):

`lang-autoit`

```autoit
#include <WinAPI.au3>

MsgBox(0, "", "error: " & @error & @CRLF & "hFind: " & $hFind & @CRLF & "hRadio: " & $phRadio)
_WinAPI_CloseHandle($phRadio)
_BluetoothFindRadioClose($hFind)

Func _BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ByRef $phRadio)
    Local $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS = DllStructCreate('DWORD')
    DllStructSetData($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, 1, DllStructGetSize($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS))
    Local $aResult = DllCall($hDllBthProps, "handle", "BluetoothFindFirstRadio", "struct*", $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, "handle*", 0)
    If @error Then Return SetError(2, @error, 0)
    $phRadio = $aResult[2]
    Return SetError($aResult[0] = 0, 0, $aResult[0])
EndFunc   ;==>_BluetoothFindFirstRadio
```

`lang-vb`

```vb
#include <WinAPI.au3>

MsgBox(0, "", "error: " & @error & @CRLF & "hFind: " & $hFind & @CRLF & "hRadio: " & $phRadio)
_WinAPI_CloseHandle($phRadio)
_BluetoothFindRadioClose($hFind)

Func _BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ByRef $phRadio)
    Local $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS = DllStructCreate('DWORD')
    DllStructSetData($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, 1, DllStructGetSize($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS))
    Local $aResult = DllCall($hDllBthProps, "handle", "BluetoothFindFirstRadio", "struct*", $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, "handle*", 0)
    If @error Then Return SetError(2, @error, 0)
    $phRadio = $aResult[2]
    Return SetError($aResult[0] = 0, 0, $aResult[0])
EndFunc   ;==>_BluetoothFindFirstRadio
```

`lang-ts`

```ts
#include <WinAPI.au3>

MsgBox(0, "", "error: " & @error & @CRLF & "hFind: " & $hFind & @CRLF & "hRadio: " & $phRadio)
_WinAPI_CloseHandle($phRadio)
_BluetoothFindRadioClose($hFind)

Func _BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ByRef $phRadio)
    Local $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS = DllStructCreate('DWORD')
    DllStructSetData($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, 1, DllStructGetSize($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS))
    Local $aResult = DllCall($hDllBthProps, "handle", "BluetoothFindFirstRadio", "struct*", $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, "handle*", 0)
    If @error Then Return SetError(2, @error, 0)
    $phRadio = $aResult[2]
    Return SetError($aResult[0] = 0, 0, $aResult[0])
EndFunc   ;==>_BluetoothFindFirstRadio
```

`lang-js`

```js
#include <WinAPI.au3>

MsgBox(0, "", "error: " & @error & @CRLF & "hFind: " & $hFind & @CRLF & "hRadio: " & $phRadio)
_WinAPI_CloseHandle($phRadio)
_BluetoothFindRadioClose($hFind)

Func _BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ByRef $phRadio)
    Local $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS = DllStructCreate('DWORD')
    DllStructSetData($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, 1, DllStructGetSize($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS))
    Local $aResult = DllCall($hDllBthProps, "handle", "BluetoothFindFirstRadio", "struct*", $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, "handle*", 0)
    If @error Then Return SetError(2, @error, 0)
    $phRadio = $aResult[2]
    Return SetError($aResult[0] = 0, 0, $aResult[0])
EndFunc   ;==>_BluetoothFindFirstRadio
```

`lang-java`

```java
#include <WinAPI.au3>

MsgBox(0, "", "error: " & @error & @CRLF & "hFind: " & $hFind & @CRLF & "hRadio: " & $phRadio)
_WinAPI_CloseHandle($phRadio)
_BluetoothFindRadioClose($hFind)

Func _BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ByRef $phRadio)
    Local $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS = DllStructCreate('DWORD')
    DllStructSetData($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, 1, DllStructGetSize($tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS))
    Local $aResult = DllCall($hDllBthProps, "handle", "BluetoothFindFirstRadio", "struct*", $tBLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS, "handle*", 0)
    If @error Then Return SetError(2, @error, 0)
    $phRadio = $aResult[2]
    Return SetError($aResult[0] = 0, 0, $aResult[0])
EndFunc   ;==>_BluetoothFindFirstRadio
```

Answer (score 1):

....... `%APPDATA%\subversion\auth\` . ...... `auth - 2021-02-04 - working after re-auth` .....

Comment: ``%APPDATA%\subversion\auth\`` . ...... `auth - 2021-02-04 - working after re-auth` ..... - looks like it works in comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
[tag:feature-request]
Just a post to see of there is a bug here. Have seen some strangeness when posting another Meta thread and want to reproduce it if possible before reporinting it. 

The word wrap was broken all kinds of ways and the tag did not render at all. Maybe it has something to do with editing in both modes (a bit in one mode, then a bit in another). I think it has put this code into some kind of code block.
```

Comment: Yup. Definitely seeing it here.

Comment: Looks like it's defaulting to a code block for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1):

```erlang
defrecord Person, first_name: nil, last_name: "Dudington" do
  def name record do # huh ?
    "#{record.first_name} #{record.last_name}"
  end
end

defrecord User, name: "José", age: 25

guy = Person.new first_name: "Guy"
guy.name

defmodule ListServer do
  @moduledoc """
  This module provides an easy to use ListServer, useful for keeping
  lists of things.
  """
  use GenServer.Behaviour
  alias Foo.Bar

  ### Public API
  @doc """
  Starts and links a new ListServer, returning {:ok, pid}

  ## Example

    iex> {:ok, pid} = ListServer.start_link

  """
  def start_link do
    :gen_server.start_link({:local, :list}, __MODULE__, [], [])
  end

  ### GenServer API
  def init(list) do
    {:ok, list}
  end

  # Clear the list
  def handle_cast :clear, list do
    {:noreply, []}
  end
end

{:ok, pid} = ListServer.start_link
pid <- {:foo, "bar"}

greeter = fn(x) -> IO.puts "hey #{x}" end
greeter.("Bob")
```

Compare Elixir example at:https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/

Above code block versus screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of example]

Answer (score 1):

The new code editor:

## Heading

**Bold**

*Italic*

`Inline code`

> Blockquote

```
Code block
```

(Shift + Enter to exit code blocks)

[image]Image

| Table (original content header 1 | header 2 | header 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 | cell 3 |
| cell 4 | cell 5 | cell 6 |
| cell 7 | cell 8 | cell 9 |

1. Numbered list

- Bulleted list

---

Horizontal rule (above)

[User Community - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) An attempt to rope @Community into the post (related to a joke on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405990/14639867) [User Community - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) Let's see if it works.
[spoiler]experiment-spoiler[/spoiler] Fails.

Answer (score 1):

[Mismatch between preview content and saved content wrt newline separator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406871/11573842)

[https://flathub.org/apps/details/net.sourceforge.Pdfedit\](https://flathub.org/apps/details/net.sourceforge.Pdfedit%5C)
https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.itextpdf.RUPS

Answer (score 1):

> Dear Prof. Smith, Prof. Johnson, Prof. Lee, and Prof. Chun,

(note the “and”).

Also, is the email directly relevant to **all** four professors? Perhaps you should consider “CC’ing” someone that’s not so relevant (in which case the CC’d person need not be addressed in the salutation)?

It’s my first answer here so any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [test answer](https://stackexchange.com) to test out a potential bug with edit notifications. Let's see what happens if we add some text.

Answer (score 1):

> Well, you clicked on the text!

### ```js
var i = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var j=0;
for (j=0; j<=1000; j++) {
  i.innerHTML+="&nbsp;"+j;
}
```

```css
*{word-break:break-word;}
```

```html
<p>hello world!<br></p>
```

```js
(function (window, init) {
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
})(window, function () {
    function getRandom(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }
    (function (draw) {
        draw();
    })(function () {
        var ctx1 = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
        // ugly image #1
        for (j = 0; j <= 3600; j += 60) {
            for (i = 20; i <= 3600; i += 20) {
                ctx1.beginPath();
                ctx1.moveTo(j, 0);
                ctx1.lineTo(100, i);
                ctx1.stroke();
            }
        }
        // ugly image #2
        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
        for (i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
            ctx2.beginPath();
            var color = "rgb(" + getRandom(0, 255) + "," + getRandom(0, 255) + "," + getRandom(0, 255) + ")";
            ctx2.strokeStyle = "";
            ctx2.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx2.moveTo(getRandom(0, 400), getRandom(0, 400));
            ctx2.lineTo(getRandom(0, 400), getRandom(0, 400));
            ctx2.stroke();
        }
        // ugly image #3
        var ctx3 = document.getElementById("canvas3").getContext("2d");
        for (k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
            var color = "rgb(" + getRandom(0, 255) + "," + getRandom(0, 255) + "," + getRandom(0, 255) + ")";
            ctx3.strokeStyle = "";
            ctx3.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx3.beginPath();
            ctx3.arc(getRandom(0, 200), getRandom(0, 200), getRandom(0, 200), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx3.stroke();
        }
    });
    (function (addAnchor) {
        addAnchor();
    })(function () {
        var link = document.getElementById("reload");
        var hash = BigInt(getRandom(100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999));
        link.href = "./?hash=" + hash;
    });
});
```

```css
canvas {
    max-width:600px;
    resize:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Canvas Experiment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Art Fair <a href="?hash=" id="reload">generate new samples</a></h1>
    <h2>Ropes</h2>
    <canvas id="canvas1" style="width:100%; border:1px solid black; height:100%;">
        <p>AAAAAAAAA... <a href="https://chrome.com">AAA AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA?</a></p>
    </canvas>
    <h2>Everyone Sees Something Different: 99999 Lines</h2>
    <canvas id="canvas2" style="width:100%; border:1px solid black; height:100%;">
        <p>AAAAAAAAA... <a href="https://chrome.com">AAA AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA?</a></p>
    </canvas>
    <h2>A Bunch of Circles (50 to be exact)</h2>
    <canvas id="canvas3" style="width:100%; border:1px solid black; height:100%;">
        <p>AAAAAAAAA... <a href="https://chrome.com">AAA AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA?</a></p>
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var $password = 'pass';
document.querySelector('[type=password]').pattern = $password;

function hideAll() {
  var $x = document.getElementsByTagName('center');
  for (var $i = 0; $i < $x.length; $i++) {
    $x[$i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function login() {
  hideAll();
  document.getElementById('complete').style.display = 'block';
}

function logout() {
  hideAll();
  document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'block';
}

function forgot() {
  hideAll();
  document.getElementById('forgot').style.display = 'block';
  var $random = Math.random();
  $random = Math.round($random * 10000);
  document.querySelector('[type="password"]').pattern = $random;
  document.getElementById('reset').innerHTML = 'New password: ' + $random;
}

function showLogin() {
  hideAll();
  document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
center:not(#login) {
  display: none;
}

input:not([type="submit"]) {
  border: none;
  outline: none !important;
  width: 100%;
}
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<center id="login">
  <h2>Log In</h2>
  <a href="#" onclick="forgot()">Forgot Password</a>
  <form action="javascript:;" onsubmit="login()">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Username</legend>
      <input type="text" required="required" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>E-mail</legend>
      <input type="email" required="required" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Password (default: pass)</legend>
      <input type="password" required="required" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
  </form>
</center>
<center id="complete">
  <h2>Logged In</h2>
  <a href="#" onclick="logout()">Log Out</a>
</center>
<center id="forgot">
  <h2>Password Reset</h2>
  <p id="reset"></p>
  <a href="#" onclick="showLogin()">&laquo; Back</a>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

I need this answer for a thing™

Because I can't fall under 30 characters, here's some copy-pasta from the question:

> Beware that since the changes to syntax highlighting in December 2010, and the inline hints added in March 2011, no syntax highlighting is applied unless the question's tags or an inline hint enable it. So, to test highlighting here in the sandbox:

---

The Thing:

I also need an edge case.

I also need an edge case?

I also need an edge case.

I also need an edge case?

I forgot, are quotes continuous?

> Line 1
> Line 2
>
> Line 3 with preceding angle bracket

> Line 4 without preceding angle bracket
> line with trailing

> Line without trailing
> line after

Answer (score 1):

Scenario is I run a hat company, and every year the hat regulator gives us a guideline as to how much we can increase the price:

| Year | Price increase |
| --- | --- |
| 2015 | n/a first year |
| 2016 | +3.2% |
| 2017 | +2.2% |
| 2018 | +4.0% |
| 2019 | +1.0% |
| 2020 | +0.0% |
| 2021 | +4.0% |

So far, I've worked out how to use product and filter to quite easily produce the following output...

| Year | Price increase | Hat price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | n/a first year | £3.00000 |
| 2016 | +3.2% | £3.09600 |
| 2017 | +2.2% | £3.16411 |
| 2018 | +4.0% | £3.29068 |
| 2019 | +1.0% | £3.32358 |
| 2020 | +0.0% | £3.32358 |
| 2021 | +4.0% | £3.45653 |

...But in the real world, I wouldn't apply an uplift of 2.2% to a £3.09600 hat and sell it for £3.16411, I actually want to apply it to rounded numbers, so I'd want to calculate (£3.10 + 2.2%) -> £3.1682 -> £3.17 in 2017 for instance. That's a penny different, and I want to introduce these penny differences as they will accumulate over time in the real world.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I might build a "real world" calculation, where I'd round the price off every year and only apply the increase to the rounded price? Easy in Excel, but I can't work out a way to do it in Power BI without producing a new column for each consecutive year, which is impractical given the size of the real data set.

Ideally I'd want my data set to look like this...

| Year | Hat price last year | Price increase | Hat price this year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | n/a | n/a | £3.00 |
| 2016 | £3.00 | +3.2% | £3.10 |
| 2017 | £3.10 | +2.2% | £3.17 |
| 2018 | £3.17 | +4.0% | £3.30 |

I'd been trying to do something in DAX but I don't think I can direct a calculated column to itself, so I suspect a Power Query solution might be better - but I'm open to a solution in either sphere!

Answer (score 1):

```css
:root {
    --xyz-ease: cubic-bezier(.26,2.05,.84,.38);
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background: #466BDA;
}

.phone {
    background: white;
    padding: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    box-shadow: -30px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);

    &:before {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #466BDA;
        border-radius: 1em;
        padding: .5em;
        width: 33%;
        top: -5px;
        left: 30%;
    }
}

.square-group {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "square square"
        "square square";

    .square {
        padding: 3em;
        margin: .6em;
        border-radius: .8em;
        background-color: #466BDA;
    }
}

.skeleton-title, .skeleton-title2 {
    padding: .6em;
    margin: 1em .3em;
    border-radius: .8em;
    background-color:#466BDA;
}
.skeleton-title2 {
    width: 60%;
}

.circle-group {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "circle circle circle"
        "circle circle circle";

    .square {
        padding: 2em;
        margin: .6em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #466BDA;
    }
}
```

the output is big so you wont see

Answer (score 1):

Test which numbers get interpreted as a link by my phone:

Yes Safari: Why does nobody look at my question, it only has 10000000000000000 views

Yes Safari not including last three 0s, DuckDuckGo not including last three 0s: Why does nobody look at my question, it only has 10 000 000 000 000 000 views

Yes Safari, DuckDuckGo: Why does nobody look at my question, it only has 1000000 views

Yes Safari: Why does nobody look at my question, it only has 42000000000000000 views

Yes Safari: Why does nobody look at my question, it only has 10000000000000000,0 views

Answer (score 1):

This is a test sentence for testing purposes.

---

Testing `~` in URLs:

- [HTML href](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/369341#:~:text=This%20is%20a%20test%20sentence%20for%20testing%20purposes.) (`<a href="..."></a>`)
- [Markdown footnote link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/369341#:%7E:text=This%20is%20a%20test%20sentence%20for%20testing%20purposes.) (`[text][1]`)
- [Markdown inline link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/369341#:%7E:text=This%20is%20a%20test%20sentence%20for%20testing%20purposes.) (`[text](link)`)

Answer (score 1):

````
<!-- language-all: lang-swift -->

Ok I gave a [VBA solution][1] but here's a pure Excel version using the relatively new LAMBDA functions, no VBA. 

To achieve this I have created a named function with signature `printf(mask, tokensArray)` where:
 - `mask` is a string you want to format, containing positional `{}` or indexed `{i}` interpolation locations.
 - `tokensArray` is the set of values to be substituted in, supplied as either a 1D Range (row or column), an array (hardcoded or returned from a function) or a single value.

... and which returns a formatted string. Called from a cell like:

[![Tooltip][3]][3]


[![Usage][4]][4]

    =printf("Some text '{1}', more text: '{2}'", A1:A2) //continuous 1D row/col
    =printf("Some text '{1}', more text: '{2}'", {"foo","bar"}) //hardcoded array
    =printf("Single Value {1}", "foo")

or with positional args (left to right)

    =printf("Some text '{}', more text: '{}'", A1:A2)

---

Define these two functions by entering them in the name manager (see [LAMBDA function][2] MSDN docs for detailed instructions, though this link will die I'm sure...) :

| Param     | Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|-----------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Name      | ReplaceRecursive                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| Scope     | Workbook                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| Comment   | Recursively substitutes {} or {i} with tokens from the tokens list, which it escapes one by one leaving \} in the result string                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| Refers To | `=LAMBDA(mask,tokens,i,tokenCount, IF(i >tokenCount, mask, LET(token, INDEX(tokens,i),escapedToken,SUBSTITUTE(token,"}", "\}"),inIndexedMode,ISERROR(FIND("{}",mask,1)),substituted, IF(inIndexedMode, SUBSTITUTE(mask,"{"&i&"}", escapedToken),SUBSTITUTE(mask, "{}", escapedToken,1) ),ReplaceRecursive(substituted,tokens,i+1,tokenCount))))` |

<details><summary>Prettified<\summary>
```lang-swift
=LAMBDA(
    mask,
    tokens,
    i,
    tokenCount,
    IF(
        i > tokenCount,
        mask,
        LET(
            token,
            INDEX(
                tokens,
                i
            ),
            escapedToken,
            SUBSTITUTE(
                token,
                "}",
                "\}"
            ),
            inIndexedMode,
            ISERROR(
                FIND(
                    "{}",
                    mask,
                    1
                )
            ),
            substituted,
            IF(
                inIndexedMode,
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    mask,
                    "{" & i & "}",
                    escapedToken
                ),
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    mask,
                    "{}",
                    escapedToken,
                    1
                )
            ),
            ReplaceRecursive(
                substituted,
                tokens,
                i + 1,
                tokenCount
            )
        )
    )
)
```
</details>

| Param     | Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
|-----------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Name      | printf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| Scope     | Workbook                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| Comment   | printf(mask: str, tokensArray: {array,} \| range \| str ) -> str \| mask: string to substitute tokens into e.g. "Hello {}, {}" or "Hello {2}, {1}" (1-indexed) \| tokensArray: 1D range or array of tokens, e.g. "world" or {"foo","bar"} or A1:A5 |
| Refers To | `=LAMBDA(mask,tokensArray,LET(r,ROWS(tokensArray), c, COLUMNS(tokensArray), length, MAX(r,c), IF(AND(r>1, c>1), "tokensArray must be 1 dimensional", SUBSTITUTE(ReplaceRecursive(mask, tokensArray, 1, length), "\}","}"))))`                  |

```lang-swift
=LAMBDA(
    mask,
    tokensArray,
    LET(
        r,
        ROWS(
            tokensArray
        ),
        c,
        COLUMNS(
            tokensArray
        ),
        length,
        MAX(
            r,
            c
        ),
        IF(
            AND(
                r > 1,
                c > 1
            ),
            "tokensArray must be 1 dimensional",
            SUBSTITUTE(
                ReplaceRecursive(
                    mask,
                    tokensArray,
                    1,
                    length
                ),
                "\}",
                "}"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

---

There will be improvements to Excel's LAMBDA functions that make this easier to write I'm sure, but this recursive approach is good for now I think.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67858844/6609896
  [2]: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyDQ5.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv8DR.png
````

Answer (score 1):

Markdown:

```markdown
**Id**|**Value**
:-----:|:-----:
7E38AD4A-4C6E-40D9-B805-08C1F4EE14D0|1,370
E48A0A4A-6E6C-41A8-B379-0E14452938C6|1,200
```

Table:

| **Value** |
| --- |
| 7E38AD4A-4C6E-40D9-B805-08C1F4EE14D0 |
| E48A0A4A-6E6C-41A8-B379-0E14452938C6 |

Markdown:

```markdown
Here is my sample data:
|ID|Name|
|-|-|
|1|Steve|
|2|Jane|
```

Here is my sample data:
|ID|Name|
|-|-|
|1|Steve|
|2|Jane|

Answer (score 1):

> (U+1F31E Sun With Face) 
>  (U+1F319 Crescent Moon)

Comment: Welcome back Jason! Are you coming to Tavern?

Answer (score 1):

Use Snippets to display [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
    [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
    [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
    [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
    [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
    [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
    [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
    [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
    [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    },
    backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's put a button:

[image: button]

[Link to SVG here.](https://gist.github.com/weeklyd3/8f037618df622bfb3a204d4311136dee)

Self description:
[image: button]

Answer (score 1):

Just an answer for some comment testing.

Comment: will this comment do something with hats?

Comment: And how about this comment then?

Comment: feel free to test if replying to me gives any hats :)

Comment: This comment has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another oddity:

> A quote.
>
> Another paragraph:
>
> > A nested quote.
>
> All is good.

But what about this:

- A list item

  > A quote.
  >
  > Another paragraph:
  >
  > > A nested quote.
  >
  > All is good.

Answer (score 1):

Render example for a Stacks editor bug report:

> - One (this point is italic in the editor)
> - Two
> - Three

This is italic, and because of a lack of termination (#21), everything after is italic

Regular text

Comment: Ignore, test comment to see if the comment archive is working

Answer (score 1):

## Formatting of images in tables:

These examples are made to see what methods work for getting the most out of a table's space.

### Default behaviour:

The table adapts to the contents of the first cell, and the contents of the adjacent cell(s) are adapted to that of the first.
The second image in the second cell is forced below the first using a `<br/>` (or two, rather, so the images have a better looking gap between them):

| [image] | [image] [image] |
| --- | --- |

### Using the `&nbsp;`

Using the HTML `&nbsp;` entity to fill out the empty space due to the table cells adjusting to the width of the contents of the first cell:

| [image] | [image] [image] |
| --- | --- |

### Using `&nbsp;` and `<br/>`

Using that same trick but preceded by a `<br/>` to force that the line of non-breaking spaces below the image (such a line can also be put above the image, logically), to prevent the scrollbar from appearing (thank you @Makyen!):

| [image] | [image] [image] |
| --- | --- |

### Using `<img>` entities with custom `width` set

Different aspect ratios behave differently, and there is still a lot of unused space in the table:

| [image] | [image] [image] |
| --- | --- |

### Using `<img>` entities with `width` *and* `height`

It takes a lot more work, but it's indeed doable (the burden of being a perfectionist, I presume). The numbers are guesswork, and the aspect ratios obviously don't correspond with the true dimensions of the images, but it looks good:

| [image] | [image] [image] |
| --- | --- |
| Width = 320, height = 640 | Width = 370, height = 305 (of both images) |

And here's how they all look when the viewport's width changes to something more narrow:

[image]

It seems the table with the images in `<img>` and only their `width` set wins the beauty contest when viewports of widths < 1265 px are taken into consideration, until the breaking point at 980 px occurs, and the right sidebar is removed. But then it immediately adapts to the viewport's width, so it only looks okay - depending on contents - for a few tens of pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Sure hope I don't get answer banned, that would be a real shame.

Answer (score 1):

> Spoiler:

> Not spoiled!
>
> Spoiled!
>
> Not spoiled!

Answer (score 1):

### Syntax highlighting currently strips HTML tags in `<pre><code>` blocks

(Since Highlight.js is being used instead of Prettify.)

HTML tags work inside `<pre>` blocks:

```
SELECT a, not_b FROM tbl WHERE a < b;
```

Same with `<pre><code>` blocks - **here** on meta.SE where automatic code highlighting is deactivated:

```
SELECT a, not_b FROM tbl WHERE a < b;
```

The same breaks on SO with automatic code highlighting. Highlight.js strips all tags before adding syntax-highlighting.

I set a language explicitly with `<!-- language-all: lang-sql -->` to trigger the same effect here:

HTML tags still work inside `<pre>` blocks:

```
SELECT a, not_b FROM tbl WHERE a < b;
```

But are stripped from `<pre><code>` blocks:

```sql
SELECT a, not_b FROM tbl WHERE a < b;  -- not the intended meaning
```

While editing, the local preview is rendered differently, and HTML tags seem to work even in `<pre><code>` blocks. But that's deceiving. Once the draft is saved, syntax-highlighting with Highlight.js kicks in and strips all HTML tags before adding colors - possibly breaking the meaning, especially for `<strike>`.

This used to work, but is currently broken. See:

- [HTML formatting inside code blocks doesn't work if syntax highlighting is being performed for the block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378134/html-formatting-inside-code-blocks-doesnt-work-if-syntax-highlighting-is-being?noredirect=1#comment1262167_378134)
- [Is having the ability to apply rich text formatting inside code blocks important?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417635/is-having-the-ability-to-apply-rich-text-formatting-inside-code-blocks-important)

Answer (score 1):

Testing comment upvote by low rep user.

Comment: hey sockboy, just a test

Answer (score 1):

```js
fetch('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites?pagesize=500&filter=!*UCL0ITv.)X')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => r.items.forEach(site => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('x');
    div.style = `--imgurl:url(${site.favicon_url})`;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }));
```

```css
.x { background-image: var(--imgurl); }
body { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr); }
div { flex: 1; height: 100px; }
```

it's better fullscreen btw

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to test the issue in:

"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419387/stack-overflow-urls-in-double-quotes-in-answers-are-not-replaced-by-the-name-of"
"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345847/3773011"

The above is:

```
"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419387/stack-overflow-urls-in-double-quotes-in-answers-are-not-replaced-by-the-name-of"  
"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345847/3773011"
```

which render in the preview as links with the question title as the link text. In the post as rendered by SE's servers, it shows as a bare URL in double quotes.

The following is:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419387/stack-overflow-urls-in-double-quotes-in-answers-are-not-replaced-by-the-name-of  
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345847/3773011
```

[Stack Overflow URLs in double quotes in answers are not replaced by the name of the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419387/stack-overflow-urls-in-double-quotes-in-answers-are-not-replaced-by-the-name-of)
[Editor preview disagrees on link title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345847/3773011)

which also renders in both the preview and server rendered version as the question titles.

Answer (score 1):

`html <h1>Heading1</h1> <details>Some details</details>`

Comment: ```html
 <html><h1>Sample comment</h1> <details>This comment comes from python stackapi</details><html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an answer in order to test some site functionality with a low reputation account.

Answer (score 1):

I am also testing something. Does this work?

Comment: What did you test?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I wanted to see if there's a message going to show up when submitting the answer.

Comment: What message were you expecting to show?

Comment: A warning of some kind about low-length or poor quality.

Comment: Oh, I think MSE and meta sites in general don't have quality filter, so that people can ask about such things or test, not sure. Didn't find official source, will keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a test answer for getting a view of revisions

Comment: Effective at creating a VLQ Review too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/83905

Comment: amusingly - this was a pain in the rear to get what I needed :D

Answer (score 1):

[image: image description]

Answer (score 1):

testing data: scheme for inline svgs, doesn't work :-(

Testing
!enter link description here

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92568/allow-svg-image-uploads) for some tricks and tips.

Answer (score 1):

Test

http://youtu.be/VE1LOYZf0cU

Comment: YouTube embedding isn't enabled here if that's what you were trying to test.

Answer (score 1):

[Paragraph in square brackets, containing a link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and some other text.]

Same test with backslashes…
[Paragraph in square brackets, containing a link [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and some other text.]

Answer (score 1):

### Start

Trying out the code blocks:

four spaces:

```
import antigravity
antigravity.fly()
#this is a comment
```

with ```python in front:

```python
import antigravity
antigravity.fly()
#this is a comment
```

## end

---

Answer (score 1):

> ### hi

okay, weird. So if you do:

```markdown
> hi
> -1
```

, it looks like `> hi -1` in the editor preview, but in the actual post, it looks like a quoted large heading. Why?

This, however,

```markdown
> hi
> -
```

Looks like a quoted heading in both preview and the post. So I guess this is a bug with the reStructuredText section title formatting syntax?

> ### hi

Hm. To test that theory:

> ## hi

```markdown
> hi
> =1
```

What if you do something other than a single `1`?

> ## hi

```markdown
> hi
> =2
```

> ## hi

```markdown
> hi
> =a
```

> hi
> =abc123

```markdown
> hi
> =abc123
```

> hi
> =ab

```markdown
> hi
> =ab
```

> ## hi

```markdown
> hi
> =⭐
```

> ## hi

```markdown
> hi
> ==⭐
```

Oh but Zero-Width-Joiner sequence emoji (such as [polar bear](https://emojipedia.org/polar-bear/)) don't do it:

> hi
> ==‍❄️

```markdown
> hi
> ==‍❄️
```

Answer (score 1):

A table where the markup for a row is commented out:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hello | world | ! |

hello | world | ! |

| hello | world | ! |

---

A table where the markup for a row is commented out, but put at the end of the previous row's line:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hello | world | ! |
| hello | world | ! |
| hello | world | ! |

---

Link to spec docs: https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-

> The table is broken at the first empty line, or beginning of another block-level structure

Answer (score 1):

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359283/its-possible-to-create-empty-content-fields-p

Answer (score 1):

[Tests for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422992/markdown-rendering-bug-different-between-preview-and-actual]

**b.**​a
**b.**a
**b.**a
**b.**a
**b**Za
**b*`a`
**b**a

Answer (score 1):

Posting a bug report on Stack Apps, I tried to link to its API docs:

> [http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=posts/{id}/comments](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=posts/%7Bid%7D/comments)

It was unsuccessful, and making the link explicit with `[http://url.com][1]` doesn't work either because the link doesn't show up. E.g., [*this is supposed to be a link*](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=posts/%7Bid%7D/comments).

Comment: The Markdown for this answer is a direct copy of [revision 4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/08ceea44-c84e-4226-a4c7-e6973460b69b/view-source) of "[Curly brackets in URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79057/271271)" by [Nikita Rybak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/149284/nikita-rybak) et al. and is under a CC BY-SA 3.0 license. It was posted here to determine if SE's backend conversion of Markdown to HTML continued to have the problem which was asked about in that question.

Answer (score 1):

Testing the rendering of a link, related to [Square brackets in hyperlinks is broken in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343694/square-brackets-in-hyperlinks-is-broken-in-comments).

```
[[class.access](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access)]
```

[[class.access](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access)]

---

Testing rendering of some more links, related to [Diamonds (♦) break the automatic hyperlink parser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242571).

- [My question was deleted by Community♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203129/my-question-was-deleted-by-community%E2%99%A6)
- [Community ♦ should discriminate more when bumping unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-%E2%99%A6-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions)
- [Users who can't write good posts ≠ users who want to write good posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238644/users-who-cant-write-good-posts-%E2%89%A0-users-who-want-to-write-good-posts)

Answer (score 1):

[The MusicBrainz API](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2) has information about artists and music
bands.
<sup>1</sup>
An example – a request for the British rock band *Coldplay* is:
http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/cc197bad-dc9c-440d-a5b5-d52ba2e14234?&fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups.
The JSON response contains – among other things – the 25 earliest
album titles by the artist/band.
This information is in the `release-groups` array.
The start of this array, including its first object, is:

```json
…
  "release-groups": [
    {
      "id": "1dc4c347-a1db-32aa-b14f-bc9cc507b843",
      "secondary-type-ids": [],
      "first-release-date": "2000-07-10",
      "primary-type-id": "f529b476-6e62-324f-b0aa-1f3e33d313fc",
      "disambiguation": "",
      "secondary-types": [],
      "title": "Parachutes",
      "primary-type": "Album"
    },
…
```

This JSON snippet shows that the first album by Coldplay is
*Parachutes*.
It also gives an `id`, in this case
`1dc4c347-a1db-32aa-b14f-bc9cc507b843`,
which is a unique identifier of the album.

This identifier can be used to make a lookup in
[the Cover Art Archive API](https://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Cover_Art_Archive/API) :
http://coverartarchive.org/release-group/1dc4c347-a1db-32aa-b14f-bc9cc507b843.
<sup>2</sup>

For each album, the JSON response contains some images,
one of which is the front cover of the album.
The first few lines of the response to the above request are:

```json
{
  "images": [
    {
      "approved": true,
      "back": false,
      "comment": "",
      "edit": 22132705,
      "front": true,
      "id": 4086974851,
      "image": "http://coverartarchive.org/release/435fc965-9121-461e-b8da-d9b505c9dc9b/4086974851.jpg",
      "thumbnails": {
        "250": "http://coverartarchive.org/release/435fc965-9121-461e-b8da-d9b505c9dc9b/4086974851-250.jpg",
        "500": "http://coverartarchive.org/release/435fc965-9121-461e-b8da-d9b505c9dc9b/4086974851-500.jpg",
        "1200": "http://coverartarchive.org/release/435fc965-9121-461e-b8da-d9b505c9dc9b/4086974851-1200.jpg",
        "large": "http://coverartarchive.org/release/435fc965-9121-461e-b8da-d9b505c9dc9b/4086974851-500.jpg",
= = >   "small": "http://coverartarchive.org/release/435fc965-9121-461e-b8da-d9b505c9dc9b/4086974851-250.jpg"
    },
…
```

Of interest here is the line
`"small": "http://coverartarchive.org/release/435fc965-9121-461e-b8da-d9b505c9dc9b/4086974851-250.jpg"`.
That URL is a direct link to the front cover of the *Parachutes* album.

#### **The code to create and visualize the API**

The overall task is to use Postman to visualize all the album titles
and front covers of a music band.
How to write code that achieves this has already been described in
quite some detail in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67824483) to
*How can I visualize an API mashup in Postman?*
– Therefore, I will avoid lengthy discussions here and just present
the code and a screenshot of the result:

```js
const lock = setTimeout(() => {}, 43210);
const albumsArray = [];
const urlsArray = [];
const urlOuter = 'https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/' +
  pm.collectionVariables.get('MBID') + '?fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups';
pm.sendRequest(urlOuter, (_, responseO) => {
  const bandName = responseO.json().name;
  const albums = responseO.json()['release-groups'];
  for (const item of albums) {
    albumsArray.push(item.title);
    urlsArray.push('https://coverartarchive.org/release-group/' + item.id);
  }
  albumsArray.length = urlsArray.length = 15;
  const images = [];
  let countDown = urlsArray.length;
  urlsArray.forEach((url, index) => {
    asynchronousCall(url, imageURL => {
      images[index] = imageURL;
      if (--countDown === 0) { // Callback for ALL starts on next line.
        clearTimeout(lock); // Unlock the timeout.
        const albumTitles = albumsArray.map(value => ({ title: value }));
        const albumImages = images.map(value => ({ image: value }));
        const albumsAndImages = albumTitles.map(
          (item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, albumImages[i]));
        const template = `<table>
          <tr><th>` + bandName + `</th></tr>
          {{#each responseI}}
          <tr><td>{{title}}<br><img src="{{image}}"></td></tr>
          {{/each}}
        </table>`;
        pm.visualizer.set(template, { responseI: albumsAndImages });
      }
    });
  });
  function asynchronousCall (url, callback) {
    pm.sendRequest(url, (_, responseI) => {
      callback(responseI.json().images.find(obj => obj.front === true)
        .thumbnails.small); // Individual callback.
    });
  }
});
```

#### **The result for Coldplay – and the documentation**

[image: Result and docs | Coldplay]

#### **How to download and run the Postman Collection**

Running the Postman Collection should be straightforward.
Assuming you are using [the desktop version of Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads),
do as follows:

1. Download and save
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/henk9/Henke/main/MusicBands.pm_coll.json
   in a suitable place on your hard drive.
2. In Postman,
   *Ctrl + O > Upload Files > `MusicBands.pm_coll.json` > Import*.
   You should now see `MusicBands` among your collections in Postman.
3. *Collections > `MusicBands` > `DummyRequest` > **Send***.
   <sup>3</sup>
4. In the Postman Response Body, click *Visualize*.
5. There should now be 15 albums if you scroll down – as indicated by
   the above screenshot.

#### **The result for Kate Bush**

The Postman collection includes detailed documentation on
how to perform the same request for a different artist / music band.
Here is what it looks like when using the MBID for Kate Bush.

[image: Result for Kate Bush]

### **References**

- [Documentation of the MusicBrainz API](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2)
- [Documentation of the Cover Art Archive API](https://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Cover_Art_Archive/API)
- [How can I visualize an API mashup in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67824483)
- [The desktop version of Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads)

---

<sup>1</sup>
This post relies heavily on
[How can I visualize a mashup API in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67824483).

<sup>2</sup>
This URL is automatically redirected to:
https://ia800503.us.archive.org/29/items/mbid-435fc965-9121-461e-b8da-d9b505c9dc9b/index.json.

<sup>3</sup>
If you get an error, *Something went wrong while running your scripts*,
try hitting **Send** again.

Answer (score 1):

Testing markdown formatting followed by a forward slash

**Markdown:**

```
a**b**/c
```

**Result:**

a**b**/c

**Result in comments:**

[image: Result in comments is the same as the unrendered markdown above.]

Answer (score 1):

```sql
Strike, bold italic etc. work again with code highlighting?
Even subtext or super?
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY col1 , col2;
```

```pgsql
Strike, bold italic etc. work again with code highlighting?
Even subtext or super?
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY col1 , col2;
```

This had been broken for the longest time ..

Answer (score 1):

why doesn't this work in comments? <kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: because... it just doesn't. Feature-request: [Can I place <kbd></kbd> in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132923/997587)

Comment: I just had to link this post ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-too-intrusive

Comment: <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Comparison, user custom sizing vs standard markdown + options/variations.
Re: [Allow pasting images in HTML format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388183/allow-pasting-images-in-html-format)

Using img src @700px
[image]
Additional disadvantage here is that there's no click-through to full size, even though all the image data must be downloaded to view in-line.

All these have clickthrough to the full image. More important for larger images, detailed photos etc.
Using standard markdown
[image]

Using imgur's built-in data save resizing on a fresh upload of the previous image to save cross-referencing
Admittedly, this is even more effort than img src
Size `l`
[image]
Size `m`
[image]

Image pre-resized to 700 & saved as 50% jpg
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified version of the tao excercise 3.2.3.
(misinterpreted the question, and ended up with a different question).
(This post is long, I'm raising only two math questions, MQ1 and MQ2, The rest can be viewed as interpretation and reasoning behind those questions).

We are given two ways of creating a set.

1. (A1) (universal specification on set) Suppose that for every set x, $P(x)$ is either true or false, then there exists a set ${x: P(x)}$ such that.
   $y \in {x: P(x)} \iff P(y)$
2. (A2) (informally) any unordered collection of sets is a set.
   A set can have a set as an element.
   (Since we can talk about universal set, I wanted to express every set which is element of the universal set.)

A1 let us build sets whose elements are sets and there's a $P(x)$ associated with it.
A2 let us build sets whose elements are sets (and we don't have to think about $P(x)$)

So you have two way of creating a set.
I ask myself if both way of creating a set has equal power, ie all the sets which can be created by the 2nd can be also created by the first and vice versa.

Below are the proof I attempted to prove A2 $\to$ A1

---

> Suppose you have an arbitrary set A which has sets as elements.
> Now construct $P(x)$ such that $P(x) := x \in A $.
> Now you have $y \in {x: P(x)} \iff P(y) := y \in A $.
>
> Thus we showed all the sets that are expressable by A2 are subsets that are expressable by A1.

---

The first question to ask is,

> (MQ1) Is the proposition and the proof above well-defined (not ill-formed) mathematically?

The rest goes on to ask another question if the answer to MQ1 is "at least partially" positive.

("at least partially", could mean, if they were asked in pre-1900 when the paradoxical set was not discovered, would it be a well-defined statement.
Or it could mean, to students who are studying not too rigorous elementary math (maybe someone who's studying pre-college math).
It seems hard for me to see an intuitive reason why the answer is not even "partially" positive.)

Statements below this point are not mathematical statements.

---

Now, I'm not sure if the proof is ok..

Because.. without constructing the set A, $y \in A$ seems hypothetical.

My main concern is the argument: we have not built the set A, and yet claims if you give me set A, I would build $P(x)$ from it.
I wonder if that argument can be made safely.

---

I ask the following questions to investigate the concern.

> QQ1. Given A2,
> "assuming an arbitrary set A exists" statement does capture all the sets expressed by "set that has sets as elements"? (or it misses some?).
>
> QQ2. Does the answer to QQ1 depends on the object we are dealing with?, (some object other than set, such as function, number etc)

I suspect the answer to QQ2 does depend on what kind of object we are dealing with.
The reasoning is the following.

If I say the answer is yes to the QQ1, and does accept the proof given below to conclude A1 $\iff$ A2, we can replace the universal specification with A2.
Then we got rid of the paradoxical set, because all the sets expressed by A2 can be assumed exist and the paradoxical set doesn't exist. (We have no way of stating the paradoxical set)
Yet with A1, we know we can build the paradoxical set. (we have a way of stating the set)
So we have a contradiction.

The paradoxical set (RS1) is ${x: P(x):= \text{ x is a set, and x} \notin x}$

If I say the answer to QQ1 is no, then I guess the answer to QQ2 is yes. (Because I think I have seen similar argument being made with different object than set).
So then the question becomes, when is it safe to make argument "some arbitrary A exists"?

I could ask a general question of "an arbitrary A exists" is always safe statement to make?
Then it feels harder to answer, so I had to lean on the set example.

The following counterfactual thinking would help to understand my question.

> Suppose the paradoxical set was not found.
>
> The equivalence of A1 and A2 was proved as above.
> Some mathematical community adopted A2, some adopted A1 thinking they are describing the same mathematical facts.
>
> But then, for someone who knows the paradoxical set exists, the two
> mathematical communities seems not to describe the same mathematical facts
>
> So how do we resolve the issue?
>
> (If mathematics have no definitive way of preventing such counterfactual happening, I think it adds more validity of asking such a question. Even though this begs a yet different question, I am mentioning it because I don't know the answer)

---

We assume some rational number exists and express an arbitrary rational number as $\frac{p}{q}$ to prove the irrationality of root 2.
I guess the validity of "assuming such number exist" comes from the fact that the rational number is defined (constructed) by the formula. Well that was the first difference I could see, maybe there's a different reason which I don't know.

But then, why would it be different to "assuming a set exist" when a set is defined (constructed) by "set that has sets as elements" (A2)

---

Another similar proof technique is used in diagonalization proof.

Where it goes, let's suppose there's such a mapping, then we can show there's an element (by inverting the diagonal elements) that couldn't be in the mapping.

The diagonalization proof is particularly (non-constructional? yet constructional?) in that, it assumes that your mapping is finalized at the time of "inverting the diagonal entries and testing".
(Maybe I am only exposed to the conceptually simple and not rigorous proof of it.)

So here again, the question I ask is essentially "assumption can be made?"
This post is an attempt to formulate the question by presenting the relevant cases.
(If I ask simply, why, when "making an assumption A exists" makes sense, I guess it's hard to deliver what I'm asking and consequently also hard to answer.)

---

I guess many different answers are possible.

It might be the case that the question I asked or formulated could be so ill-formed, it has no way of making sense of it to any mathematically thinking person.
(I want to find out if it is by asking the question).

Assuming the other possible, that there's some sense to my question.

I'm trying to summarize my interpretation. (I had to ask the questions to arrive at the interpretation. After thinking over my questions, this is the interpretation I have atm. I saw the definition of axiom of choice yesterday for the first time.)

People interpret (or react to) Russel's set differently.

Since it has a property that the statement's truth value can't be determined,

> (B1) Exclude the statement from math, by choosing appropriate axioms.
> (B2) Exclude such statement from happening (yet we not knowing), by taking an axiom that mathematical statement can be made only when it
> has a way of constructing it

B1's answer to hypothetical object creation

- Making an assumption "an arbitrary A exists" is valid (until proven otherwise).

B2's answer to hypothetical object creation

- Making an assumption "an arbitrary A exists" is valid if there is a way to construct A.

I think the above statements are close to "factual" statements.
And even though my original question may be ill-formed, the general question I raised might not be such ill-formed, if I take the existence of people with B1 and people with B2 exist as an evidence to "maybe I'm not so delusional in asking the general question"

---

Below statements are "my interpretation" on B1 & B2.
So they are not mathematical statements in nature.

B1 is practical, efficient and takes more expanding view of what mathematics is.

- If we take the view that we fix can inconsistency when it arises, we can move faster and explore more.
- Mathematical is a model and it is effective as long as inconsistency is not found in the model
- Mathematics can create an unintuitive model that doesn't resemble the model we observe outside of mathematics and it doesn't matter
- Some inconsistency can invalidate some or most of a mathematical model, but we don't have to constraint our reach when we can't pinpoint what are the reasons that can create inconsistency

B2 is more conservative, and try to avoid breaking the base after piling up many statements above the base

- Some inconsistencies seem to stem from hypothetical creation, we avoid that
- (B3?, I don't know) Maybe some people try to embrace or redefine what inconsistency and effectively expand or take a different route to explore a new mathematics

And I guess (I suspect such logicians exists purely by the name (constructivism) nothing more than that), there doesn't seem to be definite criteria that B2 can use to secure the goal either.

..

One could take B1's view and there's no reason to believe mathematics as of now has inconsistency and there's an objective world where future inconsistency can always be dealt with.

And I guess there are many possible different interpretations (on questions such as what mathematics is or any other meta questions) among who takes the B1, (and among who takes the B2).

It seems mathematics doesn't answer any of the meta questions, yet mathematicians seems to have 'interpretations, answers' to those questions.

Some may take B1's position and disregard my question as invalid or not meaningful. And there's no objective way to disprove such interpretation.

And there doesn't seem to (and some people seem to claim there can't be) be a definitive answer to whether B1 or B2 or some other view are more objective.

---

So my answer to my question is..

When is it valid to "assume A exists"? can be asked and answered mathematically..
(and to me, the answer seems to depend on the axioms of the mathematicians, and some can disprove that the answer is dependent on something other than objective truth.. and so on).

But if I ask why is it valid, it can't be asked and answered mathematically..
(I'm sure mathematicians had valid reasons to chose some answers, but the reason is not expressed in mathematical terms. I can only guess)

---

Route N1

So is that it?
Did I get the answer for the question I asked?

Yes.

What was the question and answer?
Well it's expressed in the post.

But we usually infer something more from the post (expression) assuming there's another intention or meaning that the writer has.

> What we express  &
> What we mean by what we express.

If I assume there's something beyond the first, I could ask the higher meaning behind the expression.
But then, upon understanding the meaning, I could pursue another higher meaning.

Soon, it seems that nothing can be answered fully.

If I ask myself why I asked the question, I won't be able to answer fully.
Yet if I were to be someone else who sees me asking the question and answering it, I (as the someone else) would have thought what I am thinking.

I guess that's just the way it is.
I have to settle somewhere to get off the ground.
And I also want to see what lies below the ground.

There seems to be a lot of people who talked about the limit of reasons in various ways.

---

Route N2

Wait a minute, what was the problem with RS1 in the first place?

> (RS1) ${x: P(x):= \text{ x is a set, and x} \notin x}$

It is not constructive enough to let us foresee the everything there is that can be constructed with the form. (Probably B2 side has some definition of what 'constructive' means, but I am not aware more than the word 'constructivism' about it).

So then it can be thought as yet another instance of 'assume A exists'.

It also has self referential property where an object test something against itself ($x \notin x$).
And I have seen a few instances where self referential object causes interesting problem.

There could be yet another property why RS1 caused the problem.
And we can inspect further the self referential property on other problems...
It is interesting property as its own.

It is also interesting to note that the other questions I am questioning can be viewed as questioning the hidden assumptions of the self, ie what the statements is assuming it can be applied to. (MP, and hypothetical object creation).

.. tbc..

---

Route N3

Wait a minute, I have seen this.

> What you define is the boundary of your definition vs
> Your definition is the boundary of your world

I could see "assuming A exists (makes sense because we decided it makes sense only when it seems to make sense)" as a statement of the form $\forall x P(x)$ (where P is applicable to x only when P(x) is true).

I have seen something similar.

"modus ponens".

Modus ponens (MP) says,

> $\forall x, P(x) -> Q(x)$ and $P(x)$
> $\therefore Q(x)$

I was wondering how could I know if my new x I found found (created) works with the MP?
Can you say something about what "x in the $forall x$" has to satisfy?
(I think I could view RS1 was something that looked like valid x but it was not.)

There's a similar question (I think) asked by a philosopher.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles.

I think there are other ways to capture the essence of the paradox or my question on MP. It seems to ask what is the boundary that your statement is asserting. Mathematical truth has a property that it has to be defined deterministically or inwardly
The inward statement doesn't change itself, it rather shrinks the world to make itself a tautology.
The wikipedia article says making MP tautology is an answer to the infinite regression problem.
And I'm contemplating the consequence, what does it mean to be a tautology when it has no way of describing what objects it can refer to.

Even statements about infinite object has to have that property.  For instance, for an infinite set, a mathematical statement such as $x \in A$ is considered to be true or false (deterministic) when the question is asked.
So it has no notion of 'not in then state to be able to answer because my state is changing' (from the object's perspective)

Diagonalization argument shows the deterministic truth.

> (DA1) There's no surjective $f$ from set S to power set $P(S)$.

> $RA = {x \in S | x \notin f(x) } \subset S$.
> $RA$: The elements of S that their image of $f$ doesn't contain itself.
>
> Since RA is an element of $P(S)$ and f is surjective, there's $y \in S, f(y) = RA$
>
> We ask, is $y \in RA$?
> if $y \in RA, f(y) \neq RA$ by definition of RA, this can't be
> if $y \notin RA, and f(y) = RA$, then it must be that $y \in RA$ by definition of RA.
>
> So there can be no y that is $f(y) = RA$, therefore $f$ is not surjective

$RA$ looks familiar and it resembles RS1 ${x: P(x):= \text{ x is a set, and x} \notin x}$.

> (MQ2) Are we sure that it's ok to state $RA$ exists?

We are using it to disprove $f$ is surjective here, and I'm not sure what's the validation for accepting $RA$ and rejecting RS1.
Anyway, if we don't reject the statement as invalid, we have to state its truth value, and we are saying it as truthful because it almost seems possible to exist.
And the statement has the "inward property" that it forces $y$ to abide by the definition A was created with.

There are alternative interpretation that might show a gap between the argument and my intuition (maybe it's due to the infinity is so hard to grasp and offers many different way to look at it)
(Another one is, where the diagonal argument goes, assume f, I'll show you it's not surjective for some elements, what happens if we change the reasoning backward, show me the elements, I'll show you I can make them the image of f.

There are other ways of stating unclearness.. but too long.
The other way of presenting the diagonal argument has different flavors of unclearness.. )

The diagonal argument makes sense, it might be a perfectly valid way with specific property (deterministic truth, non-hard-construction of $RA$..)

But I'm just questioning the underlying assumptions are subtle and sometimes hard to know for sure if its proof technique is consistent. Consistent in a sense that (generally whatever we do, we do it the same way, I find it particularly hard to tell when reasoning about infinity), maybe the construction of RA is not possible at all, so it can't be assumed to exist? (I'm sure it's valid, because that's how it's setup, valid until valid)

Yet another interpretation would be that, the notion of deductive reasoning is expressed inside the MP, but to find out what P it can deal with is conducted from inductive reasoning.
So the process of applying it seems rather inductive as a whole.
(The boundaries of the definitions seems to get blurred again.)

So here again, I see the pattern where definition defines the boundary of the object it refers to.
And it is fascinating that mind can imagine the boundary what MP assumes it applies to in multiple ways.

Then with realizing these "assumption A exists" + "modus ponens" having the same property, I could go further to explore the possible interpretations.

---

> Q) When is it valid to state "assuming an A exists"?
> A) We assume it's valid for all cases when we do assume it.
> And it seems very intuitive that we can assume it in all the cases.

> Q) What happens if something bad happens?
> A) Something bad?
> Q) inconsistency?
> A) Oh, that bad, We have reason to believe that we won't see the bad.
> Q) But what if it happens? do you have guarantee it won't happen?
> A) Hard to answer, do you have guarantee it will happen?
>
> Q) Suppose it did happen, what do we change?
> Are we gonna track down the cause, probably an axioms that cause the bad?
> A) That's a possibility.
> Q) Is it also possible to change the definition of inconsistency?
> A) What do you mean, the definition of inconsistency is clear, we are not going to change it.
> Q) Oh then, the objects that consistency can be applied to changes?
> Because some axioms or statements that caused inconsistency would have to be removed.
> A) Possibly
>
> Q) So there's a statement, axiom, definition that's not gonna change
> but what it can refer to can change?
> Then can we say that the definition changes?
> A) Hard to answer. That doesn't look like a well defined question.

---

So taking an axiom is a smart move in a sense that it lets you start off somewhere.

Some world is constructed (defined) from the selecting axioms and expanding the axioms.

And, it may happen that the definition of the world depends on the axioms the constructor choose.

And the constructor-A might decide if some objects belong to the world by whether the object passes the test of his or her axioms.

Then another constructor-B who has a different world might come along and ask the constructor-A why A's axiom says $\forall x, M(x)$ when B have seen some y that's not $M(y) = \text{true}$.

> A says to B, such "y" is not something we are referring with $\forall x$ we only have objects in our world where $M(x) = \text{true}$.
>
> B says, that's understandable, but we happen to have something called $M2$ in our world, and it is very similar to your $M1$ but our definition of $M2$ is different.
>
> A says, that's not possible, $M$ has to be that way, can you show me our $M$ is wrong?
> B says, yeah I can do that..
> A says, but if you use something that doesn't pass the test of $M1(x)$, I can't accept it as convincing. Because $M1$ is an axiom and a tautology
> B says.. oh.. then it's hard..

A further contemplates..

So love is something of a nature $P(x, y) := Love(x, y)$.
When x, y can be changed, are we changing the definition of "Love" or not?
If we change the set of x, y that the function Love(x, y) can handle, what the definition of Love is supposed to mean?
Are we changing the definition of defining?

---

By now, I get to a point asking the meaning or validity of "$\forall x M(x)$".

So I could ask when or why it is valid to define something?
And what is the meaning of 'meaning' or 'definition'?

In this line of thinking, mathematics seems like an attempt to create a closed system in our mind where one draw boundaries so that one can feel what it is like defining something. (It's not about invention or discovery, maybe it is both).
Much like I try hard to draw a boundary of my body and myself from environment when (I assume) it would be blurry where the boundary actually is.
But then, I could start asking myself why I would I want to draw the line.

And go on asking mathematically, because mathematics is the only way I know I can define something unambiguously and ask, When or Why is it valid

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/997587

Comment: @starball oh so there's different sandbox for different site? ;;

Comment: I don't know :P I suppose that would be useful if you want to test mathjax somewhere or latex.

Comment: @starball thanks for suggestion, couldn't find separate formatting-sandbox for math site though .. yet.

Answer (score 1):

Badges :)

(Working tooltip with explanation and link to page)

[image: Informed]

Answer (score 1):

This is to test the rendering problem mentioned in [Code highlighting and image placement breaks despite correct syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389400/code-highlighting-and-image-placement-breaks-despite-correct-syntax). See the earlier revisions for various tests.

The image used is:

- [Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png) `https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png`
  original URL: http://www.iconarchive.com/show/weathy-icons-by-icojam/24-tornado-icon.html
  Artist: Icojam
  Iconset: Weathy Icons (25 icons)
  License: Public Domain

#### Reduced example

##### Markdown

```markdown
A paragraph

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png">
 
paragraph #2, which should be separate.
  
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png">
 
paragraph #3, which should also be separate.

paragraph #4, which should also be separate.
```

##### Rendered

A paragraph

[image]
 
paragraph #2, which should be separate.
  
[image]
 
paragraph #3, which should also be separate.

paragraph #4, which should also be separate.

#### Using workaround of not having a space character on blank lines (renders correctly)

##### Markdown

```markdown
A paragraph

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png">

paragraph #2, which should be separate.

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png">

paragraph #3, which should also be separate.

paragraph #4, which should also be separate.
```

##### Rendered

A paragraph

[image]

paragraph #2, which should be separate.

[image]

paragraph #3, which should also be separate.

paragraph #4, which should also be separate.

Comment: Comment rate limit test 001. This is an attempt to invoke the comment rate limit in order to test handling of the response. iaoe opake poakepr poaksdfp oepr fpwaerj

Comment: Comment rate limit test 002. This is an attempt to invoke the comment rate limit in order to test handling of the response. oiwqehrkmnsaoinm  iowe injeoiewjroi qoimq

Comment: Comment rate limit test 003. This is an attempt to invoke the comment rate limit in order to test handling of the response. pjpeworkm epokw foka pofk

Comment: Comment rate limit test 004. This is an attempt to invoke the comment rate limit in order to test handling of the response. p[oqwkepo q owkepq kwpoke

Comment: Comment rate limit test 005. This is an attempt to invoke the comment rate limit in order to test handling of the response. lsajfpok pq,mwepoqwm 232 oaksd

Comment: Comment rate limit test 006. This is an attempt to invoke the comment rate limit in order to test handling of the response. 329i4- okj pojp kj posa093 akmlfkmmv

Comment: Another test comment that should show up in the WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

### Testing SVGs

```
alpha
```

abc

bob

[bob](/edit)

`bob`

```
ghi
```

`abc
def`

[image][image][image]
[image][image][image]

Does this SVG display?

title-A
  
  
    title-B

```
def
```

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 25 bytes

<sup>Hover over any symbol to see what it does</sup>

[Try it](http://localhost:1234/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiIDo/XFx+MTE+KmwxXFxcbi0xOi8gO25cXD8tIC8iLCJpbnB1dCI6IiIsInN0YWNrIjoiIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6ImNoYXJzIn0=)

Comment: sad. I tried data URLs with the user profile about me in the past and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @starball  I'm looking for a convenient way to add image maps to an image without needing an external server :/

Comment: map? you mean like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area ?

Comment: @starball Yea, I only need a text to display on hover of a specific area, it doesn't need to be clickable

Comment: welp. good luck!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92568/allow-svg-image-uploads

Comment: @starball I think I can just cut the image into many tiny square ones then give all of them a different title. Then hope browsers don't mess up my layout

Answer (score 1):

## `:?\~11>*l1\`
`-1:/ ;n\?- /`

Answer (score 1):

`You can put code inside code`

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&———————————— 3 per em dash

Вапапа

> Yea this banana guy is crazy

***BI*** `JavaScript brackets {}`

- Hhh
- High
- Hhhhnbn

---

Gg

Heading ##

M

1. f
2. H
3. G
4. H
5. ggg
6. fddff

alert("injected JavaScript");

highlighted

ctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhvctvyginhctbyvyvtvtvycyvtvyvyvyvyvygyhyhyhyvyvyvgvgvgvychhv

<kbd>Alt F4</kbd>

`clicky code`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to play with code snippets...

```js
$("#fade-toggle").click(() => {
  $("p").fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="fade-toggle">Show/Hide</button>
<br>
<p>text</p>
```

It worked. Maybe I can use ReactJS?

```js
function MyForm() {
  return (
    <form>
      <label>Enter your name:
        <input type="text" />
      </label>
    </form>
  )
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<MyForm />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I can... but I don't know how. Okay.

Comment: let me try something... ‮ (siht)‭

Answer (score 1):

### Syntax highlighting test with  in `<pre><code>` blocks

```
SELECT a, not_b FROM tbl WHERE a < b;
```

Answer (score 1):

alert("ACE test")

ACE does not work on Stack Exchange, because if it did you would have seen a browser alert.

Comment: aa What is ACE?

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard Arbitrary Code Execution

Comment: ok [​](https://google.com)

Answer (score 1):

## Mini web browser

```js
function openurl() {
  document.getElementById("browser").setAttribute("src", document.getElementById("text").value)
}
```

```html
<center><h1>Simple Browser</h1></center>
<center><input id="text" width="200"> <button onclick="openurl()">Open URL</button><center>
<br>
<iframe src="" id="browser" width="550" height="250"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing tags in answers. It works on Law.SE and in the preview, but is it network-wide?

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

[markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown)

What about tags that aren't recognized by the site? [bring-me-a-shrubbery](/questions/tagged/bring-me-a-shrubbery)

Answer (score 1):

<sub><sup>tiny text</sup></sub>

Is the full stop <sub>•</sub> or <sub>.</sub>?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over all possible integer numbers, let's iterate over all possible sequences
a<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> +
a<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup> +
a<sub>3</sub><sup>n</sup> +  .. +
a<sub>n</sub><sup>n</sup> = A, where 0 ≤ a<sub>i</sub> ≤ 9
and checking corresponding sums A for "Armstrongeness".

As sum is commutative (a+b = b+a) we need to iterate only over non-decreasing sequences:
a<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> ≤
a<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup> ≤
a<sub>3</sub><sup>n</sup> ≤  .. ≤
a<sub>n</sub><sup>n</sup>

For example, lets find all 3-digit Armstrong numbers:
0<sup>3</sup> + 0<sup>3</sup> + 0<sup>3</sup> = 0
0<sup>3</sup> + 0<sup>3</sup> + 1<sup>3</sup> = 1
0<sup>3</sup> + 0<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> = 8
...
0<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + 6<sup>3</sup> = 243
**0<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + 7<sup>3</sup> = 370** <-- Armstrong number 
0<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + 8<sup>3</sup> = 539
...
0<sup>3</sup> + 4<sup>3</sup> + 6<sup>3</sup> = 280
**0<sup>3</sup> + 4<sup>3</sup> + 7<sup>3</sup> = 407** <-- Armstrong number 
0<sup>3</sup> + 4<sup>3</sup> + 8<sup>3</sup> = 576
...
1<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + 4<sup>3</sup> = 92
**1<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + 5<sup>3</sup> = 153** <-- Armstrong number 
1<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + 6<sup>3</sup> = 244
**1<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + 7<sup>3</sup> = 371** <-- Armstrong number  
1<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + 8<sup>3</sup> = 540
...
9<sup>3</sup> + 9<sup>3</sup> + 9<sup>3</sup> = 2187

There is 900 3-digit numbers, but only 178 possible 3-digit permutations. Does not sound like big deal, however for 900'000'000'000'000'000 18-digit numbers, there is only 4'515'854 permutations.

My written on Java implementation computes all numbers by ~2 sec on my machine:

```java
package org.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
  private static int[] digits;
  private static long sumOfPows = 0;
  private static long[] pows;
  private static long min = 0;
  private static long max = 0;
  private static List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int numOfDigits = 1; numOfDigits <= 19 ; numOfDigits++) {
      search(numOfDigits);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
  }

  private static void search(int numOfDigits) {
    digits = new int[numOfDigits];
    sumOfPows = 0;
    pows = new long[10];
    min = powerN(10, numOfDigits-1);
    max = powerN(10, numOfDigits);
    if (max < 0) { // check for overflow
      max = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pows.length; i++) {
      pows[i] = powerN(i, numOfDigits);
    }
    searchRecursively(0, 0);
  }

  // fast power alhorithm, not relevant here
  private static long powerN(int number, int power){
    long res = 1;
    long sq = number;
    while(power > 0){
      if(power % 2 == 1){
        res *= sq;
      }
      sq = sq * sq;
      power /= 2;
    }
    return res;
  }

  private static void searchRecursively(int curI, int minDigit) {
    if (curI == digits.length) {
      if (min <= sumOfPows && sumOfPows < max) {
        int[] digitsSorted = toDigits(sumOfPows, digits.length);
        if (Arrays.equals(digits, digitsSorted)) {
          result.add(sumOfPows); // we found it!
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (int j = minDigit; j <= 9; j++) {
        digits[curI] = j;
        sumOfPows += pows[j];
        if (sumOfPows >= 0 && sumOfPows < max) { // check for overflow
          searchRecursively(curI + 1, j);
        }
        sumOfPows -= pows[j]; // backtracking
      }
    }
  }

  private static int[] toDigits(long num, int len) {
    int[] result = new int[len];
    while(num > 0) {
      result[--len] = (int)(num % 10);
      num /= 10;
    }
    Arrays.sort(result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you testing here?

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard, typical "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon." Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this on meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yeah this filter isn't active here or even in Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to narrow down a bug. Found a post where the list renders as expected in edit preview, meaning both items have `#.` bullets, but when posted, they render inconsistently.

I have tried several different methods that give the same result, not suitable for me.

1)

```
    QMatrix4x4 mat = m_view * m_projection * m_model;
```

2. 

```
    QVector3D screenPos(p.x(),p.y(),1.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

> s
>
> > t
> >
> > > a
> > >
> > > > i
> > > >
> > > > > r
> > > > >
> > > > > > s

Answer (score 1):

[This is a domain-relative link](/a/389401). And a tag: [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

This is the first part of testing what happens when a post contains a domain-relative link and is transcluded.

Comment: What’s transclusion?

Comment: @user3840170 It is: [Wikipedia: Transclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transclusion)

Answer (score 1):

SVG flowchart embedded in HTML in Snippet:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"

 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<!-- Generated by graphviz version 9.0.0 (20230911.1827)

 -->

<!-- Title: G Pages: 1 -->

<svg width="531pt" height="456pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 530.50 455.57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 451.57)">

<title>G</title>

<polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-451.57 526.5,-451.57 526.5,4 -4,4"/>

<!-- Enter -->

<g id="node1" class="node">

<title>Enter</title>

<ellipse fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.2" cx="435.25" cy="-433.43" rx="60.63" ry="14.14"/>

<text text-anchor="start" x="400.38" y="-430.93" font-family="Georgia" font-weight="bold" font-size="10.00" fill="white">Start Process</text>

</g>

<!-- Htsrb -->

<g id="node2" class="node">

<title>Htsrb</title>

<polygon fill="#fff68f" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.2" points="435.25,-396.28 348,-352.28 435.25,-308.28 522.5,-352.28 435.25,-396.28"/>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="435.25" y="-360.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Check</text>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="435.25" y="-348.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Previous Script</text>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="435.25" y="-336.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Execution</text>

</g>

<!-- Enter&#45;&gt;Htsrb -->

<g id="edge1" class="edge">

<title>Enter&#45;&gt;Htsrb</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M435.25,-419C435.25,-416.16 435.25,-413 435.25,-409.64"/>

<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="438.75,-409.86 435.25,-399.86 431.75,-409.86 438.75,-409.86"/>

</g>

<!-- Strfep -->

<g id="node9" class="node">

<title>Strfep</title>

<polygon fill="#bbffff" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.2" stroke-dasharray="5,2" points="491.25,-105.28 379.25,-105.28 379.25,-85.28 491.25,-85.28 491.25,-105.28"/>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="435.25" y="-91.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Update Last Position</text>

</g>

<!-- Htsrb&#45;&gt;Strfep -->

<g id="edge12" class="edge">

<title>Htsrb&#45;&gt;Strfep</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" d="M435.25,-307.81C435.25,-282.1 435.25,-254.78 435.25,-254.78 435.25,-254.78 435.25,-163.13 435.25,-118.78"/>

<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" points="438.75,-118.78 435.25,-108.78 431.75,-118.78 438.75,-118.78"/>

<text text-anchor="start" x="438.62" y="-247.23" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">First</text>

<text text-anchor="start" x="435.25" y="-238.23" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">Script</text>

<text text-anchor="start" x="439.75" y="-229.23" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">Run</text>

</g>

<!-- Hfsd -->

<g id="node3" class="node">

<title>Hfsd</title>

<polygon fill="#fff68f" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.2" points="69.25,-285.28 0,-241.28 69.25,-197.28 138.5,-241.28 69.25,-285.28"/>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="69.25" y="-249.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Check</text>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="69.25" y="-237.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">for File Size</text>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="69.25" y="-225.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Decrease</text>

</g>

<!-- Hfsi -->

<g id="node4" class="node">

<title>Hfsi</title>

<polygon fill="#fff68f" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.2" points="69.25,-139.28 0,-95.28 69.25,-51.28 138.5,-95.28 69.25,-139.28"/>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="69.25" y="-103.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Check</text>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="69.25" y="-91.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">for File Size</text>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="69.25" y="-79.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Increase</text>

</g>

<!-- Hfsd&#45;&gt;Hfsi -->

<g id="edge11" class="edge">

<title>Hfsd&#45;&gt;Hfsi</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" d="M69.25,-197.08C69.25,-182.98 69.25,-167.12 69.25,-152.23"/>

<polygon fill="green" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" points="72.75,-152.49 69.25,-142.49 65.75,-152.49 72.75,-152.49"/>

<text text-anchor="start" x="89.88" y="-178.73" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">File</text>

<text text-anchor="start" x="88.75" y="-169.73" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">Has</text>

<text text-anchor="start" x="89.88" y="-160.73" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">Not</text>

<text text-anchor="start" x="69.25" y="-151.73" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00"> &#160;&#160;&#160;Decreased</text>

</g>

<!-- MtS -->

<g id="node6" class="node">

<title>MtS</title>

<polygon fill="#bbffff" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.2" points="365.5,-251.28 279,-251.28 279,-231.28 365.5,-231.28 365.5,-251.28"/>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="322.25" y="-237.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Set to File Start</text>

</g>

<!-- Hfsd&#45;&gt;MtS -->

<g id="edge14" class="edge">

<title>Hfsd&#45;&gt;MtS</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" d="M139.39,-241.28C179.29,-241.28 228.59,-241.28 265.94,-241.28"/>

<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" points="265.59,-244.78 275.59,-241.28 265.59,-237.78 265.59,-244.78"/>

<text text-anchor="start" x="167.12" y="-247.98" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">File Size Decreased</text>

</g>

<!-- MtLP -->

<g id="node7" class="node">

<title>MtLP</title>

<polygon fill="#bbffff" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.2" points="265.25,-117.28 195.25,-117.28 195.25,-73.28 265.25,-73.28 265.25,-117.28"/>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="230.25" y="-103.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Go to</text>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="230.25" y="-91.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Last Known</text>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="230.25" y="-79.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Position</text>

</g>

<!-- Hfsi&#45;&gt;MtLP -->

<g id="edge10" class="edge">

<title>Hfsi&#45;&gt;MtLP</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" d="M139.4,-95.28C153.76,-95.28 168.57,-95.28 181.96,-95.28"/>

<polygon fill="green" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" points="181.78,-98.78 191.78,-95.28 181.78,-91.78 181.78,-98.78"/>

<text text-anchor="start" x="159.75" y="-117.73" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">File</text>

<text text-anchor="start" x="157.88" y="-108.73" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">Size</text>

<text text-anchor="start" x="145.5" y="-99.73" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">Increased</text>

</g>

<!-- Left -->

<g id="node11" class="node">

<title>Left</title>

</g>

<!-- Hfsi&#45;&gt;Left -->

<g id="edge6" class="edge">

<title>Hfsi&#45;&gt;Left</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" d="M69.25,-51.01C69.25,-32.53 69.25,-15.14 69.25,-15.14"/>

</g>

<!-- GrvLP -->

<g id="node5" class="node">

<title>GrvLP</title>

<polygon fill="#bbffff" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.2" points="128.25,-362.28 10.25,-362.28 10.25,-342.28 128.25,-342.28 128.25,-362.28"/>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="69.25" y="-348.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Retrieve Last Position</text>

</g>

<!-- GrvLP&#45;&gt;Htsrb -->

<g id="edge9" class="edge">

<title>GrvLP&#45;&gt;Htsrb</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" d="M141.41,-352.28C200.41,-352.28 284.09,-352.28 347.07,-352.28"/>

<polygon fill="green" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" points="141.49,-348.78 131.49,-352.28 141.49,-355.78 141.49,-348.78"/>

<text text-anchor="start" x="191.25" y="-358.98" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">Script Has Run Before</text>

</g>

<!-- GrvLP&#45;&gt;Hfsd -->

<g id="edge2" class="edge">

<title>GrvLP&#45;&gt;Hfsd</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M69.25,-341.99C69.25,-332.06 69.25,-315.47 69.25,-298.64"/>

<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="72.75,-298.86 69.25,-288.86 65.75,-298.86 72.75,-298.86"/>

</g>

<!-- RtE -->

<g id="node8" class="node">

<title>RtE</title>

<polygon fill="#bbffff" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.2" stroke-dasharray="5,2" points="352,-117.28 292.5,-117.28 292.5,-73.28 352,-73.28 352,-117.28"/>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="322.25" y="-103.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">Read</text>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="322.25" y="-91.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">New Data</text>

<text text-anchor="middle" x="322.25" y="-79.78" font-family="Georgia" font-size="10.00">to End</text>

</g>

<!-- MtS&#45;&gt;RtE -->

<g id="edge4" class="edge">

<title>MtS&#45;&gt;RtE</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M322.25,-230.84C322.25,-210.76 322.25,-163.02 322.25,-130.16"/>

<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="325.75,-130.57 322.25,-120.57 318.75,-130.57 325.75,-130.57"/>

</g>

<!-- MtLP&#45;&gt;RtE -->

<g id="edge3" class="edge">

<title>MtLP&#45;&gt;RtE</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M265.47,-95.28C270.04,-95.28 274.62,-95.28 279.19,-95.28"/>

<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="279.06,-98.78 289.06,-95.28 279.06,-91.78 279.06,-98.78"/>

</g>

<!-- RtE&#45;&gt;Strfep -->

<g id="edge5" class="edge">

<title>RtE&#45;&gt;Strfep</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M352.27,-95.28C356.83,-95.28 361.4,-95.28 365.97,-95.28"/>

<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="365.82,-98.78 375.82,-95.28 365.82,-91.78 365.82,-98.78"/>

</g>

<!-- Right -->

<g id="node12" class="node">

<title>Right</title>

</g>

<!-- Strfep&#45;&gt;Right -->

<g id="edge7" class="edge">

<title>Strfep&#45;&gt;Right</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M435.25,-84.89C435.25,-63.93 435.25,-15.14 435.25,-15.14"/>

</g>

<!-- Exit -->

<g id="node10" class="node">

<title>Exit</title>

<ellipse fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.2" cx="269.25" cy="-14.14" rx="57.45" ry="14.14"/>

<text text-anchor="start" x="236.62" y="-11.64" font-family="Georgia" font-weight="bold" font-size="10.00" fill="white">End Process</text>

</g>

<!-- Exit&#45;&gt;Right -->

<g id="edge8" class="edge">

<title>Exit&#45;&gt;Right</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M339.65,-14.14C371.52,-14.14 403.38,-14.14 435.25,-14.14"/>

<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" points="339.99,-10.64 329.99,-14.14 339.99,-17.64 339.99,-10.64"/>

</g>

<!-- Left&#45;&gt;Exit -->

<g id="edge13" class="edge">

<title>Left&#45;&gt;Exit</title>

<path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" d="M69.25,-14.14C69.25,-14.14 141.06,-14.14 198.62,-14.14"/>

<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" points="198.37,-17.64 208.37,-14.14 198.37,-10.64 198.37,-17.64"/>

<text text-anchor="start" x="146.9" y="-36.59" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">File</text>

<text text-anchor="start" x="145.4" y="-27.59" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">size</text>

<text text-anchor="start" x="130.4" y="-18.59" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="9.00">unchanged</text>

</g>

</g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/395082#395082) | Cell 4 |

[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/395082#395082)

Answer (score 1):

`<b>Test</b>` `` t`e`st `` `` `test` ``

Answer (score 1):

Testing image sizes
[Why huge images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395754/why-huge-images?noredirect=1#comment1323808_395754)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

trying to make a copy button for my markdown

```
function test() {
  console.log("This code will have a copy button to the right of it");
}
```

| Employee ID# | Employee Name | Company | Orientation Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blank space | blank space | blank space | Lifetime |
| blank space | blank space | blank space | WFD |
| blank space | blank space | blank space | 5 hours |
| Employee ID# | Employee Name | Company | Orientation Date |
| 752856 | Smith, John | Waste LLC | 12/28/2023 |
| 685273 | Jones, Tracy | Paint & Co | 11/07/2023 |
| 385418 | Ramirez, Jen | Waste LLC | 12/23/2023 |
| 787233 | Johnson, Ted | Paint & Co | 10/07/2023 |
| 988534 | Smith, Jane | Waste LLC | 10/22/2023 |
| 438541 | Williams, Ken | PipeFab LLC | 11/18/2023 |

Answer (score 1):

```
<sub>
test _hello_ test - newline at start and end
</sub>
```

<sub>test _hello_ test - newline at start and end</sub>

---

```
<sub> test _hello_ test - oneline</sub>
```

<sub>test *hello* test - oneline</sub>

---

```
<sub>
test _hello_ test - newline at start</sub>
```

<sub>test _hello_ test - newline at start</sub>

---

```
<sub>test _hello_ test - newline at end
</sub>
```

<sub>test *hello* test - newline at end</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Create Markdown from T-SQL?

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/creating-markdown-formatted-text-for-results-from-sql-server-tables

**From Excel**

| ID | Name | Age | Salary | Height | MaritalStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tim | 31 | 300 | 191.2 | 1 |
| 2 | Tom | 21 | 400 | 181.87 | 2 |
| 3 | Tam | 51 | 500 | 176.54 | 3 |

https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html

Excel > Data > Get Data > From Database > From SQL Server database

**From T-SQL**

| ID | Name | Age | Salary | Height | MaritalStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tim | 31 | 300.00 | 191.20 | 1 |
| 2 | Tom | 21 | 400.00 | 181.87 | 2 |
| 3 | Tam | 51 | 500.00 | 176.54 | 3 |

```
USE [TestMD]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Select2MD]    Script Date: 27/03/2024 07:50:32 ******/
SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Select2MD]
/*
Author: Tomaz Kastrun and David Tallett
Date: 26.Mar.2024
Description: Turns result set of selected table into Markdown suitable for use on StackOverflow
Usage:
        EXEC dbo.select2MD
                @table_name = 'TestForMD'
               ,@schema_name = 'dbo'

        DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(100)
        SET @text = 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13) + 'This is line 2.'
        SELECT @text

stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string

Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid > Retain CR/LF on copy or save
SQL Server Management Studio                        19.3.4.0

ToDO:
*/    @table_name VARCHAR(200)
     ,@schema_name VARCHAR(20)
AS 
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- get the columns of the table
        SELECT 
            c.Column_name
            ,c.Ordinal_position
            ,c.is_nullable
            ,c.Data_Type
        
        INTO  #temp
        
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS  t
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c 
        ON t.table_name = c.table_name
        AND t.table_schema = c.table_schema
        AND t.table_Catalog = c.table_Catalog
        WHERE
        t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
        AND t.Table_name = @table_name
        AND t.table_schema = @schema_name

            DECLARE @MD NVARCHAR(MAX)

            -- header | name | name2 | name3 | name4 | name5 | name6 
            DECLARE @header VARCHAR(MAX)
            SELECT @header = COALESCE(@header + ' | ','') + column_name 
            FROM #temp
            ORDER BY Ordinal_position ASC
            SELECT @header = ' | ' + @header + ' | '

            -- delimiter | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- 
            DECLARE @nof_columns INT = (SELECT MAX(Ordinal_position) FROM #temp)
            DECLARE @firstLine NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT  REPLICATE('| --- ',@nof_columns) + '|')  
            SET @MD = @header + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(32) + @firstLine + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

            -- body
            DECLARE @body_sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
            SET @body_sql = 'SELECT
            ''| '' + CAST(' 
            DECLARE @i INT = 1
            WHILE @i <= @nof_columns
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @w VARCHAR(1000) =  (SELECT column_name FROM #temp WHERE Ordinal_position = @i)
                    SET @body_sql = @body_sql + @w + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))+ '' | '' + CAST( '
                SET @i = @i + 1
            END
            SET @body_sql  = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@body_sql,1, LEN(@body_sql)-8))
            SET @body_sql = @body_sql + ' FROM ' + @table_name

            DECLARE @bodyTable TABLE(MD VARCHAR(MAX))
            INSERT INTO @BodyTable
            EXEC sp_executesql @body_sql

            DECLARE @body2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
            SELECT @body2 = COALESCE(@body2 + ' ', ' ') + MD + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
            FROM @bodyTable
            SET @MD = @MD + @body2
          
            SELECT @MD
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

### this post is so not by Stormblessed it’s just incredible how written-by-a-different-person it is (this is going to be for a bug report)

Hi this is a person who is very non-blessed-by-the-storms.

Answer (score 0):

Testing Rollbacks

Just a test answer to get my hands on rollbacks.
Edit 1111
Edit 2222

Answer (score 0):

С#:

```cs
public string X {get; set;}
```

default:

```
public string X {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

[testing testing](https://#0000)

[testing testing](https://#0100)

Answer (score 0):

.**bold text after a dot works in answers**

.**it can also be done using HTML tags**

Comment: .**but not in comments**

Comment: .<b>HTML tags do not work in comments</b>

Comment: .&zwj;**bold** test

Comment: . **bold** test

Comment: .<!-->**bold** after comment tag

Comment: word\.**bold** test

Comment: .**bold** with unicode

Comment: .​**bold** with zero-width space

Answer (score 0):

<$ ‮ !oboRhceTehT m'I ,iH

Try editing the above sentence post to say something else (but dont remove the `<$`), you'll have nightmares >:)

Comment: Aha! Unicode hacks! ‮‮⁫

Answer (score 0):

Hi I keep seeing posts that start with "hi" so I want to check to see if "hi" still gets removed.

Apparently "Hi," or "Hi everyone," gets removed, but just "Hi" without the comma doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just a test

- A Markdown based <ul>. This does not `appear to require` the syntax be uniform. With a & ampersand a real amp & "something in quotes", "something in quot", copyright©, ", and section §

A non breaking space.

[image: Graphical representation of an event dispatched in a DOM tree using the DOM event flow]
<sup>Image Copyright © 2016 [World Wide Web Consortium](http://www.w3.org/), ([MIT](http://www.csail.mit.edu/), [ERCIM](http://www.ercim.org/), [Keio](http://www.ercim.org/), [Beihang](http://ev.buaa.edu.cn/)). http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/doc-license (Use permitted per [the license](https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/doc-license))</sup>

```
An indented Markdown code block
```

Some `inline code` to help.

```html
A code-fenced Markdown-based, syntax highlighted code with <code>an in-code code block</code>
And a <pre><code>in-code pre-block in a pre-code</code></pre>
A HTML entity in code: non&nbsp;breaking&nbsp;space.

The same text that is in a Markdown unordered list above, but here in code:
- A Markdown based &lt;ul&gt;.  
  With a &amp; ampersand a real amp & "something in quotes",  
  &quot;something in quot&quot;, copyright&copy;, &quot;, and section &sect;
```

```
Same code, but using HTML, so no syntax highlighting. Code with an in-code code block
And a in-code pre-block in a pre-code
A HTML entity in code: non breaking space.
The same text that is in a Markdown unordered list above, but here in code:

A Markdown based <ul>.
This is HTML bold or italics in a code block.
This is Markdown bold or italics in a code block.
With a & ampersand a real amp & "something in quotes", "something in quot", copyright©, ", and section §A <ul> with a <li> in a <blockquote> in <code>. - An HTML based <ul>.

This is HTML bold or italics in a code block.

This is Markdown bold or italics in a code block.

With a & ampersand a real amp & "something in quotes", "something in quot", copyright©, ", and section § 

A <ul> with a <li>. - An HTML based <ul>.  
This is HTML bold or italics in a code block.  
This is Markdown **bold** or *italics* in a code block.  
With a & ampersand a real amp & "something in quotes", "something in quot", copyright©, ", and section § 
A <ul> with a <li>. - An HTML based <ul> without closing </li> tag.
This is HTML bold or italics in a code block.  
This is Markdown **bold** or *italics* in a code block.  
With a & ampersand a real amp & "something in quotes", "something in quot", copyright©, ", and section §
A <ul> with a <li>. - An HTML based <ul> without closing </ul> or </ul> tags.
  This is HTML bold or italics in a code block.  
  This is Markdown **bold** or *italics* in a code block.  
  With a & ampersand a real amp & "something in quotes", "something in quot", copyright©, ", and section §
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing [highlighted text links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#:%7E:text=purus%20eu%20dignissim)

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eget nunc sed dui ullamcorper suscipit sit amet vitae arcu. Donec egestas dolor vitae pretium consectetur. Mauris consequat, purus eu dignissim feugiat, dui massa venenatis felis, ut luctus felis felis id nunc. Fusce tristique ultrices mauris bibendum finibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin facilisis odio vel vulputate euismod. Quisque finibus a libero eu pulvinar. Aliquam porta urna non neque laoreet, vel malesuada libero efficitur. Donec consectetur tellus in nunc auctor, id feugiat sapien pretium. Sed at metus dui. Sed ipsum metus, interdum nec erat et, tempor feugiat dui. Integer rutrum.

Answer (score 0):

## An answer to the question

In line `code span` may be nice

```bash
function dummy() {
    p1=$1
    printf "Dummy gets $p1"
}
```

- **How to**
  This way
  *Besides that way is ok, the other way is quite better*
- **Whith what?**
  With this and that
- **When?**
  Right now

And as Zaratustra in `Ein Buch für Alle und Keinen` said...

> Nicht reden einmal will ich wieder mit dem Volke; zum letzten Male sprach ich zu einem Todten

crystal clear

---

### Some other matters

I love `linux` and I accept *windows*...and *doors* as well
[image: some lines of code]

Working code in this [rextester](https://rextester.com/SFI54658)

Comment: Refreshing the syntax/ Tks for this sandbox

Answer (score 0):

## Naming

### Standards

Why do you use *`x`* in your *`for`* loop when the standard is *`i`*?

### Inconsistencies

You use the name *`repeatLoop`* for one function but *`sdl_bindings`* for a class.

## Your use of `goto` makes this code very unreadable

Look up `Goto considered harmful`

Answer (score 0):

Just checking inline img tag with svg.

Normal (PNG) image:

[image]

PNG inline image:

SVG image:

[image]

SVG inline image:

Answer (score 0):

Copy this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/85572/revisions) and add a new link. Now see that there is now another link with numbered [5](https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/siv.pdf).

Is it because of the link descriptions?

---

**Disadvantages:**

- **Message length** In [Cryptography](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225910/is-there-a-sandbox-to-play-with-stack-overflow-api?noredirect=1&lq=1), usually, the message length is not considered secret. There are approaches that you can add random values to the end or beginning or both if this is really an information leak for you. The random approach depends on your actual data case...
- **The (IV, key) pair reuse** problem that can eliminate the confidentiality with the crib-dragging technique.
- **Lack of authentication** Like all unauthenticated encryption modes, the bare CTR mode lacks integrity and authentication. A single bit of flipping can have catastrophic results. The [AES-GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/84359/18298) mode that used the CTR mode of operation provides you all-in-once, however, it has the same  (IV, key) pair reuse problem. There is a Synthetic Initialization Vector (SIV) mode as nonce-misuse resistance ( [paper](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75305/18298), [rfc8452](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75305/18298) ) that eliminates this.
- **Long message distinguisher:**  The CTR mode is designed with a Pseudo-Random-Function (PRF). When using AES in CTR mode, we use it with Pseudo Random Permutation (PRP); $$E_k\colon {0,1}^n \to {0,1}^n.$$ Whit PRP as long as the message blocks are not repeated the sequence $E_k(0), E_k(1), \dots, E_k(\ell - 1)$ with $\ell < 2^n$ is not repeated. If the message with length $\ell$-block has no repeated block this is no problem. If we approach the message as uniform random block then we expect a collision $\ell \approx \sqrt{2^n} = 2^{n/2}$ by the birthday paradox/attack.

  When used with AES-128 for long messages check for the repeat. The repeat enables the attacker to distinguish this from uniform random with [non-negligible probability](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75305/18298).

  In short, a duplicate ciphertext leaks that the messages are different.

---

**Other advantages:**

1. **No need the decryption:** Doesn't require decryption of the block cipher. This is very helpful in constraint environments. Simplifies the software and hardware code, too.
2. **No need PRP:** Doesn't need a block cipher (PRP) at all. A [hash function](https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/siv.pdf) can be used like in the ChaCha series.
3. **Prepocessing:** the keystream generated by the CTR mode can be prepared before. This can help to use buffers.

---

**A little history of CTR**

CTR mode was introduced by Whitfield Diffie and Martin Hellman in 1979

- [Privacy and Authentication: An Introduction to Cryptography](https://ee.stanford.edu/%7Ehellman/publications/32.pdf) as an invited paper on Proceedings of the IEEE, 67 (1979), pp. 397–427.
- [A concrete Security of Treatment of Symmetric Encryption, Bellare et. al, 97](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/sym-enc.pdf)
- See also; [Comments to NIST concerning AES Modes of Operations: CTR-Mode Encryption](https://web.archive.org/web/20150226072817/http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ctr/ctr-spec.pdf), by Lipmaa et al.

Answer (score 0):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > 

Answer (score 0):

snippet

```html
<html>
<body>
  <p>Wow. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

| Lorem | Ipsum | Dolor | Sit | Amet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse |
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse |
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse |
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse |
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse |

Answer (score 0):

```java
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9_#@%\*\-]{8,24}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing an issue with link formatting:

[What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

"https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work"

Note that this is rendered differently in "edit" vs. "view" mode.

### View mode:

[image]

### Edit mode:

[image]

### Testing:

"https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work — Quotes just at the start break the link.

[https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work%22) — Quotes just at the end do not break the link.

Answer (score 0):

### Footnotes are weird

testaabbc [^1]

test2 [^2](https://www.google.com)

test 3 [3](https://www.google.com)

[^1]: The URL is https://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Testing for the truck hat.

More words since body requires 30 characters.

Answer (score 0):

| Road class | [Syntax explanation](https://sites.google.com/site/roadnumberingsystems/home/general-information/legend) |
| --- | --- |
| European road | E-[0-9]<2-3> |
| Motorway (Autopista) | AP-[0-9]<1-2> |
| Expressway (Autovía) | A-[0-9]<1-2> |
| Radial motorway | R[1-5] |
| National road (Carretera Nacional) | N-`Roman`{a};N-[0-9]<3>{a} |
| Regional road (Carretera Comarcal) | C-[0-9]<3-4>{a} |
| Community road | [see region table](https://sites.google.com/site/roadnumberingsystems/home/countries/spain#eregions) |

Answer (score 0):

Markdown line break directly after an URL with a path:

```
Foo http://example.com/test.\
Bar
```

Foo [http://example.com/test.\](http://example.com/test.%5C)
Bar

---

```
Foo http://example.com/test. \
Bar
```

Foo http://example.com/test. 
Bar

Answer (score 0):

Something for me to edit. I need more characters. Hi. This is text that I'm adding. Hiiiii. Hi again Test. Another thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into what caused [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkRD8.png): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/255584/20

- If you opt to *[delete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)* [your account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

Answer (score 0):

‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​

Answer (score 0):



Answer (score 0):

To create a link, use text here

This is  that

Answer (score 0):

<\!-->


<file_check type="TEST" option="Test">
1
</file_check>

Answer (score 0):

[draft for something else.]

---

Note: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See [How to download video with blob url?](https://superuser.com/questions/1033563/how-to-download-video-with-blob-url) on Super User instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt at a Community-wiki answer that responds affirmatively to
the proposal:

> Tags should be reviewed before they are created.

The aim is to
[**ensure that only quality tags are created**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404893)
.

This answer is a mishmash of opinions that have come up in non-Community-wiki
answers, along with some new views not previously brought up.
It's a bit of a summary as well.

- The reputation gate needed for *suggesting* new tags should remain unchanged
  at what is currently 5 reputation points. <sup>1</sup>
- A proposal for a new tag should always include a usage guidance and a
  tag wiki description for the tag. Both? Or at least one? <sup>2</sup>
- A proposal for a new tag should enter the already existing review queue for
  tag wiki edits. Thus, the reputation gate for voting to accept or reject a
  proposal for a new tag will be 5,000. <sup>3</sup>
- Give an option to tag proposers to link their newly created tag with another
  existing tag that is closely related. <sup>4</sup>
- No need for any approval time expiration. <sup>5</sup>
- Stack Overflow tags are a folksonomy.<sup>6</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Not previously proposed here. Reference:
[Privileges > participate in meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta).

<sup>2</sup> Reference:
[**make *at least* one of them required**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404907).

<sup>3</sup> References:
[**Use the Suggested Edits Review Queue**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404907)
[Privileges > approve tag wiki edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

<sup>4</sup> Reference:
[*This way, users can filter on the existing tags*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404897).

<sup>5</sup> Reference:
[*I think having an approval time is not a good idea as I imagine this queue
will grow substantially*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404893#comment822314_404899).

<sup>6</sup> References:
[*I think it should be more towards the folksonomy end*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404958).
[Tag Folksonomy and Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/01/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms).

Answer (score 0):

> first line
> second line

> first line

> second line

> first line
>
> second line

> first line with two spaces at the end
> second line

Answer (score 0):

---

---

## The Question.

In July 2015, the insert image feature of the toolbar of the
Stack Exchange markdown editor was changed (shortcut
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, displayed as the icon
[image: "toolbar button to insert image"]).

The [behavior since then has been to make the image clickable by
default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261182) - by adding an extra link to the image
itself.<sup>1</sup><sup>, 2</sup>

But the official help pages - *[Meta Stack Exchange markdown
formatting help on how "images can be added primarily by using the <s>the</s>
editor toolbar button [image: "toolbar button to insert image"]"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)* (see *Images* at the bottom of
the page)
and *[Meta Stack Overflow markdown editing help on images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#link-images)* - have
still not been updated to reflect this change (now more than five years
later).

Shortly after I posted this question/request, a moderator and Senior Product
Support Specialist wrote in a comment that *the syntax for images was not
changed and is still the same*, concluding *the syntax in the help pages is
correct*. - Which indeed is true if you take on a very narrow
*fail-of-conformity* attitude concerning what help and guidance is needed to
settle whether a suggested edit should be accepted or rejected.

---

Let me use a pilot case to explain why I think that a well-thought-out
update of the help pages would benefit us all.
To see the revision history of the question I have in mind, click on
the image below, possibly holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
(if you want it to open in a new tab).

[image: Revision history of question Converting a POSTMAN request to Curl.]

If you study the revisions of that question, you will notice that edit number
2 was rolled back.
The editor who rolled it back commented:
*@Henke That edit has made the post worse*.

Just to be clear - I completely agree that rolling back the edit was the right
thing to do. But the question remains: ***on what grounds***? Just referring
to gut feeling? Or by saying *the edit made the post worse*? Without any
further references this is simply not good enough or acceptable as a
motivation. Out of respect for both the editor and the reviewers we must be
capable of doing better than that!

Let me for a moment put myself in the shoes of the editor/reviewers of the
edit that made the image non-clickable.
Suppose I go to one of the help pages, such as the [Meta Stack Exchange
help about adding images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).
The current content about images is shown below.<sup>3</sup>

[image: Meta Stack Exchange help on how to add an image]

If the editor in this case did their homework and read the help page, they
would conclude that an image *can be input similarly to adding a link* by
using the suggested syntax:<sup>4</sup>
`![sample image](https://example.com/img.jpg)`
Judging from this help page neither the editor nor the reviewers did anything
wrong!

Why on earth would they look any further?
In my mind this is exactly how a help page is supposed to work. You look up
whatever information you need and apply whatever syntax you find there.
Bear in mind that a first-time reader might not even consider that an image
could be clickable.

---

I have taken the liberty of supplying
[an answer of my own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360546),
so that you can vote it up or down however you like.<sup>5</sup>

---

---

When can we expect the help pages to be updated?

---

---

**References**:
[From now on, the image uploader automatically wraps images in a link to
themselves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261182)

[Meta Stack Exchange help on how to add an image via
[image: "toolbar button to insert image"]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)
[Meta Stack Overflow Markdown Editing Help: Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#link-images)
[The recommended syntax for an image with a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2191)

[Extra square brackets and numbers when using automated link or add picture
feature in ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261863)

[Why does the images index on Stack Overflow appear twice?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307069)

---

---

<sup>1</sup> The previous default behavior was to just display the
image - without any click link.
<sup>2</sup> If you are curious to learn more about how this works, see the
reference list. - Or simply click the `Edit` feature of this question
and start reading the markdown code. I have included a few different styles
and methods on how to make an image clickable or non-clickable.
<sup>3</sup> If you find it difficult to read the text in the image, click on
it, and then on the back arrow of your web browser.
<sup>4</sup> Of course, this syntax will not result in a clickable image.
<sup>5</sup> There is nothing personal about these downvotes. It is just an
elegant way of finding out the opinion of the community as a whole.

---

---

Comment: Writing a comment just to see if I can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const words = ['save', 'hello', 'world', 'save'];
_.forEach(_.filter(words, elem => { return elem==='save' }),
  word => { console.log(word+' '); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.19/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Why does this happen? Is there a bug fix?*

It seems the reason is that `@types/react` is a missing dependency in
`eslint-config-react-app` so the obvious bug fix is to add
`@types/react` manually to your project by running :

```
npm install @types/react
```

VS Code's autocompletion through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>
now correctly suggests `react`.
<sup>1</sup>

[image: VS Code's autocompletion now correctly suggests 'react'.]

Installing `@types/react` adds `"@types/react": "^18.0.0",` in your
`package.json` under `"dependencies"` :

```json
{
  "name": "reactjs-app",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "next": "^12.1.4",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "7.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

<sup>1
If it doesn't work, try restarting VS Code.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```autoit
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Global $timeout = 3

example_1()
example_2()

Func example_1()
    Local $returnValue = MsgBox($MB_YESNO, "Example", "Press a button :-)")

    If $returnValue = $IDYES Then
        MsgBox($MB_OK, "OK", "You pressed Yes!", $timeout)
    Else
        MsgBox($MB_OK, "Ok", "You pressed No!", $timeout)
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>example_1

Func example_2()

    Switch MsgBox($MB_YESNOCANCEL, "Example", "Press a button :-)")
        Case $IDYES
            MsgBox($MB_OK, "OK", "You pressed Yes!", $timeout)
        Case $IDNO
            MsgBox($MB_OK, "OK", "You pressed No!", $timeout)
        Case $IDCANCEL
            MsgBox($MB_OK, "Cancel", "You pressed Cancal!", $timeout)
    EndSwitch
EndFunc   ;==>example_2
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

But what if, hear me `out, I just place

a backtick
and

let it do whatever`?

Because `inline is fine`, but if it's `multiline, does it disallow blanks?`

`what if a paragraph is awkwardly placed?`

what about `inline single`, `double`, `triple`?

line

```
this is also 
    a part of the block
```

Answer (score 0):

testing some testz

https://127.0.0.1:80

test

Answer (score 0):



Answer (score 0):

This is a test for a crude markdown "parser" (which is really more of an identifier `than anything else`, but I have a lot of edge-cases to test). Though using a unit test would make this easier, wouldn't it?

This is plain text.
This is plain text after a newline.

This is plain text after a blank line.
This is not a code block

```
This is a code block
```

And here's some text

```
and another block
```

Followed by text

And here's even more text

```
 ... and (you guessed it)
another block
```

```cpp
std::cout << "Followed by backticks" << std::endl;
```

```python
print("Immediately followed by another block")
```

`With an inline triple start`, followed by `double` and `single`, and some random **bold**, because why not?

also a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) (inline), and another [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) that's named.

[image: This is not an image]

[image: And neither is this]

... but pretends to be one on a TV show.:tm:

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only sentence?

Probably.

I can't type `Hi,` in the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

One column table
|C|
|-|
|1|

Comment: [​](https://google.com)

Answer (score 0):

[192.168.1.1](http://192.168.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

Epcot Center

Epcot is a theme park at Walt Disney World Resort featuring exciting attractions, international pavilions, award-winning fireworks and seasonal special events.

Answer (score 0):

| **Id** | **Value** |
| --- | --- |
| 7E38AD4A-4C6E-40D9-B805-08C1F4EE14D0 | 1,370 |
| E48A0A4A-6E6C-41A8-B379-0E14452938C6 | 1,200 |

Answer (score 0):

- `code`
- ```
   full line code
  ```

1. `code`
2. ```
   full line code
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71021836/2987828 and adding newlines before and after the table doesn't help, at least there.

To enter a permanent breakpoint in python3.7+, insert the expression `breakpoint()` in the source file. No more [need to import anything, even `pdb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20547145/2987828). In non-compiled Matlab the equivalent to `breakpoint()` is the statement `keyboard`.

The global picture is that after python's debug prompt `(Pdb)` (shown by `breakpoint()`) you add `!` before *non*-debugging commands, whereas after Matlab's debug prompt `K>` you add `db` before debugging commands.

I am also migrating from Matlab to Python. I am used to debugging inside `matlab -nodisplay`, and am switching to python3.10 without IDE. These are pretty similar. So I will continue this debugging-related rosetta stone.

You can create other breakpoints, using command `tb` or `b`, from that `(Pdb)` prompt (or in your file `$HOME/.pdbrc`). As their Matlab's counterpart `dbstop`, you can set them for another file, another line and let them be conditional.

Here is a short rosetta stone:

| python | python's available shortcut | Matlab |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `breakpoint()` |  | `keyboard` |
| `where` | `w` | `dbstack` |
| `cont` | `c` | `dbcont` |
| `up` | `u` | `dbup` |
| `down` | `d` | `dbdown` |
| `step` | `s` | `dbstep` |
| `next` | `n` | `dbnext` |
| `print` expression | `p` expression | expression |
| `!nonlocal` var;var= |  | var= |
| `break` | `b` | `dbstop` and `dbstatus` |
| `clear` | `cl` | `dbclear` |
| `list` | `l` | `dbtype` |
| `display` | `d` | variable window |

Matlab does have no equivalent for:

- `ignore` n p (n-th breakpoint will only trigger prompt after p-th execution)
- `prettyprint` expression (shortcut: `pp`)
- `jump` codelinenumber (shortcut: `j`)

I still don't know if Python has any usable equivalents for [`save` and `load`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2960864/2987828), `evalin(caller,expr)`, and plots while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

## Links

---

#### Raw links

meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122
//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122
[Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122)
[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122)
/questions/3122

#### Links + Markown

[Normal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122) [*Italic*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122) [**Bold**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122) [`Inline code`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122) <kbd>[Keyboard (style wrapping link)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122)</kbd> [<kbd>Keyboard (link wrapping style)</kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122)

---

> Blockquote (HTML "A" tag)

> Blockquote (Markdown "[text][1]")

HTML <pre> is nessesary for code block. Weirdly enough they doesn't have the same color (at least in the preview):

```
Code block (HTML "A" tag)
```

```
Code block (Markdown "[text][1]")
```

Code Snippets works ! (Doesn't work with Markdown "[text][1]")


```html
Code Snippet
```

---

#### "Special" links:

[Top of the page](/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#)
[Bottom of the page](/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#footer)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>

<kbd>Enter ↲</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

1. Testing a strange bug:

   - ```
     testing something
     ```

Answer (score 0):

test test test test test test test

Comment: two corrections and a related reference:

Comment: • `*?` and `+?` and `??` and `{2,3}?` in PCRE are called the **_lazy_ quantifiers**, also called: _reluctant_, _non-greedy_, _ungreedy_.  Not to be confused with the [_possessive_ quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `*+` and `++` and `?+` and `{m,n}+`

Comment: • **Vim’s idiosyncratic regex syntax** differs from PCRE: `/x*\?` and `/x\+\?` and `/x\?\?` and `/x\{2,3}\?` yield errors in Vim. (And in `/x*?` etc., Vim parses the `?` as a literal.)  Instead, the equivalents among [Vim’s lazy quantifiers](https://learnbyexample.github.io/vim_reference/Regular-Expressions.html#non-greedy-quantifiers) are: `/x\{-}` and `/x\{-1,}` and `/x{-,1}` and `/x\{-2,3}`

Comment: • Likewise, Vim does not have `*+` etc..  It does not even have any **possessive quantifiers** in the narrow sense.  But it provides the same functionality **via [atomic grouping](https://learnbyexample.github.io/vim_reference/Regular-Expressions.html#atomic-grouping)**: For PCRE’s `x*+` and `x++` and `x?+` and `x{m,n}+`   equivalents in Vim are: `\(x*\)\@>` (alternative `\v` `very magic` syntax: `\v(x*)@>`) and `\v(x+)@>` and `\v(x?)@>` and `\v(x{m,n})@>`

Answer (score 0):

| e | error |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0% |
| 0.3 | 0.0000002% |
| 0.5 | 0.000046 % |
| 0.6 | 0.00037 % |
| 0.8 | 0.0153 % |
| 0.9 | 0.1074 % |
| 0.99 | 1.4150% |
| 0.999 | 2.93 % |
| 1 | 4.1262 % |

Answer (score 0):

World.
Hello.
World.
Hello.
World.
Hello.
World.

Answer (score 0):

```
a setext heading
===
more pre-formatted text
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange api test!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: ok it worked again.

Comment: haha, that's you again.

Answer (score 0):

no support for mathjax?

$$mathjax$$

$inline mathjax$

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/152859

Answer (score 0):

Testing whitespace in inline code formatting. (Seems to render different in the preview.) **Edit: Confirmed**, whitespace at the start of a line gets stripped, but not in preview.

**Original**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'foo' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

**Inline formatted**

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name 'foo' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)`

How that previews (preformatted):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name 'foo' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

**Newlines replaced with spaces, inline formatted**

`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name 'foo' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)`

How that previews (preformatted):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name 'foo' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score -1):

References:
https://www.msys2.org
https://github.com
https://superuser.com

Comment: As you can see, I can post just fine the markdown "code" of this answer here at meta.stackexchange.com. But when I try to post the _**identical**_ markdown at _**non**_-meta stackoverflow.com, then I get an error similar to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277896. To me this looks like a bug. I can easily replicate the error as follows. On my answer above, I click edit and then copy all the markdown without making any changes. Then I go to _**any**_ stackoverflow question and try to post the exact same markdown as an answer. It fails! Screenshot - https://i.imgur.com/nnPXwub.png.

Comment: Error message: _Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon._ I might add that the error goes away if I remove the last reference link (the one that links to superuser). I can easily replicate _**that**_ behavior as well. - I just remove the link, then click anywhere outside the "markdown editor". It then looks as follows - https://i.imgur.com/sfY4uG5.png. If I insert the superuser link again, the error displays again.

Comment: _I can easily replicate the error_. Not any more - I **cannot** replicate the error as described in the previous comment. Maybe the bug finally got dealt with?

Answer (score -1):

References:
https://www.msys2.org
https://github.com
https://superuser.com

Comment: [Likely context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10861/unable-to-create-post-with-formatted-code)

Answer (score -1):

Comment: Meager duplicate of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360529/168269).

Comment: close this as a duplicate then

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard Answers can’t be closed. Also, this is a sandbox, so why are you downvoting?

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer Lack of humor sense, pity... Also why do you think I downvoted this?

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard I don’t, it’s also a comment for everyone else.

Comment: Y'know you can add two comments :p

Comment: Also this is sandbox, then why we can't play with downvotes?

Answer (score -1):

testy test test
test test tes test test

test grace period edit, edit 2

Edit 3, Edit 4

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Stack Exchange api test!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: YES LET'S GO IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

**Syntax highlighting has been deactivated to avoid a CPU spike every time the page loads**

Original content follows

---

````
How slow can we make this page load using highlight.js?

```javascript
hehe page load go brrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
```

And CPU utlization go 100% :(
````

Comment: OMG, don't freeze my Chrome even more,

Comment: Safari didn’t take that long to load this.

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.body.innerHTML = (`<iframe style="background-color:#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16).padStart(6, '0')}">`.repeat(1000000)) + `</iframe>`.repeat(1000000)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is really cool

**coool**
*coooool*

> so awesome

1. list1
2. list2
3. list3

Answer (score -2):

Not a big deal maybe, but can we make [tag-alias-request](/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request) a synonym of
[synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request)?

There are 16 questions tagged [tag-alias-request](/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request) of which all were asked
in 2016.
The tag [tag-alias-request](/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request) was created in August 2016.

There are (currently) 1,026 questions tagged [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) of which
the oldest was asked in 2014 and the latest in 2021 (yesterday actually).
The tag [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) was created in April 2014.

The usage guidance (excerpt) of [tag-alias-request](/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request) says:
*Use [...] when multiple tags should [...] redirect to the same tag [...].*

The usage guidance (excerpt) of [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) says:
*A request to add one tag as the synonym of another tag.*

My suggestion: [tag-alias-request](/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request) → [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request)

**References:**

- [Questions tagged [tag-alias-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request)
- [Tag wiki of [tag-alias-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-alias-request/info)
- [Tag wiki revisions to [tag-alias-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/331989/revisions)
- [Usage guidance revisions to [tag-alias-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/331990/revisions)
- [Questions tagged [synonym-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request)
- [Tag wiki of [synonym-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonym-request/info)
- [Tag wiki revisions to [synonym-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250744/revisions)
- [Usage guidance revisions to [synonym-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250745/revisions)

Comment: To the downvoters: This is a formatting sandbox. Do not treat text here seriously. Even if you disagree there is no point in downvoting a "sandbox post".

Answer (score -2):

Does HTML comments work?

<! –– No it doesn't, if you get it wrong ––>

Comment: You need to use a hypen, instead of an [en dash](https://unicode-table.com/en/2013/). There also shouldn't be a space following `!`. See the revision history of the answer in markdown mode.

Comment: @41686d6564 Ah thanks, I just copy pasted without looking at what I was doing :P

Comment: Tested some editing. Don't mind.