# Flagging testing questions

Tags: feature-request, flags, testing

Flagging behavior is not particularly well-documented in the FAQs. It's unclear whether or not flagging a question or a comment is an irrevocable action, or whether it will pop up a dialog for selecting a reason, or just seemingly do nothing.  I would like to be able to test this behavior, both to learn more about how it operates and to validate that it's working properly on my browser; however, I don't particularly want to end up flagging a random post, particularly if it's an irrevocable act; I'd rather not add more trouble for the moderators to have to deal with.

My question is, could we possibly get a question that we could use to test flagging behavior that the moderators would know to safely ignore?  That way, we can test the behavior without causing excessive work for the moderators.  It could even be this question, if that's determined to be appropriate.

Note: this comes up largely because it appears that using the "comment flag" is irrevocable (at least, it appears to be on my browser); as it turns out, I didn't know that the "flag a question" link brought up a cancellable dialog box, because I didn't want to try flagging any questions (none seemed offensive enough).  Really, this is a question about being able to test the functionality of the flag system without causing side effects; since we have no real manual for this product other than the product itself, it would be useful to have a playground to test the UI on.

And yes, I'm aware of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/can-we-get-a-test-stackoverflow-com) question, but I'm thinking of something a little simpler, just a single question with a few test answers to try this out on.

Comment: I nominate that we all flag this question and see what happens.

Comment: I'm completely okay with this question being the one used for flagging, so long as it's not actually offensive to anybody.  The idea does sort of suggest itself.

Comment: McWafflestix: I hope you know that if all works as planned, six flags (not the amusement park) will delete the question and knock off 100 rep.

Comment: Well, you've got 2 out of 6 ;-p

Comment: @TheTXI: well, better done on meta than on SO.  However, that deletion will force the need for another question like this one...  :-)

Comment: @Waffle: Why on earth would we need another one? This better put your mind to rest the first time...

Comment: @RichB: so new users to the site can test the functionality.  And what's with the "this better" in your comment?  Are you implying some sort of retribution?

Comment: Not every single user needs to test the flagging feature...

Comment: @Waffle: Why would new users need to test it? We all trust it works, because there is a definitive feedback. Just try flagging it twice.

Comment: @TheTXI: true, but having a feature that is undocumented and untestable until the need arises is a bit primitive, no?

Comment: @Waffle: How is it 'undocumented'?

Comment: Plenty of documentation to me (as if it wasn't completely self explanatory!): http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/

Comment: @Waffle: you make my soul cry

Comment: @Waffle: You monster. His soul is a pony. How dare you?

Comment: Flagging works. As a 10k user, I can see all spam and offensive flags. I do not believe I can see any view moderator flags.

Comment: OK, enough people. The flags work. It is neither undocumented nor untestable. So... should I start testing account delete? I'm going to lock this because the flags are an unnecessary distraction.

Comment: @Marc: I think some people are flagging stuff to test out the flagging interface.  Though that will cause issues mainly with comment flagging, which has no interface.

Comment: See the FAQ entries about [flagging in general](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review) and the [spam flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work) and [offensive flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work) specifically

Comment: Use mine: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149252/let-op-reject-an-answer - people have already pounded the heck out of it.  Do your worst.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you flag something as **offensive** or **spam** it goes into a separate queue that we have to remember to check manually.  If you flag something for **moderator attention** we see the "Mod-Signal" link at the top of every page and we know that the Joker has escaped from Arkham again and it requires immediate attention.

This question has been flagged for moderator attention once and offensive three times, so we know that much works.

Comment: Thanks for the "eyes on the inside," Bill.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for the "view from the top".

Answer (score 2):

The flagging functions work fine. Informing a moderator works the best.

Comment: I have noticed that the badge doesn't get rewarded properly, though. I'm flagged a number of questions on meta so far and no notification of a badge yet.

Comment: @TheTXI: Fair enough. Post it as a new issue. I can assure you the mods have been responding to flags though. We have had about 2 dozen questions they had to intervene with from my fanclub today, so I know they are working.

Comment: It's good to know that they work fine, but can you assure that they will always work properly on every release of every browser?

Comment: @Waffle: No one can ever assure that. But you can try flagging it twice to see if the system remembers you flagging it.

Comment: @RichB: right, but I don't want to hassle a moderator with my flagging of a question / answer / comment just to test the functionality; I'd like moderators to respond to flagged [objects] rapidly, and overwhelming them with "just testing" flaggings would possibly decrease their ability to do so; having a "playground" within which to test the behavior would assure that a user's testing actions aren't "harassing" a moderator.

Comment: @Waffle: Just flag it so we can stop this nonsense. Good lord.

Comment: @RichB: why is this nonsense?  It's a valid question about how users learn to use the site, with a valid suggestion about how to implement something that won't bother the existing moderators.  If you don't want to contribute, you don't need to; why would you call this nonsense or be so dismissive?

Comment: @RichB: okay, taking your advice to flag your answer.

Comment: @Waffle: Whatever puts your mind at rest sweetheart.

Comment: @Waffle: This is nonsense. We don't need a place to test functionality that we all know already works.

Comment: @RichB: seriously?  we "all know" that the functionality already works?  Isn't the existence of the question proof positive of the opposite?

Comment: @Waffle: No. We all knew it worked. That is how we were able to answer so quickly and positively. In fact, you are the only user I have ever heard question this.

Comment: @McWaffle - trust me it works....I've been flagging all of Rich's stuff all week with my puppet accounts :P

Comment: @RichB: you're astounded that in the whole week that meta has been around that i've been the only person who's asked a question about this?   Might as well close meta after a month, all the questions will have been asked by then...

Comment: @Waffle: No, in the whole time any SO site has been in existence, I have never heard anyone question whether flagging works.

Comment: @RichB, @TheTXI: It's not questioning whether it works; it's questioning how to use it, and how to let users try it without worrying that they will bother a moderator.

Comment: @Waffle: How could anyone be confused on how to work it?

Comment: @RichB: Again, the existence of the question and the body of the question answers your question.  Perhaps I'm just dense (but then it's likely that I'm not the only one).

Comment: @Waffle: You are seriously confused about clicking 'flag' and choosing one of three options?

Comment: @RichB: no, I was seriously confused about the difference between clicking 'flag' on a comment and having it do apparently nothing reversible (except presumably invisibly notifying a moderator) and clicking 'flag' on a question / answer and having a menu pop up.  Mixed modalities; it's a classic UI no-no because it causes user confusion.

Comment: @Waffle: So why not RTFM? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/   http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/

Comment: @RichB: RTFM is the bad UI designer's response to anything.  Or his apologist, in this case.

Comment: @Waffle: Again, this is not difficult behavior at all. Everything should work as expected. But if you want to know how and why everything works, there you go. Confusing comments for answers/questions is beyond the scope of any reasonable UI design.

Comment: @RichB: actually, mixed modality considerations in UI design is exactly about not changing the user's expectations of the UI across functional boundaries.  BTW, have you considered that you have a pathological inability to not have the last word?

Comment: @Waffle: Have you considered that if you keep saying stupid things and asking me questions that I kind of have to reply or look like I am dropping the conversation?

Answer (score 1):

Another month at your current rate should put you over 10K on SO. Then you'll be able to see posts flagged as spam or offensive, and those deleted for this reason, as well as those removed by moderators.

I doubt you'll have to wait long after that for an opportunity to test them yourself...

Comment: Heh.  Good point, although really this is intended more as a learning tool for new users.

Comment: Oh... Hmm. Like, a *flagging tutorial*?

Comment: @Shog9: actually, yeah, kinda.  more of a sandbox where you can act without side effects, but sure.

Comment: Hmm... That'd be kinda fun - a dummy SO, where everyone has every possible permission so you can see it all from both sides. Well... maybe if they do open up the source... ;-)

Comment: @Shog9: yeah, I actually think something like that would enhance confidence in using SO...

Comment: This game isn't that hard...

Comment: :::Randomly upvotes Shog9/McWafflestix comments to test if flagging a post has the 5 second delay.  Fortunately, it does, since I've sometimes clicked the flag button by accident when trying to upvote two comments in quick succession:::