# Do I have the right of appeal after losing rep?

Tags: discussion, flags

I think a post of mine (now deleted) was unfairly flagged. The [guidelines on flagging a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work-in-stackoverflow/22175#22175) clearly state that it should only be used for something which qualifies as hate speech or abuse.

I mentioned quite clearly in the comments on the post (when it had been flagged twice) that it was *a joke referring to a line in a film* (and hence not intended as abuse). Unfortunately for me I didn't realize that I ran the risk of losing 100 rep, as I would have just deleted the post at that point.

I'm now 100 points to the bad: tough luck, or is there some procedure of appeal?

Comment: Could you post a link to the question? Those of us with 10K rep can still see the post.

Comment: oxbow, you're taking things too seriously or you're a troll.

Comment: @John - I'm taking things too seriously. I think one look at my rep would confirm that I'm not a troll

Comment: Jon B - I can't find the original question - it's not coming up in my answer history and not in any searches either. Presumably I can't re-iterate the profanity as it will get flagged again.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: what site was it on?

Comment: nm, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685779/1687858#1687858

Comment: It also says it can be flagged if it's spam.

Comment: @Kyle: Are you sure that's it? I don't see anything related to a joke or a film in that question.

Comment: @Jed: I'm not sure. But oxbow_lakes' rep chart indicates a 100-point loss on this question (scroll to the bottom of the table http://stackoverflow.com/users/16853?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top)

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: did you by any change provide a link to the quotes section of imdb?

Comment: You know, some people might think that posting three questions to MSO over the same incident was a bit too much.

Comment: Heck, if I lose 2 rep, I have to go cool off for 8 hours. Compared to me, you're not overreacting!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question in two ways:

1. Email the team (See link at bottom of the page). They may be willing to restore your rep.
2. 100 rep is not a big deal in the long run. Hopefully this was a learning experience.

Comment: 100 points off a rep of 12,580 (at the time of writing) - http://stackoverflow.com/users/16853/oxbowlakes