# Double downvote by flagging as spam AND downvoting

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, down-votes

Currently it's possible to cast 2 downvotes on a post.  You can flag as spam, thus casting a free downvote where you don't lose the 1 rep, and then actually downvote.  It might be that you can't cast an actual downvote after the graceperiod on the vote from the flag has expired.  I just flagged a SF question as spam and it allowed me to also downvote it right away.  I did remove the downvote so as not to double dip and now I can't go in and downvote it again.

Or is the double downvote by design?  I hope it's just a bug, given the change in weight of downvotes sometime in the next 6-8 weeks.

Comment: what makes you think "flag as spam" is equivalent to a downvote?  do you lose rep?

Comment: @quack: you as the flagger don't lose rep, but the flagee loses rep

Comment: @quack: have a look at the rep on this user: http://serverfault.com/users/31055?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top  6 downvotes and one of them is my spam flag.  -12 rep on the one question the user has asked.

Comment: I see 8 downvotes on that user for -16 rep, you may have been caught with a caching thing.

Comment: @Lance: I looked at the user's rep graph **right** after I flagged it, downvoted and removed my downvote (which all happened within about 10 seconds).  It was 6 downvotes and -12 rep.  The only thing would be if the -2 from my (rescinded) downvote got stuck in the total, but that -2 is redeemed when a downvote is rescinded.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work

Comment: Just tested it myself and it did indeed cost 2 rep for the flagee. This does not apply to wiki posts, just like downvotes.

Comment: @mmyers: I'm guessing I was the flagee? :)

Comment: OK, the FAQ says they do, but I've never seen it.  Is this a new thing?

Comment: @squillman: Nope, this was on SO. And I made sure it was actually spam before I flagged. :)

Comment: @mmyers: ah, heh.  Just wondered after a flurry of 3 downvotes on this question.  Thanks for the confirmation that I'm not just dreaming it.

Comment: +1 something new every day

Comment: @down, you got that right, I'm in shock that I never realized this.

Comment: I don't think double-downvoting is much of a worry. If someone wanted to do that, all they'd have to do is go to that users profile and chainly-downvote all of their responses and questions

Comment: wow, i didn't know flags cost the flagee 2 rep. i knew about the 100 rep for 6 flags thing, but this was new to me.

Comment: @earlz there is logic in place that will identify serial (chain) voting patterns and remove them when detected.  I don't think that this would get covered by those algorithms.  It's not that huge of a deal right now, but in the future when downvotes are more heavily weighted it could be a bigger problem.  Plus, the question is whether or not it's intended behavior (ie- is it a bug or no?)

Comment: @squillman: i see.  i think most of the flag-worthy posts on SU are actual spam, by new users, so i've never noticed the rep decrease.  in that case, thanks for asking this question -- i learned something!

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, there has to be some line of code that when you flag a post it removes the two rep, I don't believe they overlooked something like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those downvotes come from the community user, but will age away if the post does not reach the offensive threshold.

Answer (score 1):

I just got a 2 point decrease in rep without it showing up in my activity summary (and now that I think about it, it's not the first time).

Could this be as a result of a flag as spam on one of my posts?

Comment: I just observed the same.

Comment: I posted this a question/feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40665

Answer (score 0):

R.E. not being able to re-downvote - just make an edit to the post, then you can, right?