# Getting flagged as spam should appear in the activity summary

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, spam, activity-summary

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40568) brought to my attention something that [was always there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work/22175#22175), but few knew: flagging a post as SPAM produces a 2 point rep penalty.

The problem is I just got a 2 point decrease in rep without it showing up in my activity summary (and it's not the first time).

Could this be as a result of a flag as spam on one of my posts?

If so, this behavior could potentially be exploited, as I don't think this will show up in the anti-vote-fraud script, and furthermore, there's no way of knowing which posts are being flagged.

Could we at least add the rep lost as a flag to the envelope summary as a way of alerting us?
If I hadn't been on the site at that moment, I probably wouldn't had known.

Comment: I would still like to know (via the question you linked to) whether or not this is intended behavior....

Comment: Plus, putting any kind of flag should also appear in the activity.

Comment: According to Jeff's answer, it's intended @squil

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If it affects rep, it should show up in the activity log.  If my posts are getting flagged as spam, I want to know so I can act and fix them.

Comment: I flagged your post as spam to test.  It does indeed produce a -2 penalty. I'm voting you up to counter-act that.

Comment: @george - mmmmmmm, spam.....

Comment: I think it downvotes you, rather than give you the -2 penalty directly @george. But it's the same result

Comment: ...except that it's not visible in the activity list.

Answer (score 5):

Confirmed; I just flagged a post that was in the flag list in the 10k mod tools and it got another downvote and the poster took a -2 rep (actually, it was -102 since I was the sixth vote).

FWIW, I don't see any posts from you in the flag list on SO.

Comment: Mine was on meta (I don't actually care about mine, but the issue is the same on all sites)

Comment: @Downvoter: I don't see any flags for you on MSO either

Answer (score 4):

These downvotes come from the Community user.

Also, these downvotes age away if they do not reach the threshold, and are deleted.

Comment: Still no reason to *not* put them in the activity summary...

Comment: so? you don't know who the other downvotes come from anyway, I don't understand this answer

Comment: I agree with @Downvoter it's irrelevant if they come from Community, Jeff or ponies.. The end effect is the same

Comment: @downvoter see my update.

Comment: I still don't see why that is a reason not to show them, could you please elaborate? also, is the rep lost from those flags restored when they are deleted or only after a recalculation?

Comment: @Jeff: I think the point is not that they affect rep so much as the fact that if I am offending people I would like to know that.  Perhaps certain users, who shall remain unnamed, might alter their behavior if faced with a constant stream of flags on their posts.

Comment: It *does* matter that the downvote comes from the community user, because the flagger is effectively able to downvote without the -1 rep penalty.

Comment: @perpetual yes, but the community downvotes are temporary unless the post reaches the threshold. The community downvotes are auto-deleted after a certain period of time.

Comment: @Koper I'm getting reports that evil ponies have invaded meta. They are randomly down voting people. And since it's ponies, they don't show in the activity summary, making it hard to track them down. Mods have responded in force, attempt to remove any traces of pony, but so far the attempts have been unsuccessful.