# How does this user have only one rep?

Tags: support, reputation

Take a look at [this fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80894). His rep graph shows he should have around 800, but his score is 1. There is no penalty box message on his account, either. The rep graph also shows no major negative activity like -100 for flagged posts. What's going on here?

Comment: Unicorns ate it

Comment: Related thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46793/problem-user-spamming-personal-library

Comment: Also see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40665/getting-flagged-as-spam-should-appear-in-the-activity-summary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first revision about [flagged posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work/22175#22175) not showing in the reputation was wrong, but if I delete this then the useful comment by [Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) might be lost? I'll just repeat what Bill commented then:

> He lost his rep due to a bunch of posts being flagged. See [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46793/problem-user-spamming-personal-library). Those should show up in his reputation graph, though.

Comment: No, you would be able to see it in their Reputation Graph.

Comment: But that would show up in the graph, wouldn't it?

Comment: For example, see this user's graph: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135854?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top

Comment: @Chacha I think you're right after all! (Let me rephrase that: After all, I think you're right!)

Comment: Actually, you were partly right.  He lost his rep due to a bunch of posts being flagged.  See the discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46793/problem-user-spamming-personal-library  Those *should* show up in his reputation graph, though.

Comment: See here also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40665/getting-flagged-as-spam-should-appear-in-the-activity-summary

Comment: @Bill what if they were deleted?

Comment: @Chacha: Evan lost his rep mostly through regular downvotes, so his graph would appear different.

Comment: @voyager: That might be it.  When a post is flagged as spam that many times it gets auto-deleted along with the -100.  I could have sworn that it still shows up on your rep graph, but maybe not after a rep recalc.

Comment: @Bill, isn't the -100 *only* applied [when flagged 6 times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work/22175#22175)? I think it's either (temporarily) -2 for each flag, or -100 *and* deletion if 6 people flag it?

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, it's -100 and auto-deleted after 6 spam flags.  The -100 is an extra system-applied penalty in addition to any downvotes the post got on its way to 6 spam flags.

Answer (score 2):

This user has actually been discussed on Meta before.  He got into some trouble for spamming a [commercial mail library](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46074/advertising-users-on-the-trilogy-outlook-plugin-case/46115#46115) and apparently also a [bar code library](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46183/time-for-a-spring-cleaning-in-the-dusty-corner-of-net-mail-reading/46831#46831).  He got tons of flags.

This culminated in a [discussion revolving around this specific user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46793/problem-user-spamming-personal-library), which he actually came and participated in, fairly amicably I think.

He actually did get flagged to death, but I think the flagged posts were deleted and just aren't showing up in his history or reputation graph (and he hasn't gotten a recalc).  Either that or he was penalized by mods but subsequently forgiven.

Comment: All flagged posts are deleted, according to [What is the effect of the Offensive flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work/22175#22175), and hence only 10k's would be able to see those -- but apparently even you cannot see any deleted posts for this user on SO? Chacha102 posted a [nice example of a Meta user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135854?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) for whom the penalties *do* show (but both of us don't have the 10k on Meta to see if those flagged posts are still in the system somewhere).

Comment: @Arjan: As a 10k on Stack Overflow I can see the flagged/locked/deleted posts of his, so I can confirm with 100% certainty that those were what killed his rep.  I can only speculate as to why they don't show up in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

This chap posted answers to various questions on .Net and email.  All of these answers included a link to his web site where he sells a .Net email library.  Often he posted these answers to quite old threads, in a way which looked like a marketing campaign.

Basically a whole bunch of his answers appeared on the Tools Flag page as spam (a couple of them are still there).  A whole number got the necessary six votes  to incur the 100 point penalty.

Comment: I only see one of his answers on the flags page and the flags are unjustified (the answer is lousy, but not spam).

Comment: @Aarobot - perhaps another post has just been hit for the magic six.   Or perhaps the flags have just expired.  As for whether the flags are justified in that case, I think things got a bit out of hand, and people started flagging his posts even when they didn't mention his library.