# accepting your own answer yields -2?

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer, self-answer

My rep on SO just went down from 15191 to 15189 at about the same time I accepted my own answer for an old post that I felt needed closure.

Do you get -2 for accepting your own answer? If so why doesn't the faq reflect this?

I don't really care about the points, was just wondering how the rules work.

**edit:** I looked at my rep history, I did not get any down votes within the last 16 
hours. The only activity was the "accepted" (which shows "acc" and *no* points, not the usual +2 for accepting other people's answer) and then in the last few minutes I went from 15189 to 15199 from another upvote.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40665/getting-flagged-as-spam-should-appear-in-the-activity-summary

Comment: thanks but I've never flagged a post as spam

Comment: You don't lose points for flagging posts, you lose points for being flagged.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

hmmm.... I wonder if I had already accepted another answer (+2 on a prior date) and then when I accepted my own answer it removed the +2.

Comment: This would be correct if you had accepted another answer. Removing an accept would undo the +2 you would normally get.

Comment: And then you can accept your own answer on this question.  Seems appropriate somehow.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the literal question, no, you do not get -2 for accepting your own answer. You get +2 if it is someone else's answer.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/reputation to audit your reputation and see what may have caused the actual drop. The most likely scenario is you got 2 downvotes at the same time.

If the audit doesn't show a -2 for the accepting (which, naturally, it shouldn't), you should instead be checking to see how it all adds up. If the audit actually shows your current reputation, then that is exactly how it should look.

Comment: +1 for the "audit" link -- I hadn't known about that.

Comment: Although you don't get +2 if you accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You get no points for accepting an answer either way.

Your -2 was most likely caused by a downvote. Your reputation history should tell you more.

Comment: You don't get +2 for accepting own answer

Comment: @S.Mark of course. Corrected.

Comment: Hah! I was right! Your answer *was* between mine and waiwai's!

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not lose 2 points for accepting your own answer IIRC. If you accept someone else's answer, then you get +2 points.

Instead, you were probably voted down simultaneously. You can check to see if this is the case by clicking on the envelope next to your name and then viewing the Reputation tab.

Edit: If you could post the last few rows of your reputation audit at http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation, we could help you find out where the -2 came from.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have any downvotes, someone flagged one of your post as spam/offensive.

Comment: If a post is removed by spam/offensive flags you lose 100 rep, not 2.