# Should support be provided for ephemeral comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I understand and respect the policy against being "chatty" with the comment system, but I think there are substantive benefits to simple "thank yous" and certain other strictly social comments. I wonder if we could support the latter by providing an "ephemeral" option when submitting a comment such that the comment goes away by itself after some appropriate event (e.g. person who it's targeted at reads it, if that's detectable) or after a certain amount of time passes (e.g. 24 hours).

I'm currently working around this policy by submitting 'thank you' comments and then deleting them after some time passes.

Alternatively, if constructive, social-only comments (e.g. thank yous) are really "ok" in the domain of comments, despite they're being actively discouraged and eliminated in questions, it would be helpful if that could somehow be made more clear.

Comment: Why do we need this "thank you" comments?

Comment: Many of the answers in this thread are concerned with obsolete comments - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Comments are ephemeral by nature.

Comment: Upvoting = thank you. I comment when there is something wrong or something I need clarification with in the post/answer.

Comment: Upvoting is impersonal and does little to give either the sender or receiver a sense of satisfaction in the case of a previously directed comment. Think of the difference in what you feel between seeing upvotes on a comment and seeing the names of people who have "liked" something you've said in FB, particular when it's from someone you just reached out to (e.g. the like is coming from someone who's post you commented on).

Comment: @doubleDown But what if you answered a question of somebody without upvote privileges yet? Commenting is pretty much the only way they can say thank you to more than one answerer. Seriously, if "thank you that helped" comments become too many, do something against them. The occasional "Thanks" under an answer is not a problem.

Comment: @AlEverett many aren't, including the one to which I am replying.

Comment: @AlEverett: In what sense do you consider comments to be inherently ephemeral? Do they go away or lose their relevance with the passage of time? I've personally seen just as much value in many comments as I've seen in many Qs and As.

Answer (score 1):

A "thank you" comment is not necessarily just social. By publicly thanking someone, it shows their answer was helpful to you. Granted, upvoting and accepting an answer are more useful metrics for SO, but there is still a place for an occasional "thanks" as long as it does not get out of hand...

Comment: Hmmm. That certainly wasn't clear to me. I've gotten a definite sense of a "just the facts" culture. I can't speak to everything that has given me that impression. Isn't there automatic eliding of trailing thank yous on comments, for example?

Comment: "thank you's" are discouraged in questions, and questions are edited all the time to remove them. But in my opinion flagging or removing a thank-you comment is a bit harsh.

Answer (score 0):

I like this idea, but I think I'd prefer the ability to send "kudos" or something of the sort that won't clog up the comment system for any period of time, but will alert the user you wish to thank with a small, private popup expressing as much.

Comment: That would work for me. Although I indicated there were other examples of "valuable social-only comments", frankly I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: Perhaps something like a button that you could press in the shape of an up arrow; we could even show the number of people that have pressed that up arrow next to the post, or even reward users based on the number of times their posts have had their up arrow pressed.  Wouldn't that just be neat.

Comment: @Servy Since we're getting imaginative here, we could maybe even allow users to award answers they particularly appreciated with a number of their own reputation points. We could call these "booties", or "benevolences" or something.