# Lower comment-delete threshold

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, moderator-tools

Recently, I've found that I am having increasingly many conversations in the comment thread of either a question or to one of its answers. When all is said and done, I either have to prod the other users to do a comment cleanup or I have to flag the post for moderator attention.

I can't help but think that I could clean up these comments myself and take the load off the mods.

So, could we possibly lower the rep-bar for allowing users to delete comments (perhaps, add it to the 10-k tools or as a 15-k privilege)?

Comment: Currently what is that bar?

Comment: @HankyPanky Currently you have to be a diamond moderator to delete comments (or the comment has to accumulate several flags)

Comment: related: [Help us figure out a way to handle the explosion of comments on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently there are almost no checks and balances for comment deletion, they're just gone and no regular user can even see that there used to be a comment there. Comment deletion does not notify or bump the post, on older posts it is practically invisible.

Without any effective way to review such actions, comment deletion as a regular user privilege is far too dangerous and too easy to abuse.

I think some way to easier get rid of obsolete or off-topic comment threads would be nice, but I don't think we can put unilateral comment deletion into the hands of regular users. The comment flagging mechanism is a start, but it has some drawbacks that make it useless for anything but truly offensive comments. Comment flags are not visible to other users, so they have to organically accumulate enough flags, which is rather unlikely. Flagging a whole comment thread is also practically impossible due to the rate limit on flagging.

So I'd like to see some improvements in this area, but some amount of review of the decision and some resistance to abuse are necessary in my opinion.

Comment: Do you think it would be feasible to add a "delete" vote on comments? This could follow the delete-vote model implemented on regular posts, which is rep-unlocked. Thus, 5 delete-votes and the comment is auto-deleted.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget that already exists with comment flags, enough flags will auto-delete a comment