# Misleading comments with high volume of upvotes

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

I see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240379/352101) on SO, the comments below receiving 90 upvotes is incorrect:

> [image: > The reason to prefer WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() is that this returns the account that the application is running as. This is not necessarily the account that is currently logged into Windows (think "RunAs" or impersonation/delegation). So, if you want to know the logged-in user, use the Environment (if you trust it). If you want to know the security context your application is running as, using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(). See msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/… for more information.]

I feel this is misleading *as both method will return the account that the application is running as*, and other users will take it as granted (because of the upvotes..), so I have

- **posted my comments to correct it in the same answer**;
- up-voted the questioning comments above it;
- and up-voted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14518508/352101) that related to this problem;
- I have also flagged it.

The problem with my approaches above is that this may never be noticed by other users, as my comments is hiding by default and the wrong comments is on the top highlighted by upvotes. (Don't get me wrong, I'm not questioning other users ability of judgement, but who will not trust it with the first sight? I only happen to find out because I have used both of them). Flagging won't help either as Mod can't do anything with a comment except to delete it  (I don't know this before I have flagged it), and it's not their duty to verify who is correct. 
So my question is not about asking how to delete the comment I think is wrong, but rather:

***Is there a better process to stop a comment with a bunch of upvotes (that I think is wrong) from misleading following users?***

**Update:**

This picture well justified my concern, user just won't get my challenging comments and keep up-voting the wrong statement as they think they have learnt something. Is this really what SO want? (spreading wrong knowledge?)

> [image]

Comment: Post another comment beneath it. Moderators don't delete information for being incorrect - if you think something is wrong, say it

Comment: @Emracool, I did that.

Comment: Then you have done what you can do - you'll probably receive feedback if the original comment is correct.

Comment: @bolu You only did this 20 minutes ago. Give the commenter a few days to respond before raising a meta thread about it. Maybe you will find that you are wrong. Or they delete the comment voluntarily otherwise.

Comment: @MartinSmith, OK so I guess the best approach is to just post my comment, and wait for response?

Comment: @bolu In this specific case the user that posted it was seen 17 hours ago so are clearly still active on the site. Hopefully they will respond to you!

Comment: Re. "I don't think you are really care about verifying it because..." The real reason, as a number of people have stated, is that this is not the moderators' job. It is the community's job.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, yeah, I get that, but why asking for example to reproduces the issue then?

Comment: To be clear, moderators *do not evaluate the technical accuracy of any content.* As *community members,* we *may* exercise our binding vote to remove content we happen to know is wrong, but that doesn't have anything to do with a moderator's duties.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, agreed, why not just say it in a comment rather than post an answer and saying that because I didn't provide an example so my claim can't be verified?

Comment: I was clarifying your question.  "Why ask for examples to reproduce the issue?"  Because that can verify your claim.  But it still doesn't have anything to do with moderator duties.  If it will help clarify the situation, I'll remove the first paragraph from George's answer.

Comment: Ack.  Just noticed your edit.  For what it's worth, *this is not a discussion forum.*  You ask a question, you get an answer.  Comments are for clarification; if you feel that people aren't responding to you correctly, say so in comments, but don't butcher your question.  Please.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, cool. And thanks for all the edits, it's more like an answer now.

Comment: In case anyone wanted to see what the two commands do, I made simple linqpad test and took a screenshot of it: http://i.imgur.com/lz3yaZU.png

Comment: @TravisJ, That is great. The only problem is it can't verify/show RunAs (any other user) result.

Comment: @Bolu - You mean "Run as administrator" for example?

Comment: [all comments should be condensed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180752/165773). This would solve the problem. "I feel that the world is awash in comments, but not answers..."

Answer (score 8):

Consider asking the original poster of the answer (who appears to be active) to update their answer to include the appropriate refutation of the incorrect information in the comment.  This will then appear above the comment.

Please note that the answer as it is at this time doesn't explain *anything* as it is a code only answer and provides no reason to believe it is correct (or incorrect).  This is likely why the comment has such high votes - it is trying to explain something.

This is ultimately part of the problem with code only answers in that they *don't* explain anything or give the reader the appropriate amount of information to be able to judge the veracity of the comments or other answers.

Answer (score 5):

It's not part of a moderator's duties to determine the correctness of a comment or an answer.  In this particular case I have expertise in this area (though I don't really have time), and so I could conceivably double check and see if the comment is incorrect.  That would be setting a bad precedent, however.

If you believe comment to be incorrect, produce a gist or somesuch, link to it in a comment on that answer, and watch your comment be upvoted if it's correct.

In general, we don't generally delete comments for being "wrong"; (although we reserve the right to), and in this case, I can't judge the accuracy of the comment off the top of my head, but apparently 90 other people did and they think it's right. So... There's that.

Comment: 71 people thought/think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696175/razor-view-engine-how-to-enter-preprocessorif-debug/4697570#4697570) is right while it couldn't be more wrong, so there's that.

Comment: I think 90 user may just think its useful to KNOW without verifying it, and that is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, one of the most common types of comment flags that I decline is "this is wrong". We can't make that call, nor do you want us to.

Comment: @BradLarson I normally solve this by just nuking comments.  If I nuke them indiscriminately, no one can complain I'm judging the accuracy of them.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker just curious, so are you saying when you do this you just nuke **all** of them for that Q/A?

Comment: @BradLarson, I see your point, and that's why I'm asking, what should be the better approach for this kind of problem.

Comment: Depends, is it Tuesday?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, I agree it's may not proper to delete a comments just because it is wrong, but you said you even can't verify it.... With your profile on SO, you should have enough knowledge and resource to verify it, so I have to down vote this answer.

Comment: That's fine. I have the technical expertise to, just not the time. Nor are my moderator duties such that I should devote time to that activity. Since you want the comment deleted, it holds you should be able to prove it incorrect

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, with the time you post this answer and all the following comments, you could have verified it 100 times... And I don't want it to be deleted, I just flagged it for attention.

Comment: @Bolu I don't think it's so much that he *couldn't* make the time but that isn't part of a mods duties and I'm sure, like most of us, has plenty of other things to do. If you don't want it deleted then what result do you want by bringing it to mod attention?

Comment: @Bolu - We're not subject matter experts on most (or even a large fraction) of the things we moderate. The site's too broad for that. In a lot of cases, we *can't* verify the technical validity of an answer or comment, only if it's rude, abusive, or otherwise complete noise. We'd have to trust the person flagging, and again, you don't want that. Say someone flagged all of your comments and said you were wrong. Would you want us to take them at their word and delete everything you've written?

Comment: @BradLarson, no I don't, that is exactly why I have asked this question..

Comment: @codeMagic, I see, so a better process of dealing with a situation I've described in my question should just ignore the flagging part.

Comment: @Bolu I would say so. By bringing it to mod attention there isn't much for them to do with a comment but delete it. Which isn't always good as mentioned previously by Brad Larson. You have done what you can do by providing a comment explaining why you think it is wrong.

Comment: Simply deleting a comment (whether or not it is wrong) also does not improve the global knowledge pool. Posting a correct follow-up can do that. In some cases, it might even be appropriate to take a comment and expand on it into a full-fledged question and answer, and link to that in a follow-up comment. Something very similar happened [here](http://ham.stackexchange.com/q/421/29), for example.

Answer (score 3):

As one of the 90 who upvoted this comment, I feel I am well placed to respond to this.

I upvoted it because I found that information useful to know. I did not verify the correctness of it, for a number of reasons (mainly time/lack of reason). I tend to read *all* comments before upvoting anything just incase something has been missed, they can be a valuable source of information.

The fact you claim it is incorrect is something I was unaware of at the time I browsed this question (a few months ago now). Retrospectively, I haven't lost anything as a result of this. I have what I need, it works, it's tested and we're good to go. If this had caused me a problem, I would have definitely gone back and challenged this comment, as you have done now.

Similarly, if someone else had challenged this comment before hand, I would have done more research of my own before upvoting. Essentially, it comes down to my own laziness and ignorance.

What I'm getting at from all of this: If you disagree with something, challenge it. If applicable, downvote it, comment it, just put your message across. It doesn't matter if it has 90 votes or not. Just say it. It isn't up to the moderators to verify the correctness of anything, and nor should it be. It's up to as a community to do something about this

Comment: Well said. Just as I've commented on the other answer, user upvote "may just think its useful to KNOW without verifying it". But sadly, that was interpreted as lying.

Comment: I trust the community here, so I didn't see the point of verifying it, if someone challenged it, it's worth verifying.

Comment: I'm not saying that is wrong, I was trying to defend my point: that it should be the common behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't take much to work out what the commenter is saying is wrong, if I relied on what the commenter had said, I'd use his advice, realise it was wrong and challenge it, I like to think the rest of the community would do the same.

Comment: yeah, agreed, I had done my part, and I shouldn't bring it here.

Comment: Looks like community is not working as we expected, just as I have pointed out previously, it will keep misleading. See my update.