# Add a word that can be put in a comment that means it can be insta-flag-deleted by any user

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags

Currently, if there is a word like "accept rate" or either of the common swear words in a comment, any user can flag it and it is instantly deleted.

Please could there be a (made up?) word added to this, that means any comment you don't need lying around can be removed by the reader?

For example, maybe `[del]` would fit in with the `[edit]` and `[site.se]` series?

Comment: Try putting zero-width spaces in your comments...

Comment: @Shog9 does that make it count as 1 word? And can be del flagged

Comment: I'd go for [speedy-obsoletion], but that might be a little long.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you are suggesting. So, the user who owns the comment can at the time of writing include a word to their comment so others can insta-delete it?

Comment: @James yes, they can flag it and be insta deleted. Like if it had a swear word or "accept rate".

Comment: if this would be a site specific setting, it would be friggin' great if Stack Overflow had ["programmers"](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7154/31260) as such a word

Comment: @gnat it may already be - post on that meta. I think they possibly can add a word, although accept rate is clearly all sites.

Comment: @Tim that's unlikely to fly - MSO folks seem to love to redirect their garbage at other sites, if you take a look at the score of similar feature request: [Prevent “I'm voting to close this because it belongs on…” custom close reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289949/839601) "just lazy suckers afraid to do the real thing by flagging for moderator to migrate... now that could be helpful, but suckers just want to avoid risk of declines..."

Answer (score 11):

How about a slight refinement. For comments that @ somebody, an optional word that allows **that somebody** to delete the comment - maybe with a flag, or maybe the x is shown to them also.

**important** - this isn't a general suggestion that I can delete comments that contain @Kate - they need to have been so marked by the comment writer. Assuming the literal text is `(instant-delete)` you can imagine

- Thanks, @Kate, edited (instant-delete)
- @Kate fixed (instant-delete)
- @Kate love this answer you're the greatest (instant-delete)

All of which save me from flagging them as obsolete and hoping they're cleared up some day, or replying myself so the person knows they can delete theirs (but then who deletes mine and when can I be sure the other person saw them?)

If the comment is nasty, I don't need to insta-delete it, and in fact I wouldn't want a flag to delete it, because I want to be able to bring down some sort of wrath on the head of someone who keeps leaving nasty comments, so I would want to flag it without deleting. That suggests either showing me the x and leaving flagging to do what it always has done, or having insta-delete only happen from an **obsolete** flag while rude etc still function as they do today.

Giving the power to anyone who happens to see the comment is probably not super useful, because someone might use it 10 seconds after the comments was posted, or nobody might ever do it. But giving that power to someone who will be notified, and who the comment is specifically for? That makes sense to me. It might even help with [Ye Olde Comment Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: +1, especially for only letting Obsolete flags trigger insta-delete.

Comment: Yea, this would work well :) If the `instant-delete` was added in, it could even add another flag reason, for that.

Comment: I did think of exactly this myself, but just can't see it working to any particular advantage. People don't really care about comments. "Most" people don't want to help the site for no reason (why we have badges and rep for edits etc). Are users likely to use their time up on deleting other users comments once read? I just imagine it would be used by so few people it's not really worthwhile. I also worry that it would take comments too close to being "social", than just useful comments on Q and A, as people can chat away and clean up afterwards.

Comment: Maybe `@@Kate`? To me it looks "cleaner" than appending an arbitrary string at the end.

Answer (score 7):

To tackle useless comments, it'd (also) be cool to have a button next to the comment box - 'self-destruct'.

Clicking it could *either* bring up a dialog that asks you 'self destruct in x days' where x is a multi-choice checkbox-thing *or* simple a pre-defined number of days (in case the other option is too complicated).

It would simply look like:

[image]

I know this is a slightly different suggestion to yours... but it kind of tackles the same problem!

Comment: I considered this, but I'm worried about a user not seeing it because it goes too soon...

Comment: @Tim It's possible, but after it's been publicized, hopefully people will know! I'm thinking this is mainly for *existing* users - new users couldn't care less about the uselessness of comments! This could also be shown within the 5 minute grace period for comments (just to add a bit more time :)

Comment: I think Tim's concern is that the person to whom the comment is addressed will not see it, if the comment self-destructs before they get to reading it.

Comment: @Tim the problem is that if someone insta-deletes the comment before the directed target reads it, then it is no different than a self distruct.

Comment: @Yes Ah.... Of course! Then maybe there can be a button to the recipient saying 'can this be deleted now?' Or maybe there can be a 'read' system where the system detects whether the recipient has read the message.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ http://stackapps.com/questions/6315/request-for-self-destructing-comments

Comment: @Tim I was just looking at that! Did you not get the +1? I'm looking into it - no promises though (like Brock :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I got the +1 as I got this comment :) Nice to see if this can be done!

Comment: @Tim Done - please see StackApps :)

Answer (score 3):

You've not really stated why it would be useful, or when or how it would be used.

*Useless* comments can already be dealt with, so I presume your idea is for comments which specifically are "*useful* for a given time period".
Either to everyone, or a specific user.

Three scenarios - A comment is:

1. Useful *indefinitely*
2. Useful *temporarily*
3. Not useful *at all*

Your proposal is no use for 1 as they should remain, and 3 as we have flags to remove those already.

However, for (2) I'm struggling to come up with a scenario or problem where we need some kind of function to assist or resolve.

What makes a comment have a finite time of being useful?

### When to delete

You need some way to identify *when* a comment has stopped being useful and can be deleted.
Otherwise, with just your "insta-delete" keyword, there's nothing stopping the comment being deleted after seconds, or a few mins.

Who benefits from it then?

I have no idea how you would identify when to delete with accuracy or where it's useful. 
Or how you would signal this within the comment so other users knew.

### Considerations needed

1. How do we identify when a comment is eligible for deletion
2. Who can delete it
3. What determines a comment only has a finite usefulness
4. Why would users use this to have their comment deleted? Users who
   post barely useful comments are not likely to bother using this so
   we can clean them up - comes with the mentality etc
5. Why would users delete them? Most community clean up actions reward
   users, or are substantially more useful than comment clean up
   etc

I'm not sure you could manage this problem successfully and realistically with a good ROI, especially given we are talking about "comments" which are "useful but not essential".
And for the most part, any suggestions for new functionality to comments tends to not be welcomed or cared about.

---

I'm still not even sure what you proposal aims to help with or resolve. Perhaps update your question with more of your thoughts? :)

Comment: It seems like this is intended especially for the cases where you need a quick notification to a specific person that they can then blow away immediately with minimal ceremony once read.

Comment: Yeah as nathan said - essentially a comment like "Fixed, thanks" etc.

Comment: 1. The user decides it, and the person it's directed at deletes it. Anyone who sees it can, or maybe Kate's suggestion. 3. The poster, for example "edited, thanks". 4. I'd use it. 5. They'd delete them because they're nice.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The question in no way explains this, and in fact states "*it can be insta-flag-deleted **by any user***". My answer was just some general observations based on info from the question

Comment: @James: No, it wasn't stated explicitly, but I did infer it based on the nature of what it seemed to be useful for.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It wasn't clear on that. So you *presumed* what was being suggested. The question isn't clear on what or when or how this was for (no offense Tim :) )

Comment: @Tim I'd probably use it too, but users on Meta tend to care more about the sites, so voting and opinion can be slightly off to what an accurate general consensus would be on the live site. I doubt of the 4 million users on SO, many would bother cleaning up, or even posting "delete this when read" in the first place. I'm not against the idea, and in principle it would be brilliant (sincerely) I just don't believe many would use it.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is an excellent idea. It would make comments much more readable and easier for people who are not familiar with how things work on other sites.

The problem is, it's hard to find such a word. It's like finding a new way of saying "delete comment".

If we had some kind of flag or something similar to say "this post will automatically get deleted", then we'd have a lot less problems when users try to remove comments.