# How does comment hiding work on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, comments, meta

I tried to find an answer to this question on meta. While I found several posts such as the following related to this topic, they do not accurately answer the specific question I have. Also, they are quite old and do not have accepted answers.

1. [Are comments turning Stack Overflow into a forum?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66794/comments-are-evil-or-are-comments-turning-stack-overflow-into-a-forum)
2. [Help us figure out a way to handle the explosion of comments on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow/)
3. [How can we measure the cost of displaying comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210265/how-can-we-measure-the-cost-of-displaying-comments)

**My Question**:

How does comment hiding mechanism work on Stack Overflow? Until recently, I had the understanding that SO displays only the top five newest comments on a post; a user has to click the link "*Show <x> more comments*" in order to see all the comments. Based on my more recent observation, it looks like the comment hiding mechanism incorporates not just time stamp but also the comment up-votes. Also, it looks to be working differently depending on the type of user:

1. Un-logged in user
2. Logged in user who has reputation score of < 10k
3. Logged in user who has reputation score of >= 10k

Consider the following example SO answer post that has eight comments. If I see this post as an un-logged in user, SO shows five comments and hides three. But if I see the same post with my user account having less than 10k points, SO shows only three comments and hides five. I don't understand the logic behind this.

[A random SO answer with eight comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38550131/5749570)

Can someone please explain how SO decides which and how many comments to hide for different types of users?

Comment: Thanks all who reviewed this question. I am afraid it is not a duplicate post. The quoted duplicate post doesn't explain the behavior mentioned in my question above.