# Losing reputation for answering my own question

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [accepting your own answer yields -2?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51121/accepting-your-own-answer-yields-2)

I [made a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6189659). It got [one very useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189659#6249977) which helped me a lot although was not precisely the solution for my problem. I marked it as a correct answer nonetheless. Then, I found all the problemas with my code and post [a more comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6189659#6266648) and accepted it. Then, I lost two reputation points. I am not that sensitive to lose them :) but I wondered: did I do something not recommended? I'd  not like to reincide in some condemned behavior.

What was my fault?

Comment: See here: [accepting your own answer yields -2?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51121/accepting-your-own-answer-yields-2), in particular [the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51121/accepting-your-own-answer-yields-2/51127#51127). In specific, you didn't "lose" two points so much as "unearn" the +2 you had for accepting someone else's answer.

Comment: Yes, that was the case. I bet that *now* I may be found in fault for posting a possible duplicate :)