# When downvoting an already heavily down-voted post, prompt "is this spam or offensive"?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, offensive

Very often spam and offensive posts are heavily down-voted before reaching the 6 flags required to delete it. When a post gets a certain number of downvotes (e.g. 5), how about prompting subsequent down-voters "Is this post spam or offensive?"

It would be interesting to do a bit of a survey of heavily down-voted posts to see what the ratio of spam or offensive : just wrong or low quality, etc. is like.

Comment: Are you sure these downvotes are genuine downvotes? Because [flagging something as spam also makes the community user cast a downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40568/double-downvote-by-flagging-as-spam-and-downvoting).

Comment: @Oak I wasn't aware of that, thanks for pointing it out! The higher down-votes may then result from people flagging *and* down-voting, but obviously we can't tell.

Comment: @Oak even so, it's probably still a worthwhile prompt? - Maybe the metric for defining "heavily" would need tweaking, and you do have the case where someone will downvote because they're out of flags for the day...