# When a question or answer is already marked spam or offensive by two or more users, tell that when down- or closevoting

Tags: feature-request, flags, down-votes, spam, spam-detection

When a question or answer is already marked spam or offensive by two or more users, tell that when downvoting, closevoting or voting to delete. Something like a pop-up saying:

> This question (answer) might be spam or contain offensive/abusive content. If you agree with that, please use the spam or offensive flag [link to flag menu] instead of downvoting or voting to close/delete.

On smaller sites, I see often spam sitting around for 15 minutes or longer, and on sites that do not get a lot of spam, users don't know what to do: I sometimes see comments like "I voted to close this question as off-topic because it is spam" or questions or answers that already reached a score of -10 or -11 before finally being deleted.

Related: [When downvoting an already heavily down-voted post, prompt "is this spam or offensive"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75042/when-downvoting-an-already-heavily-down-voted-post-prompt-is-this-spam-or-offe) However, this is not what this requests. I don't think that we should show this if it hasn't been marked as spam at least twice.

Comment: How long is a quarter, anyhow?

Comment: @Won't It also bothers more users than needed.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think I could be more confused.  Congrats!

Comment: _"~a quarter or longer"_ A quarter of what?

Comment: @AlE. I thought a quarter was a standard term. It is a quarter of an hour, i.e. 15 minutes.

Comment: In American English at least, if you're using a naked "quarter" as a unit of time, and aren't referencing a sporting event, you're more than likely talking about a calendar quarter, i.e., three months. "Sales are up this quarter." For a fifteen minute period, "quarter" is always associated with "of an hour".

Comment: I think you are assuming that all those DVs come from users with Close/Delete vote privilege. People who do have those privileges are veteran users who most likely know what to do with the situation. Many cast the vote and DV at the same time

Comment: On sites where I have the privilege, I cast the vote and DV (If it deserves a DV, duplicates don't deserve a DV). Where I don't, I flag the post and leave a DV.

Comment: @NSNoob I don't quite understand your comments. What do duplicates have to do with it? Also, is DV downvote or delete vote?

Comment: @NSNoob And why wouldn't a dupe deserve a downvote? Lack of research clearly applies and that's what the votes are intended for, no?

Comment: @wythagoras Duplicates don't have to do anything with it. I said Duplicates should not be downvoted because duplicate of a good question is a good question. DV means Downvote here. The main point is, You have no way to know who casted Downvote. If there are 11 Downvotes on a bad question, it is possible that none of them may have been from people who have privilege to cast delete/close votes

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ Read the above mentioned comment. Dupes most certainly don't have to be downvoted because duplicate of a good question is a good question and it helps finding the right answer in searching terms.

Comment: @NSNoob It still shows lack of research which is covered in the voting tooltip.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm concerned about the potential for this to lead to piling-on of innocent posts.

Back when spam flags were visible to 10k users on Stack Overflow, there were real problems with witch hunts and non-spam posts almost being destroyed due to people blindly casting spam flags. After this became too much of a problem, this public spam flag listing was removed.

If people see some kind of warning that something has been flagged as spam, I worry that they won't bother reading the post and will blindly flag it as spam. We see this happen all the time in review on Stack Overflow, where the "this might be spam" warning that sometimes appears in review seems to trigger many reviewers to flag things as spam even when they weren't.

We decline a lot of spam flags on Stack Overflow cast incorrectly or maliciously. It's not often that posts get two or more of these bad flags, but I'm still worried that such a warning would be taken as more of an order than an indication to examine a post carefully.