# How can a post have more votes than views?

Tags: discussion, voting, views

It's not a time issue, I refreshed the page a couple of times.

1 person = 1 vote.

[image]

Comment: Views don't update in real time.

Comment: @Bart I refreshed the page during a period of 40 seconds

Comment: Normally after 4-5 seconds views-votes are updated

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: If there are spam flags involved, they could also increase the number of downvotes https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40568/double-downvote-by-flagging-as-spam-and-downvoting (I don't know the question from which the screenshot is shown, but based on some keyworks like "congratulation" and "money" I would not rule out that it is spam)

Comment: Heuristics, aka guesstimates

Comment: Does working from review queue count as a view? One could have downvoted it from that tool without the system registering it as a "regular view" count.