# This deletion seems capricious and arbitrary to me. Help me understand

Tags: support, specific-question, community, moderators

Can the person who deleted my answer on this post explain the reason?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687090/what-is-a-good-program-for-storing-chunks-of-commonly-used-source-code

---

This is the deleted post, just for reference:

> Get a blog, use syntax highlighter,
>   comment the code and introduce it.
>   That way you can always find it as can
>   others in need of your wisdom. ;-P
>
> This is what I am talking about
>
> Here is some true wisdom: no matter
>   why you might consider it DO NOT HOST
>   YOUR OWN BLOG, either on your own
>   server or a host. Use WordPress. It
>   will never go down and wordpress is
>   just so fuqqin purty it makes my eyes
>   water. I HATE SUBTEXT but am stuck.
>   Don't make the same mistake.

Comment: I would've flagged it

Comment: I think I would have too, and I don't think I've flagged anything as offensive yet.

Comment: You are going to vote to delete a whole idea because there is one allusion to a word that 'offends' you? wow. not to mention that it was not used in a perjorative, malicious or salacious fashion. 

Some people.. sheesh. Oh well, no reason for me to get bent. Sorry bout your hangups and the need to control other's self expression.

Comment: fuqqin? Seriously? Is it so required to make the Fuh and the Kah and the Ing sound in one word? There is a nice replacement: `freaking` and also your entire post has a sadistic(is that the word) tone to it

Comment: @Earlz - I think you mean *sarcastic*, though reading it did cause some pain.

Comment: @Sky --  why is that your self-expression is okay, but someone else expressing that they find your's offensive is a "hang up?"  Your whole tone was rude and crass, including your comments to people who were offended by it.  As the FAQ says, "be nice" -- you might want to try it.

Comment: @tvan Actually I mean `sardonic` which I understood as basically being "sarcastic, but meaning for the other party to take offense"

Comment: @tvanfosson - dude, i most always nice. I am a nice guy. I like to help people. that said- I wonder if you even recognize the fallacy in the question and comment that you just posted. Things would be much easier if people did not attempt to rationalize their emotional reaction to something like my post and comments with faulty logic.  http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/ and with that said... peace.

Comment: @sky - no you like to pretend that you're nice, be really rude and insulting, and get away with it.  Your last comment is a fine example of that.

Comment: @TV - never mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your answer collected 6 [offensive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work), and was auto-deleted as a result. Apparently, some people found your answer to be offensive and/or spam.

Comment: thanks for the meta-data that I am not yet privy to.

Comment: It would certainly be helpful if users were notified in some way that their post was removed for being spam/offensive, but I expect this is not done for fear it would attract even more posts to meta "why was my post deleted".

Comment: @Ether - yeah, i would not even have noticed if not for the rep-drop and missing replies. not the most transparent. smells of being 'disappeared'

Answer (score 2):

Offhand I'd say it was because of the over-the-top endorsement of Wordpress that attracted the spam flags. If you edit your post to remove it, you can probably get a moderator to undelete it.  (You may need a moderator to do the edit for you, as the Community user now owns the post.)

Comment: wow - i didnt even think of that. I was railing against subtext more than endorsing wordpress, it just happens to be my unreachable promised land.. ;-)

Comment: So - it was spam and not offensive that got it deleted?

Comment: @sky: to some people they are one and the same!

Comment: While I don't agree with what you're saying at all @Sky (there is a lot of merit to self-hosting a blog) this really shouldn't have deleted.

Comment: @pekka - I was having a really bad day with subtext and I let it color my post. I am just so tired of fixing it. Anyway - being deleted doesn't bother me, it was the way it was done that is troubling. Disappeared with no notice. I get notifications for just about everything you can imagine why not for a deletion along with the reason for deletion? That is like silently spending your kids college fund when they misbehave instead of just smacking them on the hand and saying 'no! don't do that'.

Comment: @Sky I am guessing that is `by-design` to prevent every deletion being discussed by angry owners. I'm not saying I think that's a good practice, or that your speaking out against the deletion is in any way wrong, but that's probably the reason.