# Vote total doesn't decrease with -1 anymore after flagging as spam

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, flags

To take [this noisy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582215/java-nullpointerexception/2713311#2713311) as an example, flagging spam doesn't give the total vote count a -1 anymore, but when I open the vote count, it is there. Until about a week ago this has worked fine.

---

**Update**: it seems that they get fixed by some daily script.

Although this all get fixed by some daily script, this hasn't occurred until a few weeks ago. So I'd say, there has been a new bug introduced meantime which needs to be fixed.

---

**Update 2**: The same problem by the way occurs when serial downvotes get removed by the downvote anomaly checker script. The total vote count still remains the same, but when you open the vote count, it's correct.

---

**Update 3**: They are now also not anymore in the vote count details (when you click the vote count total). Until about a week ago this was the case.

So, something has changed?

Comment: Nice catch! So that's the cause of the mysterious inconsistencies between normalized votes and normal ones.

Comment: Perhaps a change to avoid implementing this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40665/getting-flagged-as-spam-should-appear-in-the-activity-summary ?

Comment: Does it still cost the flagged user two points?

Comment: @mmyers: [yes](http://tweakers.net/ext/f/vtzwG24DRCCs36pIiYImqJuR/full.png). The total vote count is still not reflected.. Or does it happen only after 3~4 flags? The linked answer actually went into -4 after a while. Or they were revived by a *real* downvote in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as my memory is concerned, this bug has been fixed somewhere in the last half year. Unfortunately there is no feasible fix report/confirmation which can be linked in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed that those flags are not real time anymore, a few weeks ago. May be some kind of logic changed.

**PS**: I tried on your question (its show 3 (+3/-1)), you could also try on mine too :D

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem is that it's simply not realtime anymore. FWIW: half a hour later after your flag, the total vote count is still not reflected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but maybe the delay in applying the spam flag was put there to give the Mods a chance to take a look and make sure it's a legitimate flagging?

I notice the -2 for your Rep has already been counted on your Rep graph for the flag on this question (it apparently wasn't delayed), but maybe the flagging delay causes the large -100 Rep loss for 6 flags to be postponed. I have noticed a couple of flagged and deleted posts recently that didn't *immediately* incur -100 penalties for the owner. If I recall correctly, when I first noticed that the post discussed in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47537/this-deletion-seems-capricious-and-arbitrary-to-me-help-me-understand) was deleted, it didn't have the -100 penalty yet. It showed up some time later.

Comment: If the user's reputation is updated immediately, then it sounds more like a bug.