# Are heavily downvoted answers automatically deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I remember in the question [What’s your biggest fear as a programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347190/whats-your-biggest-fear-as-a-programmer/3347353#3347353) there was one answer that got heavily downvoted because the user said something like "Having to learn .NET". Last time I checked it has somewhere around -20.

Are answers automatically deleted if they have been heavily downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers will only be automatically deleted if they are flagged 6 times as [spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work) or [offensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work). Downvoting won't delete them.

Incidentally, the answer you are asking about ([only viewable by 10k+ users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347190/whats-your-biggest-fear-as-a-programmer/3347312#3347312)) was deleted by the owner. It had 17 downvotes and 7 upvotes.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for looking at the answer, just got confused.

Comment: Why was the entire question removed? I think it was a good example of spontaneous and clever spirit of stackexchange people, closing would have been enough.