# Why was my answer deleted without any appropriate reason?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently/14419496#14419496) with 2 days old and over 200 up votes, pretty well structured and also funny* was deleted by a mod, without any appropriate reason.

Why did it take 2 days and 200+ up votes to remove my answer?

<sub>* Was the fun the reason?</sub>

---

Answer at the time deleted.

> As a [sock lover](http://www.wimp.com/dogslike/) it's difficult to compare socks, Is a red sock
>   greater or equals than a green sock? or Is a sock with fingertips
>   lower than a sock without them?
>
> I offer a set of solutions:
>
> **The mom's algorithm O(1):**
>
> 1. Get the socks
> 2. Ask mom to pair them
>
> **The lazy algorithm O(n):**
>
> 1. Keep in a bucket all the socks
> 2. And every time you need a sock just pick one O(1)
> 3. Find the other one at most O(n)
>
> **The Bucket algorithm:**
>
> 1. Enumerate each pair of sock with a number (from 1 to n)
> 2. Make a slot for each pair of socks with a number; Space: O(n)
> 3. Put each sock in the corresponding slot; Time O(1)
>
> **Naive approach:**
>
> 1. Pick a sock; Time: O(1)
> 2. Pick another sock; O(1)
> 3. If the two socks matches pair them put it a different basket
> 4. If not keep those socks in a little fast table for further requests.
>
> **"Deal with it" algorithm:**
>
> 1. Pick one sock
> 2. Pick another sock
> 3. Deal with it!
>
> **Protip**
>
> 1. Once you have remove your socks try to pair them, with a rubber band. (maybe socks with velcro)
> 2. So when you have to wash the socks it will wash and dry in pairs.
> 3. After pair them, remove the rubber band.
>
> Note: If the weather is warm enough you could avoid the use of socks
>   by wearing *sandals*.
>
> Update: [I'm also curious what kind of algorithm uses Dr. Sheldon
>   Cooper to pair socks.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkdXJroQFms)

---

Last edit

> As a sock lover it's difficult to compare socks, Is a red sock greater
>   or equals than a green sock? or Is a sock with fingertips lower than a
>   sock without them?
>
> I offer a set of solutions:
>
> **The mom's algorithm O(1):**
>
> 1. Get the socks
> 2. Ask mom to pair them
>
> *Clarification:* Yes, this is (obviously) a distributed approach, you can add workers (in this case moms) and you can get the job done
>   faster. And as a matter of fact, the truth is that my mother always
>   use this algorithm on me.
>
> **The lazy algorithm O(n):**
>
> 1. Keep in a bucket all the socks
> 2. And every time you need a sock just pick one O(1)
> 3. Find the other one at most O(n)
>
> *Clarification:* For all pairs of socks the time complexity is O(n^2), but from the human perspective (avoid all the work until is absolute
>   necessary) this approach has more appeal.
>
> **The Bucket algorithm:**
>
> 1. Enumerate each pair of sock with a number (from 1 to n)
> 2. Make a slot for each pair of socks with a number; Space: O(n)
> 3. Put each sock in the corresponding slot; Time O(1)
>
> *Clarification:* Yeah, this is a classical bucket sort. The time complexity is better if the number of socks groups is relative small,
>   compared to all the pair of socks.
>
> **Naive approach:**
>
> 1. Pick a sock; Time: O(1)
> 2. Pick another sock; O(1)
> 3. If the two socks matches pair them put it a different basket
> 4. If not keep those socks in a little fast table for further requests.
>
> **"Deal with it" algorithm:**
>
> 1. Pick one sock
> 2. Pick another sock
> 3. Deal with it!
>
> *Clarification:* This solution actually works and it's the most efficient if all the socks are equal. It also works if you are not
>   very exigent.
>
> **Protip**
>
> 1. Once you have remove your socks try to pair them, with a rubber band. (maybe socks with velcro)
> 2. So when you have to wash the socks it will wash and dry in pairs.
> 3. After pair them, remove the rubber band.
>
> *Clarification:* The trick here is why separate the socks in the first place? (yeah that is a rhetorical question) if you can always maintain
>   the pairs together.
>
> Note: If the weather is warm enough you could avoid the use of socks
>   by wearing *sandals*.
>
> *Clarification:* Another valid solution is to avoid using socks in the first place.

---

Comment: If your answer was just a joke, it was probably better for the Reddit thread and not SO

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the history of that question (nor can I see your deleted answer <10k) but I think this received quite a lot of external attention (hence the extreme popularity) and a number of non-serious answers. Perhaps that contributed?

Comment: @Bart That answer is actually many answers in one - some jokes, some serious. But none are explained in detail.

Comment: @Mysticial Well, there you go then. Then the OP should focus the answer, remove the stuff that doesn't need to be there, and flag for attention once done.

Comment: @Bart already done that part (refactor the answer) in the last edit.

Comment: Looking at that answer, by all means put some fun in your answer, but don't hide your answer within the fun.

Comment: @Bart, I think I have already done that. Add some detail in each algorithm / approach, remove all the links in the post and remove the reference to TBBT. And besides of that why it took so long to my question to be deleted?

Comment: I would not be surprised if it was part of a mass cleanup.

Comment: Maybe we need socks.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @fred Never going to happen. How would that remain constructive? What's more fiercely debated than socks?

Comment: The question has already been closed and reopened 4 times. It (and the answers) probably need some additional moderation care. And the original answer really isn't that good (just funny).

Comment: [Nothing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127467/possible-sockpuppet-whats-the-procedure#comment346551_127467) @bart. Many, many people [debate socks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127467/possible-sockpuppet-whats-the-procedure#comment346552_127467) :-).

Answer (score 4):

Mods don't usually delete answers just for the fun of it; they respond to moderator flags.

I remember in the [Proper use cases for Android UserManager.UserIsAGoat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375357/proper-use-cases-for-android-usermanager-isuseragoat) question, a number of answers got deleted because they received enough moderator flags.

The moderator in question *could* have deleted it on their own, but I suspect it had a number of moderator flags against it.

See also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77442/148949) to a related question:

> Answers can be deleted by mods for all sorts of reasons - but not very often. We don't have the time to go through looking for stuff to delete so only those posts brought to our attention will be considered.