# What does this reputation mean?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

In viewing the weekly list of rep change, I see [this entry](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2013-01-20/371342?sort=reputationchange#371342) on top:

```
razpeitia2 5 16 
member for: 2 years, 7 months link #1 week rank +8529 change 727 total reputation 2,286 week reputation
```

[image]

How can someone with 727 total have 2286 for the week with no bounties?  Call me curious.  Is this a bug or something else here?

Comment: Probably because of a deleted answer, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164570/why-was-my-answer-deleted-without-any-appropriate-reason

Comment: More pressingly, how could the reputation have increased by 8,529?

Comment: @JoeZeng: That's the ranking change, *not* a reputation increase. The previous week, razpeitia was ranked at number 8530, so he rose 8529 places compared to the previous week.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weekly rankings only list reputation changes for the week without accounting for deleted posts and other 'private' events.

The user lost reputation [for a specific highly voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164570/why-was-my-answer-deleted-without-any-appropriate-reason) when it was deleted ([deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently/14419496#14419496) in question, 10k+ users only). If you look at that user's [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371342/razpeitia?tab=reputation) no such big reputation gain is present anymore.

Comment: Ah, the removed answer that I cannot see until I get ~800 more rep points.  Makes sense now!

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: The linked Meta post has the same content; 225 votes for the post, since lost.

Comment: I guess we all need some funny socks :) so I guess the system will sort itself out eventually then.