# How does a user with 737 total reputation have 2,296 weekly reputation?

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this reputation mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164602/what-does-this-reputation-mean)

I've noticed a phenomenon that strikes me as odd.

Currently the weekly #1 spot on SO is taken by [a certain member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371342/razpeitia) who appears to have a total of 737 reputation, yet the leaderboard says s/he has 2,296 reputation for the week.

Tallying up the last 7 days of reputation on the [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371342/razpeitia?tab=reputation) of this user's profile only yields 37 points.

Is SO glitching, or is it something else?

Comment: It's Jon skeet in disguise, his rep finally overflowed!

Comment: I think this was reported. His highly up-voted answer was removed recently. So, the rep is low, but the rep change has not been updated.

Comment: I see.  That would explain it. That must have been one heckuvan answer.

Comment: Yeah, over 200 upvotes, makes you wonder what it was and why it was removed.

Comment: @MrLister: Something stupid that should have been deleted *long* before it got to that number of votes. ;P Just FYI, there are **30** deleted answers on that question. It got Redditted and the visitors from there don't care to follow our rules for posting answers.

Comment: @animuson wait... is this the isGoat question?? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently

Comment: @animuson oh my, one of **those**. OK, thanks!