# Removal of an Answer

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, specific-answer, community-standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was my answer deleted without any appropriate reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164570/why-was-my-answer-deleted-without-any-appropriate-reason)

So the thread that exploded last week on Stack Overflow about sorting socks, actually had a lot of interesting ideas on it; ideas that developers often don't consider when they are coding.

I added an entry that was somewhat comical about entropy, but no worse than a bunch of the other ones on the thread, and some dogooder came along and deleted it.

Seems completely arbitrary and counter productive. Wikimedia has ways of preventing such autocratic action. What recourse is available on SO?

Comment: To be fair. Your answer doesn't actually attempt to answer the CS question at hand.

Comment: Dude, there is no CS question: the thread is about socks. My answer says that to make a good decision about how to attack the problem, you have to consider the fact that there is a growing pool of unusable energy (entropy). This is very often the case with architectural decisions as well (ones that are not greenfield). I get your point, but removal seems stupid.

Comment: The prevention is moderator elections, rep requirements, and the requirement for multiple delete votes for non-mods.

Comment: your main mistake is likely [to think of this in terms of "thread"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/165204/1). _Stack Overflow is all about **getting answers**. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat..._ - just check the **[About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about)**

Comment: your main mistake is you are trying to make a point that the subject of this post is an obvious case in point of the untruth of your point.. ?? Hilarious. There's no chit chat. So someone got an answer to sock management? and you are happy? that I was kept from derailing that important work? If you are not serious, hilarious, if you are, uh maybe time to check dosages..

Answer (score 7):

Two-thirds of the answers posted to that question were removed.  This decision was not arbitrary and it was very productive.  Joke answers to the question belong on the reddit thread they likely came from.

Comment: You missed the point of the question: are you saying there are no joke answers left on the thread? I think that's clearly not the case. Hence use of the word 'arbitrary.'

Comment: @Rob Which answers are jokes?

Comment: mine was humorous, but not a joke, it added an element, so I am not saying 'you removed my joke, but not others.' As to what ones remain? I just went and looked and the first answer said 'first throw all your socks away then go to Walmart.' Yeah, I can see how that's much more serious and constructive than my discussion of unmatchable socks that increase over time.

Comment: @Rob Keep reading. That one does have a second answer that addresses the question.  Yours doesn't do that.

Comment: Yeah. Got it. What I thought was that since most people on that thread are developers, they would know that all machine learning algorithms account for entropy and/or error. So had I just said 'here's the algorithm, including the entropy control portion' that would have passed.