# Does any other one can delete user's answer?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-answers

I want to know does any other one can delete a user's answer?

and if Yes, How much reputation is needed?

delete directly? or vote to delete?

I think the question is more important than answers. So 10k or moderators need to have the privilege to delete answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

**10000**   Vote to delete closed questions, access to moderation tools

**20000**   Vote to delete negatively voted answers and stronger question deletion votes

I also think users with above 10k or moderators can delete other's answers too. Some moderator or 10k user needs to confirm.

Comment: Yes, I also think that is unreasonable. the question is more important than answers. So 10k or moderators need to have the privilege to delete answers.

Comment: @Roy: But questions need to be closed first. That's already where it gets established that the question shouldn't be here.

Answer (score 3):

From reputation section of the Stack Overflow [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> 2000   Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits
>
> 3000   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
>
> 10000  Vote to delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
>
> 20000  Vote to delete negatively voted answers and stronger question deletion votes

These are all "vote to delete" conditions which requires other users to agree and vote before action is taken (5 votes).  Moderators ♦ are the only people that can directly and immediately delete content.

For more info, please see the [Vote to Close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) and [Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege information pages.

Posts can also be removed if a post is flagged as [spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work) or [offensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work) repetitively.