# Who have the privilege to delete others' comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

After the comment be deleted, will the owner's reputation reduce? If so, reduce how much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comment will be auto-deleted if it gets enough spam/offensive/noise flags; Mods (users with ♦) can delete others' comments, too.

Comments **do not** affect reputation, even if deleted - [see this FAQ answer for a longer explanation on comment votes and flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365).

Comment: Wasn't there a punishment if it gets deleted by flags?

Comment: @Bobby: Not on comments - see the link in my edit. There is an auto-penalty if your question or answer gets flag-deleted, you may be thinking of that.

Comment: correct on all counts

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that...I didn't know that answers/questions could get flag-deleted, too.

Comment: @Bobby: If enough people mark them as spam/offensive, yes. See these: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work/22175#22175 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work/58035#58035