# What happens to the downvote an offensive flag imposes if the flag expires?

Tags: discussion, flags, offensive

In [How does the “rude or abusive” flag work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work) I found 2 rules that may conflict:

1. Each offensive flag counts **as a downvote** for calculating the post's score.
2. As offensive flags **expire** after 48 hours if the thresholds aren't reached.

When a question or an answer is flagged as offensive, less than 6 times in 48 hours, and the flags expire, what will happen to the down-votes? Are they kept or removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules don't really conflict, there's just some missing information about what "expire" means in this context.

To answer your specific question, when a flag expires the downvote that it expresses against a post is removed.

As a side note I believe that it is possible for a user to both downvote a post *and* place an offensive flag against it, meaning a score adjustment of -2. This will revert to -1 if the flag then expires.

Comment: the downvote that caused by offensive flags will not reduce any score.

Comment: @Roy, I don't understand what you mean, especially since 擦 isn't rendered on my machine...?

Comment: just a mistake.

Comment: @Roy, yes it will. If you flag a post as offensive then then post's score is reduced by 1, it adds a "virtual downvote" against the post. It's these "virtual downvotes" that are removed if the flag expires.