# Why does flagging history display "spam flag count" separately

Tags: discussion, spam, flag-history

Just wondering what was/is the reason to separately display "posts marked spam" in the flagging history. Could it be that "spam flags" carry different weight? Or I guess "spam" on SO is so rare that it calls for a separate count.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spam and offensive flags have effects on the flagged user if enough of them accumulate.

[What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work)

[How does the “rude or abusive” flag work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work)

A benefit of the separate counts on the summary page is so you know how often you're using them.

However, the information's not *immensely* valuable, I suppose; a valid flag is a valid flag, and how many you have shouldn't affect how often you do it, as long as you're flagging appropriately.