# Dismissal of spam and offensive flags (the moderator's perspective)

Tags: feature-request, spam, moderator-tools, flags, offensive

There's a post that has a [spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work) or [offensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work) flag. These flags are pretty serious, since if they're validated by the community or by a moderator, they carry a -100 penalty to the poster's reputation.

As a moderator, I had expected that deleting the post would validate the flag, and carry out the reputation penalty — just like deleting the post would dismiss other flags such as “not an answer” or “very low quality” as valid.

As it turns out¹, deleting the answer does not dismiss any pending spam/offensive flag. The flag is merely hidden (and reappears if the post is undeleted). To validate the spam/offensive flag, I need to cast one myself, instead of deleting the post.

I find this behavior surprising: I wouldn't have guessed that deleting the post didn't validate the flag until I was explicitly told so. I would prefer for this behavior to be changed, so that deleting a post flagged as spam/offensive does validate the flag.

However, this does raise the issue of posts that have both a not-an-answer or very-low-quality and a spam or offensive flag, when the post is deletion-worthy but not spam or offensive (it's just a nonsensical, off-topic or should-have-been-a-comment post). There should be a way to invalidate the spam/offensive flags while not invalidating the not-an-answer/very-low-quality flags.

My request is twofold:

- I would prefer for deletion to validate the spam/offensive flag, with a way to specifically invalidate the flags if they are not warranted. If it doesn't, then please permit casting a spam/offensive flag from the moderator dashboard.
- In any case, the guidance that appears to moderators should clearly document how to handle the three scenarios:

  - the post is spam/offensive → currently: the moderator must flag the post as spam/offensive (this can't be done from the dashboard)
  - the post should be deleted but is not spam/offensive → currently: just delete the post
  - the post shouldn't be deleted → dismiss the flags

For reference, this is the guidance that currently appears next to spam/offensive flags:

> Posts flagged as offensive or spam do not necessarily require action!
>
> If any post reaches 6 flags, it is automatically removed from the system.
>
> Flags will automatically and harmlessly age away after 2 days if they fail to reach the threshold in that time.

¹  <sub>[TL ref](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2071651#2071651) (♦ only)</sub>

<sub>*(Note that I completely rewrote this post, because it turns out that my expectations as to what would happen were wildly off the mark.)*</sub>

Comment: Out of curiosity, you're unable to dismiss flags on it's own, only allf lags at once?

Comment: Declaring the flags helpful should not cause the -100 rep penalty, only enough offensive flags or a binding flag should do that.

Comment: The offensive flag auto-resolves when you user your binding flag, which is how I would deal with a valid offensive flagged post. The "helpful" dialog for flags is for dismissing the flag if no further action is needed. I wouldn't expect it to do anything.

Comment: @Fabian I expected that deleting the answer would validate the offensive flag, but in fact only casting an offensive flag myself would do. I've rewritten my post to request a better UI and a better documentation.

Comment: Or maybe: don't allow for deleting posts (in the moderator interface) while there's still a pending spam/offensive flag?

Comment: This behaviour was fixed [a while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119723/160166)...

Comment: @yoda Was it? Thanks for the heads up. You should post an answer then :)

Comment: Hmm... hold on to that. Although Marc's answer says it has been fixed (and in the discussion in [comments here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119779/160166)), I've not been able to reproduce the behaviour Marc describes on my gardening sandbox post. But then, [there are other problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126636/160166) with gardening (possibly several beta sites), so I'll just ping Marc and check on the status before posting an answer