# Aren't moderators eligible for the Deputy and Marshal badges too, or has it changed?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges, moderators, flags

I've been, *ahem*, farming spam/offensive flags due to a [bug related to *handling* spam/offensive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109100/im-not-gaining-flag-weight-for-my-spam-flags) (which has since been fixed). In doing so, I noticed I haven't received the Marshal badge, despite having:

- 139 helpful moderator flags
- 355 helpful spam flags
- 21 helpful offensive flags
- 7 helpful comment flags

Which add up to 522. It should qualify, but I still don't have it after a week. For what it's worth, I wasn't a moderator yet when I received the Deputy badge.

Bill the Lizard was a moderator before the Deputy and Marshal badges were introduced. He got Marshal using [spam/offensive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119779/137537) anyway, but the same doesn't appear to be happening for me.

As far as I can tell, spam-flagging posts marks them as handled by the community user, so they should count toward the badges regardless of *my* mod status. Or did something change as part of the aforementioned fix?

Comment: As [a member](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127479/why-would-or-when-should-a-moderator-make-a-question-anonymous) of the official [Meta Moderator Oversight Team](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127466/question-disowned-by-author-moderator), you realize I must now open up a question about moderators abusing their power to game the flag system and gain badges, right?

Comment: I can sell you a marshal badge, how bad do you want it?

Comment: I get the undertone here, but really; why should moderators even have the option to flag posts? It violates trust and (since they have the "hammer" on whether flags should be accepted or not) as such should not be able to unwieldy swing it around. It seems appropriate that you should not have had the honor of "wearing" the badge that I (all too recently) acquired. Shame on you for doing as much work as me. ;)

Comment: _Please forgive the previous comment that was nearly as long as your question as it was not meant to be either spam or offensive._

Comment: @M.Babcock: What's the big deal about flags? Yes, for a moderator, the flag votes are binding, but that's the same as all of their other votes. Is there really a difference when it comes to the abuse rhetoric (all that hammer swingin') between them choosing to flag or just hitting delete? They have the same effect.

Comment: @TheEstablishment - Not being a mod on any of the SE sites I can't say for certain, however, based on my understanding doing so taints the record of _who_ signed-off on the flag thus possibly leading to confusion of other moderators who have to answer when the flag is questioned (Less formally... it was my sad attempt at humor).

Comment: I'll go with the humor thing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - It was a very poor attempt at making a joke of something apparently _all too serious_.

Comment: It's not that serious.  If it were serious, we'd have fixed it in the system by now.  We are, after all, talking about spammers and offensive people.  It's not like they don't deserve it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I agree completely. It must've really been a bad joke then to not be recognized as such (across 2 comments and all).

Comment: @Robert Harvey: That was the basis of all 600+ spam and 40+ offensive flags I've ever raised, before and after I became a mod. Well, that, *and* the badge.

Comment: @BoltClock - I do wonder though... is the badge worth that much to you? Or is the position just not worth it?

Comment: @M.Babcock: Frankly, I don't have a good answer to either question. When I was writing this question I was asking myself the same thing. "Did I really just farm spam flags to gain a gold badge?"

Comment: @BoltClock - Of course then again, you are _"on the record"_. I probably shouldn't expect a different response.

Comment: Just for the record, I don't actually see this as abuse or inappropriate. Heck, the moderators should probably *earn* Deputy and Marshal badges for the flags they process... And like Robert says: they're spammers. So wut.

Comment: @M.Babcock: There is one legitimate use for mods raising their own flags: they can flag their own post so that another mod can look at it.

Comment: @BoltClock - Good point, and it sounds like a _valid_ reason to introduce a special exception into the logic. That said, don't moderator's know more than Jon Skeet? If not then why isn't he one?

Comment: @The Establishment: Nice idea.

Comment: @M.Babcock: I think Jon once said that he's more interested in answering questions than handling flags :)

Comment: I don't see what the big deal is with moderators raising flags. Internally spam/offensive are votes, and moderator votes are binding. If they just outright delete a spam post, they're effectively rescuing the perpetrator from the penalties (-100 rep, and probably a big factor in the automatic post ban).

Comment: As a moderator I've flagged a couple times -- once as spam/offensive because I didn't know if the poster would get the penalty if I just deleted (there were other flags already), and once as the easiest way to get another mod to reconsider something he had posted.

Comment: Since posting my last comment I've increased my use of flagging as a mod.  It was pointed out to me that a flag creates an audit trail, while if I just delete something there's no reason on record.  If somebody questions it later, I'll have to try to remember.  So I, for example, clean up comment conversations via flags (unless purging all comments).  And no badge yet, though I was under the impression I couldn't earn one so that doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These flags do count towards the badges when appropriately dismissed as helpful, but moderators aren't eligible to receive either Deputy or Marshal badges [according to Geoff Dalgas](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1252/1193):

> The Deputy and Marshal badges are only granted to registered users - not moderators.

Comment: What happens when a user is no longer a moderator?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard They will be awarded the badges if they're eligible for them.

Comment: Moderators meaning 10K users or just diamond users?

Comment: @fedorqui Just diamond moderators.

Comment: Thanks @AnnaLear, I just updated the [Marshall description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) to reflect that.

Comment: So apparently moderators aren't registered users? That's ironic :-P

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, only your 139 helpful moderator flags count for the badge; that is true for moderators as for the normal users.
That is what happen since January 20, when the flag weight has been replaced with useful flags.

It seems moderators cannot obtain any badge for the number of helpful flags: I have more than 500 helpful flags, but I don't have the Marshal badge. I am referring to the "moderation attention" flags, and to the number shown as, "deemed helpful."

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case; if it were so, Bill the Lizard wouldn't have received the badge. See his post that I link to.

Comment: Did Bill the Lizard get the badge before January 20?

Comment: Yes, he did. Maybe the requirements did change since then.

Comment: Unless that has changed, the number of helpful flags is mod flags + spam votes + offensive votes + comment flags deemed helpful.

Comment: @lunboks In that case, I would have two badges on _Drupal Answers_, but I have just one.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation has been changed early this year.

In the old implementation (the visible flag weight era), these flags did count. In the new situation only the helpful flags count.

But if you got the badge during the old implementation, it isn't taken away.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant - spam/offensive flags can still be dismissed as helpful and a moderator using them marks them helpful pretty much by default.