# Moderator's close votes are not instantaneous on beta sites' meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, moderator-tools

Voting to close does not close it instantly for the "Off topic" and "Not a real question" close reasons — it merely casts a vote and also allows one to keep casting more than the maximum of 5 needed to actually close. The vote chain is broken and closed only if a different reason is chosen. This behaviour has been reproduced on [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/261/revisions) and [Digital Signal Processing](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/97/revisions). Possibly, the same bug as [this classic](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5335632/revisions). Screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

Now that's one crazy moderator!

Comment: You have failed. Into exile, you must go! On a more seeerious note, I couldn't reproduce on crypto meta. Nofair :( But perhaps that means they've fixed it?

Comment: Also don't believe we've seen this on bio :)

Comment: The image looks like the lyrics to my favorite Weird Al song.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to only be the case when the Community user owns the post.

The Community user tries to give itself a downvote because of the NARQ/OT close reasons and this causes an error and the mod close to fail, but registers the close vote.

Because this only seems to happen on posts owned by Community which are quite rare it is a rather edgy edge case.

Comment: This was correct. (:  A fix has been pushed to handle this case.

Comment: How did a post even get created by Community?

Comment: @BenBrocka Community wiki.

Comment: @AnnaLear No, not true. In this case, I created the post and got rchern to transfer ownership so that I don't get pinged

Comment: @yoda That's the other option. I was just giving one example... I probably should've been clearer about that. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Even when it is CW, it is not technically "owned" by Community, is it? Only the votes are eaten up by it... the badges, accept stat, bounties, all go to the original poster.

Comment: @yoda Fair point. I might misremember/misunderstand.