# My flag declined but question closed by other moderators

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, offensive

> [image]

I am a frequent user of Stack Overflow and when I see questions that does not belong to Stack Overflow I flag them with respective flags.

Today, I came across [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171069/option-to-add-a-note-about-a-friend-acquaintance-in-facebook) and flagged it but the moderator who reviewed my flag declined it. But sometime later another moderators closed the question.

What is wrong here?

Comment: It's off-topic, but it's not offensive. Did I miss something?

Comment: Well, it was declined because you flagged it as "offensive," not "off topic," which makes your flag incorrect. Did you misread the flag dialog?

Comment: Do you know the meaning of "offensive"? Please don't flag if you don't understand the meaning of it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You comment is a bit offensive, in my opinion.

Comment: @dystroy might be, but I can't think of any other reason (except simple ignorance) why he chose "offensive" flag. And this flag should not be used so lightly.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I totally agree with you. Please note that my last comment was partly a miserable try at being humorous. Won't retry :(

Comment: See also this topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You flagged the post as **offensive** where there was nothing remotely offensive in the question. This [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work) shows when it is appropriate to use the offensive flag:

> Even if a post is a bad post for some reason or other, it is probably not offensive. The Offensive flag is meant to be used only in extreme cases, like hate speech, or abuse.
>
> For example, if a user posts obscene images to the site, that should be flagged as offensive. But if someone says something bad about your favorite technology, that probably doesn't apply.
>
> As a rule of thumb, if you can't justify something as being hate speech, or abuse, you shouldn't mark the post as offensive. Instead, you should down-vote the post.
>
> When you decide to flag a post Offensive, you will get a warning dialog. Take this time to decide if the post is really offensive.

You had already flagged for ♦ moderator attention with a custom reason as off topic, which was marked as helpful, it was simply the offensive flag that was incorrect and superfluous.

It may save you time in future to know that there is a pre-written flag reason for off-topic questions:

1. Flag
2. It doesn't belong here, or is duplicate
3. Off Topic

Comment: Also, there's a reason why this Meta question is currently being highlighted in the Community Bulletin: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work?cb=1 . We've had way too many people flagging things lately as spam and offensive which really aren't.