# Could someone explain why the specific question has been deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Why was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948788/java-multi-inheritance-confusing/) deleted?

---

According to https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

> Why are some questions or answers removed?
>
> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.

The specific question was **on topic**. It was definitely not *high quality*, but **very low quality** seems a bit harsh in this case.

---

In addition, according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/209087

> 1. **You** can typically delete your own posts at will; for exceptions, see "When *can't* I delete my own post?" below. To delete a post, just use the "delete" link below it.
> 2. **Moderators** can delete any post.
> 3. **Users with reputation >= 10k** (more precisely, the [“moderator tools” privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools); 2k on beta sites) can vote to delete *questions* that have been [closed][1] for 48 hours. It takes three votes to delete; [more if the question is popular][2], but ten votes at most.
> 4. **Users with reputation >= 20k** (more precisely, the [“trusted user” privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools); 4k on beta sites) are not subject to the 48-hour waiting period for deleting closed questions. They may also delete *answers* of score -1 or lower. It takes three votes to delete.
> 5. [**The system**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) will automatically delete any post [flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work-in-stackoverflow) six times as offensive or spam.
> 6. **The system** will automatically delete [unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).
> 7. **The system** will automatically delete [unlocked, unanswered questions with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after a 365 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).
> 8. **The system** will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a score less than 0 when its owner's account is deleted.
> 9. **The system** will automatically delete questions migrated to other sites [after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082).

In this case, only reasons **2, 4,** and **5** are possible (although it was clearly *not spam* and I cannot see how it was offensive).

---

I am interested to know the **reason** and the **process** that it was **deleted**, and if there is anything that can be done to **undelete** it.

*FULL DISCLOSURE: I lost 50 rep from the deletion (which is a big amount for a noob like me)*

Comment: Apart from the deletion, your answer did not really answer the question (which was "why?").

Comment: Sure, it was not the best possible answer, but it did get upvoted...

Comment: I'd disagree entirely with your statement that "very low quality seems a bit harsh in this case." The question is practically unreadable, poorly formatted, barely on-topic, shows no research effort, etc etc. There are multiple close reasons that would apply, it received 8 downvotes (and 1 upvote somehow); it's about as bad as questions get, to be honest.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist These are reasons to close a question. Are they also reasons to delete it?

Comment: Yes; If it's closed, it is subject to being deleted if it is not improved quickly.

Comment: @user000001 Yes, since there's absolutely no gain to the community in keeping questions that are so low quality. I understand that you want your rep back (that honestly seems to be the only reason you care about this), but when you answer a question like that you run the risk that it will disappear (as it should). To be frank, I'm surprised your answer got as many upvotes as it did since you didn't actually answer the question at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: It was deleted for the same reason it was closed; Since it was closed and was not improved, three 20k+ community members voted to delete it.

Here's the text of the question:

> as we know that java dose not support multi Inheritance but i read in books that every class you are created extend from the class Named (Object) by default so it's not confusing that they lie about us and what's the if it dose inherent from it .. why the make it not support from other classes?!....am instructor and one of my student ask me this question and really i think he was right..

Your first claim about this question:

> The specific question was on topic.

Not according to [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) it isn't:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

It's not practical, really.

Also, I think 'Not Constructive' and 'Not a Real Question' would have counted as valid close reasons. (Not Constructive was, in fact, the close reason that won the close votes)

As for *how* it got deleted, you missed the two relevant items in your list:

- Users with reputation >= 10k (more precisely, the “moderator tools” privilege; 2k on beta sites) can vote to delete questions that have been [closed][1] for 48 hours. It takes three votes to delete; [more if the question is popular][2], but ten votes at most.
- Users with reputation >= 20k (more precisely, the “trusted user” privilege; 4k on beta sites) are not subject to the 48-hour waiting period for deleting closed questions. They may also delete answers of score -1 or lower. It takes three votes to delete.

Comment: I am not asking why it was closed, but why it was deleted.

Comment: It was deleted for the *same reason it was closed*; after being closed, it was not fixed, so it gets deleted.

Comment: It was deleted in less than 48 hours, so the first bullet does not apply. I included the second bullet as a possible explanation in my question. I was interested to know if it was a moderator or by votes to delete.

Comment: @user000001 Three people voted to delete it.

Comment: `"it was not fixed, so it gets deleted"` So if I edit it a bit, could it get undeleted?

Comment: @user000001 I can't possibly imagine how you could edit that question to make it a useful question, without changing its meaning.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanx

Comment: @user000001: once a question has been deleted, chances for it being undeleted are *very* slim. If you could fix a question after it gets closed, it could very well be re-opened. In this specific case, however, the question is inherently bad, so no amount of editing would fix it (as Andrew noted).