# Is it fair to an active user that you don't let them delete their question by themselves if it is an uncomfortable one?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, deleted-questions

I posted an uncomfortable question that many people down- and upvote and the consequences are:

1. it gets closed by someone
2. it got 30 downvotes
3. I want to delete it by myself
4. it is deleted by someone.
5. I got a 100 reputation penalty.

My question is:

Is it fair if many people want to get all of someone's property by vote? Is it true Stack Overflow is using this rule to manage other users' reputations, questions and answers.

**I feel upset, please inform me and let me delete it by myself if anything uncomfortable.**

I am not only a user but also an active participant. I feel many people get too many privileges.

My deleted question is specific clue. It is my fault, but I want to know. The majority can alway judge the minority, I think it is a rude rule. Do you agree with the rule?

Comment: And if we left the choice of deletion solely up to the OP, do you think everyone would heed the advice to delete? =)

Comment: When a downvoted question gets deleted, you get back the reputation you lost from the downvotes. The 100 reputation penalty means that your question accumulated a few spam or offensive flags. If that's what happened, then I think "uncomfortable" isn't really an accurate description.

Comment: Your question was really off-topic. It is better suited for a doctor.

Comment: `SO took back my 100 reputaitons without informing me for my **funny** non-programming question`.  You have a weird definition of "funny".

Comment: Is it true that the majority get the truth. and can decide the minority>

Comment: Why would you even *think* that posting a **non-programming** question on Stack Overflow would be a good idea in the first place?

Comment: I know it is not good quesiton. can i delete it by myself?

Comment: @HenryLeu - as long as there are no upvoted answers, you can delete the question. It's better to *think* before posting the question, however.

Comment: I like this site, and I spent much time helping others and finding answers. I just want to tell people. only judging by votes is not enough to a health and professional q&a site. people needs humor and relaxation and emotional factors

Comment: **From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask):** "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."  It's as simple as that.

Comment: @HenryLeu: the rest of us like this site because it's a good place to get answers for programming questions, because the useless garbage is quickly removed. You're proposing leaving the useless garbage for longer. "I'll remove this if it gets 40 downvotes" means, to me, "I don't care about the community at all and want to waste at least 40 people's time."

Comment: @HenryLeu: humor and relaxation and emotional factors are all well and good. Be we don't want them mixed up with our technical Q&A. [SO] (and [SE] in general) is a very focused community.

Comment: *Hmm* I'm *really* tempted to vote to delete this question...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your question was flagged as offensive, so you therefore lost your 100 rep.

As for deletions, we as a community can't expect to wait for users to realise their question is unsuitable and delete it themselves. In most cases, that **NEVER** happens (people often oppose the decision).

Judging by the question, to say it was off topic is an **incredible** understatement. If you really want to know the answer though, you should sign up to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and commit to either the [HealthCare](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47600/health-care), [Relationships and Dating](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating), or [Sexuality](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40921/human-sexuality) proposals, maybe they'll be able to answer it.

Comment: OK, I 've got SO's rule. I am practical active programmer so i spent my 100 reputation to prove a thing. it 's worth for me. Can i delete this question by myself. Do i have this right to do?

Comment: I don't have any rights to do anything. thanks for all your attention.

Comment: @HenryLeu As an active user, you deliberately asked a question that was against the rules.  Not only against the rules, but *offensively* so.  You paid the price for it.  You have the same rights as everyone else.  It does not override other user's rights, which was to flag it as offensive.  What you're wanting is to circumvent the penalty enacted by the community.  Actions have consequences.

Answer (score 40):

Your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540384/if-coders-sit-long-and-impact-sex-capability-is-true) read, in full:

> ### If ( Coders sit long and impact sex capability ) is true?
>
> I want to know if coder can kid here technically. if not, i will delete this quesiton. it's boring afternoon.

You accumulated at least 6 offensive flags with that post, enough for it to be deleted *automatically* by the Community user and for you to be given the -100 reputation penalty. See [How does the “rude or abusive” flag work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work)

I suspect that you didn't realize this, but apart from the post being *widely* off-topic, your question title uses language that can be seen as offensive to native English speakers.

You were waiting for the post to reach 40 downvotes. You should have deleted it *without waiting so long*, you were being given *clear* signals through the rapid accumulation of downvotes that your post was not appropriate.

Your question was ill-advised, yet you persisted in leaving it in place. Even worse, you thought it fun to see if the question would reach 40 downvotes, practically *demanding* that the community waste their time on your post. Next time, please do check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) before posting.

Comment: It probably attracted offensive flags rather than spam flags

Comment: @0A0D I'm also not a native English speaker, but I don't end my posts with "it's boring afternoon". (but my comment was snarky, so... gone)

Comment: @Yannis: "immature" non-English speaker then

Comment: @0A0D I'm immature and I have the diamond to prove it ;)

Comment: I 've seen a closed question which is closed by "not constructive or not real quesiton". I think that is very good quesiton. I just want to know why this happens. do we have a nicer approach to questions so called 'offensive'

Comment: @HenryLeu: Even reworded to use more appropriate language, the question is completely off-topic for Stack Overflow. I am not aware of any Stack Exchange site where it *would* be on-topic.

Comment: @HenryLeu, Stack Overflow is not a forum. If you want to engage in forum-like behaviors, find an appropriate forum that allows you to post supposedly "funny" time-filler questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: well, if worded more carefully and backed with actual claims, [skeptics.SE] might take it on ;-)

Comment: I just want to delete it by myself. it is not alway good to judge something by vodes and the majority who have much privileges

Comment: @HenryLeu: well, the community wishes something else. The community wishes to be able to get rid of content it does not agree with. And it does. Deal with it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - please tell me you are joking and that wasn't the question. Please. Even if it isn't true. Please.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: I wish it were so. Luckily the SO community dealt with it appropriately.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: Nope, that was the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - URGH. And someone wonder why it disappeared so quickly? OOOOOOK, I will exercise my right to refuse to comment -_-...

Answer (score 24):

> I feel upset, please inform me and let me delete it by myself if anything unconfortable.

We *did* inform you. You had ample opportunity to delete the question yourself. You had *over 20 minutes* to do it before it was locked and deleted. The question did not go from 0 to -29 in one split second, and you were participating in the comment trail the entire time the question was visible.

If you were actively engaged in your question, you had more than enough time to recognize the fact that the community was telling you your question was "uncomfortable," as you would say, or just completely inappropriate for Stack Overflow.