# Keep negative score for offensive deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, spam, offensive

When someone posts something offensive, in a responsible community they get a flood of downvotes before someone can swoop in and delete their post.  Then, the reputation loss from the downvotes is reversed after the post is deleted.

I think the person who posted offensive material (or spam) should be punished, and since I don't know his/her address and can't show up at his/her house with an itching-powder coated paddle, the least we could do is stick him with his reputation loss.

I assume it would be possible to do this without keeping the penalty to those who downvoted - if that isn't possible, cancel the whole suggestion.

Comment: If six people flag it as "spam" or "offensive" (or one moderator), then the user is dealt a 100 rep penalty.

Comment: @hichris123 I wasn't aware of that (I haven't yet been that offensive).  That pretty much addresses my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Case study: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172870/is-it-fair-to-active-users-can-you-kindly-tell-me-and-let-me-delete-it-by-mysel where a user complained about the penalty.

Answer (score 17):

As noted in a comment, a post removed via spam/offensive flags [carries a 100-rep penalty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/162102).  Sadly, in my experience most of the time this doesn't matter because such posts tend to come from throwaway accounts, but every now and then you see this sort of bad behavior from accounts that have reputation to lose, and in those cases, they lose it.

Answer (score 7):

People posting offensive account that gets downvoted and deleted *are still punished*. The reputation loss from user downvotes may be reversed, but their deleted post still carries a negative score, which will count against them towards a post ban, if they continue to be trouble makers.

Of course, if someone is repeatedly posting inappropriate content, a moderator will most likely step in and suspend the problem account anyways.