# Proper behavior for revision war over spam post

Tags: support, spam

What is the proper behavior for a person that repeatedly reverts his post to spam.

[URL as name is offensive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16600438/1890567) (Deleted now)

I have flagged it for moderator attention and flagged it as spam. Should I just leave it like that? Or should I continue reverting the post until it is deleted?

Comment: The "Is it really necessary to use jquery" comment kind of made my day.

Comment: I wouldn't really bother tug-of-war'ing the user. It's dutiful of you but SE is good at defending against this kind of crap right now (largely via mods).  If it were impossible much of the internet wouldn't have happened.

Comment: I wonder how come it didn't get [enough offensive flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22175/167534) to be auto-deleted.

Comment: @bfavaretto From looking at the post flag history, it looks like it *did* get at least 6 offensive flags on the post, as well as some on comments, at one or two 'spam' flags on the post. I wonder why it remained, too. Anyway, I deleted it (and the user) as soon as I saw them.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Maybe you should post a bug report about it -  or can mods flag for dev attention? :-)

Comment: @bfavaretto I'm escalating that particular item now :)

Comment: @djechlin I agree; that comment was kind of hilarious sitting there. Alas; it was a response to the original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flagging was the proper action. I understand your desire to try to keep something so offensive off of the site, but in that case, the troll was obviously dedicated to keeping it there, so only moderator action could kill it.

Normally, once a post collects six offensive flags, it should be auto-deleted.

In this case, the rollback 'war' is what caused the flags to be considered reverted. This is another reason it's best to just let the content be, as is, and let the system/mods handle it.

For more information on the reverting of spam flags (which applies to Offensive flags, too) due to rolling back, [See "Is there any way to remove spam flags" on this FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/152134)

Comment: Maybe because it was edited so much? Just a guess...

Comment: @Seth That could be it. I'm going to be bumping an old post on a similar topic shortly.

Comment: @Seth Which raises another question: shouldn't it have become community wiki also?

Comment: @bfavaretto Well I didn't get to see it and I don't have 10k on [so].. so I can't say much.

Comment: @bfavaretto I think we hit 40 revisions. I thought it was supposed to become a community wiki around 12.

Comment: @FDinoff Yup; it was over 40. 43, actually.

Comment: @FDinoff Follow-up; I suspect that rollbacks may not count as revisions for the purpose of becoming community wiki. There were actually only 3 edits on the post. The rest were rollbacks.