# Rollback, resetting any offensive votes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, rollbacks, tooltips

Is it the case that if a rollback is performed on an older version of a post we lose all the votes that took place between the current version and older?

Also, what is the meaning of the message "offensive votes"?

> sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any offensive votes

Screenshot:

[image: Rollback Tooltip Message]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work

Comment: As stated in the post mentioned by AsheeshR *"Rolling back a post to a previous state will revert to the number of offensive flags from that particular revision. This allows the OP (or someone else with edit rights) to rollback a post that someone else made offensive in a later revision."*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> we lose all the votes that took place between the current version and
>   older?

No that is not the case. Type and count of votes remain unchanged. Only the text/content of the post is reverted to the older version.

The message that you have mentioned is a bit misleading though. I think it should say:

> sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any offensive flags

So instead of **offensive votes** it should be **offensive flags**

Update:

Tooltip text has been **changed**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is clearer now!

Comment: The system, for some weird reason, treats offensive flags as votes internally. The misleading phrasing is a case of a technical detail spilling into the UI.

Comment: @Yannis The flagging refactoring that's Soon-To-Be-Deployed corrects that, so I'll pass this along to the devs to correct the wording on this tooltip as well.