# When and why was the "offensive" flag renamed?

Tags: discussion, flags, offensive

In researching an answer for our local meta, I noticed that all the answers here <sup>[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22174/278094), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/278094)</sup> reference "*it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech*" (how I remember the flag); however the flag is now called "*rude or abusive*."
Why did this change back in [April *and* May](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247647/278094) of 2015?

Comment: [renamed in April 2015, for reasons laid out at MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290915/839601)