# Flagging a post for moderator review

Tags: support, faq, flags, moderators

Suppose I want to have someone with moderator abilities review a post. What would be the best way to flag this?

Is there already some standard way to do this that I don't know about?

> For more information, see "[What if I see someone doing something bad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)" in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help).

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work)

Answer (score 24):

This is achieved with the [moderator flags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/14/improved-flagging/), which any user with the [flag posts privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) (15 rep) can cast. All users can use these on their *own* posts, regardless of their reputation. Just click "flag":

> [image: Flagging link]

Next, select "in need of moderator intervention", and tell us why:

> [image: Flag dialog]

Typical reasons are discussed in [What are acceptable reasons for flagging as “Requires Moderator attention”?](/q/10848/)

If unsure or not having enough reputation, you can also just [ask here on Meta](/questions/ask).