# Is it possible to move a Closed Question

Tags: support, migration

This question was closed as not on topic

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018/best-book-for-a-new-database-developer

Which looking back I agree (although when ask other sites did not exist).

However It think it would be more useful to move it to programmers or dba site however now it is closed it cannot be voted to be moved.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [flag the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-question-for-moderator-review) for moderator attention and request migration.

Having said that, I doubt your request will be considered because the question is more of list/poll question) is off-topic on both the sites.

Comment: I can see your point about the poll. Thanks