# Added bounty to the wrong question

Tags: support, bounties, cancel

I've added bounty to the wrong question (not mine).

Is there any way to cancel the bounty if I made it only minutes ago?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not by yourself. However, you can [flag the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24560/133693) for Moderator attention and mention that you want to cancel the bounty (and provide the reason too), Moderators can take a look and choose to refund the bounty.

Note that in most cases moderators are reluctant to revoke bounties that've been active for more than a short time: it cheapens the meaning of them if they can disappear without warning. Also, moderators cannot revoke bounties that've already been awarded.