# Ask questions posted in other Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, cross-posting

Is there a way to link a previously asked question in other stack-exchange sites, which can be re-asked in yet another stack-exchange site?

For example, I have asked a question in [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) and after waiting for say one month of unfruitful time, no one answers the question. Now I want to ask the same question to [Stack Exchange](http://www.stackexchange.com)'s community.

Is there a way to do that easily, except form manually copy pasting the entire question?

If not!  I believe, we need such a method, so as to have a cross collaboration.

I know that migration is possible. But that needs moderator. "I" as the questioner, cannot do that on my own.

Comment: I think it's a good thing that the questioner cannot do that. Oh, the horror if they were allowed to!

Answer (score 2):

You're right that you can't migrate on your own, but you can request that a question be migrated if it would be better on another site by just [flagging it for mod attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review). If it's already right on the site it's on they probably won't move it though, and you can't ask questions on http://stackexchange.com; that page is just showing hot questions from all the sites on the network, it doesn't actually host any itself:

[image: Screenshot highlighting the source sites]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a good idea. If your question is unanswered on Super User, then you could place a bounty on it. If it's a really good unanswered question, someone *else* might place a bounty on it.

The highest density of Stack Exchangers interested in Super User-related questions will be *on* Super User. Moving it somewhere else (unless it is really applicable in both places) will probably make it off-topic.

Migration is for when something is off-topic in its original location of posting, but would be on-topic elsewhere, not the other way around.

In short, if the question belongs on Super User, there's no point in moving it somewhere else.

Comment: there are topics which straddles the boundry of multiple stackexchange sites.

Comment: @VineetMenon Yes, but allowing users this functionality would most likely result in a bunch of unnecessary migrations.