# Avoiding asking a question that's already been asked

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions, old-questions

Someone else has already asked a question about the exact same problem that I am having.
Unfortunately, the question does not have an answer yet. Follow-on questions to the original poster have gone unanswered. How do I get an answer to that question?

I can't upvote the question unless I have 15 reputation.

I don't have an answer to the question (yet), although I do have some more information about my particular instance of that problem that may lead to an answer. I don't see how to just comment on the question.

What choice do I have other than to start a new post with the same question (and be responsive when anyone replies)?

Comment: Can you link to the original question?

Comment: Well, one way is doing exactly this - getting attention here on Meta. Somebody with lots of reputation on the main site might be kind enough to start a bounty on that question to draw more attention; after all this is for the good of the community. For this however you'll have to post link to the original question, as @cadrell0 also asked. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841172/foo-class-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-on-super-dealloc

Comment: Specifically I want to resolve my problem (the same problem that was asked in the link above). In general, I want to know how to handle a similar issue in the future, i.e.: a) I can't upvote, b) I don't have an answer (yet), c) People probably don't want me to ask the same question again.

Comment: Usually, people who ask about this topic get directed to [this FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions). The first tip doesn't apply because you're not the original OP, and you don't qualify for the second tip because you don't even have enough rep to upvote, so you're kind of stuck.

Comment: If there was more activity on the original, I would try to salvage that.  However, it doesn't have much detail and the OP appears to have abandoned it.  I would probably go ahead and post a new question.

Comment: The linked question is not worthy of an bounty IMO, it contains too little details and the OP has not provided the details that has been requested in comments and the only answer. I'd say you should just go ahead and open a new question, be sure to add enough details to make the question answerable though..

Comment: There is an answer on that question now.

Answer (score 12):

Thank you for trying. In this instance, though, it doesn't appear like you're going to succeed.

Ask your question yourself. Include, if appropriate, the information requested by the previous commenter and try and come up with a better title (i.e. not *just* an error message).

If you do get an answer your question will be more useful than the one that came before and you could [flag as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review). If the original question asker returns they will be able to find an answer (assuming that it turns out it *is* a duplicate).

It's possible that someone could [vote to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) your question as a duplicate of the original. It might be worth pointing to this meta post in the comments if this happens. Alternatively, you could always flag for moderator attention again. Use the "other" reason and explain the situation.

Good luck on getting an answer and pay attention to commenters!