# How do you flag questions on the mobile app?

Tags: support, flags, stack-exchange, ios-app

I’m wondering how you can flag questions on the mobile app. For instance, flagging a question that is off topic. Is this possible to do on mobile? Thank you!

Edit: As I posted this question, I saw a “More” option on the bottom of my post. It allowed me to flag and delete it. However, this button isn’t available on the other questions.

Comment: You probably don't have enough rep (15 points) to flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it right. Flagging in the mobile app is done by clicking "More", and then selecting "Flag" from the menu that pops up.

As per the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), you need 15 reputation to flag posts, which you don't have yet, and that's why the button doesn't appear on most questions. I'm guessing there's a specific exception that allows you to always be able to flag your own posts for moderator attention regardless of reputation, but I cannot find any confirmation for this in the FAQ.

**EDIT:**

As Glorfindel commented, he now added this to [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review/24568#24568). Thanks, Glorfindel!

Comment: I can't find it in the FAQ either (or in the help center). Solution: modify the FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24560/295232

Comment: Note that for most users, the flag link will be visible directly, without clicking More.