# Is there a place for novices to play with Stack Overflow's functions?

Tags: support, new-users

Is there a place for novices to play with Stack Overflow's functions?

In this area, users could do whatever they want to, and not be afraid of breaking the whole environment.

I was even afraid to ask a question yesterday. I can't vote because I have only one reputation. I can't comment because I can't find the comment link.

It would be great if there were a place for novices to try all the functions that Stack Overflow has!

#### Related: [Can we get a test.stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/can-we-get-a-test-stackoverflow-com)

Comment: Note that you can always comment on your own question and its answers, and on your own answers.

Comment: But I don't want to use rubbish question, answer or comment to pollute the excellent apps and my reputation.

Comment: @hutushen what do you want to try out?

Comment: @Pekka I know I must be responsible to my questions and answers, so I must be careful when ask a question. I am so cautious that I ask this question one day delay.

Comment: @hutu that is a very agreeable view in general, but there's no need for too much caution, neither on SO nor on Meta. Just ask away.

Comment: @Pekka I will just after my first step. But I will be careful ask question too, because I love this app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: @SonicWizard: Meh, the answer here explains much better the extent to which it is related to that, or not (this question is asking for a lot more than just a format/answer/comment sandbox), so there's no reason to try to force them closer together than they already are. It's not like there's some site limitation that forces us to close some questions so we can ask some more.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [sandbox question here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) to test things like formatting and stuff.

Other than that, there is no "sandbox" as such. You will have access to the functions as soon as you accumulate some points, which, for the basic things like commenting and upvoting, should be relatively easy to do.

Comment: I have see an open-source StackOverflow clone app provides a  demo site that clear all the data every night. I think StackOverflow can provide one like that or do more.

Comment: @hutushen they probably could, but what for? I don't really see the point in testing SO's functions.

Comment: >but what for? - To hook them. It always needs a first shot. Make it easier and you get more addicts.

Comment: I agree with @Ladybug Killer. Because even now I also have a lot of puzzles with StackOverflow.

Comment: @hutu @Lady I really fail to see the point. So what if I can edit tags, or other people's questions, in some sandbox? The only thing worth a peek might be the 10k+ tools that show flagged posts and such... But that's not really thrilling either. Anyway, my 2 cents...